# Code Golf: Your own pet ASCII snake

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, random

So, I wrote myself a one-liner which printed out a snake on the console. It's a bit of fun, and I wondered how I might condense my code...

Here's a (short) example output:

```
                +
                 +
                  +
                   +
                   +
                   +
                  +
                   +
                    +
                    +
                    +
                     +
                     +
                      +
                      +
                       +
                      +
                     +
                     +
                    +
```

Here's the specs:

- In each line, a single non-whitespace character (whichever you like) is printed to the console, initially with 29 to 31 spaces padding to the left of it.
- Each iteration, a random decision is made between these three actions

  - The amount of padding decreases by 1
  - The amount of padding remains the same
  - The amount of padding increases by 1

Do this 30 times, to print 30-segment long a snake to the console.

The shortest answer in bytes wins.

Comment: Can we return an array of lines? Are leading/trailing spaces or newlines allowed?

Comment: @Shaggy I want to see the snake. I don't care if it's an array, as long as it's printed to a console and you can see it.

Comment: "is printed to the console" implies a full-program only, but the default on PPCG is to allow functions too (which I recommend)

Comment: I assume trailing spaces on each line are allowed, right?

Comment: What should happen on a screen with less than 30 columns for text?  Can we start with `cols`/2 padding and iterate `cols`/2 times, or should the snake just wrap around?

Comment: What does "random" mean? Uniformly random? Random from any distribution with positive support on each of the three outcomes? Random from any distribution whatsoever? Do the results have to be different on each run of the program?

Comment: Note that, by default, [random does not mean uniformly so](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10923/76162). For example, the second part of my [brainfuck answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/156258/76162) is (as of now)  perfectly valid, despite it generating a straight line most of the time.

Comment: Seriously has nobody made a golfing language yet that takes as input a Stack Exchange question ID number?

Comment: Right now, there are two points that are unclear: 1) Does *random* mean uniformly random? (affects [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/156258/31716)) and 2) Must the output be different every time? (i.e., can the random number generator be unseeded? Affects [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/156663/31716))

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>15</s> 14 bytes

```
30DF2Ý<+ΩD0sú,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/f2MDFzejwXBvtcytdDIoP79L5/x8A)

Uses `0`.

#### Explanation

```
30DF2Ý<+ΩD0sú,
30D            # Push 30 to the stack (One for the amount of iterations we are going to perform and one for the initial padding)
   F           # Pop one of the 30s and perform the following that many times...
    2Ý          # Push [0,1,2] ...
      <         # and create [-1,0,1] from that
       +        # Add the last padding to every entry (e.g. 30 in the beginning resulting in [29,30,31]
        Ω       # Pick one of the results at random ...
         D      # and push it to the stack twice
          0     # Push 0 (Any character will work fine here) ...
           sú   # and pad it with the randomly chosen amount of spaces in the front
             ,  # Finally print the result with a trailing newline
```

Comment: 05AB1E: 0-bytes, [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/Q8E2hQAAA "05AB1E – Try It Online")... wait, no, almost though.

Answer (score 15):

## [Random Brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), <s>123 122</s> 121 bytes

```
+[--[<]>>+<-]>+[->+>+>+<<<]++++++++++>>++<[>>[->+<<.>]>[-<+>]>?>+++<[>->+<[>]>[<+>-]<<[<]>-]>-->,<[-<<<+>>>]<<<<+.-<<.>-]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYxBCsMwDAQfpK5fsGwfYnRIGwIl1AVD3u@sLpUOkmbEzm3svy9ec/uM43qfa0UHOlMKIuVLUU0y41@2wS6VJZvSG8PjaVGmeC9siiQr0XGAHvQrjSVzLw2VgFzrBg)

Random Brainfuck is an extension of brainfuck, with the helpful addition of the `?` command, which sets the current cell to a random byte. This prints a snake made of `!`s, which looks more like footsteps than a snake funnily enough.

#### How It Works:

```
+[--[<]>>+<-]>+ Create the value 30
[->+>+>+<<<]    Copy it three times
++++++++++      Create a newline cell
>>++<            Adds 2 to the second copy to make it a space and move to the counter
[ While counter
  >>[->+<<.>]>[-<+>] Print out the padding cell number of spaces
  ?>+++<[>->+<[>]>[<+>-]<<[<]>-] Get 3-(random byte%3)
  >-->,<[-<<<+>>>]   Add (result-2) to the padding cell
  <<<<+.-<           Print an exclamation mark
  <<.                Print a newline
  >-                 Decrement counter
] end loop
```

Another solution that sticks to the *letter* of the question, rather than the spirit.

#### 87 bytes

```
+[--[<]>>+<-]>+[->+>+>+<<<]++++++++++>++>[>[->+<<<.>>]>[-<+>]?[,<+>]?[,<->]<<<+.-<.>>-]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYlRCoAwDEMPVLMTlHiQ0o@pCCJOGHj@2n1oEkja12vb7gtLr0fbn/WMEANMnRSFMy/KsKq6/GLGOFj@C@m5VeizTV@BnkwKBodHvA)

This one is heavily biased towards leaving the padding alone, but increasing or decreasing the padding are both equally possible. Each one has a slightly less than 1 in 256 chance to happen.

Comment: Very nice! I was unaware of the `?` command. +1

Comment: @GrantMiller `?` is only available in *Random Brainfuck*, not classic brainfuck

Answer (score 8):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>61</s> <s>58</s> 56 bytes

Answer edited to reflect rules changes...

```c
i;f(s){for(s=i=31;--i;printf("%*d\n",s+=1-rand()%3,8));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HclBCoAgEEDRfacQQZiphMJNIN6kjWjGLLJQd9LZTVp9@M/J07nWSAfIWMOdIBsyatVSkn4SxRKAi9Hvkc95MqtMNnpAoeYNUb/tshQBWR0Yyz8Vug5YuvUToOdtHw)

Comment: save a byte by moving `s+=1-rand()%3` to the printf function. `i;f(s){for(s=i=31;--i;)printf("%*c\n",s+=1-rand()%3,43);}`

Comment: @Vaelus That makes the first line have a varying amount of spaces instead of the 30 specified in the question.

Comment: @Steadybox Which is allowed [in the comments](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/156245/code-golf-your-own-pet-ascii-snake/156259?noredirect=1#comment380672_156245) apparently..

Answer (score 7):

## JavaScript (ES8), <s>63</s> <s>62</s> 60 bytes

Includes a trailing newline. `*2-1` could be replaced with `-.5` for a 1 byte saving but the chances of each line being the same length as the previous line would be greatly increased. Of course, as "random" isn't defined in the challenge, the RNG *could* be replaced with `new Date%3-1` for a total byte count of [55](https://tio.run/##BcFBCoAgEADAe6/oEuwiStEt2LrUP1bSohCNlLLX28ypHx3X@7iS9MHYsgYfg7PKhR2gbASZPupbpDFPzOrSZvEGPkHevvWsk2162aFgUbHYQMqMA3NBQCw/).

```js
f=(x=y=30)=>x?``.padEnd(y+=Math.random()*2-1)+`+
`+f(--x):``
```

Saved a byte thanks to someone who deleted their comment before I could catch the name. I'd actually tried it this way with `repeat` and `padStart` but didn't think to try `padEnd` - don't know why!

```js
o.innerText=(
f=(x=y=30)=>x?``.padEnd(y+=Math.random()*2-1)+`+
`+f(--x):``
)()
```

```html
<pre id=o>
```

---

### Bonus

For the same number of bytes, here's a version that takes the number of starting spaces & iterations as input.

```js
f=(x,y=x)=>x?``.padEnd(y)+`+
`+f(--x,y+Math.random()*2-1):``
```

```js
o.innerText=(
f=(x,y=x)=>x?``.padEnd(y)+`+
`+f(--x,y+Math.random()*2-1):``
)(i.value=30);oninput=_=>o.innerText=f(+i.value)
```

```html
<input id=i type=number><pre id=o>
```

Comment: `f=(x=y=30)=>x?\`+\n\`.padStart(y+=Math.random()*2-1)+f(--x):\`\``
is one byte shorter. 

(Note: Since SO doesn't allow line breaks in comments, I had to type \n instead of actually using a line break.)

Comment: Thanks, @Stefnotch. Unfortunately, even with an initial value of `y=31`, there would be a possibility of the first line being too short. https://tio.run/##BcFLDsIgEADQvSeZkUCs7kzQE7hyqSYzKfRjKBCYGHp6fO/LP65jWbPomJzvY4o1BW9CmgH6ZKHZ3V4GtDet253UgUxm9xQuAruyD5bFFI4ubYDHsx5QTdDwStQR0NQcVqF3pNfpY4KPsyzY/w

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but doesn't your current solution also suffer from that issue?

Comment: Not quite, @Stefnotch. The first line should contain 29-31 spaces. In my version, we start with `y=30`, add `-1`, `0` or `1` to that and then pad an empty string out to that length, giving us the required number of spaces. In your version, though, the string we're padding is already 2 characters long so the `padStart` would only add 27-29 spaces to it. Even if the initial value of `y` was raised to 31, which wouldn't cost any bytes, we'd still only end up with 28-30 spaces.

Comment: Oh, I see. Then, couldn't you just use an initial value of 32? (29-31 spaces)

Comment: @Stefnotch, I could but it would cost me more than the 1 byte saving as `x` and `y` would have to be initiated individually.

Comment: The first line should have **exactly** 30 spaces, according to the challenge.

Comment: @Nit, the OP has confirmed that the first line *may* contain 29-31 spaces but has yet to edit that fact into the challenge, despite repeated requests to do so.

Answer (score 7):

## C# (.NET Core), <s>112</s> <s>110</s> <s>106</s> <s>100</s> <s>99</s> 98 bytes

```cs
v=>{var r="";for(int t=30,i=t;i-->0;r+="+\n".PadLeft(t+=new System.Random().Next(3)-1));return r;}
```

-1 byte thanks to *@raznagul*.
-1 byte thanks to *@auhmaan*.

**Explanation:**

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##TY6xqsJAEEV7v2JItUtMUCzXTSNYPR@ihY3NupnISpyF2UlUJN8eY/HgtZdzD8enwkfG0bcuJdi9ZwBJnAQPfQw17Fwgpb8rwPGVBO/ltiO/jpcbeplPLAe6VtCAhbG31bt3DGyzzDSRVSABsavFPFgxoSiqheHcZvmZsnLv6h9sREluCR9/8oOjOt6VLn/xKWqli6XWhlE6JmAzjN8O879mEynFFssTB0HVKOradrpMyDAbxg8)

```cs
v=>{                      // Method with empty unused parameter and no return-type
  var r="";               //  Result-string, starting empty
  for(int t=30,           //  Temp-integer, starting at 30
      i=t;i-->0;          //  Loop 30 times
    r+=                   //   Append the result-String with:
       "+\n"              //    The character and a new-line,
            .PadLeft(     //    left-padded with `t` spaces,
                     t+=new System.Random().Next(3)-1));
                          //    after `t` first has been changed with -1, 0, or 1 randomly
  return r;}              //  Return the result-string
```

Comment: One strange thing: If I call `new Random().Next()` multiple times locally (.net Framework Version 4.6.1) I always get the same result. I need to add a `Thread.Sleep(10)` between the call to reliably get different results. With a sleep time of less than 10ms I sometimes still get the same result. So .net-Framework and TIO (.net-Core) have different PRNGs or at least use different seeds. If I switch your program in TIO to C#-mono I get the same behavior as I get locally in .net-Framework.

Comment: @raznagul Hmm, that output with **C# (Mono C# compiler)** is indeed weird..

Comment: @raznagul `new Random()` uses the time as the seed so in a tight loop the time is the same and so the result is the same.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder: Yes, that is what I (more or less) expected. The strange things are that 1) .net-Core (at least on TIO) behaves differently. 2) That I need `Thread.Sleep(10)` to reliably get different results and `Thread.Sleep(1)` or even 9ms is not enough.

Comment: @raznagul Well sleeping for 1, 9 or 10ms should all sleep for the same time depending on other processes running... odd indeed.

Answer (score 7):

### [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 24 bytes

```
30* +
-29{¶<`^
 
S,2@1`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/n8vYQEtBm0vXyLL60DabhDguBa5gHSMHw4T//wE)

#### Explanation

```
30* +
```

Initialise the working string to the first line, i.e. 30 spaces and a `+`.

```
-29{¶<`^
```

There's a space on the second line. `-29{` wraps the remainder of the program in a loop, which is run 29 times. `¶<` prints the working string at the beginning of each loop iteration with a trailing linefeed. The atomic stage itself inserts a space at the beginning of the string (the basic idea is to insert one space, and then randomly remove 0–2 spaces, because that's a byte shorter than randomly choosing between deletion, inserting and no-op).

```
S,2@1`
```

This matches the empty regex against the input, which gives us every position between characters (and the start and end of the string). Then `,2` keeps only the first three matches, i.e. the matches after zero, one and two spaces. `@` selects a random one of those three matches. Then the split stage (`S`) splits the input around that match. And the `1` tells it to keep only the second part of the split. In other words, we discard everything up to our random match.

The 30th line, which is the result of the final loop iteration, is printed implicitly at the end of the program.

Comment: You know what's even shorter than removing 0--2 spaces? [Shuffling spaces around!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/n8vYQEshn0vXyLL60DabMPsEhXwF@///AQ). By the way, the new Retina is great :D

Answer (score 7):

## VBA, <s>60</s> <s>59</s> 49 Bytes

```
For l=1To 30:?Spc(30+i)"+":i=i+Sgn(Rnd()-.5):Next
```

Paste it in the Immediate window and hit enter.  (Make sure explicit declaration is turned off!)

*Far* more likely to move than to stay in a line (i.e. actions are not equally weighted) but that was not a specified requirement (Fortunately!)

**{EDIT}** *Saved 1 byte by removing the space between `=1` and `To`*

**{EDIT2}** *Saved **10** bytes thanks to remoel's comment*

Old Versions:

```
'V1
i=30:For l=1 To 30:?String(i," ")&"+":i=i+Sgn(Rnd()-.5):Next
'V2
i=30:For l=1To 30:?String(i," ")&"+":i=i+Sgn(Rnd()-.5):Next
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Comment: You can save a few bytes by replacing `String(i," ")` to `Spc(30+i)` then remove `i=30:` . Or -1 byte by removing `&` . :)

Answer (score 7):

## C, 56 bytes

```c
n;f(p){n>29?n=0:f(printf("%*d\n",n++?p-rand()%3:31,0));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z/POk2jQLM6z87I0j7P1sAKyCvKzCtJ01BS1UqJyVPSydPWti/QLUrMS9HQVDW2MjbUMdDUtK79D1SkkJuYmaehyVXNpQAExWA1JZm5qRogFWCxNA0go/Y/AA)

**Explanation:**

```c
n; // As a global variable, n is initialized to zero.
f(p)
{
    // Call the function recursively until n > 29.
    n > 29

        // At the end, set n back to zero.
        ? n=0

        // On the first iteration, n == 0 and p has an indeterminate value.
        // 'n++ ? p-rand()%3 : 31' returns 31 (without reading p), and thus
        // 30 spaces get printed. printf() returns the number of characters
        // printed, 32 (30 spaces + '0' + '\n').
        //    On subsequent iterations, p has the value the previous printf
        // call returned, which is the padding on last iteration + 2. Also,
        // n > 0, so the same expression now returns p-rand()%3, and thus
        // the padding changes either by -1, 0, or 1 spaces. The function
        // is again called with the value of the current line's padding + 2.
        : f(printf("%*d\n", n++ ? p-rand()%3 : 31, 0));
}
```

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org), 55 bytes

```c
n;f(p){n=n<30&&f(printf("%*d\n",n++?p-rand()%3:31,0));}
```

Depends on **f** "returning" the value assigned to **n** in the function, which is undefined behaviour, but works consistently with gcc when no optimizations are enabled.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z/POk2jQLM6zzbPxthATQ3IKcrMK0nTUFLVSonJU9LJ09a2L9AtSsxL0dBUNbYyNtQx0NS0rv0PVKSQm5iZp6HJVc2lAATFYDUlmbmpGiAVYLE0DSCj9j8A)

Answer (score 6):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 20 bytes

*1 byte saved thanks to [ngn](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/24908/ngn)*

```apl
↑'+'↑⍨¨-+\30,2-?29⍴3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT////1Hf1EdtEx61TVTXVgeSj3pXHFqhqx1jbKBjpGtvZPmod4vx//8A)

Comment: `¯2+` ---> `2-`

Answer (score 6):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>14</s> 11 bytes

```
× ³⁰Ｆⅈ✳～‽³+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcoxCoAwDADA3VeETgkqCI5u4iwiDq6lVgy0DdSiz4@DN5@7bHZig@qSORXcOPobDZgG@o5oqE7JgDsSwR8mzt4VloQjl5dvP0vB1aZDIvZE1ICpDQ2q2j7hAw) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
× ³⁰        Print 30 spaces (forces the desired indentation)
    Ｆⅈ      Repeat the same number of times
      ✳～‽³  Move a random downward direction after printing
          + Print a `+`
```

Would be only <s>10</s> 8 bytes if there was no initial indentation requirement.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Hmm, that's awkward, because Charcoal likes to trim by default.

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/) , <s>83</s> <s>65</s> 64 bytes

Straightforward approach:

```python
import os
k=30
exec"print' '*k+'+';k+=ord(os.urandom(1))%3-1;"*k
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P60oP1ehKDEvBUhl5hbkF5VocWXbGhtwpVakJisVFGXmlagrqGtla6trq1tna9uClALFNHQNdQw1rZW0sv//BwA)

Thanks to @Rod for saving some bytes!
Thanks to @ovs for -1 byte!

Edit: changed variable name and output string to the letter 's'

## More snake-like output for 88 bytes:

```python
from random import*
s=[30,0]
exec"print' '*sum(s)+'(S)'[s[-1]+1];s+=[randint(-1,1)];"*30
```

Comment: I like this. Really neat solution.

Answer (score 6):

## Java 8, <s>89</s> 87 bytes

First golf, I'm sure it could be much better..

Edit: Fixed first line thanks to [Steadybox](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/61405/steadybox).

```java
l->{for(int a=31,b=a;--a>0;){System.out.printf("%"+b+"c\n",'+');b+=2-Math.random()*3;}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY5PD4IwDMXvfoqGxLiJIyrHBY/cOJl4UQ9lMEXHRmCYGMJnx/qvafPSpnnvd8MHCteU9lbcJ2Ww6yDDyg4zgMr6stWoSkjfK9XDVQUodniL4ZKOIw1159FXClLQkMBkxG7QrmVkAJjEm1WeoBQCd2vJh/2z82Udud5HTUsfmgXzIMzDQJ1ssFqECy7zMNmKDP01atEWrmZ8GctxnOQ3rOlzQ2G/zA9TTchs78nvcjwj/@LqSDHbmz/oOL0A)

```java
 l->{                                           //Begin lambda
    for(int a=31,b=a;--a>0;)                  //Initialise vars, loop through 30 lines
    {
        System.out.printf("%"+b+"c\n",'+');     //Print result
        b+=2-Math.random()*3;                   //Change padding by -1, 0, or 1
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! :)

Comment: [83 bytes](https://tio.run/##NY5PD4IwDMXvfoqGxGQTR1S8LXjkxsnEi3oogyk4NgLDxBg@O9Z/TZumTd57vxrvKFxb2rq4Tcpg30OGlX3OACrry06jKiF9n1R3VxWg2OG9DJf0HGmoe4@@UpCChgQmI3ZP7TpGBoBJvF7mCUohcLeSeZhsRIb@GnVoC9cwvoj5/tH7sonc4KO2I5FmwTwI8zBQJxsstzGX4yS/Qe2QGwr65X14GsJle0/Cy/GM/IuqI8XsYP6Q4/QC)

Answer (score 5):

## Java 8, <s>131</s> <s>129</s> <s>127</s> <s>126</s> <s>119</s> <s>108</s> 101 bytes

```java
v->{String r="";for(int i=30,j,t=i;i-->0;r+="+\n")for(j=t+=Math.random()*3-1;j-->0;r+=" ");return r;}
```

**Explanation:**

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##PY/BasMwDIbvewrhk73UoaNH475Bexns0u2gOe5mN5GDowRKybNnDg0D6SDpR//3R5xQp95TbG6La3EY4ISBHi8AgdjnKzoP53UEeOcc6Aec/EihgUmZsp1LlxoYOTg4A4GFZdLHxybOVghzTVmWbxDsYb@LO7bBBK2Pe5MrK6pPEmpVRMuVPSH/1hmpSZ1Urwf9ZuK/EoQy2fOYCbKZF/O07sfvtlhvBNOK1pUE8glw@UK10d8H9l2dRq77cmFJtZM0tq3agszLHw)

```java
v->{                     // Method with empty unused parameter and String return-type
  String r="";           //  Result-String, starting empty
  for(int i=30,j,t=i;    //  Two index integers, and a temp integer (starting at 30)
      i-->0;             //  Loop 30 times:
      r+="+\n")          //    After every iteration: Append the character and a new-line
    for(j=t+=Math.random()*3-1;
                         //   Change `t` with -1, 0, or 1 randomly
        j-->0;r+=" ");   //    And append that many spaces to the result-String
  return r;}             //  Return the result-String
```

**Old 119 byte answer:**

```java
v->{String s="",r=s;int i=90,t=30;for(;i-->t;s+=" ");for(;i-->0;t+=Math.random()*3-1)r+=s.substring(t)+"+\n";return r;}
```

**Explanation:**

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##RY/BasMwEETv/YpFJ6mOhEtORSh/kFwCubQ9KLLSKrUlo10ZSvC3u0pjKOwedmYZ3lztZGUafbx234vrLSLsbYi3J4AQyeeLdR4O9xPgSDnET3D8lEIHk9BVnevWQbIUHBwggoFlkrvb@oyGsU02qGsaBPPabshsW31Jmesg5Y40NoYBE/9Sq6kxe0tfKtvYpYGL5618EbkxqLCc8S@Yk2hY8x6Zzp5KjpD1vOgHzFjOfYVZmaY77FA78QfS24cVa58fJD@oVEiN1SEeleOx9L1Yq83LLw)

```java
v->{                      // Method with empty unused parameter and String return-type
  String s="",            //  Temp-String, starting empty
         r=s;             //  Result-String, starting empty
  int i=90,t=30;          //  Temp integer, starting at 30
  for(;i-->t;s+=" ");     //  Fill the temp String with 60 spaces
  for(;i-->0;             //  Loop 30 times:
      t+=Math.random()*3-1//    After every iteration: Change `t` with -1, 0, or 1 randomly
    r+=s.substring(t)     //   Append the result with `60-t` amount of spaces
       +"+\n";            //   + the character and a new-line
  return r;}              //  Return the result-String
```

Answer (score 5):

## PHP, 61 bytes

```
for($p=32;$i<30;$i++)echo str_pad("+
",$p+=rand(-1,1),' ',0);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxr4go4CLKy2/SEOlwNbYyFol08bYAEhqa2umJmfkKxSXFMUXJKZoKGlzKemoFGjbFiXmpWjoGuoYauqoK6jrGGha//8PAA)

Comment: `$i<30;$i++` can be `$i++<30;` to save 2 bytes.

Comment: 55 bytes: `for($p=30;$i++<30;$p+=rand(-1,1))printf("%{$p}s\n",'+');` (the `\n` is counted as 1 char, and should be replaced by a real newline)

Comment: Alternative 55-byte long, without warnings: `for($i=$p=30;$i--;$p+=rand(-1,1))printf("%{$p}s\n",'+');`

Answer (score 5):

## Perl, 36 bytes

```
perl -E '$#a=29;map{$#a+=rand(3)-say"@a -"}@a'
```

Comment: So good. I always forget you can set an array length like that... and using `say` for subtraction. Am I right in thinking it doesn't change the number of runs when `$#a` is incremented because it's not a reference?

Comment: @DomHastings: It's because I use `map` which seems to first lay out the elements on the stack. `for` does not and would have had an unpredictable loop length

Comment: That's really useful to know. Thanks!

Comment: Nice golfing. I tried to shave off another byte with `perl -E 'map{$#a+=rand(3)-say"@a -"}@a=1..30'`, but that sometimes (not every time) resulted in segmentation fault. Could it be a bug in perl v5.22.1 and v5.16.3?

Comment: @Kjetil Yes, that is a well known problem that probably will never be fixed. When looping an array the entries don't get an extra refcount, so if you delete them they are freed by the time the loop reaches them and you hit freed memory. Fortunately you never do this in real programs.

Answer (score 5):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>13</s> 12 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Outputs an array of lines.

The first line can be removed, saving 3 bytes, to allow the number of starting spaces & iterations to be taken as input.

```
30
°ÆQùU±Ó3ö
```

[Test it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=MzAKsMZR%2bVWx0zP2&input=LVI) or [try it with input](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=sMZR%2bVWx0zP2&input=MzAKLVI)

```
30\n°ÆQùU±Ó3ö
30\n              :Assign 30 to variable U
    °             :Postfix increment U
     Æ            :Map the range [0,30)
      Q           :  Quotation mark
       ù          :  Left pad with space to length
        U±        :    Increment U by
          Ó       :      Bitwise NOT of the negation of (i.e., decrement)
           3ö     :      Random integer in the range [0,3)
```

Comment: Wow, can't believe we're winning at the moment! I think you can save a byte with [this](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=MzAKxlH7VbFK9SD2&input=LVI=) (on mobile so I can't really verify)

Comment: @ETHproductions: Ha! That's identical to what I started out with. The problem is, though, if `-1` is returned by the RNG on the first iteration, we'll end up with a total line length of `29` when it should be `30`, `31` or `32`.

Comment: Hmm, I'm confused about how your version gets around that then... Also, I believe OP has clarified in the comments that they don't care if an extra space is removed or added in the initial iteration.

Comment: Actually I'm confused by "when it should be 30, 31, or 32"—where is that required?

Comment: @ETHproductions: We start with `30` and then add `-1`, `0` or `1` giving us `29`, `30`  or  `31` - add the `"` and that gives us a total length of `30`, `31` or `32` for the first line.

Comment: Oh ok, I didn't realize you meant the length of the entire line. Sorry if this is another dumb question, but how could my suggestion end up with an initial line length of 29 (28 spaces)?

Comment: @ETHproductions: if the RNG gives us `-1` on the first iteration, `U` becomes `29` and `ù` would pad the start of the line with spaces until the total line length is `29` - `28` spaces plus the `"` character.

Comment: Hah, I thought the quote was just appended at the end of the string—sorry for my ignorance :P

Comment: Doors Japt really not have a decrement command???

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing, `±` is the Japt shortcut for `+=`. It could be replaced with `µ`, which is the shortcut for `-=`, but the results would be the same.

Answer (score 5):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 12 bytes

```
30:(kɽ℅+:×꘍,
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=30%3A%28k%C9%BD%E2%84%85%2B%3A%C3%97%EA%98%8D%2C&inputs=&header=&footer=)

```
30:          # Push 30 twice
   (         # Iterate over one copy (30 times)
       +     # Increment the number on the stack (initially 30) by...
      ℅      # A random choice from
    kɽ       # [-1, 0, 1]
        :    # Duplicate
         ×꘍  # Prepend that many spaces to an asterisk
           , # And output, leaving the number on the stack
```

[An alternative](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=j&code=30%3A%C6%9B3%CA%81%E2%80%B9%E2%84%85%3B%C2%A6%2B%C3%97%EA%98%8D&inputs=&header=&footer=)

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>72</s> <s>69</s> 67 bytes

```r
cat(sprintf(paste0("% ",cumsum(c(30,sample(3,29,T)-2)),"s"),"+\n"))
```

Thanks to [Zahiro Mor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/65449) for 2 extra bytes!

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/PzmxRKO4oCgzryRNoyCxuCTVQENJVUFJJ7k0t7g0VyNZw9hApzgxtyAnVcNYx8hSJ0RT10hTU0epWAlIaMfkKWlq/v8PAA)

Comment: Switching from `sample(3,29,T)-2` to `runif(29,-1,1)` will reduce byte count by 2 but moves are not equally likely anymore. And could you also switch to `paste("%"` instead of `paste0("% "` or am I missing something here?

Comment: @Rift if i was using paste the resulting strings would be of the form `% 30 s` instead of `% 30s`. As you said `runif` would mess up the probabiities.

Comment: Locally `sprintf("%30s")`, `sprintf("% 30s")` and `sprintf("% 30 s")` return the same results for me. But on TIO only the first two have identical results, so `paste0("%"` should save a byte. And there is no requirement that every move has the same probability.

Answer (score 4):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>45</s> 39 bytes

```ruby
x=30
x.times{puts' '*(x+=rand(3)-1)+?S}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v8LW2ICrQq8kMze1uLqgtKRYXUFdS6NC27YoMS9Fw1hT11BT2z649v9/AA)

Modifying `x` during the loop does not affect the loop counter. I chose S as a particularly snakelike output character.

-6 bytes: Use `rand(3)-1` instead of `[-1,0,1].sample`. *Thanks, [Eric Duminil](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/65905/eric-duminil)!*

Comment: You can save two bytes with `x.map` instead of `x.times` (equivalent since you don't use the return value)

Comment: I don't think I can... `map` is defined on Enumerable, which Integer isn't.

Comment: Oops, you're right, ignore me!

Comment: OK I've got a better one: `rand -1..1` is five bytes shorter than `[-1,0,1].sample`

Comment: @RJHunter: Or `rand(3)-1` for 6 bytes less.

Comment: You can get a one-liner : `(x=30).times{puts' '*(x+=rand(3)-1)+?S}` without changing the byte-count.

Comment: `(x=30).times{puts' '*x+?+;x+=rand(3)-1}` (same size) will print exactly 30 spaces for the head of the snake as requested by the challenge

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 18 bytes

```
1ŒRX+
30Ç’Ð¡⁶ẋ;€0Y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AScA2P9qZWxsef//McWSUlgrCjMww4figJnDkMKh4oG24bqLO@KCrDBZ//8)

The chosen character is **0**. If returning a list of list of characters is allowed, then the `Y` can be dropped and the submission can be turned into a niladic chain for **[17 bytes](https://tio.run/##AS0A0v9qZWxsef//McWSUlgrCjMww4figJnDkMKh4oG24bqLO@KCrDD/wqLFkuG5mP8)**. [Alternative](https://tio.run/##ASgA1/9qZWxsef//M1hD4oCYKwozMMOH4oCZw5DCoeKBtuG6izvigqwwWf//).

### How it works

```
30Ç’Ð¡⁶ẋ;€0Y | Niladic main link.
30           | Starting from 30...
  Ç’Ð¡       | ... Repeat the helper link 29 times and collect the results in a list.
             | (This list includes the first 30, so there are actually 30 numbers).
      ⁶ẋ     | Repeat a space that many times, for each item in the list.
        ;€0  | Append a 0 to each.
           Y | And join by newlines.
-------------+
1ŒRX+        | Monadic helper link. Alternatively, you can use µ1ŒRX+µ instead of the Ç.
1            | The literal one.
 ŒR          | Symmetric range from –1 to 1.
   X+        | Choose a random number therein and add it to the argument.
```

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 16 bytes

Combining mine, Erik’s and Jonathan’s solutions, we can golf this down to 16 bytes. The chosen character is **1**.

```
’r‘X
30Ç’Ð¡Ṭ€o⁶Y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw8yiRw0zIriMDQ63AzmHJxxa@HDnmkdNa/IfNW6L/P8fAA)

Thanks to Jonathan Allan for the heads-up (on `Ṭ€o⁶`).

Comment: You could use `Ṭ€o⁶` in place of `⁶ẋ;€0` like my 18 byter does and get to down to 17.

Comment: @JonathanAllan Thank you! Combining the three Jelly answers, I actually ended up having 16 bytes. But I posted that as a secondary solution because it is not entirely mine. :-)

Answer (score 4):

## [Swift](https://developer.apple.com/swift/), 101 bytes

```swift
import UIKit
var g=29;for _ in 0...g{print((0..<g).map{_ in" "}.joined(),0);g+=Int(arc4random()%3)-1}
```

### Explanation

A full program. This uses a rather odd trick: `arc4random()` is a member of the `Darwin` module, but `UIKit` also comes with this function installed, so it saves a byte :) Also uses one of my [Swift golfing tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/137931/59487) for repeating strings an arbitrary number of times.

```swift
import UIKit        // Imports the UIKit module, necessary for the RNG.
var g=29;           // Declares an integer variable g by assigning it to 30.
for _ in 0 ... g {  // Execute the code block 30 times (for each integer in [0; g]):
 print(             // Output the following:
  (0..<g).map       // For each integer in [0; g)...
   {_ in" "}        // ... return a literal space character. 
    .joined()       // ... And join the result to a single string.
             ,0     // Also print a "0" preceded by a single space (g starts from 29).
 );
g+=                 // Increment the variable g by...
   arc4random()%3   // ... A random integer, modulo 3...
   Int(...)-1       // ... Casted to an integer (yes, this is needed!) and decremented.
}
```

Comment: Doesn't `for _ in 0 ... g` execute the code block 29 times now instead of 30 (loop from 0 to 29 (exclusive))?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen No, `0...g` generates all the integers in **[0; g]**. My bad, fixed the explanation. `0..<g` would generate the integers in **[0; g)** :P

Comment: Ah, the `[0; g)` you've edited to `[0; g]` indeed confused me. :) Hmm, but isn't it possible to start at `g=30` and loop `[1; g]` in that case?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Looping over either `[0; g)` or `[1; g]` would definitely be possible if I choose `g=30` instead, but then `print(...,0)` needs to be changed to `print(...+"0")`, because an additional (extraneous) space would be prepended before the 0 otherwise. Either way, the byte count remains the same.

Answer (score 4):

## R, <del>54</del> 53 bytes

```r
cat(sprintf('
%*s',cumsum(c(30,sample(3,29,T)-2)),0))
```

Similar idea [as above](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/156250/1710), but with shortened `sprintf` code and a shorter character string literal. Instead of `\n` (two bytes) I’m using a literal line break (one byte).

<kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/PzmxRKO4oCgzryRNQ51LVatYXSe5NLe4NFcjWcPYQKc4MbcgJ1XDWMfIUidEU9dIU1PHQFPz/38A)</kbd>

Comment: `A field width or precision (but not both) may be indicated by an asterisk *: in this case an argument specifies the desired number. ` I've been using `sprintf` for years and somehow always missed that part... Thanks for the reminder!

Comment: The second line is sometimes indented two spaces instead of one.

Comment: @ScottMilner Found some time to fix it.

Answer (score 4):

## [SenseTalk](http://sensetalk.com), <strike>237</strike> 198 Bytes

This is a language that I came to know and love about a decade ago. It's the scripting language that drives the automated testing tool [Eggplant Functional](https://www.testplant.com). I was an avid user of the tool for many years before joining the company for a while. It's not the most golf-capable language, but I find it very enjoyable to write in. Golfing in it is actually quite challenging as the language is meant to be verbose and English-like... took me quite a while to get it down to 237 bytes.

```
set s to "                              +"&lf
set p to s
repeat 30
set a to random(0,2)
if a equals 0
delete first char of p
else if a equals 1
put " " before p
end if
put p after s
end repeat
put s
```

### Ungolfed/Explanation

```
set the_snake to "                              +"&lf #assign the first line of the snake
set previous_line to the_snake                        #set up for the loop

repeat 30 times                                       #loop 30x
    set action to random(0,2)                         #random add/subtract/stay the same

    if action equals 0
        delete the first character of previous_line   #SenseTalk really shines at string manipulation
    else if action equals 1
        put " " before previous_line                  #insert a character at the beginning
    end if

    put previous_line after the_snake                 #plop the new segment into the string
end repeat                                            #close the loop

put the_snake                                         #print to standard out
```

Edit: Saved 36 bytes thanks to @mustachemoses

Comment: Is the whitespace necessary?

Comment: I've a lot of respect for this. Particularly against the background of 'golfing languages' which seem to exist to be utterly unreadable, but short. It's nice to have an example that's just showing what you can do with your language.

Comment: Good call @MustacheMoses! Updated.

Comment: I count 198 bytes (well, the userscript counts that many)

Comment: @AllenFisher Do you have a standalone interpreter or compiler for this language that I can use without getting a Eggplant demo?

Comment: @MustacheMoses I wish I did. They used to have one, but when TestPlant acquired the EP tool, they shelved it.

Comment: @HyperNeutrino yeah I realized I was using the wrong operator in my counting script... updated

Answer (score 3):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 23 bytes

```
echo(8":~+/)\31,1-?29$3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/PzU5I1/DQsmqTltfM8bYUMdQ197IUsX4/38A)

Answer (score 3):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 42 bytes

```powershell
1..($l=30)|%{" "*$l+"x";$l+=-1,0,1|Random}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/31BPT0Mlx9bYQLNGtVpJQUlLJUdbqULJGkjZ6hrqGOgY1gQl5qXk59b@/w8A)

Loops from `1` to `$l=30`. Each iteration we put `$l` spaces plus an `x` onto the pipeline as a string, then `+=` either of `-1, 0, 1` based on `Get-Random` into `$l` for the next loop. Those strings are gathered from the pipeline and an implicit `Write-Output` gives us a newline-separated list for free.

Answer (score 3):

## Bash, 53

- 3 bytes saved thanks to @Dennis

```bash
for((i=p=30;i--;p+=RANDOM%3-1));{ printf %${p}s+\\n;}
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/Py2/SEMj07bA1tjAOlNX17pA2zbI0c/F31fVWNdQU9O6WqGgKDOvJE1BVaW6oLZYOyYmz7r2/38A).

Comment: `p+=RANDOM%3-1` works too.

Comment: @Dennis Yes of course! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), <s>53 51 50</s> 49 bytes

```matlab
printf('%*d\n',[a=31+cumsum(randi(3,1,30)-2);~a])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f@/oCgzryRNQ11VKyUmT10nOtHW2FA7uTS3uDRXoygxLyVTw1jHUMfYQFPXSNO6LjFW8/9/AA)

Saved 1 byte by no longer doing any looping. Saved another as Octave has `printf` as well as `fprintf`.

This new code creates an array of 30 random integers in the range `-1:1`. It then cumulatively sums the array and adds 30, which gives the desired sequence.

The result is printed using `fprintf` with a format that says "A decimal number, padded to a specified width, followed by a new line. The width will be the first value input, and the decimal number will be the second value input. If the number of values input is more than this, Octave will keep repeating the print automatically to get the desired output.

To achieve the looping then, we need only interleave zeros between the sequence array so the `fprintf` function uses each value in the sequence as a width, and each zero as the digit to be printed.

Prints an output like:

```matlab
                              0
                             0
                              0
                             0
                              0
                               0
                              0
                               0
                              0
                              0
                             0
                            0
                           0
                           0
                           0
                          0
                           0
                            0
                             0
                              0
                              0
                             0
                             0
                              0
                               0
                              0
                              0
                               0
                               0
                                0
```

---

The above code doesn't always print exactly 30 spaces on the first line. It will be either 29, 30, or 31. To correct that, you would use this 53 byte version:

```matlab
x=31;for i=2:x;fprintf('%*d\n',x,0);x+=randi(3)-2;end
```

Comment: You can save two bytes: `x=31;for i=2:x;fprintf('%*d\n',x+=randi(3)-2,0);end`

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I thought about that, but it doesn't work the same. It would result in the first line starting with either 29, 30, or 31 spaces.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen in fact, never mind. I've just noticed the OPs comments saying that is allowed.

Comment: Yep. It's a bit annoying a rule is in the comment (especially since it contradicts with the current challenge description..). I've asked OP to edit the challenge to reflect you can start with 29, 30 or 31, since he seems to allow it in the comments.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3.6](https://python.org), <s>84</s> <s>73</s> 69 bytes

```
from random import*
x=30
exec("print(' '*x+'+');x+=randint(-1,1);"*x)
```

Thanks to @WheatWizard for -11 bytes.
Thanks to @JoKing for -4 bytes.

Comment: Since you don't end up using `i` you can use `for i in[1]*30` instead to save bytes.

Comment: You can also `from random import*` so that you don't need the `random.` later on.  And you can remove the newline space after your `:`.

Comment: And if you change `30` to `29` the `"+".rjust(x)` can be replaced with `" "*x+"+"`.

Comment: Actually regarding my last comment it should be 30 spaces not 29.  Your current answer only puts 29 spaces and thus fails to meet the spec.  This can be fixed by changing 30 to 31.

Comment: @WheatWizard Thanks! I've added your changes and credited you as well. I changed `[1]*30` to `[1]*x` because it's one byte shorter.

Comment: [69 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P60oP1ehKDEvBUhl5hbkF5VocVXYGhtwpVakJmsoFRRl5pVoqCuoa1Voq2ura1pXaNuCVINEdQ11DDWtlbQqNP//BwA "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: @JoKing Thanks I'll edit in your changes.

Answer (score 3):

## ES5, <del>97</del> <del>95</del> 81 bytes

```js
for(p=i=30;i--;)console.log(Array(p).join(" ",r=Math.random()*3|0,p+=r>1?-1:r)+0)
```

**ES5, <del>112</del> 98 bytes** if function format is needed:

```js
function a(){for(p=i=30;i--;)console.log(Array(p).join(" ",r=Math.random()*3|0,p+=r>1?-1:r)+0)}a()
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! I think your variables have to be declared inside of a function - `_=>{p=30;for(i=0;i<p;i++){console.log(Array(p).join(" ")+"+\n");r=~~(Math.random()*3);p+=r==2?-1:r}}`

Comment: That'll kill the bytes, I'll tell you that. ES5 doesn't include the arrow functions by default. 

I'll update

Comment: @Oliver, function format added :)

Comment: Nice! I'm not sure when it was introduced, but I think you can replace `join(" ")` with `join\` \``

Comment: @Oliver I'm not sure you could do that in ES5, could you? I thought that was a template literal added in ES6?

Comment: Maybe, I'm not sure when that was introduced. Why not use ES6?

Comment: @Oliver It's more of a challenge, and there was already an ES8 answer which takes the full syntactical sugar of Javascript and turns it into some awesome.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! [Here](https://tio.run/##BcFRDoIwDADQqxi@WgfLhD@w8QQcooEpI7g2ZfGLu8/3dv7xuVjS0mVZY61vMVAaQpsoTMm5p064SD7liP6QDzS3xlvUyAW0VUdgNHPZvHFe5Qt4H66ARP2re4yGLmCtfw) are some quick improvements to get you down to 81 bytes.

Comment: @Shaggy `.repeat` is an ES6 function, so won't work for this version.

Comment: Huh, it looks like `repeat` has already become so invaluable I'd completely forgotten it wasn't introduced until ES6. [Here](https://tio.run/##BcFbDkAwEADAq4ivXbSp@CMlDuAQG88K3WaJROLuNbPTQ9coLtzK8zTHuLBAsM5WpnFKNTiyv/iY9cEr9CL0QkC9s/OQJmkhdqB700J@4hMwqz5ThNxKW3aqrAVzgzH@)'s an alternative 81 byte version, so.

Comment: @Shaggy, looks good, and has shaved 14 bytes off of the answer I gave, nice job

Answer (score 3):

### Lua, <del>81</del> 75 bytes

```
n=30;for i=1,n do print(("%-"..n.."s+"):format(" "))n=n-2+math.random(3)end
```

In `for i=1,n ...` the *to_exp* `n` is evaluated only once before entering the loop, saving one byte.

-6 thanks to @user202729

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcpRCoAgDADQq4xBMDFH5V/hYQSLhJxhdf7l54N3fVFVgp@2ozbIYR4FUoW7ZXmJcHDILMz4WDRrLyW@hIDGSBC32M6TW5RUC3mzS1L9AQ)

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! You may want to add a TIO link to your post so people can test your program more easily.

Comment: You can golf your answer down to [76 bytes](https://tio.run/##DcpRCoAgDADQq4xBsGGOpL/CwwgWCTnD7Pzm54N3f6F39euyn6VC8m5WiAWemrQR4WRRREXwNcjbKDk0QkBm9WoGLqlBY8lk3ez40Nj7Dw). Besides the page [Tips for golfing in Lua](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/24392/tips-for-golfing-in-lua) may be useful.

Comment: [75 bytes](https://tio.run/##DcpRCoAgDADQq4xBMDFH5V/hYQSLhJxhdf7l54N3fVFVgp@2ozbIYR4FUoW7ZXmJcHDILMz4WDRrLyW@hIDGSBC32M6TW5RUC3mzS1L9AQ).

Answer (score 2):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 54 bytes

```
loop n: 30[loop n[prin" "]print"+"n: n - 2 + random 3]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0pN@R@UmqIQHatQlJiXkp@rX5wK5Obll@uXZOam/s/Jzy9QyLNSMDaIhjCjC4oy85QUlGJBdImSthJQMk9BV8FIQRtqgoJx7P//AA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), <s>21</s> <s>19</s> <s>16</s> 15 bytes

*Thanks to Rod for saving 2 bytes and Mr. Xcoder for saving another 3 :)*

Uses `0`

```
VK30p*KdZ=+KtO3
```

[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=VK30p%2aKdZ%3D%2BKtO3&debug=0)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 73 bytes

```python
from random import*
l=c=30
while c>0:l+=randint(-1,1);print' '*l+"+";c-=1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P60oP1ehKDEvBUhl5hbkF5VoceXYJtsaG3CVZ2TmpCok2xlY5WjbgpRk5pVo6BrqGGpaFxQB2eoK6lo52kraStbJuraG//8DAA)

Comment: I really like the idea of creating a snake in Python

Comment: I must have been half asleep yesterday - I didn't even think about that ;-)

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 74 bytes

```
""<>(" "&~Array~#<>"+
"&)/@Accumulate@Prepend[{-1,1}~RandomInteger~29,30]&
```

Pure function. Takes no input and returns a string as output.

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia 0.6](http://julialang.org/), <strike>52</strike> 49 bytes

Full program, prints a snake with `0`. I usually prefer comprehensions to `for...end` blocks because comprehensions return things. But since I'm printing anyway this is shorter, and you can use newlines at no cost (meaning equal to `;`) for a nice readable golf. Saved a byte by using `1:n` instead of `1:30` and two bytes with `println(" "^n,0)` instead of `println(" "^n*"+")`.

```julia
n=30
for i=1:n
println(" "^n,0)
n+=rand(-1:1)
end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0@/8/z9bYgCstv0gh09bQKo@roCgzryQnT0NJQSkuT8dAkytP27YoMS9FQ9fQylCTKzUv5f9/AA)

Answer (score 2):

## [K4](http://kx.com/download/), 26 bytes

**Solution:**

```
-1(-31+\0,-1+29?3)$\:,"$";
```

**Example:**

```
q)k)-1(-31+\0,-1+29?3)$\:,"$";
                              $
                             $
                             $
                            $
                           $
                            $
                             $
                              $
                              $
                              $
                              $
                              $
                               $
                                $
                               $
                              $
                               $
                              $
                              $
                               $
                                $
                                 $
                                 $
                                $
                                 $
                                $
                               $
                                $
                                $
                                 $
```

**Explanation:**

Build a list of negative numbers to left-pad `"$"`, perform padding and print to stdout.

```
-1(-31+\0,-1+29?3)$\:,"*"; / the solution
-1                       ; / print to stdout and swallow return
                     ,"$"  / enlist "$" (e.g. ["$"])
  (              )$\:      / pad right with each-left
             29?3          / 29 choose 3, takes from 0 1 2
          -1+              / subtract 1, so range is -1 0 1
        0,                 / join 0
      +\                   / sums
   -31                     / add to -31
```

**Bonus:**

**27 byte** version in [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok):

```
`0:(-31+\0,-1+29?3)$\:,"*";
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/P8HASkPX2FA7xkBH11DbyNLeWFMlxkpHSUvJ@v9/AA)

Comment: oK 22 bytes: `\`0:(-31+\1-30?3)$\:$0;`

Comment: @zgrep, probably worth posting as a separate oK solution :) stringing 0 in K4 gives an atom rather than an enlisted char (so you can't pad it) and the above solution always pads the first line with 30 chars - a requirement which was removed as a comment.

Answer (score 2):

## [Icon](https://github.com/gtownsend/icon), 51 bytes

-2 bytes thanks to Kevin Cruijssen

```
n:=30;every 1to 30do{write(repl(" ",n),8);n+:=?3-2}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFBCoAgEADAryyelAwsL6FIbwndg1CrLFZE9HabybFQr1wippMRji2TVJ1csMbjhfzA1ApYk8p7c24oGesuBQhNSi/K0@DCasf560ip/w)

Answer (score 2):

## Clojure, <strike>88</strike> 77 bytes

Always happy to provide a Clojure answer. Always sad, it's quite long.

```
(loop[x 30 p x](when(> x 0)(printf(str "%"p"d\n")1)(recur(dec x)(+(-(rand-int 3)1)p))))
```

Ungolfed:

```
(loop [x 30 p x]
  (when (> x 0) 
    (printf (str "%" p "d\n") 1)
    (recur (dec x) (+ (- (rand-int 3) 1) p))))
```

#### Update 1

Managed to shave off 11 bytes by making the code more idiomatic. Who would have thought that making things "more right" would end up being more effective in a Code Golf challenge.

```
(doseq[p(take 30(iterate #(+ %(-(rand-int 3)1))30))](printf(str "%"p"d\n")1))
```

Ungolfed:

```
(doseq [p (take 30
            (iterate
              #(+ % (- (rand-int 3) 1))
              30))]
  (printf (str "%" p "d\n") 1))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FclJCoAwDADAr4SKkCAFpc9RD8VGcKHWNL4/6nVmOa/9ETbDdFW@x4IaD4bQ46YsURka7KBFjxJz8ltWCDQQhZ5oxiIfrFhVwLWuuDRl96/ZCw)

Comment: Hi, I added a TIO link of your solution to your post. According to TIO, it's 77 bytes long, so I updated this also.

Answer (score 2):

## SmileBASIC, 40 bytes

This answer turned out to be pretty boring.

```
X=30FOR I=1TO 30?" "*X;0X=X+RND(3)-1NEXT
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 21 bytes

```
Ln:30{PsXn.0--n+:RR3}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P/fJ8/K2KA6oDgiT89AVzdP2yooyLj2/38A)

#### Explanation

```
                       s is space (implicit)
 n:30                  Set n to 30
L    {              }  Loop that many times:
      P                 Print, with trailing newline:
       sXn               space, repeated n times
          .0             with "0" concatenated
            --n         Decrement n
               +:       and add to it (in-place)
                 RR3    randrange(3), i.e. a random integer between 0 and 2
```

Answer (score 2):

## [PHP](http://php.net/), <strike>58</strike> 56 bytes

```
for($a=$b=30;$a--;)echo str_pad('',$b+=rand(-1,1))."+
";
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxr4go4CLKy2/SEMl0VYlydbYwFolUVfXWjM1OSNfobikKL4gMUVDXV1HJUnbtigxL0VD11DHUFNTT0mbS8n6/38A)

-2 bytes thanks to [@Shaggy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/156245/code-golf-your-own-pet-ascii-snake/156560?noredirect=1#comment381469_156560)

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! :) Seeing as the first line can contain `29-31` spaces, I think you could do [this](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAk0/KLNFQSbVWSbI0NrFUSdXWtNVOTM/IVikuK4gsSUzTU1XVUkrRtixLzUjR0DXUMNTX1lLS5lKz//wcA) to save 2 bytes.

Comment: Thx @Shaggy. Yeah, I only just read the comments on the question saying I could do that xD. Thanks for helping me shave 2 bytes!

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 18 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
30µ3ẋX€_2+\+⁸Ṭ€o⁶Y
```

Uses `1` as the character.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/Y4NBW44e7uiMeNa2JN9KO0X7UuOPhzjVAXv6jxm2R////BwA)**

Comment: Your first line does not always start with 30 spaces.

Comment: See my comment under the OP

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 17 bytes

```
30µ’r‘Xµ’Ð¡⁶ẋp”.Y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/Y4NDWRw0zix41zIgAsw5POLTwUeO2h7u6Cx41zNWL/P8fAA)

Full program.

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 108 bytes

```hs
import System.Random
0%_=pure()
n%p=putStrLn(([1..p]>>" ")++"+")>>randomRIO(-1,1::Int)>>=((n-1)%).(p+)
30%30
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcuxCsMgFEDRPV8hgvAeJqJkC@geKBSSsZQi1NDQ@CLGDv16G7pdDtyXP95h22pdY9pzYfP3KCGqydNzj40WD5s@OQA2JNKZZS75QgA3o1S6O8cZRym55Ohc/j/TeIXOtGYYRiqnWgDqDApUkCQ2i@216HWNfiVm2VJ/) I was surprised to find that this code works in GHCi without the explicit type annotation but not on TIO, until [BMO told me](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/42958954#42958954) about the `ExtendedDefaultRules` flag which is set by GHCi.

Answer (score 1):

## [SOGL V0.12](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGLOnline), 14 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
'∑:{:@*O2ψH+╗p
```

[Try it Here!](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=JTI3JXUyMjExJTNBJTdCJTNBQCpPMiV1MDNDOEgrJXUyNTU3cA__,v=0.12)

Answer (score 1):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), 54 bytes

```
{for(f=30;a++<30;f+=int(4*rand()-2))printf"%"f"s\n",1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v@/Oi2/SCPN1tjAOlFb2wZIpWnbZuaVaJhoFSXmpWho6hppahYUAUXSlFSV0pSKY/KUdAxr//83BAA)

Very straightforward. This requires a 1 line input to run.  Could make it a "program" by using a `BEGIN` label.

Answer (score 1):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 31 bytes

```
{S*TN}:F;30:V{3,{V1-+}%mRz:VF}*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/vzpYK8Sv1srN2tjAKqzaWKc6zFBXu1Y1N6jKKsytVuv/fwA)

Sort of a port of @Datboi's answer

**Explanation**

```
{S*TN}:F                         -The padded string function
{                                -Start block
 S*                              -Multiply space string by argument and push to stack
   T                             -Push integer 0 to stack
    N                            -Push newline string to stack
     }                           -End block
      :F                         -Store top of stack(the block) in variable F
        ;                        -Pop from stack
         30:V                    -Push integer 30 to stack and store in variable V
             {3,{V1-+}%mRz:VF}   -The main loop
              3                  -Push integer 3 to stack
               ,                 -Array range from 0 to n-1
                {V1-+}%          -Map to array
                 V               -Push variable V to stack
                  1              -Push integer 1
                   -+            -subtract values from each other and add to array index
                       mR        -Random choice
                         z       -Absolute value
                          :V     -Store in variable V
                            F    - Execute function in F
                              *  -pop stack and repeat block
```

Comment: 21 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/39igOj5YKz8kz1jHSiM3SLvW2EDL@v9/AA "CJam – Try It Online")

Comment: Clearly, I still have a lot of practicing to do.

Answer (score 1):

## Go, <del>123</del> <del>107</del> 94 bytes

```
import(."fmt"
."math/rand")
func s(){s:=30
for i:=0;i<30;i++{Printf(`%*d
`,s,4)
s+=Intn(3)-1}}
```

call function `s`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Jc0xDsIgFIDh2XcKQmICUmsNTrUcwM0jlLRSieHRAJ0IZ8cal3/8/sXXuurpo5cXcdoigHWrD4m11LhEoaVOp/claJwpB7PhRCLjOfZKdmB8ILZX3d0Oco8Q@RksJsPG42mGsYnNjUMU6oEJmeTnaynwN34rxkmGw65BgVq/)

Answer (score 1):

### Perl 6, 39 bytes

```
$_=30;say(" "x($_+=^3 .roll-1)~"x")xx$_
```

Explanation:

`$_=30`: Sets the number of spaces to prefix to 30.

`say(" "x($_+=^3 .roll-1)~"x")`: Outputs that number of spaces and updates it (`^3 .roll-1`: pick a random integer from 0 to 2 and subtract it by 1), followed by `x` and a newline.

`xx$_`: Does this 30 times. Using `$_` instead of `30` saves one space before `30`.

Answer (score 1):

## Commodore BASIC (Tested on a Commodore 64, but recommended 128 80 columns mode) 72 tokenised BASIC bytes

```
0X=29:FORI=.TOX:PRINTSPC(X)"O":X%=3*RND(.):ONX%GOSUB1,2:NEXT:END
1X=X-1:RETURN
2X=X+1:RETURN
```

#### How it works

`X` is declared as the spacing and is reused in the `FOR/NEXT` loop - the `.` is a slightly faster way of using `0` in Commodore BASIC, so the loop counts from `0` to the initialised value in `X` (30 iterations). `PRINT SPC(X)` will print `X` number of spaces, so on the first iteration, this is 29, and the `"O"` will print the `O` character. `X% = 3 * RND(.)` declares (loosely) an integer variable (the `%` means integer, though internally it's a floating point number) - a number from `0` to `2` inclusive is decided (as a floating point number, but will be used as an integer). the `ON X% GOSUB 1, 2` will branch to lines `1` or `2` depending on the value. a `0` will not branch and fall through to the next instruction (which instigates the next iteration with the `NEXT` command). Finally the `END` will gracefully end the program (otherwise it will continue to line `1` and there will be an error because of a `RETRURN` statement without a `GOSUB` call).

Note that although `X` is manipulated in the loop, the number of iterations is set by the value that it's initialised to. Also, the Commodore C64 screen (as well as the PET, C128 and C16/+4) only has 25 rows of text in BASIC, so that's why you don't see the full 30 character PETSCII Snake.

[image: Commodore PET ASCII Snake Challenge]

Answer (score 1):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 53 bytes

```
 "+ ␞␞"r4[r}:}>1-$:\
<~x<1 }-1}o:}+^?:$o/oa;!?:{
^ \-
```

(Replace `␞` with the corresponding byte 0x1E; it is replaced with a printable unicode character here for clarity.)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/X0FJW0FOTqnIJLqo1qrWzlBXxSqGy6auwsZQoVbXsDbfqlY7zt5KJV8/P9Fa0d6qmitOIUb3/38A) The first `+` always starts at position 30.

### Explanation

#### Initialization and Iteration Cleanup

```
 "+ ␞␞"r4[r}:}
```

Let's examine this section bit-by-bit, as it's a bit more complicated than a simple stack initialization.

```
 "+ ␞␞"
```

This initializes the stack with `[43, 32, 30, 30]`, which are the `[OutputChar, PadChar, InitialPosition, IterationCount]` respectively.

```
       r4[r
```

This is a no-op on the first iteration, but on each next iteration, it only retrieves the bottom-most four entries on the stack. Our method of repeating the iteration here is to simply return to the first line, which will re-push the initial string. We want to ignore this on every subsequent iteration, hence these four characters. (While I could remove them and simply jump to the corresponding position on line 1, this should require more bytes, given the rather delecate structure of the code.)

```
           }:}
```

The last thing that needs to be done before our output loop is to move the iteration count to the bottom of the stack (`}`), and save a copy of the current horizontal position to the bottom of the stack (`:}`).

#### Horizontal Position Output

```
              >1-$:\
              ^?:$o/
```

This is a relatively simple loop. We first subtract 1 from the horizontal position (`1-`), output a copy of our padding character (`$:o$`, which is split across the mirrors to save bytes), and, if the counter has reached zero, we skip repeating this loop; otherwise, we repeat this process (`:?`).

#### Post-loop procedures

```
  +                \
<~x<1 }-1}o:}+     /oa;!?:{
^ \-
```

I've kept in only the bits necessary to illustrate the function of the more delicate part of the code. Starting at the `+` in the middle, going left, we do a few things. We discard the 0 counter we do not need anymore (`+`), output a copy of the snake character (`}:o`), subtract 1 from the copy of the iteration counter we saved earlier (`}1-`), and then we prepare to do the random procedure `}1`. This pushes a 1 to the stack, which we will randomly add, subtract, or ignore relative to the horizontal position we saved earlier.

```
  +
<~x<1
^ \-
```

Remember the `+` is part of the initialization string from earlier. The `x` instruction is ><> source of randomness; it chooses a random direction and sets the IP to go that way. This means we have four options: left, right, up, and down. If it goes right, it simply encounters the `<` instruction and we are redirected back to the `x`, once again obtaining a random direction. Effectively, we limit the random directions to be only left, up, or down.

If we go left, we'll simply pop the 1; the horizontal position does not change. We then continue left and wrap around to the rest of the post-loop procedures.

If we go up, we encounter the `+` from earlier, adding 1 to the horizontal position. We will then continue up and wrap around to the mirror, reflecting left, then following the arrows to the rest of the post-loop procedures.

If we go down, we find that same mirror, but reflect right instead, encountering the `-`, and subtracting 1 from the horizontal position. We continue and wrap around to the right, following the arrows as before and continuing on.

```
                   \
                   /oa;!?:{
```

After modifying the horizontal position, we now want to examine the loop counter (`{`). If it is 0, we terminate (`:?!;`). Otherwise, we continue on, outputting a newline (`ao`), hitting the mirror from before, going down, wrapping around, hitting the other mirror, and going to the left. This brings us back to the very start of the code, and the process begins again.