# Print random integers until 0

Tags: code-golf, random

You are to write a program which generates random integers between \$0\$ and \$99\$ inclusive, outputting each integer in turn, until \$0\$ is generated. You may choose which single-order random distribution (uniform, binomial, Poisson etc.) you use so long as each integer has a non-zero chance of being generated and is chosen independently. The output should always end with `0`. As each integer must be chosen independently, the output cannot be some permutation of the integers \$\{0, 1, 2, ..., 99\}\$ trimmed to end with \$0\$.

You may follow another method to accomplish the same task, so long as the result is identical to the described method here (for example: you may generate a number \$K\$ geometrically distributed with parameter \$\frac 1 {99}\$, then output \$K\$ independent numbers with a uniform distribution on the set \$\{1, 2, ..., 99\}\$, then output a \$0\$).

The integers may be separated by any non-digit, non-empty separator (e.g. newlines, spaces etc.), and may be output in any consistent base. You may output in any [convenient method](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods) or [format](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9501/66833).

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20653/66833). [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/168221/randomizing-until-0)

Comment: Maybe I read past it, but the integers doesn't necessary have to be unique? If they do, can we also output them as a list, or is one integer at a time mandatory?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen No, the integers do not have to be unique (aside from `0`, which should appear exactly once), and yes, you may output them as a list

Comment: Are we allowed to output the integers in descending order?

Comment: @Adám I'm going to say no, as otherwise, printing the range `99 98 97 ... 0` would be a "technically valid" solution, circumventing the random aspect of the challenge, and saying "yes, so long as you generate them in a random order" is an unobservable requirement

Comment: I would generate a random subsequence of 99…0 each time.

Comment: @Adám I'm sure you wouldn't create a cheating solution, it's more that allowing that could open the door for others to completely trivialise the challenge by going "well, according to the OP in the comments ..."

Comment: Surely if the integers must be chosen independently, then the output **cannot** be unique?

Comment: @pxeger I don't think so. For example, shuffling an array `[0, 1, 2, ..., 98, 99]` and outputting the integers up to 0. Each integer has an independent chance of being "in front of" the zero, just the output will always be unique

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing for example, if a 5 is chosen, the chance of choosing another 5 has changed to 0. That isn't independent.

Comment: @LuisMendo pxeger’s last comments somewhat confused me, so I reverted my edit until I make a decision either way

Comment: @pxeger FWIW I agree with pxeger. The output numbers being unique is not compatible with independence

Comment: Just to check: can there be an extra separator before the first number?

Comment: @LuisMendo Yep, that’s fine

Comment: May we output reversed, so that 0 is outputted first?

Comment: @att No, `0` must be last

Comment: Can the "random" sequence be unseeded (ie outputs the same output for every run of the program)?

Comment: @Noodle9 I think the site default is that unseeded RNGs are acceptable: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/15026/66833

Answer (score 20):

## [Scratch 3.0](https://scratch.mit.edu), 9 blocks/76 bytes

[image: beautiful]

As SB Syntax:

```
define
set[N v]to(1
repeat until<(N)=(0
set[N v]to(pick random(0)to(99
say(N
```

[Try it on Scratch](https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/480455636/)

It just wouldn't be right if I didn't golf this in scratch. This is a function that achieves the desired result

### Explained

```
define                             // Create a function with no name (not a lambda)
set[N v]to(1                       // Initalise the variable we will use to generate random numbers with
                                   // If we didn't set it to 1, the next loop wouldn't start, as it would see that N = 0.
repeat until<(N)=(0                // Pretty self-explanatory
set[N v]to(pick random(0)to(99     // Also pretty self-explanatory. But putting this here means we don't have to include two calls to this block: we've essentially created a post-test loop instead of a pre-test loop
say(N                              // Output the randomly generated number and repeat
```

Comment: Given that you can execute blocks of code by single-clicking in Scratch, do you need the `define` line?

Comment: @wizzwizz4 without the define, this submission is no longer a function/full program. What you're describing is somewhat analogous to using a repl.

Comment: I'm not familiar with SB syntax, but wouldn't it be better to pick Ns from 1 to 100 and say N-1 to avoid the set N to 1 problem? I'm not sure how costly subtraction is though.

Answer (score 15):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 58 bytes

```python
from random import*
print(*iter(lambda:randint(0,99),0),0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P60oP1ehKDEvBUhl5hbkF5VocRUUZeaVaGhllqQWaeQk5ialJFqBVIAEDXQsLTV1DEDo/38A)

Answer (score 14):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 25 bytes

```r
c(sample(99,rexp(1),T),0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dcwxCsAgDADA3Ve4mYCDjvqOfiBICoLaoBbs620/0PWG63snGFSlMIRgOy8Bj/ZA63AnmmBUZ2Ga2junZ648olIG1SCR8oCPn9vzbmnmq8HC3w33Cw)

p(0) at each iteration is (e-1)/e.
p(each other number) at each iteration is (1/e)*(1/99).

Obviously this choice of random distribution gives a rather unsatisfying-looking output (since most of the runs are rather short).  So [this link](https://tio.run/##fcwxCsAgDADA3Ve4NYFQdNR39AMiKQhqg1qwr7d9Qdcbrq0VoYcimcE5ajwFLO3GIh1IBlcMAzbVWDgMbY3RIxXuXqkNVQ8i@QHrP6fzrnGkq8LE3xHXCw) uses the same approach, but changes p(0) to roughly 0.01 to illustrate some longer runs...

**What's going on?**

```r
            rexp(1)         # First determine where the '0' will occur:
                            # We generate a single random number using
                            # an exponential distribution with a
                            # rate parameter equal to 1
                            # (so the chance of any value x is e^-x).  
c(                    ,0)   # Now place '0' at the subsequent position, 
  sample(99,rexp(1),T)      # and fill all the previous positions with
                            # numbers sampled from 1 to 99,
                            # with replacement (specified by the 'T' for TRUE).
```

Comment: I see, you need the `replace=T` since there's a nonzero probability that the sample size will be larger than `99`, though in practice, it seems...unlikely. `exp(-100)` or so?

Comment: @Giuseppe - Yup.  Also, the output needs to be the same as independent sampling, so this would be violated without replacement.

Answer (score 13):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>19</s> 18 bytes

-1 byte thanks to [Dingus](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92901/dingus)!

```ruby
loop{1/p(rand~99)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/Pyc/v6DaUL9AoygxL6XO0lKz9v9/AA)

`rand~99` generates a random integer below `abs(~99)=abs(-100)=100`, `p` prints it to the output and returns the integer as a function and `1/x` fails for `x==0`, stopping the program.

Comment: @Dingus thats non-intuitive behaviour, thank you ;)

Comment: Yes, I can't imagine the intended use case for negative arguments. Now a [tip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/218195/92901).

Answer (score 13):

## [Random Brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), <s>67</s> <s>66</s> <s>65</s> 49 bytes

```
+[>>-[>++<-----]>--<?[>->+<[>]>[<+>-]<<[<]>-]>>.]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcnBCYBAEAPAgpZYQYiFhH2ciiDiCQfWv@p8Z7S@3ReW0Y6@P@tZFZZgRRC/FMDZgoJWygwhSfOblKasegE)

Finally found a use for this silly variant.

Assumes wrapping cells and that the tape will never overflow (which would be statistically improbable).

Basically, Random Brainfuck is just normal Brainfuck, except it adds the `?` opcode which reads a byte from `/dev/urandom`.

All I have to do is modulo 100.

I move forward 6 bytes each iteration.

Outputs random **bytes** to stdout.

```python
+                             (1) 0 0 0 0
[ do
    # advance tape two places for sentinel
    >>                        0 (0) 0 0
    # set 100
    # https://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainfuck_constants#100
    -[>++<-----]>--           0 0 0 (100) 0
    # Read random byte
    <?                        0 (rng) 100 0
    # mod 100
    # https://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainfuck_algorithms#Modulus_algorithm
    [>->+<[>]>[<+>-]<<[<]>-]  0 (0) * rng % 100
    # move left and print
    >>                        0 0 * (rng % 100) 
    .                         print
] while rng % 100 != zero     note: start
```

The equivalent C algorithm:

```c
void print_random(void)
{
    uint8_t rng;
    do {
        rng = randbyte() % 100;
        putchar(rng);
    } while (rng != 0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to random brainfuck. I posted my own solution

Answer (score 12):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>30</s> 29 bytes

```r
while(print(sample(0:99,1)))T
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/vzwjMydVo6AoM69EozgxtwDIMbCytNQx1NTUDPn/HwA)

`print` returns its argument invisibly, so this will choose an integer from 0-99 uniformly at random until a `0` is printed, because `0` is falsey in R.

Uses the "do-`while`" [tip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/157131/67312).

Thanks to Robin Ryder for saving a byte.

Comment: Nice.  I can't see any way to easily beat this without resorting to a [highly-tweaked distribution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/218176/95126)...

Comment: [29 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/r/vzwjMydVo6AoM69EozgxtwDIMbCytNQx1NTUDPn/HwA "R – Try It Online")

Comment: @RobinRyder very nice, thank you!

Comment: @RobinRyder - Well, that'll teach me...

Answer (score 11):

## [Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), <s>52</s> 50 bytes

-2 bytes inspired by [EasyasPi's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/218184/64121).

Produces some integers with probability \$\frac 2 {256}\$ and some with probability \$\frac 3 {256}\$ in each iteration.

```python
import os
while id:print(id:=os.urandom(1)[0]%100)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/PzO3IL@oRCG/mKs8IzMnVSEzxaqgKDOvRAPIsM0v1istSsxLyc/VMNSMNohVNTQw0Pz/HwA)

Uses the builtin function `id` to avoid assigning a new variable before the loop.
[`os.urandom(size)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.urandom) returns a `bytes` object with `size` random bytes. The `bytes` object behaves quite similar to a list of integers, which means `os.urandom(1)[0]` gives a single random integer from \$[0,255]\$, which we map to an integer from \$[0,99]\$ with a modulo operation.

---

## [Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 53 bytes

Generates integers from a uniform distribution over \$[0, 99]\$.

```python
from random import*
while id:print(id:=randint(0,99))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/P60oP1ehKDEvBUhl5hbkF5VocZVnZOakKmSmWBUUZeaVaAAZtiAVILaBjqWlpub//wA)

Comment: Python needs a do-while loop

Comment: @pxeger Charcoal and Retina probably do too :-(

Comment: Nice solution! I figured the walrus operator could come in handy here.

Comment: I like the misuse of `id` here :)

Answer (score 10):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
♀(wo▲
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7///RzAaN8vxH0zb9/w8A)

**Explanation:**

```python
    ▲  # Do-while true (!=0) with pop,
       # using the entire program implicitly as inner code-block:
♀      #  Push 100
 (     #  Decrease it to 99
  w    #  Pop and push a random integer within the range [0,99]
   o   #  Print it with trailing newline (without popping)
```

Answer (score 9):

## Batch, 48 bytes

```
@set n=%random:~-2%
@echo %n%
@if %n% gtr 0 %0
```

Works by taking the random number as a string and extracting the last two digits. (But the comparison is a numeric comparison so 00 still compares equal to 0.) 50 bytes if leading zeros are not allowed:

```
@set/an=%random%%%100
@echo %n%
@if %n% gtr 0 %0
```

Answer (score 8):

## [Bash (coreutils)](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 22 bytes

```bash
shuf -ri0-99|sed /^0/q
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/vzijNE1BtyjTQNfSsqY4NUVBP85Av/D/fwA)

Bash is amazingly short here.

Using the little-known sed `q` (quit) command.

Comment: very nice, beats `jot -r 0 0 99|sed /^0/q` by 1 byte..

Answer (score 7):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 24 bytes

```powershell
for(;$x=random 100){$x}0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/Py2/SMNapcK2KDEvJT9XwdDAQLNapaLW4P9/AA)

Answer (score 7):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 6 bytes

```
W
O100
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/P5zL39DA4P9/AA)

---

Python 3 translation:

```
from random import randrange
def n(b):
    print(b)
    return b

while n(randrange(100)):
    pass
```

Answer (score 7):

## x86-16 DOS .COM file, <s>15</s> 10 bytes

Machine code:

```
00000000: 0f c7 f0 d4 64 cd 29 75 f7 c3                    ....d.)u..
```

Assembly:

```c
        // sed -i -e 's#//#;#g' dosrand.asm
        // nasm -f bin dosrand.asm -o dosrand.com
        [bits 16]
        org 100h
        section .text
start:
.loop:
        // don't mind the completely non-suspicious AVX instruction
        // ax -> rand()
        rdrand  ax
        // al -> al % 100
        // ah -> al / 100
        // set flags on al
        aam     100
        // putchar(al)
        int     29h
        // Loop if aam didn't return zero
        jnz     .loop
.end:
        // return to dos (jumps to 0000h which is int 20h)
        ret
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XU7LDoIwELzzFZt4hiCe5Bv8B7OUAjXbR9qSFD/eysO06h52sjOT2UHnuOxoKUfGYiWU53R3i/IYQGlj@SBCUY2kOwKJQhXbamN1I61NW8BnbG9R9QAYEoUodzzXdeJO4IScCT2H9RM01ylJZnbT8HNtyL8CGRIdmmcT2uzVBv69K5fDHuq541E6d@Y@xhcbCEcXS3lp3g) (`int 29h` simulated with `pushf/popf` and `putchar`)

[This binary needs a 2013 processor running a 1981 operating system](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AnachronismStew). Nothing weird here.

Specifically, it requires [the `rdrand` instruction](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/rdrand) introduced in Ivy Bridge. However, QEMU supports this even on non-x86 hosts with `-cpu max`.

Prints raw bytes to stdout.

I might make a version for i386 using `printf` later, but I like this meme better.

Thanks to 2x-1 for recommending `int 29h` and saving 5 bytes!

Note that a solution using `mov al, 100; out 41h, al; in al, 41h` was suggested for a portable alternative, but I was unable to get it to work properly; they either infinite looped or the data wasn't random enough depending on the DOS implementation I used (NTVDMx64, DOSBOX, and QEMU/FreeDOS).

Comment: Could `int 29h` work here?

Comment: Ooh, it might. I didn't know about that interrupt! I will test it all on my PC tomorrow.

Comment: @2x-1 nice one! I think you can omit the `TEST AL, AL` since the `DEC AL` will set the `ZF` for you. Also, `DEC AL` is actually 2 bytes, whereas `DEC AX` is 1 (though you can't use that without zero'ing out the contents of `AH` which would cost you at least that byte back). Also, you do need a `RET` at the end to make it legal, either as a callable function OR a standalone COM it's necessary [updated](https://tio.run/##SywuTs1NyqnUzUsszv3/PzjEMSjEiktBwdc/TMHRR0FHwczEQ0HBWkHByQDIBEr4h4YomBh66IBkwRKuZkA@UMLTTwGiAygLkTCBSLi4OkMUgwFQws1VwdkCrCNEwcjSAyHh7ALkAyW8/KIUwC6BSZibKriBLA9yDVHgRDLJ2fj/fwA)

Comment: @2x-1 actually if you submitted that as a standalone executable you could use `DEC AX` since we can assume registers are in known startup states and most common DOS version zero out `AX` ( [Tips for golfing in x86](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/181407/84624) ). That'd get you to 12 bytes (`b064 e641 e441 48 cd29 75f5 c3`)!

Comment: Using `int 29h` should save you total 5 bytes since you can eliminate 3 bytes from `xchg` and `mov ah, 2`. Also `aam 100` will set `ZF` when `al == 0` so you can eliminate 2 more bytes by removing `test dl,dl` too. Great suggestion @2x-1!

Comment: @2x-1 I can't seem to get the `out 41h, al`  to work. Both DOSbox and FreeDOS on AArch64->x86 QEMU only seem to dump up to `11h`

Comment: And NTVDMx64 never stops running . But TIL that QEMU emulates `rdrand` and the 10 byte solution using `int 29h; jnz .loop` works, so I will add that. I am interested in that `out/in` solution if you can get that working right, though.

Answer (score 6):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 61 bytes (recursive)

```java
Object f(){int r=100;return(r*=Math.random())<1?r:r+" "+f();}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY3BCsIwEETv/YrFU6IY2qtR/ILiwaN4SNOqG9ukbDaClH57DDi3YZj3nPmYvevfGac5EIMrXSXGUT2St4zBq62u7GhihNagh6WKbBhtvnRusAwPIRf0DHRq6lrTwIm8oO2pNfxSZHwfJiHlsTnTgXYb2OzKQa8ZYE7diBb@NPgE7GEqAnFlQv@83cHQM8rig5LrN/IwqZBYzWXm0YvCkbqMa7XmHw)

```java
Object f(){         // Method returning an Object because it either returns an Integer or a String. 
 int r=100;         // Initialize r as an int(eger) to 100.
 return             // The rest can be inlined, so use the return here.
  (
   r*=Math.random() // Multiply 100 by a random double number in range [0,1).
                    // Also, *= is a compound operator that implies a cast,
                    // therefore changing the double to an int at no cost.
                    // So now, r is an integer in range [0,100).
  )<1?              // If the multiplied number is zero (the only possible value below 1)
    r               // Return r as an int, which is automatically boxed to an Integer.
                    // Technically, r is 0, so I could have written 0 instead of r
                    // This is the recursion-closing branch.
   :                // Otherwise
    r+" "+f();      // Return a String, composed of r, a space and the result of the next call to f()
                    // which may either be another String or 0.
}
```

## Java (JDK), 64 bytes (iterative)

```java
v->{for(int r=1;r>0;System.out.println(r*=Math.random()))r=100;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYyxisMwEER7f8WWUiDCqXV2c3WqQJqQYk@2c/JJK7NaGY7gb3eUVMPMPN6MKx7n4W/3cUksMNduivhgpkJOfCJzsI0LmDOc0RM8G4Cl/ATvIAtKjTX5AWL91EXY0@N2B@RH1h8U4DtRLnHkr2vlepi6fT32zymx8iTA3cly39rLf5YxmlTELFUigRQfujPKr2GkIUWlta5w29pttx/xZNC5cRFFJQT93rZm218)

### Credits

- -2 bytes thanks to [Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen) on the iterative version

Comment: Recursion beating iteration in Java is rare enough to notice!

Comment: You actually can do recursion with lambda, but no one on this site ever uses it, so I am not sure how it should be counted. [57 bytes](https://tio.run/##LY/BboMwDIbP5CmsnkKrpu11lO26S7VDb5t2MBBoWEiQY5imimdnXrXj59/6frvHGfd987W6YYzE0AubiZ037RRqdjGYbaFqjynBBV2Au1KZC2ypxdrCu3CWvVW9rRk6nRcqW2QhMbKrJW0LoXGqvND/cI6ugUFU@srkQvfxCUhdyh/mFspV5/vnu1QAlafjsSDLEwVN2/KCfDOEoYmDzvPz6YWeaLeBza41f9XLWmSHA7ziLFZAGJFwsHIpRIIQGb6d91BZ4JuFJBF4GzpRSu/1J7EdTJzYjHIU64dS3lEAi1rWXw)

Comment: It's called named lambda and it's not usable in Java because the full lambda type should've present, that means having all the parameter types. Unless you use an existing functional interface, in which case you need to give the full interface name. In short, it's usable in some languages but not in Java.

Comment: Oh, my apologies. [Could you do something like this, then?](https://tio.run/##NY7BbsIwEETPzlesONkgLLjWTfkCxIETVD0Yxw5OEzvarKmqKN@emrQ9zozm6TX6obdN9Tn7ro9I0OQsE/lWuhQM@RjkWhWm1cMAR@0DjEXBBtLkDfy2l1wx5gNZdNpYuC6ZnW6NNQQ1FyrH6f80X8Gp0ZVcbN/GfAIs97udQksJA8d1edR0l6hDFTsuxOv@gC@4WcFq4@STNalpzrSC9enWZoc/lUf0FXTZj58JfajfP0BjPYjF5fw9kO1kTCT7PBIP9gsuXMgFmf0Anshp/gE) @Olivier Grégoire

Comment: I'm not so sure... Now it looks more like a snippet instead of  a function, lambda or full program.

Answer (score 6):

## [Raku](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 19 bytes

```perl6
{{100.rand+|0}...0}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/utrQwECvKDEvRbvGoFZPT8@g9n9BaYlC2n8A)

Comment: [18 bytes](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/utrQwECvKDEvRbvGoFZPT8@g9n9BaYlC2n8A)

Comment: @bb94 i don't think you've got the right link, that's the same code as in the answer. I assume it was something like `^100 .pick`?

Comment: Indeed, [it was!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/ujrO0MBAQa8gMzm7Vk9Pz6D2f0FpiULafwA)

Answer (score 5):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <sup><s>15 11 10 <sup>33</sup></s></sup> 16 bytes

```apl
100,∘?⍨⍣{0=⊃⌽⍺}⍬
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG@qp/@jtgkGXI862tP@GxoY6DzqmGH/qHfFo97F1Qa2j7qaH/XsfdS7q/ZR75r/QDX/0wA)

A full program which outputs the numbers separated by spaces.

Uses `⎕IO←0` (0-indexing).

-4 then -1 byte from Adám.

-19 bytes from 1_am_Jack.

Comment: Is `x` guaranteed to always contain `0`?

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing yes, that's why the 0-indexing.

Comment: [11](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG@qp/@jtgkGXI862tP@P@pYdXj6o44ZQKJ3RYw9kDA0MACKtv9PAwA "APL (Dyalog Unicode) – Try It Online"): `∪×∘×⍨\?⍨100`

Comment: @Adám Added it in.

Comment: Note sure if interesting, but `×∘×⍨` is `×⍛×` in Extended.

Comment: This answer does permute-and-trim, which is now disallowed by an edit to the question.

Comment: @w123 I hope it's correct now.

Comment: Here's another approach {⍵,?100}⍣(1>(¯1↑⊣))⍬

Comment: @1_am_Jack Nice idea, but the numbers can only occur once.

Comment: @Razetime Not according to the OP's comment https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/218138/print-random-integers-until-0#comment508561_218138

Comment: @1_am_Jack huh. When I chatted earlier on TNB, I heard the opposite. I'll change it.

Comment: @Razetime No big deal, I just wanted to contribute :)

Comment: Our chat in TNB was asking about the first version; I wasn't sure exactly how `?` sampled it's output. There must have been a misunderstanding between us :)

Comment: Ah, no problem.

Answer (score 5):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 25 bytes

```
./^0/^{L$`^
99*
\L@$`
$.`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/X08/zkA/rtpHJSGOy9JSiyvGx0ElgUtFL@H/fwA) Explanation:

```
.
```

Suppress the default output.

```
/^0/^{
```

Repeat until the value is zero.

```
L$`^
99*
```

Replace the value with 99 `_`s.

```
\L@$`
$.`
```

Take the length of a random prefix and also output it on its own line.

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 bytes

```
³X’+ƲƬI;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///Q5ohHDTO1j206tsbT@v9/AA)

### Explanation

```
³X’+ƲƬI;   Main niladic link
     Ƭ     Repeat and collect results until there's a duplicate result
    Ʋ      (
³            100
 X           Choose a random number from 1 to 100
  ’          Decrement (to get a number from 0 to 99)
   +         Add to the current value
    Ʋ      )
      I    Increments (deltas)
       ;   Join with the implicit argument, 0
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 29 bytes

-4 bytes thanks to @Bubbler.

```
[ 100 random dup . 0 > ] loop
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0tMLskv@h8a7OnnbqWQnVqUl5qjkJtYkqFQlJiXkp@rUFCUWlJSWVCUmVeiYP0/WsHQwAAmlVJaoKCnYKBgpxCrkJOfX/D/PwA)

Comment: [29](https://tio.run/##S0tMLskv@h8a7OnnbqWQnVqUl5qjkJtYkqFQlJiXkp@rUFCUWlJSWVCUmVeiYP0/WsHQwAAmlVJaoKCnYKBgpxCrkJOfX/D/PwA). Using `loop` saves a `[ ]` here.

Answer (score 5):

## [Phooey](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Phooey), 9 bytes

```
(&~r99$c)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8jIz0@t/P9fQ62uyNJSJVnz/38A)

Dumps raw bytes to stdout.

```
(      do
  &      set cell to 0 by popping from empty stack
  ~r99   generate random from cell to 99
  $c     print as byte
)      while cell is nonzero
```

## Phooey, integer output, 12 bytes

```
(&~r99$i" ")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8jIz0@t/P9fQ62uyNJSJVNJQUnz/38A)

Does the same thing, only instead of printing as a raw byte, it prints it as an integer and adds a space.

Answer (score 5):

### Javascript (V8), 39 bytes

-4 bytes thanks to [Redwolf Programs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/79857/redwolf-programs) and [aaaidan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/51510/aaaidan).

```
do print(a=Math.random()*99|0);while(a)
```

---

### Javascript (V8), <s>45</s> 43 bytes

-2 bytes thanks to [EasyasPi](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/94093/easyaspi).

```
do{a=~~(Math.random()*99);print(a)}while(a)
```

```
do {
  a = ~~ (Math.random()*99);
  print(a)
} while(a)
```

Uses a double bitwise NOT operator (~), as a [substitute for Math.floor](http://rocha.la/JavaScript-bitwise-operators-in-practice).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/j/PyW/OtG2rk7DN7EkQ68oMS8lP1dDU8vSUtO6oCgzr0QjUbO2PCMzJ1Uj0c5A8/9/AA)

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! I think you can golf this down by at least four bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/j/PyVfoaAoM69EI9HWN7EkQ68oMS8lP1dDU8vSssZA07o8IzMnVSPRzkDz/38A "JavaScript (V8) – Try It Online")

Comment: You can also just do `while(a)`. (Pun intended)

Comment: Building on Redwolf Programs's golf ... `do print(a=Math.random()*99|0);while(a)`

Comment: Or what about `while(print(a=Math.random()*99|0)||a){}` 39 bytes

Comment: Suggested golf by [mydarkstar](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/70271/mydarkstar): `while(print(a=Math.random()*99|0)|a);` for 37 bytes

Answer (score 5):

## [Random Brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 37 bytes

```
+[>-[>++<-----]>--[->?[<<+>>[-]]<]<.]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcHRCYAwEAPQgY44wREHCfmoiiDSCgXnP/G92cbxdGyzXeN897sqRIgRiZ8JCFyVGaRgp3NxVX0)

This answer is inspired by EasyasPi's solution, but I am avoiding modulo by not even trying to get a uniform distribution.
This theoretically should work, but practically will take a long time to finish.
If you change the code setting the cell to 100 to a lower number you will see that it indeed terminates at some point.

```
+                          ; initialise cell[0] with 1
[  
    >                      ; make cell[1] the new cell[0]
    -[>++<-----]           ; set cell[1] to 100
    >--                 
        [->?[<<+>>[-]]<]   ; 100 times increment cell[0] with some probability
    <
    .                      ; print cell[0] 
]                          ; until cell[0] is 0
```

Comment: Ooh, that's really clever!

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), <s>26 23</s> 21 bytes

*@KjetilS's comment inspired me to save even more bytes than suggested, and @DomHastings got another 2 bytes off by changing to `$=`*

```perl
say$==rand 100while$=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVLF1rYoMS9FwdDAoDwjMydVxfb//3/5BSWZ@XnF/3V9TfUMDA0A)

Comment: Shave a byte with `say$_=0|rand 100until/^0/` [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVIl3tagpigxL0XB0MCgNK8kM0c/zkD///9/@QUlmfl5xf91fU31DAwNAA "Perl 5 – Try It Online")

Comment: Nice one! You can save a couple more if you use `$-` too! [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVJFtzwjMydVRde2KDEvRcHQwOD//3/5BSWZ@XnF/3V9TfUMDA0A "Perl 5 – Try It Online")

Comment: @DomHastings - That doesn't output 0 at the end. Required by "The output should always end with 0".

Comment: @KjetilS. Ah nice, I didn't read the spec and made assumptions! Using `$=` works instead then: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVLF1rYoMS9FwdDAoDwjMydVxfb//3/5BSWZ@XnF/3V9TfUMDA0A "Perl 5 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
[99ÝΩ=_#
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/2tLy8NxzK23jlf//BwA)

**Explanation:**

```python
[         # Start an infinite loop:
 99Ý      #  Push a list in the range [0,99]
    Ω     #  Pop and push a random integer from this list
     =    #  Print it with trailing newline (without popping)
      _   #  Pop and if this integer is 0:
       #  #   Stop the infinite loop
```

Answer (score 4):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <sup><s>59</s> \$\cdots\$ <s>44</s></sup> 42 bytes

Saved 2 bytes thanks to [dingledooper](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/88546/dingledooper)!!!
Saved a byte thanks to [Davide](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/100356/davide)!!!

```c
f(i){for(;printf("%d ",i=rand()%100),i;);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY3BCsIwEETv@YolUNilLSTn2D/xEtKkLNRYUkGh5NeNsVZxTjNvZ1jXT86VEpBpC9eEZkkcbwFlM4LseEg2jkiNVoo6NmRyqWe4WI5IYhNQVWeAb8px9A8YQJnDnkBX37Z7IvjU9wmS@YXvx3OUf3SdvV9QHySLXJ4uzHZaS39/AQ)

Keeps on printing random integers in \$[0,99]\$ until \$0\$ is printed.

Comment: [55 bytes](https://tio.run/##TY3BCoMwEETv@YolIOxihXhO/ZNeQkxkQVNRoYLk15umqS3d08yb3VnbDNam5JHp8PcF18WEHjeeHCoizZrmhcPmUVY9yAt3JaeqVYp0TDmCyXBAEoeAPLkD8E059G6HDpQ@5RXarOu6OILPejlB0j/z/XYL8o@uo3MztieJIqan9aMZ1tQ8Xg "C (gcc) – Try It Online") But is srand() necessary?

Comment: @Davide Yup, there's another rule about random number generation in functions can't be the same for all first and subsequent runs. Also unsure about your golf, `i` could be \$0\$ at the onset. But having it as a parameter saves a byte - thanks! :D

Comment: Oh you are right. Then [57 bytes](https://tio.run/##TY3NCoMwEITvPsUiCLtYITmnvkkvIT@yoKlEoQXJqzeN1pbuaebb2VnTDcbk7JFp8/eIS9TB4sqTQ0Gk2pYVzZHD6rFuLNQX7o8ENVIIUimXFUyaA1K1VVCmtADulIN1T@hBqFNeQRZdKndH8IkfJ0jqZ77fbqH@o8vo3IzyJKlK@WX8qIcld483) One byte from the `i` as a parameter and another byte by swapping `i=!` with `++`

Comment: @Davide Incrementing `i` before checking if its \$0\$ never stops! T_T

Comment: Ahaha I am sorry, my brain needs some rest.

Comment: @Davide Turns out we don't need to call `srand` anymore, that rule has changed. But you still need to init `i` as your copy of my answer doesn't do! T_T

Comment: I think [this](https://tio.run/##TY3BCsIwEETv@YolUNilLSTn2D/xEtKkLNRYUkGh5NeNsVZxTjNvZ1jXT86VEpBpC9eEZkkcbwFlM4LseEg2jkiNVoo6NmRyqWe4WI5IYhNQVWeAb8px9A8YQJnDnkBX37Z7IvjU9wmS@YXvx3OUf3SdvV9QHySLXJ4uzHZaS39/AQ) works for 42 bytes.

Comment: @dingledooper That's a very nice one (basically a `do` `while` template for golfing) - thanks! :D

Comment: @noodle9 I am going to fix this and it's nice to know I don't need to add `srand`. Anyway I wrote my answer even before the challenge was published, looking at the sandbox. But since I got also a recursive one, I am going to delete the iterative so there are no copies around :)

Answer (score 4):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), <s>10</s> 9 bytes

```
{S100mr}h
```

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/vzrY0MAgt6g24/9/AA)

Prints each number with a space before it.

#### How it works

```
{       }h    e# Do-while loop, withput consuming the condition. Nonzero is truthy
 S            e# Push space      
  100         e# Push 100
      mr      e# Random integer with uniform distribution on [0 1 2 ... 99]
              e# Implicit output
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>66</s> 56 bytes

```python
from random import*
x=1
while x:x=randint(0,99);print(x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P60oP1ehKDEvBUhl5hbkF5VocVXYGnKVZ2TmpCpUWFXYgiQz80o0DHQsLTWtC4pA7ArN//8B)

Thank you to [xnor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/20260/xnor), [danis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/99104/danis) and [mhawke](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/61175/mhawke) for showing new stuff and helping improve the code!

Comment: Welcome to the site, and nice first answer! Be sure to check out our [Tips for golfing in Python](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54/tips-for-golfing-in-python) page for more ways you could golf your answer.

Comment: https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEoMS8lP1chsVihiKvC1pCrPCMzJ1WhwqrCtkgPJJeZV6JhoGNpqWldUARiV2j@/w8A

Comment: Shaved down to 56 bytes (1 better than @Danis's improvements). See https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P60oP1ehKDEvBUhl5hbkF5VocVXYGnKVZ2TmpCpUWFXYgiQz80o0DHQsLTWtC4pA7ArN//8B

Comment: Oh wow. I've tried doing this without indent, but Jupyter didn't allow me to do that for some reason. Also, I was looking at how to make a proper post, so I clicked edit on one of the existing ones and four space were there so I used the same method

Answer (score 4):

## [Ohm v2](https://github.com/nickbclifford/Ohm), 10 bytes

```
⁸‹#£D§D,X‽
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8/INfr//1HjjkcNO5UPLXY5tNxFJ@JRw97//wE)

**Commented:**

```
⁸‹#          push a list containing the integers in the range [0-99]
   £    X‽   while the the picked number is not 0
    D        duplicate the list and
     §D,     pick a random number from the list and display it
```

Answer (score 4):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 40 bytes

```c
f(r){printf("%3d",r=rand()%100)*r&&f();}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYrLDkAwEADv/YqGkF1BKo4e/yKt0oQlq07i2@sxp8lkdDFpHWJHejnNKNvDG7eVcx8sMF47O/IWoqQ2Uc4dD2QAk0opzDhNLWBzh/eQ6@AIUFxCvnxZ/MajP5mkasQdHg)

Comment: This isn't valid, `r`s value is whatever was left on the stack so it could be \$0\$ at the onset. This is basically my answer without the init of `r`.

Comment: @Noodle I removed the iterative one :)

Answer (score 4):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org/), 43 bytes

```lua
repeat a=math.random(0,99)print(a)until a<1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yylN/P@/KLUgNbFEIdE2N7EkQ68oMS8lP1fDQMfSUrOgKDOvRCNRszSvJDNHIdHG8P9/AA)

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! This is a nice first answer. Be sure to check out our [tips for golfing in Lua](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/24392/95792).

Answer (score 4):

## [Orst](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/Orst-Geo), 25 bytes

```
{100ZЉΞªκ}{ªΐŌ}Ꮳΐ
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##yy8qLvn/v9rQwCDqQue5eYdWndtVWw0kJxztqX3Yv/jchP//AQ)

Yes, Caird, I used one of your esolangs to answer your challenge.

### Explained

```
{100ZЉΞªκ}{ªΐŌ}Ꮳΐ
               Ꮳ   # While:
{100ZЉ             #   A random number chosen from the range [0, 100] is truthy
      Ξªκ          #   And stored in variable y
         }
          {ªΐŌ}    # Print that number
                ΐ  # Push 0 and print that too
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/) + coreutils, 24 bytes

```sh
shuf -i0-99|grep -xB99 0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P@/OKM0TUE300DX0rImvSi1QEG3wsnSUsHg/38A)

`shuf`fle the `i`ntegers `0-99`, then search (`grep`) for a line that e`x`actly matches the pattern `0`, outputting the `99` lines `B`efore that.

Comment: zsh - or pretty much any other shell.

Comment: @DigitalTrauma I just use zsh because I have it bookmarked on TIO :q

Answer (score 3):

### Javascript (JQuery) 31 bytes

```js
while(alert(a=$.now()%100)||a);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Could you edit in a link to an online interpreter such as [Tryitonline!](https://tio.run) so that others can test your program?

Comment: idk how to get jquery working on TIO.

Comment: `$.now()` is just an alias for `Date.now()`, so you can easily define it in the header section of TIO. Same thing for `alert()`. Note that extra code in the header and footer sections does not count towards your code size. [Here is an example](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/a@iYKvgkliSypWYk1pUAuQk5@cV5@ek6uXkp/8vz8jMSdUAy2gk2qro5eWXa2iqWlpq1tQkalr//w8A). That said, in this particular case, using `console.log()` instead of `alert()` does change the behavior, as you lose the entropy provided by the user input (by closing the alert popup).

Comment: Is using `$.now()` generate random number multiple times allowed on this site?

Comment: @tsh the challenge itself is very cool on which random to use.

Comment: @tsh i am using an alert poppup, the time interval is in principle random.

Comment: Can it ever generate 99?

Comment: @l4m2, real sharp thank you, i will fix it.

Answer (score 3):

## TSQL, 52 bytes

```sql
DECLARE @ INT A:SET @=RAND()*100PRINT @;IF @>0GOTO A
```

Probably shorter ways to do this. Declaring the variable as an integer means we don't have to explicitly call a `ROUND` or `FLOOR` function. A `GOTO` loop is shorter than a `WHILE` loop.

Answer (score 3):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 60 bytes

```bash
while true;do echo $(($RANDOM%100));done|grep -B99999 -m1 ^0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/vzwjMydVoaSoNNU6JV8hNTkjX0FFQ0MlyNHPxd9X1dDAQFMTKJGXWpNelFqgoOtkCQIKurmGCnEG//8DAA)

Comment: 44, no external programs: https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/vzwjMydVITU5I19BRUMj0TbI0c/F31fV0MBAU9MaKKCpyZWSr2BlnZKfl/r/PwA

Although I'm fairly certain `$RANDOM` doesn't qualify here, it is deterministic after the first call.

Comment: -1 byte: `$(($RANDOM%100))` -> `$((RANDOM%100))`

Answer (score 3):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 30 bytes

```
While[Echo@RandomInteger@99>0]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78/z88IzMnNdo1OSPfISgxLyU/1zOvJDU9tcjB0tLOIPb/fwA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 6 bytes

```
{₁ʁ℅…|
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%7B%E2%82%81%CA%81%E2%84%85%E2%80%A6%7C&inputs=&header=&footer=)

I'm actually quite happy with the way this one turned out. It's always fun when you can print things in the loop's condition.

### Explained

```
{₁ʁ℅…|
{      # Open a while loop which loops while:
 ₁ʁ    #      From the range [0, 100)
   ℅   #      A randomly chosen item is truthy (non-0)
    …  #      (Print that value without popping it)
     | # Branch to the empty body of the while loop
```

In summary, this works by randomly choosing and printing a random number in the range [0, 100) until that value is 0.

Answer (score 3):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <del>45</del> <del>36</del> 31 bytes

```powershell
$x=1;while($x){($x=random 100)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X6XC1tC6PCMzJ1VDpUKzGkjYFiXmpeTnKhgaGGjW/v8PAA)

Shameless port of Python 3 verbose answer by @Gotoro!

-5 bytes thanks to @Zaelin

Comment: You can save a byte by using a (mostly empty) for loop rather than a while loop, another byte by implicitly outputting x by wrapping its assignment in parenthesis, and 4 more bytes by implicitly aliasing `get-random` -> `random`. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X6XC1tA6Lb9Iw1qlQrNaA8gtSsxLyc9VMDQw0Kz9/x8A "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Comment: And you can save an additional 1 byte in Powershell 7 (unfortunately, TIO uses 6), by using the null-coalescing operator `??` like so: `for(;$x ??1){($x=random 99)}`

Comment: @ZaelinGoodman thanks for it

Comment: Down to 28 using [`do...while`](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/PyW/WkOlwrYoMS8lP1fB0MBAs7Y8IzMnFSio@f8/AA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Icon](https://github.com/gtownsend/icon), 39 bytes

```
procedure f()
write(r:=|?100-1)&r=0
end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0zOz/ufk5mXrVCUmJeSn/u/oCg/OTWltChVIU1Dk6u8KLMkVaPIyrbG3tDAQNdQU63I1oArNS8FSV1uYmYeUKmCAtSIzKpUCBdkAEgpAA)

Please note that `link random` is needed for the `randomize()` function, because the output in TIO is always the same. The `random` function in [Icon](https://github.com/gtownsend/icon) is `?`

### Explanation:

`?100` returns a random integer in the range 1..100

`|?100` turns it into a generator

`|?100-1` subtract 1, so that the random number is in the range 0..99

`r:=|?100-1` assign the value to a variable `r`

`write(r:=|?100-1)` prints the value

`&r=0` if `r` is not zero, backtrack and generate a new value

Answer (score 3):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 10 bytes

```
WnTZ=TO99T
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/PzwvJMo2xN/SMuT/fwA)

---

Explanation:

```python
W            # while loop
 nTZ         # compare T (initially 10) not equal to Z (initially 0)
    =TO99    # assign T to a random number from 0 to 99
         T   # output T
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Julia](http://julialang.org/), 27 bytes

```julia
while 0<@show rand(0:99)end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/vzwjMydVwcDGoTgjv1yhKDEvRcPAytJSMzUv5f9/AA)

Answer (score 3):

## TI-BASIC, 14 bytes

```
Repeat not(Ans
int(E2rand
Disp Ans
End
```

Uses E2 as a shortcut for 10^2=100 to save a byte along with int(rand to save bytes over randInt( - Ans also makes a useful appearance

Answer (score 3):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/),<sup><s>54</s></sup> 47 bytes

***-1 bytes** by using `/dev/random` (@EasyasPi), **-2 bytes** by using `$_` instead of assigning a new parameter, **-4 bytes** by reading a line instead of a single character.*

```sh
read -u0 c</dev/random
echo $[#c%100]
((_))&&$0
```

<s>[1](https://tio.run/##qyrO@J@moVn9vyg1MUVBt9RAQTfbUCHZRj8ltUy/tCgxLyU/lys1OSNfQSW6wlY5WdXQwCCWS0OjQlNTTU3F4H8tF1fafwA)
[2](https://tio.run/##qyrO@J@moVn9vyg1MUVBt9RAQTfbUCHZRj8ltUy/tCgxLyU/lys1OSNfQSVaOVnV0MAglktDI15TU01NxeB/LRdX2n8A)
[3](https://tio.run/##qyrO@J@moVn9vyg1MUVBt9RAQTdbIdlGPyW1TL@0KDEvJT@XKzU5I19BJVo5WdXQwCCWS0MjXlNTTU3F4H8tF1fafwA)</s>

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@J@moVn9vyg1MUVBt9RAIdlGPyW1TL@0KDEvJT@XKzU5I19BJVo5WdXQwCCWS0MjXlNTTU3F4H8tF1fafwA)
(uses `/dev/urandom` instead due to TIO's jail)

Bash and Zsh's `$RANDOM` does not qualify as an independent RNG. The first call is random, but subsequent calls are intentionally deterministic. So we have to make our own, reading a line from /dev/random. We get the codepoint of the first character with `#c`.

Finally, the `$_` parameter is the last argument of the previous command, which saves us having to do `$[x=#c%100]`.

The TIO link uses a function, but this will also work as a standalone program (just mind the recursion)

Comment: -1 byte for `/dev/random`, although TIO's jail artificially prevents accessing it.

Answer (score 3):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 32 bytes

```
until[0 = probe -1 + random 100]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0pN@R@UmqIQHatQlJiXkp@rX5wK5Obll@uXZOam/i/NK8nMiTZQsFUoKMpPSlXQNVTQhqpUMDQwiP3/HwA)

Comment: Note that, as Red is the Language of the Month, it's recommended that you edit your answers into the [list of answers](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/22415/66833) so that we get a rough metric of how well used Red was this month :)

Answer (score 2):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), <s>38</s> 36 bytes

```
until[print p:(random 100)- 1 0 = p]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0pN@R@UmhIdy1WUmJeSn6tfnJqaopCXX/6/NK8kMye6oCgzr0ShwEoDIq1gaGCgqatgqGCgYKtQEPv/PwA)

Answer (score 2):

### [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/)/MATLAB with Statistics Package/Toolbox, <s>31</s> 29 bytes

```matlab
@()[randi(99,1,geornd(.1)) 0]
```

Anonymous function that takes no inputs and outputs a row vector.

This uses a modification of the approach described in the second paragraph of the challenge, with the probability of `0` being `1/10` and the probability of each of `1`, `2`, ... , `99` being `1/110`.

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f/fQUMzuigxLyVTw9JSx1AnPTW/KC9FQ89QU1PBIPZ/Yl6xhuZ/AA)

Answer (score 2):

## [F#](https://fsharp.org/), <strike>72</strike> 70 bytes

-2 bytes: changed number from "a= -1" to "a=1" (typo)

```
let mutable a=1
while a<>0 do a<-System.Random().Next(99);printfn"%i"a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyvWTc4vSv3/Pye1RCG3tCQxKSdVIdHWkKs8IxPEsrEzUEjJB9K6wZXFJam5ekGJeSn5uRqaen6pFSUalpaa1gVFmXklaXlKqplKif//AwA)

There probably would be a way of doing this in a more functional manner, but this is what I've come up with.

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 10 bytes

```
Ｗ‽¹⁰⁰⟦Ｉι⟧0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/788IzMnVUEjKDEvJT9Xw9DAQFNTIaAoM69EI9o5sbhEI1MzVtOaCyKiZKCkaf3//3/dshwA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｗ‽¹⁰⁰
```

Repeat while a randomly chosen integer from `0` to `99` is non-zero...

```
⟦Ｉι⟧
```

... print the integer on its own line. (Appending a separator doesn't help because the string needs to be separated from the following code.)

```
0
```

Print a `0`.

Answer (score 2):

## [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/), 156 bytes

```
with
t as (select 1 x union all select abs(random())%100 from t limit 1e5),
s as (select group_concat(x) s from t)
select substr(s,3,instr(s,',0,')-1) from s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYxRCsIwEAWvsj/SLERIEM8jaYy6kGw0u6G9fSy0gn@P4c3IJ5OmMRbSFygEASMpp6jgYYXOVBlCznDAMItpge@1GMSTdw4erZZNzFRoc9IVrfxXnq329y1WjkHNiiCHgL@i9Fm0GbEXS7yvyTo74dnj/pUxvg)

Answer (score 2):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 65 bytes

```scala
def f=Seq.fill(99999)(util.Random.nextInt(100)).takeWhile(_>0):+0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcqxCgIxDADQ3a/omCCUOiooODq46HCjxGuK0ZirdxEE8durvvlNPSm14Xzl3sOexAK/nC1PYVvru2UuoayP/IhFVGH5h/B00Xggy8M92u/vzGGREmJ0unF3EWU4bRKu5qnVUczVoODs074)

Answer (score 2):

## [Nim](http://nim-lang.org/), <strike>61</strike> 60 bytes

```
import random
randomize()
var x=1
while x>0:x=rand 99;echo x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8vM/f8/M7cgv6hEoSgxLyU/lwtCZValamhylSUWKVTYGnKVZ2TmpCpU2BlYVdiC5BUsLa1TkzPyFSr@/wcA)

*-1 byte thanks to Danis*

Comment: `x!=0` --> `x>0`

Answer (score 2):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), <s>37</s> <s>36</s> <s>35</s> 33 bytes

```php
for(;$n??1;)echo$n=rand(0,99),~_;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAk0/KLNKxV8uztDa01U5Mz8lXybIsS81I0DHQsLTV16uKt//8HAA)

Another great way to save 2 bytes by Sisyphus with the PHP 7 `??` operator, and no more preceding space!

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 35 bytes

```php
for(;(print~_.$n=rand(0,99))&&$n;);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAk0/KLNKw1Cooy80rq4vVU8myLEvNSNAx0LC01NdXUVPKsNa3//wcA)

No answer yet for the language we love to hate? Having to display the last zero is not optimal, still trying to get rid of it..

**EDIT**: finally got rid of the extra display for the zero, with a preceding space

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 36 bytes

```php
a:echo~_.$n=rand(0,99);if($n)goto a;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAkE61SkzPy6@L1VPJsixLzUjQMdCwtNa0z0zRU8jTT80vyFRKt//8HAA)

A 36 bytes version with an infamous [goto](https://xkcd.com/292/), also with a preceding space

Comment: That `goto` is disgusting. I like it.

Comment: Nice one! [Another golf](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAkU/KrU5Mz8lUqbIsS81I0DHQsLTV16uKta8szMnNSNVQqNK3//wcA) still at 35 bytes though!

Comment: @640KB yeah I was wondering if something like my old basic's `REPEAT ... UNTIL` existed, it does but i thought "too long". My plan was to use `&$n` with a single `&` for 34 bytes but for a reason I cannot explain the last zero doesn't show..

Comment: [33 bytes](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAk0/KLNKxV8uztDa01U5Mz8lXybIsS81I0DHQsLTV16uKt//8HAA "PHP – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [Befunge-98 (Rc/Funge-98)](https://www.rcfunge98.com/) + RAND fingerprint, 17 bytes

```
#@_"DNAR"4('dI:.!
```

It doesn't work on [TIO](https://tio.run) with FBBI nor with PyFunge because they don't have the RAND fingerprint implemented.

Answer (score 2):

## [Racket](https://racket-lang.org/), 58 bytes

```lisp
(define(f[r(random 100)])(and(writeln r)(when(< 0 r)(f))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0pMzk4t@a@ck5iXrlAE4WikpKZl5qVqpEUXaRQl5qXk5yoYGhhoxmpqADka5UWZJak5eQpFmhrlGal5GjYKBiB2miYQ/AdS/wE)

Answer (score 2):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), <s>18</s> 16 bytes

```
(*|){x,1?100}/""
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/X0OrRrO6QsfQ3tDAoFZfSen/fwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 67 bytes

*Creates a monad containing the random list*

```hs
import System.Random
m=randomRIO(0,99)>>=k
k 0=pure[0]
k x=(x:)<$>m
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/PzO3IL@oRCG4srgkNVcvKDEvJT@XK9e2CMwI8vTXMNCxtNS0s7PN5spWMLAtKC1KjTaIBbIrbDUqrDRtVOxy/@cmZubZ5gLVaBQUZeaVWFlFe@aVxOraAXVrav4HAA)

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 80 bytes

*Complete program*

```hs
import System.Random
main=randomRIO(0,99::Int)>>=k;k 0=print 0;k x=print x>>main
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/PzO3IL@oRCG4srgkNVcvKDEvJT@XKzcxM8@2CMwO8vTXMNCxtLSy8swr0bSzs822zlYwsC0oyswrUTAAsiug7Ao7O5C2//8B)

Answer (score 2):

### Swift, <s>57</s> <s>54</s> 51 bytes

```swift
var a=1;while a>0{a=Int.random(in:0...99);print(a)}
```

```swift
var a = 1                    // Set last randomly generated value to 1 as magic value
while a > 0 {                // End when a == 0
  a = Int.random(in: 0...99) // Generate new random number
  print(a)                   // Print number
}
```

-1 byte after reading comment by @Danis saying I can use `>` instead of `!=`, other 2 bytes from removing whitespace (`a!=0` makes Swift think that I'm unwrapping `a`)

-1 byte after other comment

-2 bytes after removing whitespace

Comment: Welcome to the site, and nice first answer! Be sure to check out our [Tips for golfing in Swift](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/79203/tips-for-golfing-in-swift) page for more ways you could golf your answer.

Comment: `var a = -1` --> `var a = 1`

Comment: You don't need the word `Int`, you can just say `a = .random(in:0...99)`. However, when you do that the whitespace around the `=` is no longer optional, so you only actually save one byte.

Answer (score 2):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), 51 bytes

```
{for(srand(systime());$++x=int(100*rand()%100););}1
```

This works by assigning positional variables random numbers until a 0 is generated.

The awfully long,

```
srand(systime())
```

line is needed to seed the random number generator. I couldn't find a shorter way to do that without passing in random info from outside the script.

The only other trick here is using a "truthy" test with no action, which trigger AWK to print all the positional variables by default.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v@/Oi2/SKO4KDEvRaO4srgkMzdVQ1PTWkVbu8I2M69Ew9DAQAssqakKZGpaa1rXGv7/r6QEAA)

## [Ly](https://github.com/LyricLy/Ly), 9 bytes

```
1[!'c?:]+
```

I found two the same length in `Ly` but I like this one better since it's quirkier IMO. :)

```
1         - need truthy value on the stack to start the loop
 [     ]  - loop until the top of stack is "0"
  !       - map top of loop number to "0"
   'c     - push "99"
     ?    - generate a random number in 0-99 range
      :   - duplicate the top of stack
        + - top two entries will be "0 0", add to consume one
          - numbers on the stack print automatically on exit
```

The other nine character one is `'cs?[0l?]` which is similar, but more straightforward.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y6n8/98wWlE92d4qVvv/fwA)

Answer (score 2):

## ARM Thumb-2 machine code (Linux, no libc/div), 34 bytes

Machine code:

```
4668 2101 2203 01d7 df00 4669 2201 2704
780d 3d64 d8fd 3564 700d df00 d1f0 2701
df00
```

Commented assembly:

```c
        .syntax unified
        .arch armv6t2 // technically ARMv4T compatible
        .thumb
        .globl _start
        .thumb_func
_start:
.Lloop:
        // It sucks that this takes the buffer in r0. :(
        // buf = sp
        mov     r0, sp
        // size = 1
        movs    r1, #1
        // flags = GRND_RANDOM | GRND_NOBLOCK = 3
        // 0 is preferred, but this allows us to cheat loading the getrandom
        // syscall which won't fit in a narrow movs.
        movs    r2, #3
        // getrandom = 0x180 = 3 << 7
        // no movw required
        // movw r7, #0x180
        lsls    r7, r2, #7
        // getrandom(&x, 1, GRND_RANDOM | GRND_NOBLOCK)
        svc     #0

        // getrandom for sizes < 256 return 1 in r0, as long as it isn't
        // interrupted, blocked, or out of entropy, corner cases I don't care
        // about. :P

        // fd = stdout
        // movs r0, #1
        // buf = sp
        mov     r1, sp
        // len = 1
        movs    r2, #1
        // write = 4
        movs    r7, #4

        // load the random byte returned by getrandom()
        // note: ldrb r5, [sp] is a wide instruction. :(
        ldrb    r5, [r1]

        // modulo 100 using subtraction loop
        // x %= 100
.Lmodloop:
        subs    r5, #100
        bhi     .Lmodloop
.Lmodloop.end:
        // note: this sets the zero flag which is preserved in syscalls
        adds    r5, #100

        // store the random byte mod 100 back to [r1]
        strb    r5, [r1]
        // write(1, &x, 1);
        svc     #0
        // syscalls preserve flags, so loop if
        // the value was zero.
        bne     .Lloop
.Lloop.end:
        // exit
        movs    r7, #1
        // exit(dontcare)
        svc     #0
```

Not gonna win any golfing contests, but I'll post it anyways cuz it is pretty well golfed for what it is.

No libc, only uses the `getrandom`, `write`, and `exit` syscalls.

Prints raw bytes to stdout, hence why the demo is piped to `xxd`.

[Try it online! (sorta)](https://travis-ci.com/github/easyaspi314/easyaspi-ppcg/jobs/478739600#L468) (Travis demo)

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 54 bytes

```
NestWhile[Append[#,Echo@RandomInteger@99]&,{},FreeQ@0]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78/981OSPfwS@1uCQ8IzMnNdqxoCA1LyVaWScoMS8lP9czryQ1PbXIwdIyVk2nulbHrSg1NdDBIPb/fwA)

It basically does the same thing as [att's 30 byte solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/218172/56524), but additionally it returns the collection of random values as a list, rather than `Null`

Comment: `RandomInteger[99]` can be replaced with `RandomInteger@99` to save one byte.

Comment: @numbermaniac Thanks for pointing that out. I also use `FreeQ@0` to replace `!MemberQ[#,0]&` to save more bytes. Now it looks more compact and readable!

Comment: It is encouraged to keep different language submissions in different answers.

Comment: @Razetime Didn't realize that one can post more than one answer. I'll move the bash solution to it's own answer.

Comment: No problem. Welcome to Code Golf!

Answer (score 2):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), <strike>46</strike> 45 bytes

```bash
until(echo $((RANDOM%100));exit $_);do :;done
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/vzSvJDNHIzU5I19BRUMjyNHPxd9X1dDAQFPTOrUis0RBJV7TOiVfwQpI5KX@/w8A)

*-1 byte thanks to EasyasPi*

Comment: You don't need a space after `until`.

Comment: @EasyasPi Updated

Answer (score 2):

## [Befunge-98](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Funge-98), <s>19</s> 13 bytes

*-3 bytes thanks to @ovs!*

```
?+<1
<@w.:%d'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tPj/317bxpDLxqFcz0o1Rf3/fwA)

Generates each number according to a geometric distribution modulo 100.

### Explanation

The instruction pointer (IP) starts at the `?` in the top left corner, which sends it in a random direction. If it goes right, the `<` turns it around back to the `?`, and the `+` (which is executed twice, once in each direction) adds 0 to the current number. If it goes left, `1` puts a 1 on the stack, `<` sends the IP back to `?` again, and `+` adds the 1 to the number (which, given an empty stack, starts at zero). As long as `?` keeps sending the IP left, this can happen arbitrarily many times, so there is a nonzero chance of reaching each number.

If the IP goes up or down, `<` turns it onto the second line, which processes the number.

```
 @w.:%d'

    :       Copy
   .             and print
     %                     the number modulo
      d'                                     100.
  w         If the copy is zero,
 @                               end the program.
```

If the printed result was greater than zero, `w` sends the IP up to the first line, and `<` starts the program over from the beginning.

Comment: If you take the random number modulo `100` instead of skipping the print if you reach a number higher than 99, this gets a bit simpler: [16 bytes](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tPj/395G25ArNt5BWc9KNUWdq@z/fwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Pxem](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Pxem), Filename: <s>23</s> 17 bytes + Content: 0 bytes = <s>23</s> 17 bytes, depends on ASCII-compatible encoding.

- Filename: `d.!.t.w.m.r.c.n,.o.a`
- Content: empty

### Commented

```
d.t  # heap = 100
.w # loop
  .m.r # push(random(min=0,max=heap-1))
  .c # dup()
  .n # printf("%d",pop())
  ,.o # putchar(',')
.a # break if pop()==0
```

Answer (score 2):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 50 bytes

```
701>x1>$:2*}*+ }1-:?!v}30.>
   ^\0/.;?=0oan:%*aar<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/39zA0K7C0E7FykirVktbodZQ18pesazW2EDPjktBQSEuxkBfz9re1iA/Mc9KVSsxscjm/38A)

After many iterations, I got down to this version. Pretty happy with it, although I will admit I'm not convinced it's optimal.

### Explanation

The ><> language doesn't have a natural builtin for generating a random number in a range. The only source of randomness we have is the `x` command, which sends the IP in a random direction. This gives us 1 of 4 options, which doesn't immediately fit into the range 0-99. However, we can easily use this command to generate a random bit, 0 or 1, like so:

```
>x1>
^\0/
```

Going in a left-to-right direction, the IP can either be sent leftwards back to the `>`, where it tries again, upwards, wrapping around to try again, rightwards to `1`, or downwards to `0`. This uniformly generates a random bit, although perhaps it can be made shorter by making that not so.

We're going to loop 7 times each time we generate a random number, for 7 bits. This will give us the binary for numbers from 0 to 127—more than we need, but we'll fix that later. Instead of collecting all the bits and subsequently converting that to a decimal number, we'll do both steps at once. `701` initializes the stack with our configuration. `7` is the loop count, `0` is the running sum, and `1` is the multiplicative factor.

`$:2*` will make a copy of the multiplicative factor and double that copy for the next iteration. `}*+` will multiply the generated bit by the multiplicative factor and add it to the sum. `}1-:?!v` will decrement the loop counter, and if it's 0, stop looping. `}30.`, in the event we don't stop, will reorganize the stack for the next iteration and jump back to the beginning (past the initialization).

The second line mostly contains the outer loop. It is written "backwards" to save space. First, `r` will place the generated sum on the top of the stack. `%*aa` will take that value mod 100, giving us a value from 0 to 99, albeit not uniformly. Then, we simply output that number followed by a newline (`oan:`). After that, `;?=0` terminates the program if 0.

We then have a single `.` command, which pops `y` and `x` off the stack and jumps to that location in the code. Since the stack contains `[0, 64]` at this point (the counter and the multiplicative factor, respectively), this jumps to (0, 64). Of course, this position doesn't exist in the code. In the Python implementation (the standard one), the interpreter will first increment this by the delta, which, at the time of execution, is (-1, 0). So, the IP is then (-1, 64) internally. To resolve this, ><> will first fix the y-coordinate, wrapping it around to 0 since it exceeds the bound, giving (-1, 0). When x < 0, it gets wrapped around to the end of the line, hopping to (28, 0), which is the `>` command. This puts us back on the right direction and back at the beginning of the line.

### Catalogue of Attempts

**103 bytes:** My first attempt. Completely ungolfed. First collects the bits, then converts it to a decimal in a separate stage.

```
7>x1>$1-:?!v!
 ^\0^   v$1<
{2*$l2=?\@:}*+
  !     >:0=?v:'d'(?v     >0[700.
           ;n<      >n' 'o^
```

**105 bytes:** Post calculating the sum while collecting bits. Longer, but the structure offers us more opportunities to golf.

```
701>x1>$:}*+}1-:?!v}2*30.
   ^\0^           >r:0=?v:'d'(?v     >0[700.
                      ;n<      >n' 'o^
```

**90 bytes:** Introducing the modulus trick, rather than retrying if the number is 100 (`'d'`) or more.

```
701>x1>$:}*+}1-:?!v}2*30.
   ^\0^           >r:0=?vaa*%nao0[700.
                      ;n<
```

**64 bytes:** Inlining the terminate-if-zero condition.

```
701>x1>$:}*+}1-:?!v}2*30.
   ^\0^           >raa*%:nao0=?;0[700.
```

**54 bytes:** Moving the modulo calculation into the main loop so we have enough room to flip the second line and tuck it into the whitespace we have.

```
701>x1>$:}*+aa*%}1-:?!v}2*30.>
   ^\0/     .;?=0oan:r<
```

**53 bytes:** Since we have spare whitespace left, we can use it to set the pointer in the right direction to save the `>` off the first line. Since that means we're jumping to the beginning of the line, we'd naturally skip `7`, so we have to duplicate it before we jump.

```
701>x1>$:}*+aa*%}1-:?!v}2*30.
   ^\0/ #.!@7;?=0oan:r<
```

This approach, however, left me at a dead end, so I tried putting the modulo calculation back into the second part, which leaves us with what we currently have.

Answer (score 2):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), <s>87</s> <s>60</s> <s>58</s> 54 bytes

```c
main(a){for(srand(&a);printf("%d ",a=rand()%100),a;);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VchBCoMwEADAu68QRcmCFnuO9i9rYuxCXCVJ8SB@3W3pzTmOaY1HnqUkNv5jp7yPydL6eL@yW3ka75domX4jCxIrhMOtQcWAbFWNoLdAnJwqKpsXDQ7/h@rZddCgBn2KXMZ5nKO0@xc)

Learned new functions thanks to this.

Thanks to caird coinheringaahing, along with the help of a stone arachnid, for golfing 27 bytes. Thanks to a stone arachnid for golfing another 2 bytes. Thanks to ceilingcat for golfing 4 bytes.

Comment: [74 bytes](https://tio.run/##VYrBDoIwEAXvfkWDIdlN1JTzCv9SW9CXlMWUejJ8ey3euE1mxl99dPosZ6iPnzCa@5oDlttrOB1UxOPoMuaxmgLNZnZQ4u@O6DtZk9NA@0CWWaYlkUBq7/@B285aeae6T9S0wTQXsGxbKT8)

Comment: Adding to @caird coinheringaahing: [60 bytes](https://tio.run/##VcjNCsIwDADgu08xJoMEnNRz1HeJ7ToDXSZtxcPYqxt/bvuOn@99Yh1tL@rTMwzNudQg8/F@3W0qyW17VabhO8Y0sSjgUjJrgF@DQ6Q4ZyC@/BO7k3OEjyxaI7RdaNoDI61mbx8Tj8X61wc "C (clang) – Try It Online")

Comment: [58 bytes](https://tio.run/##VclNDoIwEEDhPacgGJKZxJq6rniXsaU4SRlMW@OCcHXHnx3L9z1vfCKZ9MDi0zOM7aXUwMvpfm12lPi2t8rz@BWdiQUI17hkKJkkwO@ARXQ0/Bv7s7UOH5mlRuj60HZHQrepvn1MNBU1rw8 "C (clang) – Try It Online")

Comment: This doesn't print the ending zero.

Answer (score 2):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 7 bytes

```
W PRRhx
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P8/XCEgKCij4v9/AA)

#### Explanation

```
W        While
   RRh   random integer in [0, 100)
  P      printed
         is truthy (nonzero):
      x   No-op
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 54 bytes

```
while {[set R [expr int(rand()*99)]]} {puts $R}
puts 0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0nO@f@/PCMzJ1WhOro4tUQhSCE6taKgSCEzr0SjKDEvRUNTy9JSMza2VqG6oLSkWEElqJYLzDD4/x8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>11</s> 9 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
Lö
OpU
©ß
```

[Test it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=TPYKT3BVCqnf)

Outputs delimited by newlines, with a trailing newline after the 0

```
Lö      # Get a random number from [0...99] and store it as U
OpU     # Print U and a newline
©       # If U is non-zero:
 ß      #  Run the program again
        # Otherwise end with no further output
```

Comment: [9 bytes](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=TPYKT3BVCqnf)

Answer (score 1):

## VBScript, 51 bytes

```
Randomize
Do
r=Int(100*Rnd)
msgbox r
Loop Until r=0
```

Answer (score 1):

## [CSASM v2.2.1](https://github.com/absoluteAquarian/CSASM/releases/tag/v2.2.1), 74 bytes

```
func main:
.lbl a
push 100
extern Random.Next(i32)
dup
print.n
brtrue a
ret
end
```

**Commented:**

```
func main:
    .lbl loop
        ; Get a random number in [0, 99]
        push 100
        extern Random.Next(i32)
        ; Duplicate it so it can be printed and then checked
        dup
        print.n
        ; Keep looping as long as the i32 generated is truthy (non-zero)
        brtrue loop
    ret
end
```

Answer (score 1):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 14/15 bytes

```
{100rand.}do]`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/v9rQwKAoMS9FrzYlPzbh/38A)

Uses `rand` built-in to generate random numbers from 0-99, inside a `do` loop to terminate once a 0 is generated. The output of the loop is collected into an array and formatted for output. If the brackets and quotation marks invalidate the output, here is another version that sacrifices 1 byte for cleaner output:

```
{' '100rand.}do
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/v1pdQd3QwKAoMS9FrzYl//9/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Knight](https://github.com/knight-lang/knight-lang), 12 bytes

```php
W;O=n%R100nT
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVltc9vIDf4s/Yq1MpZIikpI2p25kURpkpyd8dSxc3bSfLDVmKYom3PUSiUp@9zE/espgH3hUi9p015mLIq7D7DAs1gAq8S9uzj@/iLlcbaaJsOinKaLl/ejpjmSpbe1obh8WiZroDzld7WhMp0LzDSZpTxhWcayBb@jj6Ye/Xj26T3zq9fLjxcsqF7/9vqCHVavx2dv2S/V68Un5lfg49NLA3v26dSAfjp7//ryr1ZhMws/2uxf/l9sPfv6EpYVk/F9lDPHrgRMFNiqVYxG7LCaOzv6jJMcJsmjbwy/D4drGFyGMOgmYLLMRmAN8@b8/JRA@DEmJ/vom2HIxTsBAHnD1ocoWyW2fcUndrNJfsCuXE3Ci9bR@bH1/fPgPOT7F77n8Y/fbRhqDQTKAVgSzVmI@EGzCUqXUV4kls2@NhspL1k6aDZglBZwmTNb8RhGSDiG93K@dIslvwom4VfP9Z5BRyMFdYSHp4cDr16h@nTJHu/TMimWUZw0G/A9SywYB3FLmOGy1nV5za9n1zn7@nw1sez@i5ZNpjTSGbO0tSHrvOjYTKhQo3swes1huNsVI2BnI8mKxBx4FubE90n8O5stcsZX89skL6Q9zEqLaXqXlkorrI7u@K72SDwd5nusyxxpebdrsx7reB1YAi1NbZYn5SrnTIWEEKOoGKzb8BDlaXSbJcoKMCJbPCa5FcN6yhD27RtTxsX0FhMRXzq2pCfd4noa@i7sUaiH16zDQyaDESB8ulpauKVMctpj8LZpsDjyhdAmzLjudCqbWh2xaSAMHmijGCiBFAHfwbJlVJSsvE9AWZSXAJYb4ChGcUNjGz1RxhonZ6ex8OnbtNGNigwyH0O3TBcczMaI9SZgWqwYKVbLJRJuq6hSIyb9ZvwB7QbZqEOF8pJDHEO6wsiVlgtWPnb0mRYDxziAqauPKQvNVEFG2U64aqHdaGqUZYvYOvRc30YHcVg7QQ7yVZZF@ZPpaLU/F8b2fOhoy2hBKb/ia9K0hI9LyKSwzdOjN29vfts7/fXc8NfUeptuVRtsqt2r6X13crlDY5nkpDLiU/aPVaReUe2DucTB5hLC/3cdTcXJFipI@LAuXMc8U6bMVxw3aCAzrlMuCkulSop/iOwyjRnN3q5mV8HhRNoh9rlN2UEbUCzhVJUzC6Dg/36WTVsq7VDFcVHJugI4E1qBqGVi/RpuyPyDup/oPIbimLXKfJW0IAT1OEYkjM8iSCA40cLAalUkoJ/ouyw6RMeXN4tFBjO3dQZ2@lq59SOHnJ/3yDTzdsPMDG3kf6qNELTlIsss01SXeS4UiP/BZL5hMhbh968/nLlYikWgwevJFRRzD8IJXIFX9Vak/0y@lAwfAyNGDW@RAXhz8SOgz4PQVxUdExwWdXzQZyAeBwA4Pjk9ctgMcuOgoUNbrodZOI6WbpZwagAMrlRPJDiDc7eLjHVBLE1Y2bDeWCm1ElCKh8TFAGpKipM6b8Tz5doOEEnppEohSFM6wWWKx7SM7y0HmNlooZCjGOsTZMy@EpUtXg4Zx7Lb3h8z/Ie7K5AfAAk2CBvvkjKDTs1qE5dtZAgr1DTl9sDQR11nmWMNg4dNNVZoOxLaRFuGZw17Psz5Shr3VGamyoY3lbUCr2feVjMoiX9SY4W5AQxyDbsbLhfLhFvGwm4rb1EdBqvCuShDsNth4B3@QuOyclui3M/A9Ck6Bf0RBISLzRPAoTDTG64BS6vNs2CQdUPqM/A8ANKWZIIeWouIRA1OyAKzIahorDz5DTxJ/oAeCc/Shp97tT2ldnsP88QG8HRj82GVrM6LAf@105dNmIij0GRZ5xWZ31tn1HNamOFtleJHo0O76to2ko0SvaTOy9ovUNAM@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@rPPgkIJ1rfBh0qvlxbCeFcfMPPxD8xigaF/@lNVmAjBmtTaMBl1mZEPU4QlJVXIDUQcQuxdCtTG6oBEcSgytxXTRZ/NkHi8xzDgb3Yz/X1dGf4IrI@XK3hZfQumLdGW8m32x6haTcXrMaoBAIwJVQPe22Vm9aPdU5jEVaPPaVfpDX7bVhrEpKVOJlv/238jLHGSo0fKDTt9E19rcdWxYZd369E9fE1RvW90TENeo3RV0KiQMapyENWkjTaIEIrpdLSZM/gzuiZ@UzEaz5h0zexcpdlLv2hFqyI@D/oFByztxZQiNDqtrFqDNeweXFw9Xn4WDWkN7KYheUzpYL3nBtpJ3YOs@INDShzT4HxoiNAyfuBWxbv51O2T2RgF4iKt2fWySqEEQ8S8m6UGIrjwJsPo0mUWQJMEz1WGmHCbTKf1EE8UllKnOftzBnhNHbLbjjojKdA2EblBe0@dRyrFZZVF@F7uk1HHg@4ONPwbR7RH/Z8TyyJr6Ne75@78B)

Very simple.

```php
# Loop while RANDOM % 100 is non-zero.
# Because we need to output 0 as well, we
# use a semicolon to output first, then check n.
WHILE (; OUTPUT (= n % RANDOM 100):n)
    : TRUE # empty loop body
```

`;` can act sort of like the comma operator in C. It evaluates two statements and returns the second value.

Therefore, it is basically this in C:

```c
while (printf("%d\n", n = rand() % 100), n)
    ;
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 39 bytes

```javascript
for(x=1;x;)print(x=Math.random()*100|0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/j/Py2/SKPC1tC6wlqzoCgzrwTI8U0sydArSsxLyc/V0NQyNDCoMdD8/x8A)

Comment: 99 must be inclusive, so you need to multiply to 100

Comment: You are, of course, correct, @EzioMercer. Stupid, pre-caffeine brain!

Answer (score 1):

## [Scala](https://www.scala-lang.org/), 151 bytes

Golfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcuxCsIwEIDh3ac4g0NuCXGWCo6uOjhKTE8aTS@huWJFfPZYdfzh@4t30dUa@pwGgfItM0qI5uC4Tf0iXW7kBXZAkxC3BXY5v44ykOuNTyyBRxfjUzM94L9oNDzjPYteW4toxN3p1IVI@gzLBiyaa5p/3@kJmi3kIcy0qNUECnHzy8haWYXvWj8)

```scala
import scala.util.Random
object A extends App{Stream.continually(new Random().nextInt(100)).takeWhile(_ != 0).foreach(x => print(s"$x "));println("0")}
```

Ungolfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY49T8MwEIZ3/4ojYjgvlrtWChIjAwuo6lBV6Ejc1sU5V84VUqH@9nBNEBLje/d@PH1DicYxdqdcBPqbcmeJyb0Qt7kzJr8fQyPwTJHh2wC0YQdl@q1YfR7tEl6lBOo2TyxbqCcXwCclKNyq5vAFcxva6TXbXZO1gM@U0gXV6TgMohW48N5aJ/QR1oeYAr7BXQ3@Fr2aX4BOaZDKvl/CYyl02Whl5P1WWVYc5Q/iP6jbZR1uDjhA/QAnTQj21f0AlZ3BplNirHw1z13NOP4A)

```scala
import scala.util.Random

object Main {
  def randomUntil0(): Stream[Int] = {
    val rnd = new Random()
    Stream.continually(rnd.nextInt(100)).takeWhile(_ != 0)
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    randomUntil0().foreach(x => print(s"$x "))
    println("0")
  }
}
```

## How it works?

The task needs to print a sequence of random numbers between 0 and 99 (inclusive) until a 0 is generated. This Scala code achieves the same purpose by defining a randomUntil0 function that generates a Stream of random numbers and takes elements while the number is not equal to 0. The main method iterates over the Stream generated by randomUntil0 and prints the numbers followed by 0.

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
(ɦLɼß
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWKzROLvM5uefw_CXFScnFUEGYJAA)

##### Explanation

```python
(ɦLɼß  # Full program
(      # While loop
 ɦL    # (condition)  Push [0..99]
   ɼ   #              Pop and choose a random item
    ß  #              Print it without popping
       # (This runs until 0 is selected,
       #  since 0 is the only falsy integer)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Swift 5.9, 51 bytes

```swift
var r=1
while r>0{r = .random(in:0...99)
print(r)}
```

Yes, the whitespace around the second `=` is required.

Comment: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky7PTCsx@f@/LLFIocjWkKs8IzMnVaHIzqC6SMFWQa8oMS8lP1cjM8/KQE9Pz9JSk6ugKDOvRKNIs/b/fwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Assembly (nasm, x64, Linux)](http://www.nasm.us/), 308 bytes

```
s:mov edi,100
mov eax,edi
mov edx,0
neg eax
div edi
r:rdrand eax
jnc r
imul rax,rdi
cmp eax,edx
jb r
shr rax,32
mov rsi,n
mov ecx,10
l:mov edx,0
div ecx
add dl,48
dec rsi
mov[rsi],dl
cmp eax,0
jnz l
mov rax,1
mov rdi,1
mov rdx,n
sub rdx,rsi
inc rdx
syscall
cmp byte[rsi],'0'
jnz s
section .bss
resb 2     
n:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY/NjkIhDIX3fQp2bnCCP4vJfRXjAihRDOCkvRquL38tYEY2nPbQ7xTLHLJLy7ZYzuvKU74/VcCod8ZA17ZqqYfGqg2UcGldwNhfAk2EZAv25q14RRDzIymSSRLf578PRWwnLl@pm4d9pxJHXQbfV8mFNH3DeoivYBEVJn38BQy@jbSBk9xnjek/wkj@S6WBlXo3VPvOR1WJ4ofrqlFi21cW44W9TYPkljkM9MZsOpGBg5/jvagfxwwU2Km9agfKtK5v)

## How it works?

The nasm code implements [Lemire's Method](https://www.pcg-random.org/posts/bounded-rands.html) which gives a random number between 0 and 100, not including 100 itself. It ports Lemire's Method from C to nasm:

```
uint32_t bounded_rand(rng_t& rng, uint32_t range) {
    uint32_t t = (-range) % range;
    do {
        uint32_t x = rng();
        uint64_t m = uint64_t(x) * uint64_t(range);
        uint32_t l = uint32_t(m);
    } while (l < t);
    return m >> 32;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 44 bytes

```python
i=s='a'
while i:print(i:=hash(s)%100);s+='a'
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3dTJti23VE9W5yjMyc1IVMq0KijLzSjQyrWwzEoszNIo1VQ0NDDSti7VBiiB6oFphRgAA)

Note that Python's [string hash randomization](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-R) makes this produce a different sequence each time you run the program.

Answer (score 1):

## VBA <s>38</s> <s>37</s> 39 bytes

Is the exit on error allowed? I just wanted to use the division by zero error...

```
Do
a=(Rnd*99)\1
Cells(1+a)=a
a=1/a
Loop
```

#### Update:

Added two bytes `+a` to the 3rd line to avoid rewriting the previous numbers.

Comment: I am not sure that this counts as properly outputting all of the values as you are overwriting them as you go - but you can avoid this by rewriting as an immediate window function along the lines of `do:a=(rnd*99)\1:?a:loop while a` - note the use of `99` in place of `100` here - while rnd cannot output 1, it can output close enough to it that the loss of precision with multiplication allows for `(rnd*99)\1` to output `99` ( and for `(rnd*100)\1` to output `100` )

Comment: @Taylor Raine
you were correct about 99 instead 100. But your code does not work in my VBA/Excel. Do you mean `do:a=(rnd*99)\1:Debug.?a:loop while a` ?

Comment: No the debug object is not needed. If you run code in the immediate window (from excel `alt + F11` then `ctrl + g`) you do not need to include the `debug.` when executing any `print` statements - this is super helpful for making Excel VBA competitive, hope it helps

Comment: You can read more about this over on the [Tips for Golfing in VBA](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/90484/61846) page

Answer (score 1):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org), 17 bytes

```
⇌⍢(⊂⌊×100⚂|±/×)[]
```

[Try it on the pad!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_10_0-dev_1__4oeM4o2iKOKKguKMisOXMTAw4pqCfMKxL8OXKVtdCg==)

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno), \$ 11 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 9.05 bytes

```
[Z2RZwD!)ZK
```

(No ATO link since this requires v1.2.2)

##### Explanation

```python
[Z2RZwD!)ZK
[            # Forever:
    Zw       #  Get a random element of
 Z2R         #  range(100)
      D      #  Duplicate
       !)    #  Break if 0
         ZK  #  And print the number
             # The 0 is implicitly output at the end
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Go](https://go.dev), 79 bytes

```go
package main
import."math/rand"
func main(){for{n:=Intn(100)
println(n)
_=1/n}}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70oPX_BgqWlJWm6Fjf9CxKTsxPTUxVyEzPzuDJzC_KLSvSUchNLMvSLEvNSlLjSSvOSwZIamtVp-UXVeVa2nnkleRqGBgaaXAVFmXklOXkaeZpc8baG-nm1tRBjoabDbAEA)

Exits with a divide-by-zero error.

#### [Go](https://go.dev), 108 bytes, seeded

```go
package main
import(."math/rand";."time")
func main(){Seed(Now().Unix())
for{n:=Intn(100)
println(n)
_=1/n}}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70oPX_BgqWlJWm6FjdzChKTsxPTUxVyEzPzuDJzC_KLSjT0lHITSzL0ixLzUpSs9ZRKMnNTlTS50krzksHKNDSrg1NTUzT88ss1NPVC8zIrNDSB0vlF1XlWtp55JXkahgYGmlwFRZl5JTl5GnmaXPG2hvp5tbUQO6FWw5wAAA)