# Find the odd one out

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, random

## Challenge

The goal of this challenge is to generate and output a \$16 \times 32\$ (height \$\times\$ width) grid where all cells contain a decoy
character, except for a random single cell that contains the target character. The input will be a pair of ASCII (32-126) characters: ***[target,decoy]***, where ***target*** is the character to find, and ***decoy*** is the character that fills the rest of the grid. The selection of the target cell must be uniformly random from among the \$512\$ cells, ensuring that each cell has an equal chance (\$\frac{1}{512}\$) of being chosen for modification.

## Examples

The preferable output format should closely resemble these examples below as this enhances the challenge of locating the target character. However,
creative solutions are welcome and minor deviations in format (e.g., additional leading/trailing whitespace, alternative ways of representing the grid) are acceptable.

**Input**

```
[0,O]
```

**Output**

```
OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO
OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO
OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO
OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO
OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO
OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO0OOOOOOOOOOO
OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO
OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO
OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO
OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO
OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO
OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO
OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO
OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO
OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO
OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO
```

**Input**

```
[v,w]
```

**Output**

```
wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww
wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww
wvwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww
wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww
wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww
wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww
wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww
wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww
wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww
wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww
wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww
wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww
wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww
wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww
wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww
wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww
```

## [target,decoy] suggestions

```
[0,O] [1,l] [1,I] [2,Z] [5,S] [8,B] [v,u] [m,n]
[b,d] [p,q] [C,G] [E,F] [V,U] [V,Y] [s,z] [6,9]
[D,O] [&,8] [C,O] [$,S] [R,P] [8,3] [4,A] [c,o]
```

Comment: Can we reverse the input i.e. decoy followed by target?

Comment: Sure. Both `[target,decoy]` or `[decoy,target]` are fine.

Comment: I've VTCed because you need to specify the acceptable output formats.

Comment: Like Shaggy said, there seems too much wiggle room.  For example in C, is `char grid[16][32]` an acceptable output format, like `f(t,d,char g[][32])`?  Some would argue that a 2D grid layout is implicit in a 2D array, unlike in a string where newlines are needed.  Especially in languages like Python where common implementations have pretty-printing of 2D arrays.

Comment: One of your test-cases has a non-ASCII character: "¢".  The challenge part says "The input will be a pair of ASCII characters".  Perhaps that's intended as a bonus for answers that support unicode or an 8-bit character set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Uiua, <s>16</s> 15 bytes

```
↯∞_32⊏=⌊×⚂⟜⇡512
```

[Try it](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_10_0-dev_1__RiDihpAg4oav4oieXzMy4oqPPeKMisOX4pqC4p-c4oehNTEyCgriiaEmcCBGICJvWCIK)

Explained:

```
↯∞_32⊏=⌊×⚂⟜⇡512­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
             512  # ‎⁡Push 512
          ⟜⇡     # ‎⁢Push the range [0, 512) behind it
       ⌊×⚂        # ‎⁣Multiply 512 by a random float and round down
      =           # ‎⁤For each in the range, a 1 if it’s equal to this number and 0 otherwise
     ⊏            # ‎⁢⁡Index into the input with this
↯∞_32             # ‎⁢⁢Reshape this list to have 32 equal columns
```

Created with the help of [Luminespire](https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire).

### Uiua, 17 bytes

```
↯16_32⊏=0⍏[⍥⚂512]
```

[Try it online](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_10_0-dev_1__RiDihpAg4oavMTZfMzLiio89MOKNj1vijaXimoI1MTJdCgriiaEmcCBGICJvWCIK)

This was my first attempt at the problem, but I ended up saving a byte with a slightly different method.

Explained:

```
↯16_32⊏=0⍏[⍥⚂512]­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
          [⍥⚂512]  # ‎⁡512 random floats
         ⍏         # ‎⁢Indices of this sorted
       =0          # ‎⁣Is each equal to 0? (Leaves a 1 in a random position and 0 everywhere else)
      ⊏            # ‎⁤Index into the input with this
↯16_32             # ‎⁢⁡Reshape list to 16*32
```

Created with the help of [Luminespire](https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire).

Answer (score 9):

## Google Sheets, 52 bytes

```
=index(if(randbetween(1,512)=sequence(16,32),B1,A1))
```

Put the decoy in cell `A1`, the target in cell `B1`, and the formula in cell `C1`. The formula outputs in cells `C1:AH16`.

[image: odd one out.png]

In Google Sheets, array formulas take the dimensions of the argument that has the biggest dimensions. In this instance, it is the matrix produced by `sequence()`. The value given by `randbetween()` is compared with each element in the matrix in turn.

<sub>(-14 bytes thanks to [z..](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/120719/z))</sub>

Comment: -14 `=index(if(randbetween(1,512)=sequence(16,32),B1,A1))`

Comment: D'oh. Thanks @z..

Comment: If you convert this to an excel answer, you can drop the index call, and just go with `=IF(RANDBETWEEN(1,512)=SEQUENCE(16,32),A1,B1)`

Answer (score 9):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 87 bytes

```python
import random as r,textwrap as w
f=lambda t,d:w.fill("".join(r.sample(t+d*511,512)),32)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3wzNzC_KLShSKEvNS8nMVEosVinRKUitKyosSC0C8cq4025zE3KSURIUSnRSrcr20zJwcDSUlvaz8zDyNIr3ixNyCnFSNEu0ULVNDQx1TQyNNTR1jI02I8RsLijLzSjTSNJQMlHSU_JU0oeIw6wE)

Same sampling technique as @movatica, but a different approach to wrapping, using [textwrap](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html)

Comment: Nice! You can [move 'f=' out](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY3Q3MSc5NSEhVKdFKsyvXSMnNyNJSU9LLyM_M0ivSKE3MLclI1SrRTtEwNDXVMDY00NXWMjTS5MnML8otKFIoS81LycxUSixWKdEpSK0rKixILQLxyiOEbC4oy80o00jSUDJR0lPyVNDUh4gsWQGgA) for -2 bytes

Answer (score 6):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), <s>59</s> <s>46</s> 44 bytes

```r
\(x)write(sample(rep(x,c(1,511))),"",32,,"")
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMEG5eLUEr3i1NQUDRMjTa4026WlJWm6Fjd1YjQqNMuLMktSNYoTcwtyUjWKUgs0KnSSNQx1TA0NNTU1dZSUdIyNdICUJkTP2jSNZA2lCCUdJT0lTajYggUQGgA)

Takes input as a vector `c(target,decoy)`.

Answer (score 5):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 17 bytes

```
(SHaX511.b)<>32Jn
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ILNgwYKlpSVpuhYbNYI9EiNMDQ31kjRt7IyNvPIg4lDpldFK8Uo6SgZKsVABAA)

First time trying Pip!

Explanation:

`(SH...)` shuffle the following:

- `aX511` first input repeated 511 times
- `.b` append second input

`<>32` split into chunks of length 32

`Jn` join on newlines

This can be 14 bytes with the `-n` flag:

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip) `-n`, 14 bytes

```
SHaX511.b<>:32
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ILNgWbSSbp5S7IKlpSVpuhbrgj0SI0wNDfWSbOysjI0gglC5ldFK8Uo6SgZwxQA)

Same as above, but uses assignment at the end to reduce the operator precedence of `<>` and save a parenthesis. The `-n` flag joins the output list on newlines at the end of the program. We can't do anything else after the assignment trick because of how it works, so this isn't applicable to the first solution.

Answer (score 5):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-pl`, <s>47</s> 45 bytes

*Credit @DomHastings for saving 2 bytes.*

```perl
$_ x=512;substr$_,rand 512,1,<>;s/.{32}\K/
/g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18lXqHC1tTQyLq4NKm4pEglXqcoMS9FASiiY6hjY2ddrK9XbWxUG@Otz6Wf/v9/Dpfhv/yCksz8vOL/ur6megaGBv91C3IA)

Comment: Nice one! This is almost exactly the same idea I had, but you can save a couple of bytes using `-p` instead of `-n` and finishing with `s/.{32}\K/\n/g` (literal newline) too!

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), 66 bytes

Expects `(target)(decoy)`.

```javascript
(a,k=Math.random(n=512)*n)=>g=b=>n--?(n^k?a:b)+[`
`[n&31]]+g(b):''
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFLDoJADADQvceYhbTgED5xQ1I4gfEABEOHz6hga4B4/fG9N/94H7bX97Ci4xRmCsCXhW58PNONZdQPCF3zAmNBqj05qsXaBuSxNFw5TNr@1LdyLvOuSzw4rKIoDCq7rlO6qocZTGYQzN0ghj8)

Answer (score 4):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 15 bytes

Full program. Prompts for target+decoy. Requires 0-based indexing (`⎕IO←0`).

```apl
⍞[16 32⍴×?⍨512]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG@qp/@jtgkGXI862gv@P@qdF21opmBs9Kh3y@Hp9o96V5gaGsX@B8r9VwCDAi4DfwA)

`⍞[`…`]` prompt for target (index 0) + decoy (index 1) and index with the following array:

`?⍨512` random permutation of integers 0…511

`×` sign (leaves a single 0 and the rest as 1s)

`16 32⍴` **r**eshape into 16 rows and 32 columns

Comment: @LuisMendo The inputs don't include indices. I'm just pointing out that in the input (a two-element character array – "string") the target ends up having character index 0 and the decay ends up having character index 1, so later when we (multi-)index the string with a large Boolean matrix, we end up selecting each result-character from among those two input characters.

Comment: Ah, I see, thanks

Answer (score 4):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), <s>108</s> <s>105</s> <s>103</s> <s>101</s> 95 bytes

*-2 bytes thanx to CursorCoercer*
*-2 bytes thanx to vengy*

```python
from random import*
f=lambda*x,k=randrange(512):''.join('\n'[i%32:]+x[i!=k]for i in range(512))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY349OK8nMVihLzUoBUZm5BflGJFleabU5iblJKolaFTrYtSA6I01M1TA2NNK3U1fWy8jPzNNRj8tSjM1WNjaxitSuiMxVts2PT8osUMhUy8xQQyjWh1igXFGXmlWikaahHqOuo66lranKhiGipw5TCXAYA)

Target and Decoy can be given as iterable or two arguments.
Returns grid as string with an extra newline in front.

Still a little longer than the `textwrap`-approach though :)

Comment: -2 bytes by removing `k=`

Comment: How could I miss that :)

Comment: [101 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3U9OK8nMVihLzUoBUZm5BflGJFldKappCmkaJToqmVbFtcWJuQU6qRol2ipapoaGOqaGRpnV0QVFmXomGVnF0jpaxkVVstJWxUaxOcWqBrbq6Zlp-kUKOQmYeyNT0VA1DM81YiGVb0zTUI9R11PXUNbmgTC11TYgczEEA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-2) `j`, 57 [bits<sup>v2</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 7.125 bytes

```
k¶ø↳Þ℅32ẇ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2&c=1#WyJqPSIsIiIsImvCtsO44oazw57ihIUzMuG6hyIsIiIsIlwiQlwiXG5cIjhcIiJd)

Bitstring:

```
100000101110010111110010011011011010000100001111110101001
```

Comment: I thought I was cool until I realized my idea was literally exactly this lol

Comment: i mean it just pads the second input to length 512 using the first one and shuffles and splits, really is the most straightforward way of doing it

Answer (score 3):

## APL+WIN, 20 bytes

Prompts for decoy followed by target.

```
16 32⍴(?512)⌽⎕,511⍴⎕
```

[Try it online! Thanks to Dyalog Classic](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob6qvz6O2CcZcQJanP5BlyPWooz3tv6GZgrHRo94tGvamhkaaj3r2AuV1TA0NgUJA1n@gGq7/6gFF@flpCkCUnJ@XnFpQoqjOlcalrqvOpV4BxApAHJyfm1qSkZmXrpCbX5SqkJyRmJOTmpcOFFCEqACq9weyHvWuUQcA)

Comment: This one was tricky to find the odd one out. ;)

Comment: @vengy That is surprising as I am using '-' as the decoy and 'x' as the target on the TIO example

Comment: I know, it's so obvious, that's the joke. ;)

Comment: `⍞[16 32⍴×512?512]` should work in APL+Win if I understand right.

Comment: @Adám Thanks indeed it does. I will leave my answer as is so as not to become simply a clone of yours.. Also it does show an alternative to your indexing approach.

Answer (score 3):

## [Knight](https://github.com/knight-lang/knight-lang) (v2), 51 bytes

```
;=r+%R512=a!=p*P32W>17=a+1aO Sp%r 16T I?a+1/r 32P[p
```

Input the `decoy` in the first line and the `target` in the second line.

[Try it online!](https://knight-lang.netlify.app/#WyI7PXIrJVI1MTI9YSE9cCpQMzJXPjE3PWErMWFPIFNwJXIgMTZUIEk/YSsxL3IgMzJQW3AiLCIwXG5PIiwiMi4wIl0=)

I think there are way too many spaces in this code, but this is what I got for now.

Comment: I clicked the Minify button and it reduced a space from `%R 512` to `%R512`.

Comment: @vengy ah yep ofc, brainfart moment. I thought `R` was a variable name instead of a function so I thought I needed a space between `R` and `512`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org) <sup>[SBCS](http://tinyurl.com/Uiua-SBCS-Feb-17)</sup>, <s>16</s> 15 bytes

```
↯∞_32deal⚂⊂↯511
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_10_0-dev_1__ZiDihpAg4oav4oieXzMyZGVhbOKaguKKguKGrzUxMQoKZiBAIyBALgo=)

-1 byte thanks to noodle man!

Note that `deal` was deprecated after I submitted this answer. It still works for now, but won't in the future. I'll leave this here for posterity.

```
↯∞_32deal⚂⊂↯511
           ↯511  # create an array of 511 decoy characters
          ⊂      # prepend target character
     deal⚂       # shuffle
↯∞_32            # reshape to 16x32
```

Comment: `↯16_32⊏=⌊×⚂⟜⇡512` also works for equal bytes and takes input as a string.

Comment: Note deal was removed after this was made. Also, you can save a byte by changing 16 to infinity, as in my solution.

Comment: @noodleman Good thinking, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

## [Rattle](https://github.com/DRH001/Rattle), 39 bytes

```
|!Ig0[s>]512P1=?512+$>^~sP2[[b~>]32B]16
```

[Try it Online!](https://www.drh001.com/rattle/?flags=&code=%7C!Ig0%5Bs%3E%5D512P1%3D%3F512%2B%24%3E%5E%7EsP2%5B%5Bb%7E%3E%5D32B%5D16&inputs=%5B%27.%27%2C%27X%27%5D)

Takes input as [decoy, target] e.g. `['.','X']`. This would also work for `.X`

## Explanation

```
|                                         take input
 !                                        disable implicit output
  I                                       save decoy, target to memory slots 0,1
   g0                                     get value in slot 0 (decoy)
     [  ]512                              loop 512 times
      s                                   save decoy to memory at the pointer (starting at 2)
       >                                  shift pointer right
            P1                            set pointer to 1
              =?512                       set top of stack to a random value 0-511
                   +                      increment (random 1-512)
                    $                     swap target value with random value in memory
                     >^~                  move pointer right by the value in memory (random value)
                         s                save target value to its random slot
                          P2              set pointer to 2
                            [........]16  loop 16 times
                             [...]32      loop 32 times
                              b~          add the value in memory to the print buffer
                                >         move pointer right
                                    B     print and clear buffer
```

Basically, this generates a 512-character string of the decoy character, makes one of these characters the target character, then outputs as a 16x32 array.

This code is relatively slow. This is due to Rattle's expanding data tape - the data tape is set to a width of 100 slots by default but will automatically expand as needed (which I apparently need to optimize more because it slows execution down here).

Answer (score 3):

## K(ngn/k) <strike>20</strike> <strike>19</strike> 16 bytes:

Input comes in as `[decoy,target]`.

```
{x@&/:/(*1?=)'32 16}
{16 32#x@~-512?512}
```

-3 bytes thanks to @ngn.

```
{16 32#x@~<?512}
```

[try it online](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJyrrnBQ07fS19AytLfVVDc2UjA0q3VQ8tdT4qo2NFMwNlKucKjTNTU0sgdiDAkbhCgAZD4Q6g==)

Comment: i have an idea for a shorter solution. there's an overload of monadic `?` that generates n random floats - `?n`. it can be used together with "grade" to mask a random item: `~<?512` (there's a negligible theoretical bias to lower indices but it's ok for golfing). then that can be reshaped and indexed into `x`.

Comment: I tried the link but got a 404 error. Is there a way to switch to [https://tio.run/#k-ngn](https://tio.run/#k-ngn) instead? Thanks.

Comment: @vengy can you access https://codeberg.page/ at all? the [status](https://status.codeberg.org/) looks ok right now. tio uses an ancient version and cant be updated, unfortunately.

Comment: Works now... although the period in the output is always in the same position? ("OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO"
 "OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO"
 "OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO.OOOOO"...)

Comment: @vengy the prng's default seed is fixed. this sets it to the current time: `prng@0

Comment: @vengy It seems the version of ngn/k on tio.run is a bit old. For example, the overload of monadic `?` mentioned by @ngn [is not supported](https://tio.run/##DcjbDYAgEATAVrYBI1RgLRIuQJQl4WX5583nPAcTVS/vYM6Zy8DIbb0RqWyBfb8ZWwVXDdIRZH4ihIM1vOoP).

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>42</s> 41 bytes

```ruby
->a,b{[b,*[a]*511].shuffle.each_slice 32}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsGiNNulpSVpuhY3NXXtEnWSqqOTdLSiE2O1TA0NY_WKM0rT0nJS9VITkzPii3Myk1MVjI1qoRoU0qKVDJR0lAyVYsEKFKoVCkpLihXiDfWy8jPzFKDqFiwx5DLggrAB)

Outputs an `Enumerator` of lines. Jordan had the nice idea to use `*` to combine the lists instead of `+`, which saved a byte.

Comment: @Jordan Thanks! I'm still so bad at Ruby :) I liked your idea too. I had thought of doing `.scan /.{32}/` but it was so much longer with `.shuffle`

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>43</s> 42 bytes

A byte longer than [noodle man’s Ruby solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/271461/11261) but I liked it anyway.

```ruby
->a,b{a*=512
a[rand 512]=b
a.scan /.{32}/}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsEiN9ulpSVpuhY3tXTtEnWSqhO1bE0NjbgSo4sS81IUgMxY2ySuRL3i5MQ8BX29amOjWv1aiI71BaUlxQpu0UoGSjpKhkqxENEFCyA0AA)

Comment: TIL strings are mutable in Ruby

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 11 bytes

```
žA<×«.ržwô»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASAA3/9vc2FiaWX//8W@QTzDl8KrLnLFvnfDtMK7//9PCjD//w)

How?

```
žA<×«.ržwô»             
   ×                    String of first input
žA<                        of length 511
    «                   Append second input
     .r                 Shuffle
       žwô              Split into chuncks of 32
          »             Join by new lines
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 29 bytes

```
^"/./@_`$0"~L$0`.
16*$(32*$0¶
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/P05JX0/fIT5BxUCpzkfFIEGPy9BMS0XD2EhLxeDQtv///bkMAA)

A nice single eval stage (that hides several stages inside). Takes as input the decoy character followed by the target character, with a newline separating them.

#### Explanation

```
^"/./@_`$0"~[...]
```

This is an eval (`~`) stage, that builds a Retina program as a string and runs it against the input. Normally the following stage would build the program, and the input of this stage would be used as input to that program as well. We are changing this behaviour in two ways:

- `^` swaps the input and the program, so the following stage will generate the new input instead
- `` "/./@_`$0" `` is a string option that will be applied as a substitution to the input to generate the new program

All this means that when we have an input of `O\n0`, we will apply the string substitution to generate the program `` "/./@_`O\n0" ``.

This is a Replace stage `O\n0` that can replace `O`s with `0`s. This stage is applied to a random character thanks to the match mask `_`, with the option `@` selecting a single random match of the regex `.` (any non-newline character).

So we have a program replacing one random decoy character with our target character, all that's left is generating a 16*32 rectangle of decoy characters:

```
L$0`.
16*$(32*$0¶
```

This `L`ists the character (`.`) in position `0` (first character of the input, that's the decoy character), and `$`ubstitutes it with `16*$(32*$0¶`, which means `16 times ((32 times that character) plus a newline)`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), <s>24</s> 21 bytes

```
^.
511*$&
V?`
L`.{32}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/P06Py9TQUEtFjSvMPoHLJ0Gv2tio9v9/fwMA) Takes input as a pair of characters `<decoy><target>`. Explanation:

```
^.
511*$&
```

Make `511` copies of the decoy.

```
V?`
```

Shuffle the characters randomly.

```
L`.{32}
```

Split into rows of `32`.

Edit: Saved 3 bytes thanks to @Leo.

Comment: That's a much better idea than mine! You can save some bytes in your shuffling line by using `?` [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/P06Py9TQUEtFjSvMPoHLJ0Gv2tio9v9/fwMA "Retina – Try It Online")

Comment: @Leo I thought I was being so clever...

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 10 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage/wiki/Code-page)

```
x511;Ẋs32Y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/7/C1NDQ@uGurmJjo8j////H/3cAAA)

I'm revisiting this language after several years and I kinda want to write a tool that translates something like `(Y (s (Ẋ (; (x λ 511) ρ)) 32))` into the above.

### 12 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage/wiki/Code-page)

```
2*511BẊṃs32Y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/99Iy9TQ0Onhrq6HO5uLjY0i////7xAPAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 11 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
•r_wm=§y♥/n
```

Inputs as a pair \$[fillterChar,randomChar]\$.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7//9Rw6Ki@PJc20PLKx/NXKqf9/9/tJK/ko6SgVIsV7RSOZBVBmbFA1kVSrEA)

**Explanation:**

```python
•r          # Push a list in the range [0,512)
  _         # Duplicate this list
   w        # Pop and push a random item from this list
    m       # Map over the list with this random item as argument
     =      #  Check which item equals this argument
            # (we now have a list of 511 0s and a random 1)
      §     # (0-based) index those into the (implicit) input-pair characters
       y    # Join this list of characters to a string
        ♥/  # Split it into parts of size 32
          n # Join by newlines
            # (after which the entire stack is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Go](https://golang.org/) (1.19+), <s>138</s>137 bytes

```go
import."math/rand"
type S=string
func f(a S,b S){p:=Intn(512)
for i:=0;i<512;i++{if i==p{print(b)}else{print(a)}
if i%32==31{println()}}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY5BDsIgFET3nIKQmPBjo7aNm1YO4MpFT0Ar1B9bIBQXhnB2bNXlm8nLzGizk8NTjorOEk3G2VkfDmyW4XH00twZCW@naCeW4NGMRL/MQDWXtCt62kF0jbiaYPi5rIBo6yk24tTiZeUW9/uImqIQLrrVDryHpKZF/UlCIlu/qysh6vKXToZDSil/h7ZPHKLmzLKC3Rik/AE)

Note: On the Tio platform you will get the same output each time. This is because it is using an older version of Go that do not auto seed the RNG which was [introduced](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/443058) in 2022. See the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/ry3FiONcx15) for a working (but force-ungolfed) example.

Comment: I'm getting the same output when run each time. Perhaps your code needs to seed the random number generator such as this [example](https://tio.run/##NY7LCsIwEEX3@YoQEGZQfOKmNR/gRhfFD4ia1MF2EmpEpeTba@tjec6Fe2/pu2BOV1NaWRvijurgmzhVtYmXWWP4rMRfRaqtEvEVrCz0LTbEpXB3PkkHRhaToyywLaw9w84/AKcHpufOsAdEETK95ciwXixRON9IyvQ8p03POY3HLTlJWoc29KURjphsdbM/MpjEkI9WS61Xi6@tGDCl1H32h@OArQPl1UTtFabuDQ). Thanks!

Comment: I noticed that too! It shows different number on my machine and AFAIK go by default seeds the RNG differently every time. I think it is an issue of the Tio runtime.

Comment: I've never coded in GO, but `p:=Intn(512)` is always outputting `33` as seen in this [example](https://tio.run/##NY5LCsIwGIT3OcVPoJBgUdvipjUHcKXQE6SP1GDzII0LCTl7bH0s55sPZiaTLO8ffBpBcamTVNY4v8eK@/vBcT1g9EdCeYz8y47QssU7qScknroHQTi0eQctDbZmF@01ORUlRbdV8YJgCwyyAedgKRLGgazZsZHn1WnkbhekAMmYDXbTSUfjOC/jL3Ea0dZnVclYVXzprAmNMabP@Haa0LDOGJzjK6YxvQE)

Comment: If you run it on the official [Go playground](https://go.dev/play/p/ry3FiONcx15) you should get different numbers. I should have addressed this in the answer. I delved a bit more into this it seems Go set the random seed automatically since [this](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/443058), maybe tio is running an older version of Go. I will update my answer to explain this

Comment: The TIO Go version is [go1.11.13](https://tio.run/##S8//X5CYnJ2YnqqQm5iZ9z8ztyC/qERPKS23RIkLxikqzSvJzE1V4korzUsGq9PQrA4oyswrycnTUHLPVyhLLSrOzM@zUtJRCIMwNTQ1a///BwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
⁹ḤṬẊịs32Y
```

A monadic Link that accepts a pair of characters, `[Target, Decoy]`, and yields a list of characters.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AR8A4P9qZWxsef//4oG54bik4bms4bqK4buLczMyWf///1gu)**

#### How?

```
⁹ḤṬẊịs32Y - Link: pair of characters, TD
⁹         - 256
 Ḥ        - double -> 512
  Ṭ       - untruth -> [0,0,...,0,1] (511 zeros, 1 one)
   Ẋ      - shuffle
    ị     - index into {TD} (1:T; 0:D)
     s32  - split into chunks of length 32
        Y - join with newline characters
```

Answer (score 2):

## Swift 5.9, <s>138</s> <s>130</s> 105 bytes

```swift
let h={let s=([$0+""]+{[_].init}()($1,511)).shuffled()
(0...15).map{print(s[$0*32..<$0*32+32].joined())}}
```

The first argument to `h(_:_:)` is the "decoy", and the second is the "target".

> Try It Online doesn't support a modern enough version of Swift, and Attempt This Online doesn't support Swift at all as of yet. So, here's a link to [something entirely different](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/YgB) (JDoodle) that'll still get the job done.

Whitespace restored:

```swift
let h = {
  let s = ([$0 + ""] + { [_].init }()($1, 511)).shuffled()
  (0...15).map {
    print(s[($0 * 32)..<($0 * 32 + 32)].joined())
  }
}
```

I'll run through this step-by-step.

```swift
let h = { /* ... */ }
```

Function signatures in Swift are long. So I decided to assign a closure to a variable instead. I was able to infer the types of both arguments and the return value (which is just `()` anyway, this saved one byte).

```swift
let s = ([$0 + ""] + { [_].init }()($1, 511)).shuffled()
```

There's a lot to swallow here, so I'll go inside out.

- `[_].init` is inferred as `[String].init`; this saves two bytes over `Array.init`.
- We toss the initializer in a closure and immediately call it, giving us the same initializer, but with one important difference: *all argument labels are removed*. This is especially handy for the bulky `.init(repeating:count:)` initializer.
- We then call this new label-less initializer with two arguments:

  - the value to repeat (the "target" value, referred to as `$1` thanks to implicit parameters)
  - the number of times to repeat it (512 - 1)
- We prepend (or append, it doesn't matter) an array literal containing one value -- the "decoy". This gives us a 512-element array, containing 511 "targets" and 1 "decoy".

  > Notice the trick here with `$0 + ""` -- appending an empty string gives the type checker a hint that the type of `$0` is `String`, which, combined with other inferences, allows us to drop type signatures entirely.
- Finally, we call the `shuffled()` method on this mess, giving us an identical array, except that the "decoy" is now somewhere else. (I'm trusting that Swift's `SystemRandomNumberGenerator` is good enough for this challenge.)

```swift
(0...15).map { /* ... */ }
```

We create a `ClosedRange` from `0` to `15` and iterate over it. `map` is four bytes shorter than `forEach`, and it behaves identically, with the exception that it'll generate a warning if you don't use the return value (which doesn't exist here anyway).

```swift
print(s[($0 * 32)..<($0 * 32 + 32)].joined())
```

What this basically does is iterate over `s` in 32-element chunks. For some reason, Swift still doesn't have some sort of `chunk(into:)` method in the standard library, and implementing one would be overkill for this challenge, so I'm just doing a bit of math instead.

We join the chunks into strings and print them. By default, Swift's `print(_:separator:terminator:)` function prints a trailing newline, which is exactly what we want here.

Answer (score 2):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), <strike>76</strike> 71 bytes

```
srand(){for(r=int(rand()*512);i<512;++i%32?b:a=a"\n")a=r-i?a$2:a$1}$0=a
```

- -5 bytes, thanks to [cnamejj](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/99540/cnamejj)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v@/uCgxL0VDszotv0ijyDYzr0QDIqBlamikaZ1pA6SstbUzVY2N7JOsEm0TlWLylDQTbYt0M@0TVYysElUMa1UMbBP///dX0AMA)

Comment: This is a little bit shorter, but still uses the same algorithm ```srand(){for(r=int(rand()*512);i<512;++i%32?b:a=a"\n")a=r-i?a$2:a$1}$0=a```

Answer (score 2):

## [Scala 3](https://www.scala-lang.org/), 85 bytes

A port of [@Nicola Sap's Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/271414/110802) in Scala.

---

Golfed version. [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=RY7BagIxFEX38xWPrF6shlopyICCH1AExZV1EU0yTptJbOZNSxH_Q3BjF-2mX-TfGA2tq_vO5d7LO_zUK2ll73fOOs5_yODY4rT3yxe9IniSpYNtBqC0gSoCylDUOYxCkJ_zKYXSFQuew8yVBINrEuBdWrgQu2f_rC48TryJLbIODVIbFOfR3GVZloImB8Q03IakfDD8O-C7IdPpn2axqqJ_fV00VFoxkU75StTrxhirEelOtR67XS7IT_UbF9VrGhFF8M1GK-w93Exkz47xNP61S3o8Jj0D)

```scala
(t,d)=>scala.util.Random.shuffle((t+d*511).toSeq).mkString.grouped(32).mkString("\n")
```

Ungolfed version. [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bZO_TsMwEMYlxj7FqVMCJaVUSKgSA2JCAiFRmAAprnNp3CZ26lxaKtQnYekCD8V7sGPnb1uxRD7fd9_97Is_vzPOYjbcbr9yCk8vf45-1WSGnOCeCQkfHYAAQ0hM4DA9zUZwrTVbv4xJCzl9c0fwLAXBVaEEWLIYbNQ96zZxYOOHMk5NFcXSCR3qQeC6ZnPTqXqYvRGUviZXL9160fTo9-FGIyMEBrEyiazMT9bAleQmIRnZDZ98WAmKwA980JjamgAuBgMgkWDWAFqTpgfBiSE-trJC0LRUcomagCKsG5IyBBkucpQcQYXAI6YZJ9RZD7IoD8MYQZiDMhlYtKJ-wvjcVpYeDUMlDxqOYixeTiL2Hk29SrxK4rS4HqkxLlwvmY9btxp4nMaiwq28a24zAgWxkJhZ6OH5Djcg41HBO1Nm_KY6Ka9Q4spW7EiLPivN0id8J2efv2dc92bb6Mh82ilbyzuUU4pGcCvp31m357C1B_B-6-Afslm5N9UqTzFwWl17XU73VXZLzE3591ePoH4Mfw)

```scala
object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val t = "0"
    val d = "O"
    println(f(t, d))
  }

  def f(t: String, d: String): String = {
    // Create a long string by concatenating `t` with `d` repeated 511 times
    val longString = t + d * 511
    
    // Convert the string to a sequence of characters, shuffle it, and convert back to string
    val shuffledString = scala.util.Random.shuffle(longString.toSeq).mkString
    
    // Split the shuffled string into lines of 32 characters each and join them with newline characters
    wrapText(shuffledString, 32)
  }

  def wrapText(text: String, lineLength: Int): String = {
    // Split the text into lines of `lineLength` characters
    text.grouped(lineLength).mkString("\n")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## VBA Excel, <s>43</s> 54 bytes

```
[b1:ag16]=[a1]:cells(int(rnd*16+1),int(rnd*32+2))=[a2]
```

- Input the values `target` and `decoy` into the cells A1:A2
- Run the code in immediate window

[image]

Comment: Just curious, does your random method (pick a random row, then a random cell within that row) agree with each cell having a \$\frac{1}{512}\$ chance of being chosen? Probability was never a strong point. Thanks.

Comment: Looks like it's okay: P(specific cell) = P(row) \$\times\$ P(cell in row) \$ = \frac{1}{16} \times \frac{1}{32} = \frac{1}{512}\$

Comment: @vengy It is a very good point. I have just run 100000 cycles and I have found out that the columns B and Q and rows 1 and 16 are populated about 4 times less frequently when I use the formula `cells(rnd*31+1,rnd*15+2)`. I will optimize the code. Thanks for paying attention.

Answer (score 2):

## [Easyfuck](https://github.com/Quadruplay/easyfuck/wiki), <s>50</s> <s>49</s> <s>48</s> <s>47</s> 43 bytes

```
Â¡ã$SPAÖ¼\úëå8CCH>|ÅókVTSÞ[[NELòçEPAT¬|³␓ô¿U¼~MW[èòEPA␀ÿ
```

<sup>due to lack of unicode representations for c1 control characters, they have been replaced by their superscripted abbreviations</sup>

Decompressed:

```
a(<2$[-<.>]>)b(>>1>6\+<[-a>.<]),>,b?%}+<?%+>GJ.
```

Explanation:

`a(          )b(                )`                 declares functions a and b

`,>,b`             takes input into 1st and 2nd cell, then executes b

`>>1>6\+<`                          sets cell 3 to 16 and cell 4 to 10

`[-a>.<]`                  16 times executes a and prints a new line

`<2$[-<.>]>`                                     prints second input 32 times

`?%}+<?%+>`    sets cells 3 and 4 to random numbers in the correct range

`GJ.` moves the cursor and prints first input

This one is shorter but may be breaking the rules as it generates the rectangle, moves the cursor to a random spot on it, and from there asks for input, immediately outputting it.

```
a(<2$[-<.>]>)b(>>1>6\+<[-a>.<]),b?%}+<?%+>G,.
```

I'd greatly appreciate it if OP could discern the illegalness of the second solution.

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <del>73</del> <del>70</del> 69 bytes

*-3 bytes, thanks to Arnauld*
*-1 byte, thanks to ceilingcat*

```c
r,i;f(t,d){for(i=512,r=rand()%i;i--;i&31?:puts(""))putchar(i-r?d:t);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYxBCsIwEEXvUrSZgQy0ipuG0iN04QlCYuqArTKJuChe3ZgK7j6P/56jybmcRbMJkLTHNdwFuD@1By292MUD7tkwkeH62A7d45kiVBViGe5qy5dk8F1C886z5QVwjT8t8XyBBrF01VlptVNo/vLGxsIatWkfF252ipleXw)

**Note** To possibly increase performance (why not?) and keep the same number of bytes, I've replaced \$i\%32\$ (modulus operation) with \$i\&31\$ (bitwise AND operation) since when the divisor is a power of 2, these are equivalent

$$i\%2^n \quad \equiv \quad i\&(2^n - 1)$$

for any positive integer \$n\$.

Comment: [Your function is not reusable](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4940/58563). [Here](https://tio.run/##NctBCsIwEIXhuxRLZmACteKmQ@kRXHiCkJg6YKskERfFqzdNBbffe7/Vo7U5BxL2kMjh4p8BpD8fWwp9MLMDrIVFa369k72bMuowuC4hSX1qh65whKpC5G@ejMyAS/x1SaYbNMU9qKsidVDI//Nul2KN2rPV@ocZY9afDQ) is a fixed, shorter version.

Comment: Nice! Thanks for those tips and code changes. Although it would be nice to somehow remove the `puts("")` and just have the `putchar()` handle all the output characters. But, it   
probably would make the code longer not shorter.

Comment: [This works](https://tio.run/##HczRCsIgFMbxdxkNzwmlTRnEZOwRuugJRHMdaCvU6GL06tnc7e/j/1kxWZtz4KQ9JO5w9c8ANHTyzMMQzOIA666VmoTQr3eyd7PNtVIjHZU8KSXC6PrUtw2i/ubZ0AK4xj1MNN@guAd2ZZwdGJaLCFW122WzhpXsZ/3DTDGLzx8) but is one byte longer.

Comment: Thanks for the single `putchar()` solution too!

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 15 bytes

```
ＵＯ³²⊗⁸ＳＪ‽³²‽¹⁶Ｓ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/98/KSc/L13D2EhHwSW/NCknNUXDQlNHwTOvoLQkuKQoEyinqWnN5VWaWxCSrxGUmJeSnwtUDVQCZRuageQDgCpLNNB0AU3nMvivW5YDAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes the decoy as the first input and the target as the second input. Explanation:

```
ＵＯ³²⊗⁸Ｓ
```

Fill a `32×16` oblong grid with the first input.

```
Ｊ‽³²‽¹⁶
```

Jump to a random cell.

```
Ｓ
```

Overwrite it with the second input.

Answer (score 1):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org/), 110 bytes

#### Header

```lua
-- Get inputs
t,d=io.read(),io.read()

-- Randomise seed
math.randomseed(os.time())
```

#### Main code

```lua
g={}for i=1,512 do g[i]=d end g[math.random(1,512)]=t for j=1,#g do io.write(j%32==0 and g[j].."\n"or g[j])end
```

Input is on separate lines, first the target, then the decoy.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY0xD8IgEIV3fsWlxgQSSmyNI7O7q3Yg4azXWGiAxsH42xE6GLf3Lt/37rma3LZwxgTkljVFlqTV5FVAY7mQv8RYwS7GWT9TRIiIls0mPVTYbrVzH1WiGbkQedTvz90HIN3JU9eD9TBeadAW0NkS/1S@EWLQCaoxFWM3VqH8fgVKyKf9sdf6AGZTp0Gp5uaawtYiymDOiskv)

---

### Explanation

In the header, we get the inputs `t` (target) and `d` (decoy). We set the seed of `math.random` so that `math.random` can be randomised every run.

In the main code, we create a grid and populate it with decoys:

```lua
g = {}
for i=1,512 do
    do g[i]=d
end
```

After that, we set a random cell to the target, `t`.

```lua
g[math.random(1,512)] = t
```

And then we print the grid. At the end of a row, we add a new line.

```lua
for j=1,#g do
   io.write(j%32 == 0 and g[j] .. "\n" or g[j])
end
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Windows Batch Scripting](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Windows_Batch_Scripting), 183 bytes

```
@echo off&setlocal enabledelayedexpansion&set/ar=%random%%%512
for /l %%i in (0,1,511)do (if %%i==%r% (set c=%1)else set c=%2
set a=!a!!c!&set/ae=%%i%%32&if !e!==31 echo !a!&set a=)
```

[image: odd]

Answer (score 1):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 22 bytes

```
~511*+{;9.?rand}$32/n*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/v87U0FBLu9raUs@@KDEvpVbF2Eg/T@v/fyUDJQWlfCUA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Assembly (nasm, x64, Linux)](http://www.nasm.us/), 158 bytes

```
660fc7f56681e5ff0141b810000000b92000000049b90000000000000000
b0586639dd7402b02e41880149ffc166ffc3e2ec66b8010066bf010048be
000000000000000066ba21000f0549ffc875c0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY7NCsIwEITv@xR78xKLtShWX0QQD9skSEr@TKK0vnxNk55m@JhhhmKUZtDz3lI0S0L5/uDuvkO8YaLwkglEZU1hQnI3L0EEsgIHD1XYqW3BuC@GC2vP4K/F84l1x4p7RhAKJc0ScOPX1jDBKJHDxgXwNfII/ZORBmV5LhbJQe2cx1CjE6trQm0mRJUHCsqbHcQ5ctIa8tt8CUb7Qw9R8qScxUZQIiBMysiIXYdiwPawLH8)

**Source**

```
rdrand bp
and bp,511
mov r8,16
p:mov rcx,32
mov r9,a
r:mov al,t
cmp bp,bx
je c
mov al,d
c:mov[r9],al
inc r9
inc bx
loop r
mov ax,1
mov di,1
mov rsi,a
mov dx,33
syscall
dec r8
jnz p
section .data
a times 33 db 10
```

Answer (score 1):

## [J](https://www.jsoftware.com/indexno.html), <s>26</s> 25 bytes

```
{{x(<(?16),?32)}16 32$y}}
```

Left argument is the target, right argument is the decoy.

this probably could be optimized, I'm new to J and array programming in general.

This uses a J direct definition because otherwise the random numbers would only be generated once on assignment and never again.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY3NCoJAFEb3PcW3CK6CRFq4kEJo1yY3vYA0V5youeJc@0F89mlo8y3OgfPdQ@hwrLBHBfokh6TOyzSrd0W65CV2xfpLuJw20J5xPTewTnkcRo4L6yEPg9YZGGHvSOGnYZBRMc9/vCwZvODN6NsXQwWT52jwjHcOhjvrrFpxseuVW7PiWy9IaEvoQA2lIfwA)

Comment: Could you add a [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/v7q6QsNGw97QTFPH3thIs9bQTMHYSKWytvb/fz0FLQA) example? Thanks.

Comment: @vengy done (altho the code there is a bit different since it looks like the TIO interpreter doesn't support `{{` and `}}`)

Answer (score 1):

## Qbasic, 106 bytes

```
SUB F(a$,b$):FOR i=1TO 16:FOR j=1TO 32:?a$;:NEXT:PRINT:NEXT:LOCATE INT(RND*16+1),INT(RND*32+1):?b$:END SUB
```

`F "O", "0"`

##### Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## [YASEPL](https://github.com/madeforlosers/YASEPL-esolang), 61 bytes

```
=u=t'=d'=r¢0,512=i$`1!)d!i}7,r,3!)t`3!~$i%32+[2>""`2!i+}2,513
```

takes in 2 inputs. first one is the target, second one is the decoy.