# Verify Wolstenholme's theorem

Tags: code-golf, number-theory, combinatorics

## Definition

[Wolstenholme's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolstenholme%27s_theorem) states that:

[image: Wolstenholme's theorem]

where  `a` and `b` are positive integers and `p` is prime, and the big parentheses thingy is [Binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient).

## Task

To verify that, you will be given three inputs: `a`, `b`, `p`, where `a` and `b` are positive integers and `p` is prime.

Compute:

[image: Verification of Wolstenholme's theorem]

where  `a` and `b` are positive integers and `p` is prime, and the parentheses thingy is [Binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient).

## Specs

Since:

[image: combinatorics]

where and the parentheses thingy is [Binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient).

You can assume that `2b <= a`

## Testcases

```
a b p  output
6 2 5  240360
3 1 13 3697053
7 3 13 37403621741662802118325
```

Comment: I feel like outputs should have a `.0` on the end, to *really* show that there's no leftover.from the division.

Comment: @El'endiaStarman Come on.

Comment: Would `[240360]` (singleton array) be an acceptable output format?

Comment: @Dennis Where's the meta for this?

Comment: I don't think there is one, which is why I'm asking.

Comment: @Dennis Then make one.

Comment: @LuisMendo clarificado

Comment: @LeakyNun Gracias :-) Can we compute the negative of that fraction? It's equally valid to test if it's zero

Comment: @LuisMendo Eh, I'd say no.

Comment: Not a bad idea, but it wouldn't reapply retroactively to your challenge anyway, so you'd still have to make the call.

Comment: @Dennis If meta approves singleton array I'll let you retroactively do it.

Comment: What does "verify" mean? If you compute the ratio (binom - binom)/p^3 using integer division, the answer will always be a whole number, so you've verified nothing.

Answer (score 5):

## Haskell, <s>73</s> 71 bytes

Due to the recursion, this implementation is very slow. Unfortunately my definition of the binomial coefficient has the same length as `import Math.Combinatorics.Exact.Binomial`.

```
n#k|k<1||k>=n=1|1>0=(n-1)#(k-1)+(n-1)#k --binomial coefficient
f a b p=div((a*p)#(b*p)-a#b)p^3       --given formula
```

An interesting oddity is that Haskell 98 did allow for *arithmetic patterns* which would have shortened the same code to 64 bytes:

```
g a b p=div((a*p)#(b*p)-a#b)p^3
n+1#k|k<1||k>n=1|1>0=n#(k-1)+n#k
```

Comment: Shouldn't the Haskell 98 version still be a valid submission?

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>12</s> <s>11</s> 10 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ż×c/I÷S÷²}
```

Expects `a, b` and `p` as command-line arguments.

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=xbzDl2MvScO3U8O3wrJ9&input=&args=NiwgMg+NQ) or [verify all test cases](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=xbzDl2MvScO3U8O3wrJ9CsOnIg&input=&args=WzYsIDJdLCBbMywgMV0sIFs3LCAzXQ+NSwgMTMsIDEz).

#### How it works

```
ż×c/I÷S÷²}  Main link. Left argument: a, b. Right argument: p

 ×          Multiply; yield [pa, pb].
ż           Zipwith; yield [[a, pa], [b, pb]].
  c/        Reduce columns by combinations, yielding [aCb, (pa)C(pb)].
    I       Increments; yield [(pa)C(pb) - aCb].
     ÷      Divide; yield [((pa)C(pb) - aCb) ÷ p].
      S     Sum; yield ((pa)C(pb) - aCb) ÷ p.
        ²}  Square right; yield p².
       ÷    Divide; yield  ((pa)C(pb) - aCb) ÷ p³.
```

Answer (score 4):

## Python 2, <s>114</s> <s>109</s> <s>85</s> 71 bytes

A simple implementation. Golfing suggestions welcome.

**Edit:** -29 bytes thanks to Leaky Nun and -14 bytes thanks to Dennis.

```python
lambda a,b,p,f=lambda n,m:m<1or f(n-1,m-1)*n/m:(f(a*p,b*p)-f(a,b))/p**3
```

A simpler, same-length alternative, with thanks to Dennis, is

```python
f=lambda n,m:m<1or f(n-1,m-1)*n/m
lambda a,b,p:(f(a*p,b*p)-f(a,b))/p**3
```

Comment: [Here](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/3133/43214) is a golfed factorial lambda

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 11 bytes

Takes input as:

```
[a, b]
p
```

Code:

```
*`c¹`c-²3m÷
```

Uses the **CP-1252** encoding. [Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=KmBjwrlgYy3CsjNtw7c&input=WzYsIDJdCjU).

Comment: Did you out-golf Dennis?

Comment: If I were in Dennis' shoes I think I'd get a little tired of all these "outgolf Dennis" comments...

Comment: @LuisMendo I may or may not be nuking them on a regular basis.

Comment: and hes at 10. it was fun while it lasted boys

Answer (score 3):

## R, <s>50</s> 48 bytes

```
function(a,b,p)(choose(a*p,b*p)-choose(a,b))/p^3
```

As straightforward as can be... 
Thanks to @Neil for saving 2 bytes.

Comment: How many of those spaces are necessary?

Comment: 42 bytes by renaming `choose` and by using `pryr::f` to define the function: `B=choose;pryr::f((B(a*p,b*p)-B(a,b))/p^3)`.

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 13 bytes

```
y*hZ}Xnd2G3^/
```

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=eSpoWn1YbmQyRzNeLw&input=WzY7Ml0KNQ)

The last test case doesn't produce an exact integer due to numerical precision. MATL's default data type (`double`) can only handle exact integers up to `2^53`.

#### Explanation

```
y   % Implicitly input [a; b] (col vector) and p (number). Push another copy of [a; b]
    %   Stack: [a; b], p, [a; b]
*   % Multiply the top two elements from the stack
    %   Stack: [a; b], [a*p; b*p]
h   % Concatenate horizontally
    %   Stack: [a, a*p; b, b*p]
Z}  % Split along first dimension
    %   Stack: [a, a*p], [b, b*p]
Xn  % Vectorize nchoosek
    %   Stack: [nchoosek(a,b), nchoosek(a*p,b*p)]
d   % Consecutive differences of array
    %   Stack: nchoosek(a,b)-nchoosek(a*p,b*p)
2G  % Push second input again
    %   Stack: nchoosek(a,b)-nchoosek(a*p,b*p), p
3^  % Raise to third power
    %   Stack: nchoosek(a,b)-nchoosek(a*p,b*p), p^3
/   % Divide top two elements from the stack
    %   Stack: (nchoosek(a,b)-nchoosek(a*p,b*p))/p^3
    % Implicitly display
```

Answer (score 2):

## J, 17 bytes

```
(!/@:*-!/@[)%]^3:
```

### Usage

```
(b,a) ( (!/@:*-!/@[)%]^3: ) p
```

For example:

```
   2 6 ( (!/@:*-!/@[)%]^3: ) 5
240360
```

This is just a direct implementation of the formula so far.

*Note*: for the 3rd testcase input numbers must be defined as *extended* (to handle big arithmetic):

```
   3x 7x ( (!/@:*-!/@[)%]^3: ) 13x
37403621741662802118325
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 52 bytes

```
tT;T P&t^₃D&h↰₁S&h;Pz×₎ᵐ↰₁;S-;D/
hḟF&⟨{-ḟ}×{tḟ}⟩;F↻/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/vyTEOkQhQK0k7lFTs4taxqO2DY@aGoPVMqwDqg5Pf9TU93DrBIiYdbCutYs@V8bDHfPd1B7NX1GtC2TVHp5eXQKiH81fae32qG23/v//0dHmOgrGsToKhsax/6MA)

Accepts input `[[a, b], p]`.

```
% Predicate 1 - Given [n, r], return binomial(n, r)
hḟF              % Compute n!, set as F
&⟨               % Fork:
  {-ḟ}           % (n - r)!
  ×              % times
  {tḟ}           % r!
⟩                
;F↻              % Prepend n! to that
/                % Divide n! by the product and return

% Predicate 0 (Main)
tT;T P           % Set P to the array [p, p] 
&t^₃D            % Set D as p^3
&h↰₁S            % Call predicate 1 on [a, b], 
                 %  set S as the result binomial(a, b)
&h;Pz×₎ᵐ         % Form array [ap, bp]
↰₁               % Call predicate 1 on that to get binomial(ap, bp)
;S-              % Get binomial(ap, bp) - binomial(a, b)
;D/              % Divide that by the denominator term p^3
                 % Implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Nim](http://nim-lang.org), <s>85</s> <s>82</s> <s>75</s> 59 bytes

```
import math,future
(a,b,p)=>(binom(a*p,b*p)-binom(a,b))/p^3
```

This is an anonymous procedure; to use it, it must be passed as an argument to another procedure, which prints it. A full program that can be used for testing is given below

```
import math,future
proc test(x: (int, int, int) -> float) =
 echo x(3, 1, 13) # substitute in your input or read from STDIN
test((a,b,p)=>(binom(a*p,b*p)-binom(a,b))/p^3)
```

Nim's `math` module's `binom` proc computes the binomial coefficient of its two arguments.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3 with [SciPy](https://www.scipy.org/scipylib/index.html), 72 bytes

```
from scipy.special import*
lambda a,b,p:(binom(a*p,b*p)-binom(a,b))/p**3
```

An anonymous function that takes input via argument and returns the result.

There's not a lot going on here; this is a direct implementation of the desired computation.

[Try it on Ideone](https://ideone.com/50ytXo) (the result is returned in exponential notation for the last test case)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 67 bytes

```python
def f(a,b,p):B=2<<a*p;R=(B+1)**a;print(R**p/B**(p*b)-R/B**b)%B/p**3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcZBCoMwEAXQvadwI8z8jkgSWqHRTY6QGyRoaDd2EDc9fSRv9fR/fX6HrXXbS18oSRbld1jtsiSojyuFh2EgeT2/x0UR0CkApMg8xtbMQ5gUcLXQS6w8uSvkxIhxbbO4tnoD)

Expresses the binomial coefficients arithmetically using [this method](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/169115/20260).

Answer (score 0):

### JavaScript (ES6), 70 bytes

```
(a,b,p,c=(a,b)=>a==b|!b||c(--a,b)+c(a,--b))=>(c(a*p,b*p)-c(a,b))/p/p/p
```

Save 1 byte by using ES7 (`/p**3` instead of `/p/p/p`).

Answer (score 0):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 18 bytes

```apl
{(-/!/¨⍺1×⊂⍵)÷⍺*3}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R24RqDV19Rf1DKx717jI8PP1RV9Oj3q2ah7cDuVrGtf//myqkKRgpmAEA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 43 bytes

```
(a,b,p)->((c=binomial)(a*p,b*p)-c(a,b))/p^3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcrBCoMwEATQXxk87cqGoqHtSX9ELGwClkBqF@nBfn2aFObwZhjTI7mnlQ1TIZUgxm4milNI@/uVNDNpbxL6usd2YL7Ywxc1y1864WbYkfZPZddKh6g50yY4mQXLchOMguta7QVDjW@@C/zfK5cf)