# Repeated! Factorials!

Tags: code-golf, integer, factorial

Not to be confused with [Find the factorial!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/607/find-the-factorial)

### Introduction

The factorial of an integer `n` can be calculated by
$$n!=n\times(n-1)\times(n-2)\times(...)\times2\times1$$

This is relatively easy and nothing new. However, factorials can be extended to [double factorials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial), such that
$$n!!=n\times(n-2)\times(n-4)\times(...)\times4\times2$$
for even numbers, and 
$$n!!=n\times(n-2)\times(n-4)\times(...)\times3\times1$$
for odd numbers. But we're not limited to double factorials. For example
$$n!!!=n\times(n-3)\times(n-6)\times(...)\times6\times3$$
or
$$n!!!=n\times(n-3)\times(n-6)\times(...)\times5\times2$$
or
$$n!!!=n\times(n-3)\times(n-6)\times(...)\times4\times1$$
depending on the starting value.

In summary:
$${\displaystyle n!^{(k)}={\begin{cases}1&{\text{if }}n=0 \\n&{\text{if }}0<n\leq k\\n\cdot\left({(n-k)!}^{(k)}\right)&{\text{if }}n>k\end{cases}}}$$
where
$${\displaystyle n!^{(k)}=n\underbrace{!\dots!}_{k}}$$
Or, in plain English: **Subtract the factorial count from the base number repeatedly and multiply all resulting positive integers.**

### The Challenge

Write a function that will calculate any kind of repeated factorial for any non-negative integer.

#### Input

Either

- A string containing a non-negative base-ten integer, followed by 1 or more exclamation marks. E.g. `"6!"` or `"9!!"` or `"40!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!"`.

or

- The same values represented by two integers: one non-negative base value and one positive value representing the factorial count. This can be done according to any format from the default I/O rules.

#### Output

The result of said calculation.

### Challenge remarks

- `0!` equals `1` by definition. Your code must account for this.
- The factorial count is limited by $$ 0 < factorial~count \leq base~value $$outside this range, you are free to output whatever. Aside from `0!`, which is the only exception to this rule.

### Examples

```
Input                              Output

3!!!                               3
0!                                 1
6!                                 720
9!!                                945
10!!!!!!!!                         20
40!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!             800
420!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!  41697106428257280000000000000000
```

Try it with an ungolfed Python implementation: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY5BCoMwEEX3/xQZNyZiRasULPQwImkrSAwxKe3p06mK7aJ/9XnzZhL78vfJ1FE/dS/bLEmSOBgrOBfBJXip8OjGoFfgJcNi9m6wMqVUKRghdrvop8DKZyAmJ5Y9OD2H0bNQAVemA5vCdeam5SLkZX4w6ozlzCZnfA6w7vPgihQi/03FmohQEk6ElltV0hY0e/0NmuNf/s0b)

### General remarks

- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the answer using the fewest bytes in each language wins.
- [Standard rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet/), [I/O rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods) and [loophole rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) apply.
- Please include a [Try it Online](https://tio.run/#)-link to demonstrate your code working.
- Please motivate your answer with an explanation of your code.

Comment: The examples list `0!` but the challenge remarks say that the factorial count will be less than or equal to the base value.

Comment: Wouldn't 3!!! be zero? n*(n-3) = 3*(3-3) = 0.

Comment: @ouflak If it works like 1!, not really. It's more like 1! = 1. 2!! = 2. 3!!! = 3. There's no calculation, because you are at the end of the recursiveness. No 0 in products or else every single factorial would drop down to 0 in the end.

Comment: `3!!!!!!!` should not be undefined—it should just yield the answer `3`. It's the same as `1!!=1` (not undefined). Also your input specification says that there will always be at least one `!`, so the first example `3` doesn't fit the specification.

Comment: Thanks all! I reviewed the comments and have edited the post accordingly. It is indeed so that a factorial count higher than the base number should return the base number. It seems a bit unfair to change it now, but I think most answers comply with it anyway.

Comment: Tile should actually be "Repeated factorials!!!!".

Comment: I'm surprised that nobody found a language yet where the solution is 0 or 1 Bytes. There are many that automatically print the output and surely there must be one that automatically parses the input as calculation or has one command to parse a string input as calculation and also supports repeated factorials.

Comment: @FabianRöling: But that's not what this is.  It's not `(3!)!` instead it's *removing* terms from a factorial.  It's a misleading name; I came in assuming it was going to be applying the Factorial function repeatedly in a chain and had to read carefully to see what it actually was.  Fortunately the question does explain it clearly.  **A better name might be stride factorial** or step factorial or something.

Answer (score 17):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 33 bytes

```r
function(n,k)prod(seq(n+!n,1,-k))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LclJCoAwDEDRvaeouwQjdBDRhadRA1JIHc8fW3H1H/xTeVJ@ZL63JCAUcT/TAtd6gDS1kKM2IipDIBOwYrBkXGn/dyTjS10eQ0GX4e0nnxks6gs)

Handles \$n=0\$ by adding the logical negation of \$n\$.

Answer (score 14):

## [ArnoldC](https://lhartikk.github.io/ArnoldC/), <strike>702 698</strike> 634 bytes

```
LISTEN TO ME VERY CAREFULLY f
I NEED YOUR CLOTHES YOUR BOOTS AND YOUR MOTORCYCLE n
I NEED YOUR CLOTHES YOUR BOOTS AND YOUR MOTORCYCLE p
GIVE THESE PEOPLE AIR
HEY CHRISTMAS TREE r
YOU SET US UP 1
HEY CHRISTMAS TREE c
YOU SET US UP 0
STICK AROUND n
GET TO THE CHOPPER r
HERE IS MY INVITATION r
YOU'RE FIRED n
ENOUGH TALK
GET TO THE CHOPPER n
HERE IS MY INVITATION n
GET DOWN p
ENOUGH TALK
GET TO THE CHOPPER c
HERE IS MY INVITATION 0
LET OFF SOME STEAM BENNET n
ENOUGH TALK
BECAUSE I'M GOING TO SAY PLEASE c
GET TO THE CHOPPER n
HERE IS MY INVITATION 0
ENOUGH TALK
YOU HAVE NO RESPECT FOR LOGIC
CHILL
I'LL BE BACK r
HASTA LA VISTA, BABY
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rZJBb9swDIXv@hXvlksPTlsM25GWaUuoLBqSnMDHIVtPRTZ02@/PqGYd0C3BtmZH0k8f6ff4/nH/6eHD7uDLKiM72RY/sjGOF1iXfC4jZZTEjMePX749fDWLzMhcMGfMExpjBi20mUBZlYKRUn4WdwJfEGWLe9zgxhQKd1VTHMNR7J51fw1psL4c8uZ/QN7h@nLIusHbyym3Da6b85iamKMNo2WOKJxGH6lwdwgab@0ombHhpJFT4n4OYcG98YjM3XEBG0Sx@Vi0IiWjTngqRymS7GIDY/@aR5/N4HW5KmVMLJP2yKeTJ/jL9a1PiXa/nWgu3t6Bksw6fv9k6w@frJNp4qRgx4nhM8YFPm58oeIlHgeu9EvvE9e3HGUeHKrXpzj7M5zj0E62UX/3D4zdGUZjgoql75FF89LoaNRIY9Tuy8VatjSrmX41YhAfhzoi0wK1lnJ16B9Wb16gf95SFCTOE9uCXhKCDN4a63wIxq9C0MXQkrquzlIuhEDYaEp0pe12ORy@Aw)

Translated to pseudocode:

```
f(n,p) {
  r=1;
  c=0;
  while (n) {
    r=r*n;
    n=n-p;
    c=n<0;
    if (c) n=0;
  }
  return r;
}
```

Note: ArnoldC has only one type of data: 16-bit signed integer. Hence I cannot test the `420!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!` case.

Comment: Just curious about your psuedocode. What is the variable 'c' for?

Comment: @ouflak I edited my answer a couple of times and forgot it. The `c` variable actually stores the value of the comparison between `n` and `0`.

Comment: +1 and I borrowed it (minus the 'c') for my LUA answer.

Answer (score 13):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage/wiki/Code-page)

```
RṚmP
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/o4c5ZuQH///83MfhvZAAA)

**How?** Given \$n\$ and \$k\$, it first generates the range \$n,\cdots, 1\$ (with `RṚ`), then with `m` it keeps every \$k^{\text{th}}\$ element of this range (so \$n, n-k, n-2k,\cdots,n-\lfloor n/k\rfloor k\$), and finally multiplies them using `P`.

Comment: Works well, and so simple in the end. I don't know Jelly at all but at least it looks good :)

Comment: @V.Courtois Given \$n\$ and \$k\$, it first generates the range \$n,\cdots, 1\$ (with `RṚ`), then with `m` it keeps every \$k^{\text{th}}\$ element of this range (so \$n, n-k, n-2k,\cdots,n-\lfloor n/k\rfloor k\$), and finally multiplies them using `P`. Just the straightforward approach. *Edit:* I added this explanation in the answer.

Comment: Hah thank you very much. One day I might want to golf in this language so I'll have to learn those monads, dyads etc.

Comment: Alternative that looks like CJam: `r1mP`.

Comment: Isn't the `Ṛ` itself 3 bytes (`\xe1\xb9\x9a`), making this 6 bytes total?  (Or, I'm new to code golf, and "byte" here means one unicode character...).

Comment: @KyeWShi  Jelly has its own [codepage](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage/wiki/Code-page), so each of the 256 characters it contains is encoded as 1 byte.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Oh, I see!  Thanks.

Comment: `RUmP` is a more direct ASCII-only version as well.

Answer (score 8):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 21 bytes

```hs
n%a=product[n,n-a..1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcVLDoMgEADQq8yiJpCMZoCmqQtPYlxM6M8UR4Ky8PKltJv3Xry97yGUIg0PMa237PdRUFruOjOVhWeBAWKaZYcTLBxBZfE5pQNUozWMyqHTqAhN9fK3R1s1hNfamdDSb0voSE/l4x@Bn1tpfYxf)

Combining the built-in product function with stepped range enumeration beats what I could code up recursively (even with flawr saving a byte).

**22 bytes**

```hs
n%a|n<1=1|m<-n-a=n*m%a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcXNCgIhEADgV5lDgsYIo0a0sD5JdBikn6V1ELc9BPvsmXX5vgcvz@s8tyaKNxlddFserViOss@KW@ZJIEKpk7xgB5kL6FXSWusbtDIGzjpgMKgJXff4d0DfdYSn3oHQ029PGMhc2ifdZr4vzaZSvg)

Here's a solution taking input in string format like `9!!`, which I think is more interesting.

**42 bytes**

```hs
(\[(n,a)]->product[n,n-length a..1]).reads
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bcFBCoAgEADAr2zRwSCloGt9JDssphbZJmrfb/tAMzvm04bAbtIs9CKow3aVc0z39piyUEcyWPJlB1RqWFuVLG6ZLzwIJojpoAINOKjHvvpR82tcQJ9Zmhg/)

Comment: I think you could shorten the recursive solution to `n%a|n<1=1|m<-n-a=n*m%a`

Answer (score 8):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 7 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

Anonymous tacit prefix function. Takes `[n,b]` as argument.

```apl
×/-\…1¨
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn///B0fd2YRw3LDA@t@J/2qG3Co96@R31TPf0fdTUfWm/8qG0ikBcc5AwkQzw8g/@nKRgrGHOBSHMgaaBgCCTNwKSlghGQNDRQsABSJgYKRgYg2shAwdgAAA)

`1¨` one for each element of the argument; `[1,1]`

`-\` cumulative difference; `[n,n-b]`

`…` range using second element of left argument as indicator of step, e.g. `[9,7]` continues with `5`

`×/` product

Answer (score 6):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 6 bytes

These are all equivalent 6-byters:

```
*F:Q1E
*F:E1Q
*F%E_S
```

[Try it online! (`*F:Q1E`)](https://pythtemp.herokuapp.com/?code=%2aF%3AQ1E&input=40%0A20&debug=0)

Or, **11 bytes**, taking input as a string:

```
*F:.vQ1/Q\!
```

[Test suite.](https://pythtemp.herokuapp.com/?code=%2aF%3A.vQ1%2FQ%5C%21&input=%2240%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%22&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%223%22%0A%223%21%21%21%22%0A%223%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%22%0A%220%21%22%0A%226%21%22%0A%229%21%21%22%0A%2210%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%22%0A%2240%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%22%0A%22420%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%21%22&debug=0)

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES6), 21 bytes

Takes input as `(k)(n)`.

```javascript
k=>g=n=>n<1||n*g(n-k)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZcxBDoIwEAXQvadgOWOCtEOhJbHchSA0CmmJGFfcvRY1IZSf2b3/59G8m7l93qdXat2t8732g66Ntrq2V74s9mzApgP61tnZjd1ldAZ6yDEcJmuyLMlPe@UIbFN@1HJTSSxyQqg2r0QRuULg//fBj3OGIH4eWLHY89XpWwgueFlJzkpBigpJob6P/wA)

Or [**24 bytes**](https://tio.run/##bc1LDoIwEIDhvadg2ZognVLaYiyehSA0CpkaMV6/Dj4SQCfp6v86c6kf9djcztd7iuHUxs7F3lXeoavwAHgE3OPWM0x7HpuAYxja3RA861iOfHo8mSbLknyz7EBdzDr86XrWjRQrIUmUM1GqYiUsCfgeIfG7giJTH0HAirXIX0K@CQkFujQgtJJWFkbSh@XEJw) to support BigInts.

---

## JavaScript (ES6), 55 bytes

Takes input as a string, using the format described in the challenge.

```javascript
s=>(a=s.split`!`,k=a.length-1,g=n=>n<1||n*g(n-k))(a[0])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jc7dCoIwGMbx867CebSFH9v8huaNROAwNXNs0qQj790sImqG@D//Pe975Xeuy1vbD65U52qq2aRZDjnTnu5FOxSgcDrGPVHJZri4xGmYZLk8kHGU@wZKt0MI8iM@oalUUitReUI1sIZ2AACwEbLW830r2BkSb3AvSUwZb5UJxabNtrz7tFkYmZZg8G5tYrbLs@GHfmfOzDTFS0v/YmNmtiGJs4TgOKQpjRI6T/02PQA)

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>10</s> <s>8</s> 7 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
Ý¦RIιнP
```

Input as two separated inputs: first input being `base`; second input being `factorial`.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8NxDy4I8z@28sDfg/38DLkMA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfWVC6H8fA@@giHM7L@wN@K/zPzraWMc4VgdImgNJAx1DIGkGJi11jICkoYGOBZAyMdAxMgDRRgY6xgaxsQA).

-2 bytes thanks to *@Mr.Xcoder*.
-1 byte thanks to *@JonathanAllan*.

**Explanation:**

```python
Ý        # Create a list in the range [0, (implicit) base-input]
 ¦       # And remove the first item to make it the range [1, base]
         # (NOTE: this is for the edge case 0. For the other test cases simply `L` instead
         #  of `Ý¦` is enough.)
  R      # Reverse this list so the range is [base, 1]
   Iι    # Uninterleave with the second input as step-size
         #  i.e. base=3, factorial=7: [[3],[2],[1],[],[],[],[]]
         #  i.e. base=10, factorial=8: [[10,2],[9,1],[8],[7],[6],[5],[4],[3]]
         #  i.e. base=420, factorial=30: [[420,390,360,...,90,60,30],[419,389,359,...],...]
     н   # Only leave the first inner list
      P  # And take the product of its values
         # (which is output implicitly as result)
```

**Original 10 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage) answer:**

```
L0KD¤-IÖÏP
```

Input as two separated inputs: first input being `base`; second input being `factorial`.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fx8DbxfPwtMP9Af//G3AZAgA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfWVC6H8fA2@XQ0t0Iw5PO9wf8F/nf3S0sY5xrA6QNAeSBjqGQNIMTFrqGAFJQwMdCyBlYqBjZACijQx0jA1iYwE).

**Explanation:**

```python
L           # Create a list in the range [1, (implicit) base-input]
 0K         # Remove all 0s (edge case for input 0, which will become the list [1,0])
   D        # Duplicate this list
    ¤       # Get the last value (without popping)
            # (could also be `Z` or `¹` for max_without_popping / first input respectively)
     -      # Subtract it from each item in the list
      IÖ    # Check for each if they're divisible by the second factorial-input
        Ï   # In the list we copied, only leave the values at the truthy indices
         P  # And take the product of those
            # (which is output implicitly as result)
```

Comment: This 6-byter: `LR²ιнP` ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fJ@jQpnM7L@wN@P/fjMsQAA "05AB1E – Try It Online")) works for every test case, except for 0.

Comment: But I guess that 0 case can be fixed in at most 2 bytes. If you figure out a way to fix it, you may take it :) **EDIT:** Perhaps `LR²ιн0KP` for 8 bytes?

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Nice answer! Never even used uninterleave with a given step. :)

Comment: `0K` should be unnecessary as `0!` is an invalid input by the specification (even though it's been included in the examples) - I have [commented](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/189240/repeated-factorials/189270#comment453269_189240) about this.

Comment: ...and *if* `0!` is in the input domain `Ý¦RXιнP` saves a byte.

Comment: @JonathanAllan Nice way to save a byte. And now that you've mentioned it, it's indeed a bit confusing that the `0` is included when it's outside the specified range. (I know the range has been added later than the `0` edge case in the Sandbox, though.)

Comment: I was looking at the documentation, doesn't 05AB1E have a maximum of two elements command? I.e. `pop(a, b), push(max(a, b))`.

Comment: @maxb Nope. it does have popAndGetMaxOfList (`à`), maxOfListWithoutPopping (`Z`), and maxOfStack (`M`). So if you cannot use `M` because it also has other elements on the stack, you could use `‚à` (pair + popAndPushMax) instead.

Comment: I tried getting it to 6 bytes, but I needed a swap to get the uninterleave working correctly. I ended up with [`MLRsιнP`](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W9ioGBk8N/XJ6j43M4LewP@/wcA), which needs the input to be in the header.

Answer (score 5):

## [Whitespace](https://web.archive.org/web/20150618184706/http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/tutorial.php), 91 bytes

```
[S S S T    N
Push_1][S N
S _Duplicate_1][S N
S _Duplicate_1][T   N
T   T   _Read_STDIN_as_integer_(base)][T    T   T   _Retrieve_base][S S S N
_Push_0][T  N
T   T   _Read_STDIN_as_integer_(factorial)][N
S S N
_Create_Label_LOOP][S N
S _Duplicate_base][S S S T  N
_Push_1][T  S S T   _Subtract][N
T   T   S N
_If_negative_jump_to_Label_PRINT_RESULT][S N
S _Duplicate_base][S T  S S T   S N
_Copy_0-based_2nd_(result)][T   S S N
_Multiply][S N
T   _Swap_top_two][S S S N
_Push_0][T  T   T   _Retrieve_factorial][T  S S T   _Subtract][N
S N
N
_Jump_to_Label_LOOP][N
S S S N
_Create_Label_PRINT_RESULT][S N
N
_Discard_top][T N
S T _Print_result_as_integer]
```

Letters `S` (space), `T` (tab), and `N` (new-line) added as highlighting only.
`[..._some_action]` added as explanation only.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##JYxRCoAwDEO/k1PkCGN6IZHB/BMUPH5tulLS5pH2m9c7nvs4R4QkUFQ2CFcSei2W4gBKsICNjFgqriu/ofOeaRCx98at/Q) (with raw spaces, tabs and new-lines only).

**Explanation in pseudo-code:**

```
Integer result = 1
Integer base = STDIN as integer
Integer factorial = STDIN as integer
Start LOOP:
  If(base <= 0):
    Call function PRINT_RESULT
  result = result * base
  base = base - factorial
  Go to next iteration of LOOP

function PRINT_RESULT:
  Print result as integer to STDOUT
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 29 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,b:n<1or n*f(n-b,b)
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P802JzE3KSVRIU8nySrPxjC/SCFPK00jTzdJJ0nzf0FRZl6JRpqGoZGOqabmfwA)**

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 22 bytes

```perl6
{[*] $^a,*-$^b...^1>*}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hc3RCoIwFIDh@z3FGUjoZnObc9OLepFKUFMINEOvRHz2ZRChUPnfnJvvnPMou1rbZoBdBQc7nsgFnDTzyd5Jc8ZYKo5kslXbgVvf7mXvwYgA@myAyqVNcL7SwH9NTANWtE3uocmGGGP4X4j4FgEQSG8jIzlKNv9BoiIkOH73k83H1EctW6mYz0x@dcsNJXRiBNdKxjIyct5a9wQ)

Anonymous codeblock that returns the product of the range starting from the first input, decreasing by the second until it is below `1`, excluding the last number. This works for `0`, since the base case of a the reduce by product is 1, so the output is 1.

Answer (score 4):

## x86-64 machine code, 12 bytes

Same machine code does the same thing in 32-bit mode, and for 16-bit integers in 16-bit mode.

This is a function, callable with args `n=RCX`, `k=ESI`.  32-bit return value in `EAX`.

Callable from C with the x86-64 System V calling convention with dummy args to get the real args into the right registers. `uint32_t factk(int, uint32_t k, int, uint64_t n);`  I couldn't just use Windows x64 because 1-operand `mul` clobbers RDX, and we don't want REX prefixes to access R8/R9.  `n` must not have any garbage in the high 32 bits so JRCXZ works, but other than that it's all 32-bit.

NASM listing (relative address, machine code, source)

```
 1                         factk:
 2 00000000 6A01             push 1
 3 00000002 58               pop rax             ; retval = 1
 4 00000003 E306             jrcxz  .n_zero      ; if (n==0) return
 5                         .loop:                ; do {
 6 00000005 F7E1              mul   ecx            ; retval *= n  (clobbering RDX)
 7 00000007 29F1              sub   ecx, esi       ; n -= k
 8 00000009 77FA              ja   .loop         ; }while(sub didn't wrap or give zero)
 9                         .n_zero:
10 0000000B C3               ret
```

0xc = 12 bytes

---

Or 10 bytes if we didn't need to handle the `n=0` special case, leaving out the `jrcxz`.

For standard factorial you'd use `loop` instead of sub/ja to save 2 bytes, but otherwise the exact same code.

---

Test caller that passes `argc` as `k`, with `n` hard-coded.

````
align 16
global _start
_start:
  mov  esi, [rsp]
;main:
  mov  ecx, 9
  call factk

  mov  esi, eax
  mov  edx, eax
  lea  rdi, [rel print_format]
  xor  eax, eax
extern printf
  call printf
extern exit
  call exit

section .rodata
print_format: db `%#x\t%u\n`

```
````

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 11 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

Anonymous tacit infix function. Takes `n` as right argument and `b` as left argument.

```apl
×/1⌈⊢,⊢-×∘⍳
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT/////B0fcNHPR2PuhbpALHu4emPOmY86t38P@1R24RHvX2P@qZ6@j/qaj603vhR20QgLzjIGUiGeHgG/zdWSFMw5jIHk4ZA0gBMmnEZAUlLLgsgaWjAZWQApE0MuIzBtJEBAA)

`×∘⍳` multiply `b` by the **ɩ**ntegers 1 through `n`

`⊢-` subtract that from `n`

`⊢,` prepend `n`

`1⌈` max of one and each of those

`×/` product

Answer (score 3):

## Java 10, 44 bytes

```java
f->b->{int r=1;for(;b>0;b-=f)r*=b;return r;}
```

Takes the factorial as first input, base as second.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##jZA9b4MwEIZ3fsWJCYohQKp@uTBWytApY9XBfDgyJQaZI1IU8dupIW4Jnbrd8/pO95wrdmJ@VXyNec26Dt6ZkBcLoEOGIodKvwY9ijrgvcxRNDJ4M8XrTmJ5KBX5X5Mp0hQ4JCP308xPL0IiqCSivFEOzdKQZn7CXXWXZFSV2CsJig4jtbRQ22e1FjJep0YUcNSuzh6VkIePT2Du5A2AZYfOlmxduuDjGiMSrvHhFmPyfItPJFp1xyG5/wk2m@s2HcXXbLCWz5sl54bpTs5ybJRg9U62PZIpylhXzmTU9@cOy2PQ9Bi0@iqspbOe8mxgsgDb@5307BeNPGBtW5//dLsmXdYYxWH8Bg)

This above doesn't work for the largest test case due to the limited integer range (32-bits). To fix this we can use `BigIntegers`, which <s>coincidentally</s> is <s>exactly double the size - **88**</s> 79 bytes:

```java
f->b->{var r=f.ONE;for(;b.signum()>0;b=b.subtract(f))r=r.multiply(b);return r;}
```

-9 bytes thanks to *@OlivierGrégoire*.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##nZE9a8MwEIb3/Iojk0UckY/SL9ceCi1kaDNkLB0kx3KVyrKRToYQ8ttdxTV1HDqUbnreu1fce7djNZvutp9Nqpi18MKkPowALDKUKex8lTqUigqnU5Slps/d46GtFQw/6KPMVxqzPDPhfx0XapKAgLgR04RPk0PNDJhY0PXrUyRKE0ScWplrVwQkmUU89ug4GpZiIAgxsaGFUygrtQ84iUyGzmgw0bGJRj5a5bjy0bqEdSm3UPjUwQaN1PnbOzBy2gAAZhaDZbgkUY83Q5yHsyFen@MivDvH23A@6F7MwquBsPTC4ls5jvojtCO2DVIjCB@zNJKpla4chieJM5u11A2@2VvMClo6pJXPhEoHQ9dkDExvYTz5cU7G9x4FZdVpa7@dhNZMuWwtLr4i5C@efkLSxTs2Xw)

**Explanation:**

```java
f->b->{       // Method with two integer parameters and integer return-type
  int r=1;    //  Result-integer, starting at 1
  for(;b>0;   //  Loop as long as the base is still larger than 0
      b-=f)   //    After every iteration: decrease the base by the factorial
    r*=b;     //   Multiply the result by the base
  return r;}  //  Return the result
```

Comment: [I'm sorry I broke your coincidental exact size doubling... :(](https://tio.run/##nZE9a8MwEIb3/Iojk0UckY/SL9ceCi1kaDNkLB0kx3KVyrKRToYQ8ttdxTV1HDqUbnreu1fce7djNZvutp9Nqpi18MKkPowALDKUKex8lTqUigqnU5Slps/d46GtFQw/6KPMVxqzPDPhfx0XapKAgLgR04RPk0PNDJhY0PXrUyRKE0ScWplrVwQkmUU89ug4GpZiIAgxsaGFUygrtQ84iUyGzmgw0bGJRj5a5bjy0bqEdSm3UPjUwQaN1PnbOzBy2gAAZhaDZbgkUY83Q5yHsyFen@MivDvH23A@6F7MwquBsPTC4ls5jvojtCO2DVIjCB@zNJKpla4chieJM5u11A2@2VvMClo6pJXPhEoHQ9dkDExvYTz5cU7G9x4FZdVpa7@dhNZMuWwtLr4i5C@efkLSxTs2Xw)

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Np, and thanks! :)

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 25 bytes

```ruby
f=->s,r{s<1?1:s*f[s-r,r]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hdDbCoJAEIDh@32KXehCS9fddT2F5oPYgQ4IQqXsKBjas9teRChU/tffzMCo5vQYhjyxN2CpDmKe8jUs8wxsZandc2iTOAbkEkLw/1zE5gjGHPnzKBAMRbP3cCQ9xBl595PpZfKjxk1UyDQTX914QnI/CjjzpQiFFwg9NQ0BqpoacEuhuha1sXBMejtWXa/6PFOZs99eVs6O1uWhsLCi57K510ZKTP3oFw)

Answer (score 3):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <s>22</s> 21 bytes

```
1##&@@Range[#,1,-#2]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE7876Zg@99QWVnNwSEoMS89NVpZx1BHV9koVu1/QFFmXkm0sq6dhpuDg7JmrJq@Q3W1sY5xrU61gY4hkDQDk5Y6RkDS0EDHAkiZGOgYGYBoIwMdY4Pa2v8A)

-1 thanks to attinat: `Times --> 1##&`

Explanation: use `Range` to make a list of the values `{n, n-k, n-2k, n-3k, ...}`, stopping before going below 1 (i.e., stopping just right). Then multiply all numbers in this list with `Times` (or `1##&`).

Comment: [-1 byte](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE7876Zg@99QWVnNwSEoMS89NVpZx1BHV9koVu1/QFFmXkm0sq6dhpuDg7JmrJq@Q3W1sY5xrU61gY4hkDQDk5Y6RkDS0EDHAkiZGOgYGYBoIwMdY4Pa2v8A) with `1##&` instead of `Times`

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 4 bytes

```
ɾṘḞΠ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBIiwiIiwiyb7huZjhuJ7OoCIsIiIsIjMsIDNcbjMsIDdcbjAsIDFcbjYsIDFcbjksIDJcbjEwLCA4XG40MCwgMjBcbjQyMCwgMzAiXQ==)

Answer (score 3):

## [Knight](https://github.com/knight-lang/knight-lang), <s>34</s> 33 bytes

```
;=p=xE P;=yP;W<0=x-x y=p*x pO+p!p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVhrc9s2Fv2eX0GzqUWINC17Ou1YNO1JvM5OZhvZG7vNtJISgSAksaFIhQ9brsT96957wReol9MvHgo4uC@c@4D/og80ZpE3T46C0OXPzKdxrPwn8CbT5DqKwkjhi4QHbqyIX8ssB9zSKObNfelMifqYBok3exl3l0SczpYsDOIkSlkSRholy2TqxWYcphHjNs1gx5t/mnoJj@eUca3Yn9GETbXjz1p/MBz0BzGsZ92hvvqh/3kQDNvaIFi9JqR9TLI5519hN@JJGgWKJLzfGa5WQer7WS7MMZjdIUufJwq1HZMvONMkOLEKEXjEtm16iR9dGWJL32acOmC7RkGN6fNgkkyJQftsSLIkBMe9YLLVqiwT4VDu/7i9vrP7QysP1e/UT/kyTmjiMWWOt6A5ZOmYG@GxxhDFBxqBDx2LngsxhX6L6nruH7PFep8OzVKW5Y01Rgp7WCb5mkVpIMIehY9KwB9zRmQud9LJlvUd3gkhZr0JuF46c3i0A1duAu5tGPqcBjuA1W5WsOpXCEZE/Yp4eejWSBanc5RuCFFfXJpQ4FruqKRkizPF7/rcNk@K303Qhhvlggzj33w0r0BQxQOracB4OM69ltw4PJSMBz7mX2UUUHgVgiIkG/wpuV5n0/27Iem/Ofpz2D42TirK08NDvGCUqan3KmojmZvO5pUzo9KZ1yI/MzLK/GRau3JQ23p4SBvXNpFxiow7aAKznMzzNJ5quEqsPFWue7@//3jT@3Ddu7eXWZEw710eJGsceMn9Pj36@8sQ/3aOzr5ACNYDIISCsdk@NnkIAjY14yOOemMPcHmIchwGCsz1JgHKkTzp15hhRc3c4B0ozOCH0HOVzgHeT2m5VSeoXJe10W/B1yB8DBSvskxpNUxrjZoxFy6QMr5SdL@XXgNX3wwpBLRIF0rWSVVs1JyiritxpTxfc0anUukgGdTgvfCjJnyW@nvh7Sbc9R5kL@stvInGJZSiPtBkagJvAiZJPQa/d12SekWDIEwUUAV3ojhPyt88ClUwNXT/oe5a4Y/0RX0gPvVDSd88fNyvrxa/Wh1o9LxDvsv5dvs7vOeLeRggSWnChUFKEkJtDPgE@PbAFTCOR2Ckv6OSnMv3trPeXDRQDeLXtO9BQ9zPe6l6V8TvFSWV5JxHIY0SUlYQbLdrOaAiWCPqvs4g5BXOvxBKFs7ATC6OmGoVjH94Sg4OrpXRgeb4YnCQQo5NpZ6jtoYE5rh4cDdsX5LBybFxKmiF0QBmOTKRQAMOK/kQQ818uEOw2sK2xFarltrCD1K7VA@tWPTAqpkXAJNc5VsaAqF4wMIUl7nbVV4vaTba1tKF/c08Mk46ZLXqrNWsYkDYV7PQiVEBKBRulh4E1brMiM85hd4jV6AXGF@NWnsZX6HkS4XForvCKerePQWsSzM74t9SL@KaOo5VYixxRBZbjrTFpp7vfplHIeMxot791ru6f3/Tu6t78zuoAftas8SS/IJhMq/E9B2p04mblmZVS@LVZVdknb4yyXHOGI7zNM7H@MOF@dg9Z@Vs7Jaz8dgWFpmlKajsYLyDTh886N3BRKHRJJ3hwPF66eonmQJKlDF6CR3VwUZq8TywY5JJd4yB0JjhGHxtpIAltjZWoDib5t8BnXHbyb9BdWyzzdlVHNBM06xQVWXJq7iK2hMvDDRVr6RW4XGUcuQUR6luq4ai6o6Zy6i6uK5u1KYb5y/OEtOLBX8NGJeycaFKifjEixMuXCRLCO0J9qrygbT2ltDUHpikzFIY8hxI1AVlif@kQC9Q2JRG8AtmFj8MJlCTrJogdGg7kkYITNW55KstkgxeoJoj5QGRa089RuXvDWsrDdReqDygZCiUqe@irUKFewC1UsoqDDgxqhCot6qhEfuieJKpquHYb9PxmEcm9f2QaTCAuyEGiWodYEQHJnIDKO/Ak5I4YPhXi@ng6iNkHNdOoAuLHfGSMzG3PnmQ@OogUAlhNjNj34MXYsdQjurJvqw0jGSyZR9zyxqte@yH4OtPp2c/nf38y@nZz22xGtHADWcYNvn8tWpQ@wJDRhuhrSGtNy2EVImeh7ewypG7GxhwWZqZSzLHUTi7AgZchS4MmsXbiXRLc@XrNFmBe5PgzCYb@VYYSeWlq3ypeFyKv/L2SGxXfajp3A5H1f@KQ0VBNPnCW6/iEvagUiDeWs0HUAP5a4VEj2VDymSS0f9Cbl1U41sj2KVlceKGaWI@RtC4QWCe58SgjZjdNAXVWgtp6mAgnoflvz@Aapc7FBSIjlGmP2BJdyt4hF3y1YgY1fQk26QDWbGc1BeHLbfwshGGow0kvhC2IdsbSOzQ25DHG0jxLtiC/HFTZrjdzs8bSDF/b0GeV8iKNOURnA2qI/KZi91nJrvOXO4@g8V/65nD6oxGywxv/MfmsjjWbeTg6sVjtOts5qYlHct3jW0BsyVYo8rg43a1ApXSQ7@Z0tQsXuqOXel3GsI/VcKX2EetRvpaZC3xtpL5fS4C2r99QbcGi236/m/pkAhabbfhNJ5rBjYC6WdZy6p0RCGrlao2o3ZXKHCFivLQC6pc293UXIHLrMcB/5LqMF/WFcEhOtNrk3QXu3LdOv7Xkmtf8xEPOIhOWUVgdnnon0JPfH5@Pnt1@urZsuf24lq5teynW@vTecdeHC2UJ3veXijzG31@MP8/)

-1 byte thanks to Aiden Chow

Comment: 33 bytes: `;=pT;=xP;=yP;W<0x;=p*x p=x-Ex yOp`.

Comment: @AidenChow I tried that initially. That doesn't work for `0!` as it will output `true` instead.

Comment: Oops didn't test it lol. What about this? `;=p=xE P;=yP;W<0=x-x y=p*x pO+p!p`

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 8 bytes

```
TõUV f ×
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=VPVVViBmINc&input=MCwx)

-1 thanks to EoI pointing out how dumb uncaffeinated Shaggy can be!

Comment: `kT` can be replaced with `f` for 1 byte

Comment: @EmbodimentofIgnorance, of course it can! I knew it was too early for golf! :\

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 41 bytes

```c
r;f(n,k){for(r=1;n>0;n-=k)r*=n;return r;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZcnBCkBAEADQM1@xKTWjVUsumtaXuGhZSYamdZJvX5y963Pl7FyMQh5Yr3j5XUBsRdwZ4tKuKIVlkimcwkrojtuwMKC60uSQhYOHLB97zrSHxmhVG0T6V/vOF3d8AA)

Comment: 36 bytes `r;f(n,k){for(r=1;n>0;n-=k)r*=n;n=r;}` for C(gcc)

Answer (score 2):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf), <s>7</s> 6 bytes

```
╙╒x%ε*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7///R1JmPpk6qUD23Vev/f2MFYy4LIDZUMABiMy4jBUsg39CAy8hAwcSAyxhIGhn8BwA)

Found a clever way to handle 0! without changing the other test cases. Takes input as `k n` (reverse order), which helps with implicit popping.

### Explanation

```
╙        maximum of two elements (pops largest of k and n,
         which is n for every valid case except 0!, where 1 is pushed)
 ╒       range(1,n+1)
  x      reverse int/array/string
   %     slice every k:th element
    ε*   reduce list with multiplication
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 53 bytes

Takes two arguments, the first being the number and the second being the `!` count.

Somehow breaks on the big test case. This step range costs many bytes in the end because of this `-1*` so improvements ought to be possible by refactoring.

I have, as always, a doubt about how we count bytes for function declarations, because everyone doesn't do the same way everywhere down there, so well... It's **17 bytes less**, so **36 bytes**, if we count out func variables' (`a` and `b`) declaration and func brackets.

```scala
(a:Int,b:Int)=>{var s=1
for(i<-a to b by -1*b)s*=i
s}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZBPb4MgHIbvfIqfnrSlKSD1TzOW7LjDPgRUzFgMGrHNlqafnblsdRo99D1wep73BdxJ1tI36kOfeniTxoL@7LUtHby07RWhUldQCR/J46vtsfo5Y/F8vcgOnKCoarrIPO0k9A0oUF@woxsVu40wyN082u/bzti@tlGYgIBwW0UJJvE2BGlLcO/NuS5BaTjbYcdYXYYx@jeCIBilZCklAzwdCH4zKtmDO@SuEEyXCp2i6R1N19CMkSlcjHcpMFvSBT9MaUqC@QMowfnSmk/wUZrmr4ATzFb@OifzCrbasWxjBCcrdZymRUZJylnODhkb2ucZttDNe/8N) I commented out the broken test cases, because, well, they do break.

Comment: You need the function declaration, otherwise this would be a snippet that takes input via predefined variables. Typically only the function assignment is left out since anonymous functions are allowed as submissions, though it depends on the language and the question

Comment: Ok thanks, so it is 53 indeed.

Answer (score 2):

## [Attache](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Attache), <s>21</s> 19 bytes

```
${x<y∨x*$[x-y,y]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SywpSUzOSP2fpmBl@1@lusKm8lHHigotlegK3Uqdytja/36pqSnF0SoFBcnpsVwBRZl5JSGpxSXOicWpxdFqaToK0VwKQGBvrxBtrKNgEKsD5oLYxlA2VMocJmWgo2AIY5shsS11FIxgbEOgIgsYxwTIMYKbbGIE5BobxHLFxv4HAA) Pretty direct recursive implementation. (Note: `true` is essentially `1`, as it can be used in arithmetic operations as `1`.) This is one of the few programs I've written for this site where using a unicode operator saves bytes (1, to be precise).

### Alternatives

**20 bytes:** `${x<y or x*$[x-y,y]}`

**21 bytes:** `Prod@${{_%y=x%y}\1:x}`

**27 bytes:** `` ${x*[`1,$][x>y][x-y,y]∨1} ``

**27 bytes:** `${If[x>y,x*$[x-y,y],_or 1]}`

**27 bytes:** `` ${x*[`1,$][x>y][x-y,y]or 1} ``

**29 bytes:** `${If[x>y,x*$[x-y,y],_+not _]}`

Answer (score 2):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), <s>92</s> <s>73</s> 61 bytes

```rust
fn f(n:i128,k:i128)->i128{if n<=0{return 1}return n*f(n-k,k)}
```

I am just starting to learn rust, so I'm sure this can be shorter. Will update as I learn. The return value should be `i128` in order to compute the last test.

Edit: Recursion is shorter.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dYxLDgIhEET3fQqcFZiepAFjxu9dXEhC0I5hmBXh7IgTd@KqKu@lKi5zqtWxcJKPXpsJwxpqvH4ieyf4fKEc72mJLHT5Ft62wRgwqAIAbf@8eZYKMryi5/TgjRxyGbD9WrRKnX45oe7y/R9@QNPlmnDqih2hob4xhHZVpdY3)

You can add your own test, or edit one of the already existing ones.

Answer (score 2):

### **[q](https://code.kx.com/v2/ref/), <s>59 57 55</s> 53 bytes**

```
{prd 2+(&)1_i=last i:("J"$x(&)not[n])#(!)sum n:"!"=x}
```

explanation:

```
q)x:"12!!" / let our input be 12!!, assign to x
q)sum n:"!"=x / count "!"s
2i
q)(!)sum n:"!"=x / (!)m -> [0,m)
0 1
q)("J"$x(&)not[n]) / isolate the number in input
12
q)("J"$x(&)not[n])#(!)sum n:"!"=x / x#y means take x items from list y, if x>y, circle around
0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
q)i:("J"$x(&)not[n])#(!)sum n:"!"=x / assign to i
q)i
0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
q)(last i)=i:("J"$x(&)not[n])#(!)sum n:"!"=x / take last elem of i and see which are equal in i
010101010101b
q)1_(last i)=i:("J"$x(&)not[n])#(!)sum n:"!"=x / drop first elem
10101010101b
q)(&)1_(last i)=i:("J"$x(&)not[n])#(!)sum n:"!"=x / indices of 1b (boolean TRUE)
0 2 4 6 8 10
q)2+(&)1_(last i)=i:("J"$x(&)not[n])#(!)sum n:"!"=x / add 2 across array
2 4 6 8 10 12
q)prd 2+(&)1_(last i)=i:("J"$x(&)not[n])#(!)sum n:"!"=x / product across array
46080
```

here also is a version in k (same logic), <s>42</s>41 bytes

```
{*/2+&1_i=last i:("J"$x@&~:n)#!+/n:"!"=x}
```

Comment: Welcome to the site! I've added code formatting to your post which can be done with four spaces before the line or by enclosing it with triple backticks.

Comment: @SriotchilismO'Zaic thanks :-)

Comment: I recommend adding an explanation and maybe a link to an online interpreter like [TIO](https://tio.run/#). Code-only answers are usually automatically flagged as low quality.

Comment: @mbomb007 interesting. is there a bot flagging answers? what happens to low-quality submissions? i will update soon!

Comment: Yes, there is a bot. StackExchange uses bots to look for potential spam and low quality answers. People with high enough reputation can view the Review Queue. https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/161391/285610

Comment: Additionally there is an obscure feature of casting automatic downvote on answers marked as potential low quality. Though the exact behavior changed in time (see [Community should not autodownvote “low quality” autoflags cleared by edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/276269/community-should-not-autodownvote-low-quality-autoflags-cleared-by-edits)), the best strategy is to avoid being marked.

Answer (score 2):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `math.unicode`, <s>30</s> <s>29</s> 24 bytes

- Saved 1 byte thanks to @Bubbler
- Saved 5 bytes thanks to @chunes!

```
[ 1 rot neg <range> Π ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY47DsIwEER7TjEniBKQED/RIhoaRBWlsJxNiDB2WG8KFHIXTsSVjAkpdt7sSKvZSmlxHC7n4@mwwY3YkkHLJPJsubECT4@OrCYP47QyHncl11ESVramf5B0ttGuJGxnPXosMMcQmU5cIhu5nvYsxSqaAfkLBr/xpJ0to6ka9hLyeMBOYKnGbuzZ4/NGEeILBkXsbJGELw)

Takes `k` (which -th factorial) and then `n`. First we push an `n` onto the stack, then `rot` makes the stack look like `n 1 k`. `neg` negates `k`, which will act as the step for a range from `n` to 1 (made using `<range>`). Then `Π` finds the product of that range, and that's it.

Comment: If you take the arguments in `k n` order, you can do `1 rot neg` instead of `neg 1 swap` to save a byte.

Comment: You can save 5 bytes with `Π` from `math.unicode` instead of `product`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), 3.5 bytes (7 nibbles)

```
`*`%@\,
```

```
      ,         # get the range from 1..first input,
     \          # reverse it,
   %            # and take each element in steps of
    @           # the second input,
`*              # and finally get the product
```

[image]

---

Or **7.5 bytes (15 nibbles)** with input as string of a base-ten integer followed by exclamation marks:

```
`*`%,|$\$D\,`r$
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## [Physica](https://github.com/Mr-Xcoder/Physica), 22 bytes

```
f=>n;k:n<1||n*f[n-k;k]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8ioLM5MTvz/P83WLs862yrPxrCmJk8rLTpPN9s6O/a/W36RQklqcYmCZ55CdbWxtXGtNZA0B5IG1oZA0gxMWlobAUlDA2sLIGViYG1kAKKNDKyNDWprrbg4A4oy80oc0qK1QEbF/gcA)

---

**26 bytes**

Re-learning how to use my own "language" \o/... If I knew how to write a parser 2 years ago, this would have been 20 bytes :(

```
->n;k:GenMul##[n…1]{%%k}
```

or

```
->n;k:GenMul##Range[n;1;k]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8ioLM5MTvyfpmCrEPNf1y7POtvKPTXPtzRHWTk671HDMsPYalXV7Nr/bvlFCiWpxSUKnnkK1dXG1sa11kDSHEgaWBsCSTMwaWltBCQNDawtgJSJgbWRAYg2MrA2NqitteLiDCjKzCtxSIvWAhkV@x8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 8 bytes

```
1õUV f ×
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=MfVVViBmINc&input=MTAKOA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 66 bytes

```
^0
1
\d+
*!,
+`(!+)(!+),\1$
$1$2,$2,$1
!+$
1
+`(!+),(\d+)
$.($2*$1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TUoxCoAwENvzi8AJ1RbpqQi@wE@IKOjg4iD@v7aKYkhCSHKs57bPGjLTT2H0UAyLRUEHOxnaPMkNKhCVyiUqaCX@nt2Z@M8hpZGqEA2hRk3ytgR4oiW6mNTzLZsv/nEB) Link includes faster test cases. Mauls numbers without exclamation marks. Explanation:

```
^0
1
```

Fix up `0!`.

```
\d+
*!,
```

Convert `n` to unary and add a separator.

```
+`(!+)(!+),\1$
$1$2,$2,$1
```

Repeatedly subtract `k` from `n` while `n>k`, and collect the results.

```
!+$
1
```

Replace `k` with `1` (in decimal).

```
+`(!+),(\d+)
$.($2*$1
```

Multiply by each intermediate value in turn, converting to decimal.

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 47 bytes

Recursive function with tests

```php
function f($n,$c){return$n>0?f($n-$c,$c)*$n:1;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY9NDoMgEEb3nIIaErWZNqhN/2z1ILZpDMHYDRLAlfHsFohYFsObl28CI3u5PGppazcKZr6DwF1CBBCWToqbUQkiKlo7dyDM6T0R96ycF2K4Nho/cYOwPU0BxRsCXgJSyAKe/3iDPGBG4Rr4RCGnW5NTKFz3LhHqBsVb1ifro63GntLJZ4mw3/CioTbtFdtUtirO@sFFj1gb9VFc8tYk8S4GG06tje1EbG@//@qil4hKNCNUV8sP)

---

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 54 bytes

Loop version (original answer)

```php
for($n=$argv[1],$f=1;$n>0;$f*=$n,$n-=$argv[2]);echo$f;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAk0/KLNFTybFUSi9LLog1jdVTSbA2tVfLsDKxV0rRsVfJ0VPJ0obJGsZrWqckZ@Spp1v///7f8bwQA)

---

First argument is the the base value and second one is the factorial count.

Supports specified valid range, but outputs big numbers in scientific notation. For example the last sample is shown as `4.1697106428257E+31`.

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 35 bytes

```javascript
(n,i,f=i)=>i-n<1?f:r(n,i-n,f*(i-n))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fcxNDoIwEAXgfU/RZUsG@0NpwYiehSCYGtKaQrw@tmpCwMTZTDLfm3dvn@3UBfuYc@ev/dJ5N804NAtxYGFoLG3ONncncRmOId1yB0NG4qL0HfZjfxj9jQQioaYUp2EMF4hlWxbAVxZoj3pFIzn6U12rcscViG935N9nDurDUSu@5yKyTBxVCV0bwbWSlSyNjOHtZGxRHHD5Ag)

Answer (score 1):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), 50 bytes

```forth
: f 1 1 2over / 1+ 0 do 2over i * - 1 max * loop ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYxdCsIwEITfc4qhj0riJhVRC94lpI2KlV3S@nP7uC2y8M0My0zmMt/sNS9S6xkZXi/weyjYwW9B6Pmf79jA6vcZv@pGZkGnFUHoX4LpE9XBFbQLXAPYCxpddEjjEMs0x/RAKuhMqytiaOVh5UmrYjzhqLInBILUHw)

#### Code Explanation

```forth
: f                \ start a new word definition
  1 1              \ add placeholder and accumulator to stack
  2over / 1+       \ get the number of times to run the loop (num/factorial + 1)
  0 do             \ start loop from 0 to num/factorial
    2over          \ copy num and factorial to the top of the stack
    i * -          \ get the current number to multiply by (num - factorial * i)
    1 max          \ make sure it can't be 0 or negative [set to 1 if it is]
    *              \ multiply accumulator by result
  loop             \ end loop
;                  \ end the word definition
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-Mbigint -p`, 45 bytes

```perl
$b=s/!//g;$\=1*$_||1;$\*=$_ while($_-=$b)>0}{
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18lybZYX1FfP91aJcbWUEslvqbGEMjUslWJVyjPyMxJ1VCJ17VVSdK0M6it/v/fQBEL@JdfUJKZn1f8X9fXVM/A0ABIJ2WmZ@aV/NctAAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
å▐█ΩV∟
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=86dedbea561c&i=3+%093%0A1+%090%0A1+%096%0A2+%099%0A8+%0910%0A20%0940%0A30%09420&a=1&m=2)

It takes input in the form `{count} {base}`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Gaia](https://github.com/splcurran/Gaia), 6 bytes

```
…)¦v%Π
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0/MTPz//1HDMs1Dy8pUzy34/9@AyxgA)

Takes input as `n`, `k`, so input of `3 4` would be `3!!!!`.

```
…	 push [0...n-1], or [] if n == 0
 )¦	 increment each value (does nothing if [])
   v	 reverse list
    %	 take every k'th element
     Π	 product; product([]) = 1.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) + coreutils, 27

```bash
seq -s\* $[$1+!$1] -$2 1|bc
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcPLCsIwEAXQ/f2KK8zCB4WZpKjFT1EXrUmpICkmCxfVb489cIa@THXc7rjUEt9sym1PuYodNmJ3NuJo3@FRf/hMz1dkjn1gYr4wzBgpiZIR5hSrp8LTr09QGo7rjg6mPKNVOkXrlF7xBw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org), <s>150</s> <s>145</s> 129 bytes

```lua
i=io.read()p,c=i.gsub(i,"!","")p=p+0
function f(n,c)r=1 if n~=0 then
while(n>0) do r=r*n n=n-c
end
end
return r end
print(f(p,c))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY7LCsIwEEX3/YppVonGEsGl8zE1DztQJmFM6M5fj1bElRfO4sBZ3LXNvRNSniTOQZtiPdJ0f7SbJqtGZZUyBcvRDamxr5QZkmbrjeAZKAE/0UFdIg/bQmvUuxsIGQTlwMDIJ//prt@M0Q2Rww@JtQmDwC5FiKtO@v3CmN4vbvyzFw)

Ported from Charlie's ArnoldC psuedocode.
*-16 bytes thanks to Charlie*

Comment: You can submit only the function as answer, which can also be [improved](https://tio.run/##bY27DsIwDAD3foWbyYFQBYnV/EvJg1qqnMgkYuPXQ8XMSTfcdHtfBxOXRdMa0VYXiJfnqz@QnZmNM8ZWqmc/cpfQuAhkFBes0hU4g3zIQ9uSTO@N94Ry9xZiASU9CQjJJUxJ4k9NrauAwhGjKkvDjMfQ2nHz8x@@).

Comment: @Charlie, Yeah when I get more comfy with the idea of headers and footers in TIO, I'll experiment a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/) (Input as string), 82 bytes

```python
m=lambda n,s:n<1or n*m(n-s,s)
f=lambda x:int(m(int(x.split("!")[0]),x.count("!")))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bU1LCsIwFNy/U/RllSexpLYIFnsAzyAuqlIsNK@hSSGePjb4oQtnMQwzw4x9@sfIZQxNz3b2kqJphtZc723GytV8LMYp442RvHXKEXTfNNQ9e2lk4pA7O/ReChR01hdSIb@NM78Nomin1OpkIAIhxCk9uRpKRASNsEc4LKrQ@AFUP7kGVLu//qqxrMdl6wU)

Note: the outer `int()` in `f` is solely for the fact that without it, `0!` will output `True`

Comment: Nice approach! `True == 1` in Python, so without conversion it is still valid.

Answer (score 1):

## Regex  ([RME](https://github.com/Davidebyzero/RegexMathEngine/) / PCRE2 <sub><sup>v10.35+</sup></sub>), 25 bytes

```
^(x+),((?*x+)(?>\1|.*))*$
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=hVbdTuNGFL5unuLgrciMY2gSWkRjDGIhEki7sMoGdbtALeNMEgt7bNnj5afltg_Q2970ppf7AO2btJd9kp75seOQVI2wPT_nfOd3vuHXz2EWl4V8_FkYfr6ytuIszFl_a8-6-Wv0asKmEWfw7ng07PvHFydD__L8bOx_d3YyPoW91quIh3E5YbCvlLbnB61wHuTgZ1c34MHIen1_f3e7U37_-PhhPN-9n5PfSzHd2vvjB_LQoQ4hhzZ-yeHBde-nbZtS-0u9__cXm_SlquWAnXl-1um5DbuFyCM-k4YXa1GKqyxIDlbkDloRF5DhUPgsz9OchCkvBCin7YQVRTBjFH4sxGQwCFEC9vfBLMuhWmd8EruQM1HmHHru8wqmnIfphDlwm6YxpN40iAsJq8wYuKv-N7s3bgvwF02BqPz5M2YwfCNFNA7RBbg8Pj0a7dnUbDpQRE8snZLa8a-qlYY8pVRZkT-SwqEOIkxLAQOoA6UyPEupgfJgANaL4JWyZaGWdc0tWudjis0z15HUSWk9t0peRDPOJhCnfKZfAS_uWe6qhCWPfhjEMbphYjcz_zZOwzuwQwc-pdEE7EkgAsydTJIcgucBkTs23VxgUIPd6dSV6ZrKJEHECQIoB7MrbISYcZLRrd6N13V1CLo7IAs9ixwOLBdHHS_THwv78xifDYrrJSLu9H2BRUVdCT_DgYJuAkU8K4VUV4FhCcHOWTVPAhHOfRWLvRhrtJwVZSwcXQLXnLv3Zx-HamU6LRhuYrwYwkzMlwTs9BMLBWqZSuD5q-wnWRQzYpri_bvxiGbhduijs4Q6BuPjcHThj4ejt2fnR-PhSbU8_DAenp_I-abyyXyNJ1266OCNHBvQ5L55GtTbyDVC91ay4eM8EMyf5mniZ4EQLOckxy4_v3zzxgA0dfDoCvYgMInVyFu3b2DJCgpGULdgBeE0-tJZ12cvAbSpOEqiJshWj7oNoQnLxP8K5Sws8yJK-VpBZXaa5qDY5anuXGSMGBma6IMccUf3HnWrjq_K80QB1yUDkfY1b6PpJ6_nqi2lsS2Zg1DP61KQliNeMneBgEax56RZzZXFYq_2KksLFFiyXOlydu-jvgMcixSINDJGTRNCRypTd1lP0iKuvoCrz5qiMMlajuWuSqAdIl21KZYfaxeSAgtq_MBN-e5ADx8uzffoGowrFOp05E3WdtrL-8_AkNPXubYwnGi7DaNrTT0vzRKWYDeQAgVVwtoPbcwalkt5IzE0mvSqaoIqE3wZGJOHQjrReI1PCEbhqFXlRJVgyagN8hoMuMr6LebtztXinqT0VX-XywD__PwLIEdqJlbu1ZKa15YPqDrbTVLCAqmQu-pvQQw4NmehkTnpvEbd78LmprGw4RnaGo0uRv75xduj8fEpXc5Kg5squhV5yRrYsrRLOkuBmvjWXH_P_8VRyGmMkUUUq9ynBeo5bV4eehPptb7btN94y-p_l377c8fZafWcLj67rb7zbWvP6XVb_a7zdVdL_As) - PCRE2
[Try it on replit.com!](https://replit.com/@Davidebyzero/regex-Repeated-Factorials) - RegexMathEngine, in ECMAScript+`(?*)`+`(?>)` mode

Takes its input in unary, as two strings of `x` characters whose lengths represent the numbers, in the order {factorial count, base value}, joined/delimited by a `,`. Returns its output as the number of ways the regex can match. (The rabbit emoji indicates this output method.)

```
^(x+),      # \1 = input factorial count; tail = input base value
(
    (?*x+)  # Assert tail > 0; multiply the number of possible matches by tail
    (?>     # Atomic group – lock in this match once it's finished
        \1  # tail -= \1
    |       # or
        .*  # tail = 0
    )
)*          # Iterate the above as many times as possible, minimum zero
$           # Assert tail == 0
```

## Regex  ([RME](https://github.com/Davidebyzero/RegexMathEngine/) / PCRE2 <sub><sup>v10.35+</sup></sub>), 26 bytes

```
^((?=(x*).*,\2)(?*x+)\2)*,
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=hVbLbttGFF1XX3HNANYMRbuS3BquaNpwbAE2kNiBIqNpbJegqZFEmBwS5DB-FN7mA7Ltppsu8wP5k3bZL-mdBynKUlFBpOZx77nPOaPfv4ZZXBby8Wdh-PXK2oqzMGf9rT3r5q_RqwmbRpzBu-PRsO8fX5wM_cvzs7H_89nJ-BT2Wq8iHsblhMG-UtqeH7TCeZCDn13dgAcj6_X9_d3tTvnL4-OH8Xz3fk7-LMV0a-_br4QceuTBptu2c92n5NB-6FAc2I4W-Pu7TfpS13LAzjw_6_TchuFC5BGfScuLtSjFVRYkBytyB62IC8hwKHyW52lOwpQXApTXdsKKIpgxCr8VYjIYhCgB-_tgluVQrTM-iV3ImShzDj33eQVTzsN0why4TdMYUm8axIWEVWYM3FX_x90btwX4iaZAVAL9GTMYvpEiGofoClwenx6N9mxqNh0ooieWTknt-PfVSkOeUqqsyA9J4VAHEaalgAHUgVIZnqXUQHkwAOtF8ErZslDLuuYWrfMxxe6Z60jqpLSeWyUvohlnE4hTPtOvgBf3LHdVwpJHPwziGN0wsZuZfxun4R3YoQOf0mgC9iQQAeZOJkkOwfOAyB2bbi4wqMHudOrKdE1lkiDiBAGUg9kVNkLMOMnoVu_G67o6BN0dkIWeRQ4HloujjpfpHwvb8xifDYrrJSLu9H2BRUVdCT_DgYJuAkU8K4VUV4FhCcHOWTVPAhHOfRWLvRhrtJwVZSwcXQLXHLz3Zx-HamU6LRhuYrwYwkzMlwTs9BMLBWqZSuABrOwnWRQzYpri_bvxiGbhduijs4Q6BuPjcHThj4ejt2fnR-PhSbU8_DAenp_I-abyyfwaT7p00cEbOTagyX3zNKi3kWuE7q1kw8d5IJg_zdPEzwIhWM5Jjl1-fvnmjQFo6uDRFexBYBKrkbdu38CSFRSMoG7BCsJp9KWzrs9eAmhTcZRETZCtHnUbQhOWif8VyllY5kWU8rWCyuw0zUGxy1PducgYMVI00Qc54o7uPepWHV-V54kCrksGIu1r3kbTT17PVVtKY1syB6Ge16UgLUe8ZO4CAY1iz0mzmiuLxV7tVZYWKLBkudLl7N5HfQc4FikQaWSMmiaEjlSm7rKepEVcfQFXnzVFYZK1HMtdlUA7RLpqUyw_1i4kBRbU-IGb8t2BHj5cmu_RNRhXKNTpyKus7bSX95-BIaevc21hONF2G0bXmnpemiUswW4gBQqqhLUf2pg1LJfyRmJoNOlV1QRVJvgyMCYPhXSi8R6fEIzCUavKiSrBklEb5DUYcJX1W8zbnavFPUnpq_4ulwH--fwFkCM1Eyv3aknNa8sHVJ3tJilhgVTIXfVdEAOOzVloZE46r1H3u7C5aSxseIa2RqOLkX9-8fZofHxKl7PS4KaKbkVesga2LO2SzlKgJr4119_zf3EUchpjZBHFKvdpgXpOm5eH3kR6re827Tfesvrv0h_fdpydVtfptXbx-cnpt3pdZ6_1Q9fpd7XEvw) - PCRE2
[Try it on replit.com!](https://replit.com/@Davidebyzero/regex-Repeated-Factorials-26-bytes) - RegexMathEngine, in ECMAScript+`(?*)` mode

Takes the two numbers in the order {base value, factorial count}. Although this is 1 byte longer, it does not need an atomic group to be this length, using an atomic lookahead instead.

```
^             # tail = input base value
(
    (?=       # Atomic lookahead
        (x*)  # \2 = maximum value ≤ tail for which the following matches:
        .*,   # tail = input factorial count
        \2    # Assert tail ≥ \2
    )
    (?*x+)    # Assert tail > 0; multiply the number of possible matches by tail
    \2        # tail -= \2
)*            # Iterate the above as many times as possible, minimum zero
,             # Assert tail == 0
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
RrẈhp
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPVJyJUUxJUJBJTg4aHAmZm9vdGVyPSZpbnB1dD00MjAlMEEzMCZmbGFncz1l)

##### Explanation

```python
RrẈhp  # Implicit input
Rr     # Push the range [n..1]
  Ẉ    # Uninterleave into k pieces
   hp  # Product of first group
       # Implicit output
```