# Knook to Mate... With Portals!

Tags: code-golf, chess

*Alternatively: Now you're checking with portals!*

*[Inspired this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/256814/knight-to-fork)*

I am somewhat of a self-declared [Chess Anarchist](https://www.reddit.com/r/AnarchyChess/). That means that when I play chess, en passant is forced (else the brick gets used), double check is mate (and [pasta](https://www.reddit.com/r/AnarchyChess/comments/ylrn7m/new_chess_rule_just_dropped/)), and all sorts of new pieces and squares are added to the game.

One such piece is the [Knook](https://www.reddit.com/r/AnarchyChess/comments/xv6q0s/white_to_move_and_mate_in_1/) (also called an "Empress" or "Chancellor" in fairy chess). It moves like a horsey and a rook combined. Another common addition are portals, like the kinds you see in the [Portal](https://store.steampowered.com/app/400/Portal/) series. They behave as you would expect.

Therefore, in this challenge, I'll be give you the position of a white knook, two black kings and an orange and blue portal. You'll give me the square I should move my knook to in order to check both the kings at once and win the game.

### Detailed Explanation of Knooks and Portals

#### The Knook

Here is how a knight moves in chess:

[image]

Here is how a rook moves in chess:

[image]

Therefore, this is how a knook (knight + rook) moves in chess:

[image]

In BCPS notation, it's move is `EM`. In Parlett notation, it's move is `n+, ~ 1/2`. In Betza notation, it's move is `RN`.

#### Portals

From the [Portal Wiki](https://theportalwiki.com/wiki/Portals):

> Portals in a pair act as a direct link between one another. Anything that goes into one portal comes instantly out the other.

Therefore, when a piece moves into a portal, it comes out the other portal. Portals occupy a single square. There are only ever two portals on a board - one orange and one blue. Pieces cannot land on a portal, as they'd just infinitely teleport between the orange and blue portals. Pieces can also attack through portals (so a piece in a position where another piece could exit a portal would be able to be taken.)

Here's are some examples of how a rook would move through a portal. Note that it always exits the other portal in the direction it entered the first portal. Note that the rook also cannot "jump" over the portal - it has to go through if there is a portal in its way.

| [image] | [image] |
| --- | --- |

Here's how a knight would move through portals. Note that it can either move two squares into a portal and exit one square in a perpendicular direction, or one square into a portal and exit two squares in a perpendicular direction.

| [image] | [image] |
| --- | --- |

Therefore, this is how a knook would move through a portal, obeying laws of both the rook and knight portal movement rules:

| [image] | [image] |
| --- | --- |

### An Example

On the following board, the knook is on square `b2`, the black kings are on `d7` and `f6` and the portals are on squares `b5` and `d2`. The winning move is to move the knook through the blue portal to d5, which checks the king on `d7` via rook moves and the king on `f6` via knight moves.

[image]

On the following board, the knook is on square `c5`, the black kings are on `g3` and `h4` and the portals are on squares `f7` and `g4`. The winning move is to move the knook to `d7`, as the knook threatens to take the king on `h4` with rook moves after portal travel and threatens to take the king on `g3` with knight moves after portal travel.

[image]

On the following board, the knook is on square `f4`. The black kings are on `b8` and `d3`. The portals are on squares `f6` and `a4`. The winning move is to move the knook through the portal on `d6` and exit the portal on `a4` via a knight move (up 2, right 1). This checks both kings.

[image]

### Rules

- The positions will be given in algebraic chess notation (letter then number of the square).
- The winning move will be returned in algebraic chess notation.
- Positions can be given and returned in any reasonable and convienient format, including:

  - A list of strings (e.g. `["f4", "b8", "d3", "f6", "a4"]`)
  - A list of list of strings (e.g. `[["f", "4"], ["b", "8"], ["d", "3"], ["f", "6"], ["a", "4"]]`)
  - A list of list of numbers that represent the character codes of each string item (e.g. `[[102, 52], [98, 56], [100, 51], [102, 54], [97, 52]]`)
  - A list of string, number pairs (e.g. `[["f", 4], ["b", 8], ["d", 3], ["f", 6], ["a", 4]]`)
- Input formats and output formats don't have to match, so long as they are consistent.
- Piece positions can be taken in any order (e.g. `[portal 1, portal 2, knook, king 1, king 2]` or `[knook, king 1, king 2, portal 1, portal 2]`)
- This doesn't change much, but you can assume that the black kings will [never be on the `c2` square](https://www.reddit.com/r/chessbeginners/comments/y57x1y/i_cant_move_king_to_c2_why/).
- You may assume that there will always be at least one solution to each input.
- The board layout may start with 0 or 1 king(s) already in check. Your goal is to double check.
- Double check is strictly defined as checking both kings for this challenge. A knook checking a king through a portal and starting in check is counted as a single check only for simplicity.
- It doesn't matter if a king can capture the knook if double check is achieved. All that matters is that both kings are in check at the same time.
- If there is more than one solution, you can output one, or all of the solutions.
- Portal travel might not be required for a winning move. Double check via normal knook movement is just as valid as portal usage.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in bytes in each language wins.

### Testcases

*Input order is `[knook, king 1, king 2, portal 1, portal 2]`*

```
Positions -> Winning Square
["b2", "d7", "f6", "b5", "d2"] -> "d5"
["c5", "g3", "h4", "f7", "g4"] -> "d7"
["f4", "b8", "d3", "f6", "a4"] -> "a4"
["h1", "a1", "a3", "c1", "f1"] -> "b1"
["c2", "a8", "h8", "d2", "d6"] -> "d8"
["d2", "c6", "g2", "b2", "g7"] -> "g6"
["d3", "f6", "h6", "d4", "e4"] -> "g4"
["c4", "f7", "h5", "a2", "f5"] -> "b2" // Attacks through the portal
["h5", "a7", "e2", "a4", "g6"] -> "g3" // Attacks a7 through the portal and e2 normally.
["h6", "d4", "g3", "a1", "a8"] -> "f5" // No portal travel needed
```

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman as stated in the introduction: "double check is mate (and pasta)". This isn't your regular chess game. This is the anarchist's game! Therefore, it doesn't matter if a king can take the knook. Also, it's stated in the rules that there may be more than one solution.

Comment: you actually put all the anarchy chess memes into a codegolf challenge what has this world come to

Comment: An interesting way this differs from the linked challenge is that, on top of the portals, the rook movement means the board size can't be ignored for a lot of approaches.

Comment: Can the knook choose to not use a portal? For example if it's on f3 and there is a portal on d3 can it move to d2 or c3?

Comment: @loopywalt as shown in the last test case, portal travel is not required

Comment: @lyxal  Sorry, I should have phrased more clearly. What I mean is If the portal is directly in the path of a "normal" move can the knook still make the normal move or will it be sucked into the portal?

Comment: @loopywalt if it's a knight move, it can jump over the portal. Rooks however will go through the portal

Comment: Can I rook pass king? and add all possible output to test. and is there case where u can't get to somewhere check cuzof portal

Comment: @l4m2 knooks can move past kings on their way to the final place. Only one output is required - it's optional to output all valid moves. There will always be a square to move to that delivers double check

Comment: I mean you list all possible outputs so they can check if answer is correct.

Comment: In the `["d3", "f6", "h6", "d4", "e4"]` test case I assume `"e6"` is not a valid answer?

Comment: @Neil that's right, because it only checks a single king. Both kings need to be checked at the same time

Comment: For what it's worth, your 'knook' is a fairly widely known "fairy chess" piece; it is most commonly called "Empress", "Marshall", or "Chancellor". See https://www.chessvariants.com/piececlopedia.dir/rook-knight.html

Comment: @JeffZeitlin I mention that in the introduction :p

Comment: @lyxal - Sorry 'bout that; not sure how I missed it...

Comment: Is it allowed to land on one king and check another?

Comment: @l4m2 no. It needs to attack both kings at once without capturing either.

Comment: In a normal chess board, knight moving is a single step instead of "move 2 steps in one direction and then move 1 step in another direction". Otherwise, the knight should be blocked if there are some other pieces in the middle of moving, and therefore move B1-C3 at the beginning should be invalid.

Comment: I'm familiar with definition "move length 1, rotate 45 degree, move length sqrt(2)", maybe because knight in Chinese chess(horse) get blocked by it and therefore not an usual expression for chess

Comment: Downvoted because bad test case costing my extra time(`b6` is valid answer for 1st case, and I thought it rook pass portal)

Comment: @l4m2 https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/257236/knook-to-mate-with-portals?noredirect=1#comment568823_257236

Comment: Can the knight only pass through the portal on the square that it turns i.e. `"f5"` is not a valid answer for `["d3", "f6", "h6", "d4", "e4"]` (would need to move up 1 square, pass through the portal, move up a second square and then right 1 square)?

Comment: @Neil that's right. After portal travel, the knight has to move in a direction perpendicular to the direction it entered, as indicated in the images for knight portal movement

Answer (score 7):

## Python3, 970 bytes:

```py
M=[((1,0),1,3),((0,1),0,2),((-1,0),1,3),((0,-1),0,2)]
def A(c):
 q=[(c[0],i,1,[c[0]])for i,*_ in M]+[(c[0],[(i,2),(M[j][0],1)],0,[c[0]])for i,*J in M for j in J]+[(c[0],[(i,1),(M[j][0],2)],0,[c[0]])for i,*J in M for j in J]
 while q:
  (x,y),m,o,P=q.pop(0)
  if o:
   X,Y=m
   if 0<=x+X<8 and 0<=y+Y<8:
    if(T:=(x+X,y+Y))in P:continue
    if T in c[1:3]:yield(1,T)
    elif T in c[-2:]:q+=[([*{*c[-2:]}-{T}][0],m,o,P+[T])]
    else:yield(0,T);q+=[(T,m,o,P+[T])]
  else:
   [(X,Y),C],*I=m
   if 0<=x+X<8 and 0<=y+Y<8:
    if(T:=(x+X,y+Y))in P:continue
    if C-1==0 and[]==I:yield(T in c[1:3],T)
    else:
     if T in c[-2:]and C-1:continue
     q+=[([T,[*{*c[-2:]}-{T}][0]][T in c[-2:]],[[[(X,Y),C-1]]+I,I][C-1==0],0,P+[T])]
def f(d):
 S,*c=[(8-int(b),ord(a)-97)for a,b in d]
 q,s=[S],[S]
 while q:
  S=q.pop(0)
  for x,y in A([S]+c):
   q+=[y]
   if x==0:
    k=[[],[]]
    for X,Y in A([y]+c):k[X]+=[Y]
    if{*k[1]}=={*([1]+c)[1:3]}:return chr(97+y[1])+str(8-y[0])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVNNb@JADL3zK0acZpLJKoG2pFnmUPVEJaRK5NBqNFpBPkgKJRColgjx21nbSUWI9rCHvYwc@z3b72G21SErNkN/W14uU6U596QrpCeHQnLuSk9IVw4wdm4LTlMxvThJ2ROPRNBjO2gQadfIHIAaIyPSomS5tH6xfMOmxm4AmufUdqo/DH57wkC7W8oLURh@fWD4csP2WuzBP7F77HeWrxO2g00ZP8pKyE9ZyFe1@7EtttwVkM5TVmCZvcl39YkBZNyxOtpvY5/NNzF@VPb72CcUVHkYKA5lCVkhYNBrEBWbQ775ShoEC3F@pL1gaIIqT9YxmBwKqibra90ZBCbY2eChtk5W/X12TuGZNNKqtg4NWF4z90nTzYVuP4kYdmAEQrjmIEjIZyOtyX/T9ex4SrnI1kapSbNNS@1VZbNG2w6Uh4Ohy21nVnsQyr/YYHSLDYegv4U5njH2RE6MrrfCg/j2AS805TFe6ExaETT3nXxz4AshizLmc@E8juhs5nKB3WOwbif3Ss9gwuz2bmbta0EO3BFynjggbfoX1AIq07h8hG1q8SulNXQ09Q@IZNi9IVdEXuk3A9x301h8slbaM2elThaHACDk6zkok8NXCT5kJX8c2RXUhL0/lCCsApfEZVuiwJTr/mLQl6wfj/BNH/Bd3FNm0DdC9K7AiNLLIb7ZHcGJtLzrAFMqLnzqMrz2nXeBmUfp@iVgRHHqdUfTjnPqmPnNdvg@dIB1OqJxS4prectRF9jaK6M3pq2T7o5RS2lGDsypY3rfFVMXCZgMGr04urtje1ztZuOAj8DLHw)

Comment: I think replacing the `continue`s with `0`s and then replacing the next `if`s with `elif`s will save a few bytes. (The TIO link is too long to put in this comment.)

Comment: i.e. `if(T:=(x+X,y+Y))in P:continue`; `if T in c[1:3]:yield(1,T)` becomes `if(T:=(x+X,y+Y))in P:0`; `elif T in c[1:3]:yield(1,T)` and you can do the same for the other one.

Comment: `"d5", "d2", "d4", "e5", "e6"` should be `"e4"`

Answer (score 4):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 367 bytes

```javascript
(R,J,K,$,_)=>(
  U=p=>parseInt(p,36),     // internal type
  P=U($),Q=U(_),           // Portal
  g=n=>(                   // p^P^Q switch P and Q
    M=(p,a,b)=>a?M((p+=a)-P&&p-Q?p:p^P^Q,b):p==n,
                           // Two movements for knight
    h=(p,x)=>
      [1,2,-1,-2].some((i,_,o)=>o.some(j=>
        i*i-j*j&&M(U(p),i*36,j)|M(U(p),j,i*36)
      ))|                  // X then Y; Y then X
      (e=(w,i=24,q=U(p))=>q-U(x)?
                           // Maximum 13 moves + w%36 range 8
        (q+=w)-P&&q-Q?
          w%36<i&&q==n|e(w,i-1,q)
        :
          e(w,i,q^P^Q)     // Not counting teleport don't hurt
      )(36)|e(-36)|e(1)|e(-1):0
  )(R)&h(J,K)&h(K,J)&~-n%36<8&
  !~[J,K,$,_].indexOf(N=n.toString(36))?N:g(-~n)
)(360)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVFdb9pAEHzvr6AotXbJGrAhBLk9kKpWVRJBIRVPUYKM8cdZ6dkGGnhA/HV6t7ZU1Phlb@9mZnd2L/Xf/G2wkfnOVtk6PH/7/nXxQ3QpEmd4pHt6oCtaohjBQuRilPubbXindpBTb4A0Ewu4QprrY4kUC6V5E6FBn1Za448nAPm18NGeWVZuz8e5l7/MXuYa9XIhFCWGfNDUJ4dcsh2y3ef2NvsdAkhaUqaRrLynYiRb0k5bqWVNYAE5kmz1BpTisbqm/ICIRwgF7EkKt0@FMJguU9gLOOAYimuxZzuFtrP/1Bt8kTrXXo6h0WgLBXqcUmGsotdF0GU1bJeHw7mDCI9ofTw9VTt6bku1Dg8/I5gK1d5lv3YbqWIjRSsBTTLHA92jdbKV6TscT70Y7JNC06CL588fgkxts9ew/ZrFEEFz5Tap0VzfmhgNTFzd8IvbRHzHDhiLeyYmfdawMu7XsSNmrIZcr/evg1/LThzGysjsgPPIqXXCvn2unQwrxyYO6tglFnD3mPNy7vi2ln3hNeG45knC0nen87@Xi00kvCGfq0c3ht/odBrTrKEFf3YyU@/GLgUsDt1qPcZa7SCXdspvqBY2NOzzXw)

[Modified](https://tio.run/##bVFdb9pAEHzvr2hRau2StYVt4iCnB1LVqGoiCKTiCRFkjD@Vnm1AhQfEX6d3a6RYlV92925md@fm8uBvsAu3Wbk3ZbGJLj8ev89/ih7FsbjAKz3RM93QCsUQ5qIUwzLY7qJfcg8luR7SVMzhBmmm0gopEVIM5dD1uvZgtFj6MBaKF9BatQejMUB5KwI0p4ZRmrNR6Zdv07eZQv1SCEmpJh8VdWGTQ6ZNprO0dsWfCCCjFRUKKepzLoZZNzPzbm4YY5hDiZR1XY9yPF2POV8g4gkiAQfKhNOnSmhMjanMORxxBNWtOLCcSsk5fHW9b5mqlZZTpHuUhAp9LqnSUtHvIaixCjbrZHNtI8IrGl/Oi6tdSyuTm@j4EsNESGtf/N5vM5noVjRSUCSdnukJjbMp9V5l14Qsy0rAPEtc@nXWy3p4eYgFKExbExZyV7xH1nuRJHBUn1QD@KkJiMahCYhsNwkmzRuIobN2OvS5s7nXMfZ0XN/xjdNBfPifHTKWuDqmfe7hzqTfxo6ZsR7wPPdjQ9DKTm3G6sjskOvYblXCugOenQ6uinX02tg1FvL2hOv63cl9K7uhNeW44ZdErbrDhg8p@xPw7Piu9ZU1g9mRc3VDK2nV3dxeu371Z6DZl38) to list all possible outputs

```javascript
[ 'b2', 'd7', 'f6', 'b5', 'd2' ] [ 'b6', 'd5', 'd6' ]
[ 'c5', 'g3', 'h4', 'f7', 'g4' ] [ 'd7', 'f5', 'h5' ]
[ 'f4', 'b8', 'd3', 'f6', 'a4' ] [ 'b4' ]
[ 'h1', 'a1', 'a3', 'c1', 'f1' ] [ 'b1', 'c2' ]
[ 'c2', 'a8', 'h8', 'd2', 'd6' ] [ 'c8', 'd8' ]
[ 'd2', 'c6', 'g2', 'b2', 'g7' ] [ 'a7', 'c2', 'c7', 'e7', 'g6' ]
[ 'd3', 'f6', 'h6', 'd4', 'e4' ] [ 'g4' ]
[ 'c4', 'f7', 'h5', 'a2', 'f5' ] []
[ 'h5', 'a7', 'e2', 'a4', 'g6' ] [ 'g3' ]
[ 'h6', 'd4', 'g3', 'a1', 'a8' ] [ 'f5', 'g4' ]
```

Comment: `"d5", "d2", "d4", "e5", "e6"` should be `"e4"`

Comment: @tsh Fast fixed

Comment: seem new issue that die in

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>194</s> 163 bytes

```
ＵＭθ⍘ι⁴⁰≔Ｅ²⊟θδＦ⁸ＦＥ⁸⁺κ⁺⁴⁰¹×⁴⁰ι¿¬№⁺θδκ«≔⟦⟧ηＦθ«≔⊙⊞ＯΦ⟦δ⮌δ⟧⬤⟦κλ⟧№⟦¹¦²¦⁴⁰¦⁸⁰⟧↔⁻ξ§μπυ№⟦³⁸¦⁴²¦⁷⁹¦⁸¹⟧↔⁻⁻λκ↨μ±¹ζＦ⟦¹¦⁴⁰±¹±⁴⁰⟧«≔κεＦ¹⁵«≧⁺με≧⁺⁼λεζ¿№δε≦⁻Σδε¿‹⁰⌕θε≔⁰μ»»⊞ηζ»¿⌊η⟦⍘κ⁴⁰
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVJNa@MwED07v2LIaQQqJK27m7KnbGmh0I/Q9mZ8cOtJLCLbsWWXtkt/u3dGcszC1mBJaN68eU8zr0XWvtaZHYa77HBZl2VW5dho@J05eupaU@3QaIgXSv2arZ0zuwoZiKcaNvUBG6U05Bza1i3gSoHfBbBigO0d7sc9Xiw1PJuS5KjBKPnAbAHv6w4v677q0AMbIdSwl/CfWTTWTFINBdeJfIHGh46xdfWBm94VDwdqs65u8drYjlpMcg2P9EatI8wVE6ytxYQFWT6HigmLOhV7GlYLQby42vYd4Z2pWMs733Q3VU7vWGo4eM2srVdT/hn7jJnh5wUzLP9nCKsVP@FNheiedhkjlke@TzEWnIkgUTNBpiO3IA22j77ZCfnMkLo8H8MRv3@APJpdEZ5VQzmhv49fNX1mvVSaJEWRNChYzSWgYMq9pW0X7Gl46kuUph0LkHXke3tLziHbuTZhqki6Osrn6zLgv2bhlyZiMRbnC2HgCqZk@oITNzyO/Ob/jObej2bK@K9hSJJ5fjbXMN/@kLXwax7LSvE8TYeTN/sX) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
ＵＭθ⍘ι⁴⁰
```

Inspired by @l4m2's use of base conversion, convert the inputs from "base 40" (chosen to make it easier for me to calculate the various constants).

```
≔Ｅ²⊟θδ
```

Split off the portal squares.

```
Ｆ⁸ＦＥ⁸⁺κ⁺⁴⁰¹×⁴⁰ι¿¬№⁺θδκ«
```

Loop over each potential square, converted into a "base 40" value, but excluding the input squares.

```
≔⟦⟧η
```

Start counting the number of pieces this square attacks.

```
Ｆθ«
```

Loop over the knook and the two kings.

```
≔⊙⊞ＯΦ⟦δ⮌δ⟧⬤⟦κλ⟧№⟦¹¦²¦⁴⁰¦⁸⁰⟧↔⁻ξ§μπυ№⟦³⁸¦⁴²¦⁷⁹¦⁸¹⟧↔⁻⁻λκ↨μ±¹ζ
```

Check whether the portals are near to the two squares (trying both permutations of squares near to different portals), then also considering the case of a regular knight's move away, see whether the squares are a knight's move away, and if any of the three cases succeeds then mark this square as attackable.

```
Ｆ⟦¹¦⁴⁰±¹±⁴⁰⟧«
```

Loop over all possible rook movements.

```
≔κε
```

Start at one square.

```
Ｆ¹⁵«
```

Repeat 15 times.

```
≧⁺με
```

Move one square in the current direction.

```
≧⁺⁼λεζ
```

If this is the target square then mark it as attackable.

```
¿№δε≦⁻Σδε
```

If it's a portal then jump through it.

```
¿‹⁰⌕θε≔⁰μ
```

If it's a king then stop moving.

```
»»⊞ηζ
```

Keep count of the number of pieces that were attackable.

```
»¿⌊η⟦⍘κ⁴⁰
```

Output the square if all three were attackable, meaning that the knook can move to this square, and from this square can check both kings.