# Play a sound, any sound

Tags: code-golf

Your program has to make the computer produce a sound, any sound.

Shortest code wins, not sooner than 10 days after the first valid answer. If there is a tie, the one submitted sooner, wins.

- The program should run on a reasonable, not too uncommon personal computer.
- Opening a pop-up, message box, etc. (for example, on a web page) does not count, as they might or might not produce a sound, depending on a lot of settings.
- Just entering a wrong command or invalid character on a console and receiving a warning beep does not count, just as the compiler/interpreter/OS beeping on an error or crash does not count either. Your code must be a valid program.

Comment: ^G aka system bell or OS beep may be suppressed on many systems too (e.g. switched to be a visible "bell") and should be handled like sounds of popus and so on too: Not a valid solution.

Comment: Every program that prints "\a" to a terminal fails if xterm uses a visible bell.

Comment: `rm /` will cause a lot of screaming.

Comment: My left fan has been dying noisily for a while. Would that be a valid 0 bit answer?

Comment: I think this question should be reopened. The joke answers that rely on the fan spinning or the CD tray opening are invalid, since the question says "play a sound". Seems pretty clear to me that the output needs to come from the speakers as a result of the program, not the OS or the user or the hardware.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

## dc, 2 chars

this one prints the bell character, too:

```
7P
```

Run with `$ dc <<< 7P` or save `7P` to file and run `$ dc file`.

Also:

## Befunge, 2 chars

Similar but infinitly looping and beeping:

```
7,
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate what language that is? I never heard about it, and its name is too short (and a very common abbreviation) to be efficiently searched for.

Comment: From the man-page: `dc  is  a  reverse-polish  desk calculator which supports unlimited precision arithmetic.` -- it's included in most linux/unix distros as far as I know.

Comment: A few more examples if you're interested: [1](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/7313/given-a-number-program-must-return-the-alphabet-letter-correspondent/7333#7333), [2](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/4676/code-golf-first-n-fibonacci-sequence-elements/6104#6104) and [3](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/4434/print-the-amount-of-ones-in-a-binary-number-without-using-bitwise-operators/8861#8861). Seen a few others use it here as well.

Comment: My bad for not elaborating what I mean under "language"

Comment: @vsz dc is – of course – turing complete, as any better calculator such as ghc should be.

Comment: Here no ^G produces a sound... ^G should not count as valid answer because it can be disabled like window-create and other OS sounds...

Comment: All sounds can be disabled. Just turn the volume down.

Answer (score 48):

## bash (13)

```
sudo rm -rf /
```

The faster the hard drive the better the sound. Don't work with SSDs.
**(Don't try this at home, `sudo rm -rf /` erases everything on your hard drive)**

Comment: I think that one should come with a disclaimer -- "Don't try this at home" :D

Comment: Yeah, that's the sound when your computer *r*eads your *m*ail *r*eally *f*ast (rm -rf).

Comment: Wait, you got it wrong. The task is to make the _computer_ produce a sound, not the user... though I have to admit that scream was quite impressive...

Comment: It doesn't do anything without `--no-preserve-root`, except maybe on ancient systems.

Comment: @nyuszika7h ancient as in before 2005.

Comment: The warning _Don't try this at home.._ is misleading - someone might try this e.g. in `/tmp/` instead of `~/`, which would be equally harmful (:

Comment: *Don't try this at home* so it's OK *at work*...

Answer (score 43):

## *sh (5)

```
eject
```

(does not work if you have no CD/DVD or similar drive..)

Comment: I like this one. But, on my Mac (Mac OS X), the command is not found : `sh: eject: command not found`

Comment: Nicolas: right, on Mac, the eject "command" seems to be much shorter: [⏏](https://www.google.com/search?q=mac+eject-key&tbm=isch) (:

Comment: @ mykhal — If you go this way, I have a solution that works on all modern Macs : [](http://www.woowoomac.com/storage/post-images/adjust-volume-mac-keyboard.png?__SQUARESPACE_CACHEVERSION=1286394681886)

Comment: This fails with OpenBSD. `usage: eject [-t] device` The device argument is not optional! The shortest that works here is `eject cd0` for 9 characters. Also, if the drive has no tray (as with a slot-loading drive), then `eject cd0` makes no noise unless a disc is in the drive.

Comment: kernigh: you're right. on the other hand, it might succeed on many systems without a sound card or speaker, where most of the other solutions would fail

Answer (score 36):

### Befunge, 0

If I read the spec correctly, this is an endless loop.
Endless loop = you'll hear your CPU cooler spin up.

Answer (score 27):

### sh 7

```
w|aplay
```

Plays a short noise.

Also 7:

```
aplay *
```

### Assembly

Another non-bell solution. Resulting binary is just 15 bytes.

```
mov al, 182
out 43h, al
out 42h, al
mov al, 16
out 42h, al
mov al, 3
out 61h, al
ret
```

Assemble with `nasm sound.asm -o sound.com`. Can be tried with `dosbox sound.com`.

Comment: +1 for not just relying on a terminal to translate BEL characters to beeps.

Answer (score 25):

### brainfuck: 8

```
+++++++.
```

Prints the bell character.

Comment: +1 BF Solution both understandable AND shorter than C.

Comment: A brainfuck is easier to mentally digest than C... we should learn from this incident.

Answer (score 22):

#### bash (Mac OS X) 5

```
say a
```

although stylistically I prefer the somewhat longer:

```
say 'Hello, Code Golf !'
```

Comment: If your Mac is set to English, you could also do `say 'hahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahaj'`.

Comment: Oooh... I've got ssh access to an osx box...

Comment: This command works in AppleScript. I did not know it works in the Terminal too. Funny with ssh !

Comment: Corollary on Linux: `espeak`...

Answer (score 18):

Haha, good ol' QBASIC code.

```
BEEP
```

Comment: Ah, the fun that could be had with the PLAY command! For reminiscence, see e.g. [this video](http://youtu.be/5pwxjJAMjo8?t=3m54s).

Comment: I'm 15, xD. We learned QBASIC in school.

Answer (score 16):

## Python 3.3.3, one character

```
<bell character>
```

The error message will contain a bell character, causing the sound.

## Python 3.3.3, 10 characters

If errors are not allowed, this solution won't output the error message, only the sound.

```
print('<bell character>')
```

Comment: Why the downvote, this code actually produces a sound.

Comment: 1 char O_o nice +1

Answer (score 13):

#### Golfscript 3

```
'.'
```

*(where the `.` is in fact a BELL character)*

The HEX representation of the above code is:

```
27 07 27
```

Comment: Ouch, Golfscript strikes again!

Answer (score 11):

## Java - 222

Enough of this bell character or predefined beep function stuff, this makes a real sound :)

```
import javax.sound.sampled.*;class S{static{try{SourceDataLine
l=AudioSystem.getSourceDataLine(new
AudioFormat(4000,8,1,0<1,0>1));l.open();l.start();for(byte
i=9;i!=0;i+=9)l.write(new byte[]{i},0,1);}catch(Exception e){}}}
```

Comment: Java truly sucks for golf

Comment: @boothby not always, check [this](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/9359/shortest-program-that-throws-stackoverflow-error/10961#10961) out

Comment: Okay, Java sucks for golf except when the challenge is to throw errors.  ;)

Comment: @boothby What about this? http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/28818/24965

Comment: @JopVernooij That's not golf, that's an underhanded popularity contest.

Answer (score 10):

### DOS Prompt / DOS Script

```
a:
```

Requires 3.5" floppy drive :)

Comment: What magic is this?

Comment: It causes DOS to try to read from the floppy, which does cause a sound. It is, however, wrong that this needs a 3.5" floppy drive; a 5.25" floppy drive works even better.

Comment: Aye. Wouldn't the 5.25" normally be `b:`?

Comment: Try a CD drive with a defective disk inside, works great too :)

Comment: The drive letter in DOS depended on which connectors of the cable the drive was attached to (and on newer machines, a BIOS setting). My first computer only had a 5.25" drive and I *had to* attach it as master (making it the A drive), since it couldn't boot from the slave.

Answer (score 9):

### J (2)

```
a.
```

This prints all the characters from 0 to 255, that includes the bell.

If I have to do it without printing anything else, it's 4 characters:

```
7{a.
```

Answer (score 9):

## Pascal: 30 characters

```pascal
uses Crt;begin
Sound(999)
end.
```

This takes advantage of the lack of any rule regarding the sound's duration. So just turns on the speaker on 999 Hz and lets it so. (At least until another program calls `Nosound` or the computer is turned off.)

Comment: And the sound keeps screaming even after the program has quit ? I like this one ! :-)

Comment: @NicolasBarbulesco, exactly. That was the normal behaviour of all programs on DOS, including those written in C or assembly.

Comment: -2: Change to 9 Hz: `Sound(9)`.

Comment: @EʀɪᴋᴛʜᴇGᴏʟғᴇʀ, would be hard to prove the sound is actually generated. [Frequency Range of Human Hearing](http://hypertextbook.com/facts/2003/ChrisDAmbrose.shtml)

Comment: @manatwork Well, add an identical code with another frequency that can be heard. Because the codes are identical, it can be proved. (the number only changes)

Answer (score 8):

## Mathematica 6

This will evoke the system beep.  On my computer, it is currently a chirp.

```
Beep[]
```

Answer (score 8):

### Bash, 22

Back in the 90's, my brother taught me this one -- to be used in a computer lab where one has remote access and knows a person to be alone in said lab.  Kids these days won't know what a computer lab is... but oh well.

```
cd /dev;cat sda1>audio
```

Comment: I get `bash: audio: Permission denied` even running under sudo. :(

Comment: This worked on Debian as of 2006.  I can't get it to work on my Ubuntu box :*(

Comment: I think you mean dsp, not audio.  See below for a similar example I wrote using /dev/random

Comment: or `cat /dev/sda | aplay`

Comment: @TheDoctor or `aplay</dev/sda` (UUOC ;-))

Comment: What is this supposed to do ?

Comment: `cat /dev/sda1>audio`

Answer (score 7):

## cat/type/PHP 1

This is actually polyglot. It runs in `cat` (or Microsoft Cat called `type`) and PHP.

```
$ xxd file
0000000: 07                                       .
```

Execution:

```
$ xxd -r > file
0000000: 07                                       .
^D
$ cat file # cat could be replaced with type (on Windows) or with php
```

Comment: What is the program ? How to run it ? This is not clear.

Comment: @NicolasBarbulesco: The program is one byte (`\x07`), however because it's binary, I cannot paste it here. You can run it in PHP CLI, with `php`.

Comment: It is not clear. But it works ! With `cat`. The trick is the ASCII char 7 “bell”.

Comment: That's not a serious attempt.

Answer (score 6):

#### brainfuck, 5 bytes

```
+[.+]
```

prints all chars including bell

Answer (score 5):

### R 9

The bell character

```
cat("\a")
```

Answer (score 5):

## Ruby, 7

```
$><<?\a
```

Tested on Windows with Ruby 1.9.3.

Answer (score 5):

### DOS, 5

Indirect, requires user cooperation.

```
pause
```

Comment: Are you sure? I can not remember any beeping version of DOS `pause`. (At least not MSDOS and FreeDOS.)

Comment: Run the program.  Cooperate.  Listen.

Comment: Could you at least specify which DOS implementation's which version you used?

Comment: Looked up. Found no mention of `pause` making sound. Tried it. `pause` made no sound.

Comment: You have to press a key... which makes a sound. @mana He said it was indirect - `pause` didn't make the sound, YOU did.

Comment: @Riking, how that conforms with the _“Your program_ has to make the computer produce a sound” part of the requirement?

Comment: I do not understand programmers on puzzle sites who cannot think outside of the box.

Comment: Well, "playing a sound" cannot be considered as a "puzzle", anyway. Just move on. Nobody can feel "puzzled" by that.

Comment: @JoanLeaven Who said this was a puzzle?  I said this was a puzzle site -- do you read (I like reading)?  Well, except for manatwork, who was obviously puzzled by my far-too-subtle joke.  And anyway, you move on!  This is my solution, I'll comment as often as I please!

Comment: I wasn't criticizing your answer. I was criticizing the question. A pointless question will obviously get pointless answers. Your answer then make as much sense as any other answer to that stupid question. So, i'm giving you +1.

Answer (score 5):

### PowerShell, <strike>24</strike> 17

Since nobody has posted this version yet:

```
[console]::beep()
```

**UPDATE:** Removed frequencies so it uses the default frequency and duration ([MSDN says the default is 800 hertz and 200 milliseconds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8hftfeyw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))

Comment: Surely you could at least use smaller numbers

Answer (score 4):

**Python** 9 chars

---

produces beep sound when executed.

```
print'\a'
```

Comment: You can shorten this to 8 characters if you replace `\a` with the actual bell character (ASCII code 7).

Comment: But how to print with the help of the value 7 ?

Comment: You can type the bell character into your editor with [`Alt+07`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alt_code). Alternatively, you can run this snippet to create a python file with the 8-character solution: `open("play_a_sound.py", 'w').write("print'"+chr(7)+"'")`

Answer (score 4):

## Applescript (4 Characters)

```
beep
```

This will play the default beep sound of OS X.

Answer (score 4):

## top & aplay - 9

`top` has rhythm!

```
top|aplay
```

The periodic display sometimes does not feed the sound sink fast enough but `aplay` continues after grouching a bit... :-)

...this will run on many Linuxes...

#### Bonus:

While running this, type "s 1 ENTER" to get more beats per second. :-)

Party on!!!  \o/

Comment: This is pure genius... :D

Answer (score 4):

## Mathematica 7

Using Mathematica's built in text to speech capability.

```
Speak@x
```

Will make it say "x"

Answer (score 3):

## **C: 19**

```
main(){puts("\a");}
```

**edit:** header file is not needed for "puts"

Comment: You can remove the space between `#include` and `<` :)

Comment: puts(char*);main(){puts("\a");} is smaller IMHO.

Comment: You can just remove the `#include`.

Comment: @FUZxxl How can you have an opinion about code size?

Comment: @DoorknobofSnow Because of the first amendment?

Comment: The First Amendment of what country, again? Oh wait, this is the Internet and not a specific country.

Answer (score 3):

### [><>](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish) 3

As in all answers, prints the bell (0x07) to stdout.

```
7o;
```

Answer (score 3):

### Tcl, 1 char

```
-
```

replace `-` with the bell char.
It will print the bell char as part of the error message. Twice.

And if you think this is not a valid program, add this before the bell char:

```
proc \007 {} {};
```

It is a valid program, I just did not define the command, because I like the error message.

Comment: Is that based on some Tcl 8.6 feature? In Tcl 8.5 I got different result: http://pastebin.com/bh73UF6F Or are you on Windows?

Comment: No. The 2nd part should show that this is a valid Tcl file. And it should beep 2x (the error message contains the command to be executed twice). Calling a command that does not exist is not an error for Tcl, it is only one if it can not find it. (e.g. `parray`, which is loaded on the first use)

Comment: Oops. I misunderstood you. I thought you mean, it should beep with the `proc` declaration too. (Regarding the beep count, probably my terminal is doing something as `puts [string repeat ".\a" 10]` displays 10 dots but beeps only once.)

Answer (score 2):

#### Ruby 8

```
 puts"\a"
```

Tested on Windows with Ruby 1.9.3.

Answer (score 2):

### Bash, 26

Standard unix (not modern linux, sadly, unless you have alsa-oss installed; the BSDs are fine):

```
cat /dev/random > /dev/dsp
```

Comment: You can save 2 bytes by removing the whitespace around `>`.

Answer (score 2):

## Scala: 44

```
java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
```

*same as [@nrubin29's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/30298/24788), but shorter*

Answer (score 2):

## GolfScript (3)

Since everyone else is doing this anyway:

```
'^G'
```

where `^G` is the bell character.

Hex dump:

```
0000000: 2707 27                                  '.'
```

Comment: Now what is it, '^G' or "^G"?

Comment: It doesn't matter, but I'll fix the inconsistency.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [this answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9006).

Answer (score 2):

## Linux shell (6 characters)

This requires a correctly configured analog modem (you also might need to run it as root):

```
wvdial
```

Answer (score 1):

### sh 6

```
echo .
```

*(where the `.` is in fact a BELL character)*

The HEX representation of the above code is:

```
65 63 68 6f 20 07
```

Answer (score 1):

**Autoit 6**

```
Beep()
```

Although declaring a function would allow for less characters, not counting the declaration:

```
z()
Func z()
Beep()
EndFunc
```

Comment: That way that you made the program longer?  It didn't make it shorter.

Comment: Writing own functions count toward the the length. otherwise everything would be a `how can I call the method with less chars` and some languages allow that with 1 char.

Answer (score 1):

## ATARI BASIC (4 chars)

```
?"E"
```

(? is short for "print".  E is in fact the "escape" symbol; see http://raster.infos.cz/atari/chars/atascii.htm, item 1B.  Printing this symbol would make a characteristic noise.)

Answer (score 1):

#### PowerShell, 3

```
'^G'
```

Of course, the `^G` has to be entered manually, or written to a file with another script, like the following:

```
"'$([char]7)'"|Set-Content beep.ps1
```

Answer (score 1):

### VBScript

```
CreateObject("SAPI.SpVoice").speak "a"
```

Nice thing about this is you can make it say anything you want.

Answer (score 1):

## Windows Command Promt

```
logoff
```

Indeed, this makes an OS sound but it is not `OS beeping on an error or crash`.

Comment: Which version of DOS has a `logoff` command?

Comment: @celtschk I don't know why did I wrote that:D

Answer (score 1):

Matlab **UNTESTED** (1)

```
␇
```

I am not sure whether this works in matlab, as I don't have sound available, but `␇` is in fact a single character. Hence calling or printing it may produce the desired effect in some languages.

Matlab verified (4)

```
beep
```

Comment: Calling the character actually does some strange things. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21097072/what-happens-when-i-call-the-character-in-matlab) if you are interested.

Answer (score 1):

## Windows batch script, 14

```
sort %comspec%
```

%comspec% just points to C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe, and calling sort will find the bell character at some point in cmd's binary.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work on Windows 8.1 64-bit.

Answer (score 1):

## Batch, 16

```
type sethc.exe
```

I discovered this. When I do this, I'll get the 'BEEP' sound from reading the < BELL > character.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript - 99 <strike>103</strike>

```
Audio
  ("data:audio;base64,UklGRgWsAABXQVZFZm10IBAAAAABAAEARKwAAESsAAABAAgAZGF0YeGrAACAbebe")
.play();
```

*chirp* (in firefox, it is definitely a chirp)

Comment: This code throws the following error: `TypeError: Failed to construct 'Audio': Please use the 'new' operator, this DOM object constructor cannot be called as a function.`

Comment: firefox doesn't need that operator. however if i wanted to be pedantic (crossbrowser) i would definitely use 'new' (+4 characters)

Comment: I'm getting the error `TypeError: Constructor Audio requires 'new'` in Firefox Aurora 32. So yeah, it does.

Comment: oh dear.. "Omit the new keyword when possible"
I had Firefox 29 now 30, it works like charm.
(it's funny you try to prove your point with an alpha release)

Answer (score 1):

### Java: 103

```
public class S {
    public static void main(String[] a) {
        java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
    }
}
```

Comment: Will fail to compile without class wrapper and import.

Comment: I didn't realize we needed everything. I'll add it.

Answer (score 1):

### JS, 117

```
new Audio('data:audio/wav;base64,UklGRl9vT19XQVZFZm10IBAAAAABAAEAQB8AAEAfAAABAAgAZGF0YU'+Array(1e3).join(123)).play()
```

Comment: You can save 4 bytes by using `audio` instead of `audio/wav`, and 1 byte by using `join(10)` instead of `join(123)`.

Comment: Even `Array(10).join(1)` appears to play a sound, but `Array(99).join(9)` is more audible.

Answer (score 1):

## QBASIC (8)

```
PLAY "A"
```

---

> Body must be at least 30 characters; you entered 19.

ಠ_ಠ

Answer (score 1):

## Python3 34

Any of the python versions printing the bell character to stdout was working for me, so here it is one using the standard libarary, in Windows:

```
import winsound as w;w.Beep(99,99)
```

The semicolon could be replaced with a newline, but looks cooler this way :)

Comment: You can save a character by using `from winsound import*;Beep(99,99)`.

Answer (score 1):

## Powershell, 4

```
"`a"
```

Sends a beep signal to the computer's speaker.

Answer (score 1):

## OS X Command Line

> say a

This causes the computer to say the letter 'A'

Comment: I do not think `say` is a bash command.

Comment: sorry, yeti. I was under the impression that OS X command line was Bash. Thank you for the correction

Comment: It may be BASH where you type `say a` but that does not make `say` a BASH command. So I meant something like "`say` is not part of the BASH language". Maybe that was trying to be too exact... it may have caused more confusion than needed...

Answer (score 1):

## Visual Basic 6

```
beep
```

VB 6, good times.

Answer (score 1):

### C 23

Make a beep sound.

```
int main(){putchar(7);}
```

Comment: This should still compile without the `int ` at the beginning

Answer (score 1):

## Debianish solution, works on some other systems too - 9 chars

```
aplay /i*
```

...will play the files `/initrd.img` and `initrd.img.old` which are symlinks to some system startup ramdisks in directory `/boot`.

If you prefer the sound of kernels, try...

```
aplay /v*
```

...and look yourself why it works or fails on your system.

I got...

```
$ LANG=C ls -l / | grep ^[^d]
total 88
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    36 Dec 15  2012 initrd.img -> /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-0.bpo.4-amd64
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    30 Dec  9  2012 initrd.img.old -> boot/initrd.img-2.6.32-5-amd64
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root     4 Dec  9  2012 lib64 -> /lib
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    32 Dec 15  2012 vmlinuz -> boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-0.bpo.4-amd64
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    27 Dec  9  2012 vmlinuz.old -> boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-5-amd64
```

...here and that may or may not explain a lot to you and I demand the absence of solid facts and that I may or may not be called vroomfondel!

Comment: you are saying that your solution needs neccessary data - that may not even exist - from outside the code. i think it needs reasons to prove it's valid.

Comment: Oh... I didnt see my harddisk as "outside"! :-D               ll think about a different solution for some minutes...

Comment: Ok... let's narrow it down: Debian is a common system and has these links... they can be disabled by editing some config file in `/etc/` but their existence can be widely assumed because most users don't touch/change the defaults...

Comment: "The program should run on a reasonable, not too uncommon personal computer." was the wording I was looking for. And I think Debian not being configured to be far far away from the installation defaults on contemporary hardware does not describe an uncommon personal computer.

Answer (score 1):

### PHP (CLI): 1 byte

Source code as seen in Notepad++:

[image: source code]

In the absence of `<?php` opening tag, source code is simply dumped to output.

Yeah, I know, another BEL answer, but still, tough to beat a single byte, especially in an interpreted language like PHP ;)

Answer (score 0):

## k/Q (6 chars)

Bell character to stdout.

```
1"c"$7
```

Answer (score 0):

### Windows Command Script - 1 Byte

As most of the answers, this also uses the bell character.

```
0x07
```

Note: Must be run from console to work, since the sound needs some time to trigger.

Answer (score 0):

### [Spoon](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Spoon), 13

```
1111111001010
```

Similarly to the BF solution, it prints the bell character.

Answer (score 0):

## C++  45

```
#include<iostream>
int main(){std::cout<<'\a';}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Fortran 95, 18 chars

```
print*,char(7);end
```

Produces a bell sound

Answer (score 0):

## ZX Spectrum BASIC (3)

```
SAVE STR$ PI
```

It is only 3 bytes because BASIC keywords (with surrounding spaces) occupy single byte in ZX spectrum's memory. Here's its hex representation:

```
F8 C1 A7
```

This program saves current program to audio tape under the name "3.1415927" which is the string representation of π.

In fact it require 7 keypresses: S Caps+Symbol Y Caps+Symbol M

Answer (score 0):

### C#

```
System.Media.SystemSounds.Beep.Play();
```

It's long, but anyway...

Answer (score 0):

### R, 7

```
alert()
```

but sadly I think this is just a wrapper for printing the bell character.

Answer (score 0):

**In AppleScript ; 4 characters**

```
beep
```

[ This is so short that my answer firstly did not reach the minimum length to be posted ! ]

Answer (score 0):

### Ruby, 8 chars

```
puts ?\a
```

### ><>, 2-3 chars

```
7o;
```

or with infinite loop:

```
7o
```

Answer (score 0):

### Autohotkey

I found my answer in the Documentation on the Autohotkey Docs.

```
SoundBeep
```

Answer (score 0):

## C#, 72 bytes

```cs
class Program{public void main(string[]args){System.Console.Beep(500);}}
```

Answer (score -1):

## C on linux

```c
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <linux/cdrom.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>

int main() {
  ioctl(open("/dev/sdb", O_RDONLY), CDROMEJECT);
}
```

Opens the CD-ROM door.

You may need to change sdb to whatever your optical drive's device is.