# Find the nth Fibonnaci Prime, in the shortest code

Tags: code-golf, number, primes, fibonacci

The challenge is rather simple:

1. Take a positive whole number \$n\$ as input.
2. Output the \$n\$th Fibonacci prime number, i.e. the \$n\$th Fibonacci number that is also prime.

Input can be as an parameter to a function (and the output will be the return value), or can be taken from the command line (and outputted there).

*Note: Using built in prime checking functions or Fibonacci series generators is not allowed.*

The first 10 Fibonacci primes are

```
[2, 3, 5, 13, 89, 233, 1597, 28657, 514229, 433494437]
```

Shortest code wins. Good luck!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fibonacci function or sequence](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/85/fibonacci-function-or-sequence)

Comment: Is there a limit to the size?

Comment: @MrZander Size of what?

Comment: Size of input/output.  Do i need to account for prime_fib(1000000000000000000)?  Where is the limit?

Comment: @MrZander The algorithm should support arbitrarily large numbers, but the function may raise an out of bound exception if the result is too big for a normal int.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Ruby, 55

```
f=->n,a=1,b=2{n<1?a:f[n-(2..b).find{|f|b%f<1}/b,b,a+b]}
```

Calls itself recursively, keeping track of the last two numbers in the Fibonacci sequence in `a` and `b`, and how many primes it's seen so far with `n`. `n` gets decremented when the smallest factor greater than 1 of `b`, divided by `b` and rounded down to the nearest integer, is 1 rather than 0, which happens only for prime `b`. When it's seen all the primes it's supposed to, it prints `a`, which is the most recent `b` tested for primality.

Answer (score 4):

## C, 66

`f(n,a,b){int i=2;while(a%i&&i++<a);return(n-=i==a)?f(n,b,a+b):a;}`

Comment: I think you should define starting values of `a` and `b` inside your function.

Comment: Wouldn't a for loop be shorter? (I don't know C well)

Comment: Does one need the space after the return?

Comment: Can be reduced to 65 chars: `f(n,a,b){int i=2;while(a%i&&i++<a);return(n-=i==a)?f(n,b,a+b):a;}` - @ArtemIce: `a`= 1 and `b`= 2 worked for me.

Comment: @schnaader of course they worked, but code that sets a & b should be counted because it's codegolf

Comment: @schnaader - Thanks! Updated!

@Inkbug - `for` will be the same because of two `;`s.

@ArtemIce - Question allows parameters.

Comment: @Gautam The question allows for n to be a parameter, but the start inputs for your fibonacci series should be part of the program and part of the character count.

Comment: Lacks initialisation code for a & b... So can you improve upon just adding `g(n){f(n,1,2);}`?

Comment: How does it work? :) I'm interested.

Comment: This is exponential time, by the way, without DP.

Answer (score 3):

### C, <strike>85</strike>, <strike>81</strike>, 76

```
f(n){int i=1,j=0,k;for(;n;n-=k==i)for(j=i-j,i+=j,k=2;i%k&&k++<i;);return i;}
```

- borrowed code style of simplified prime number check from @Gautam
- self contained C function (no globals)

Testing:

```
main(int n,char**v){printf("%d\n",f(atoi(v[1])));}

./a.out 10
433494437

./a.out 4
13
```

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 59 or 63 bytes

```
(a=b=1;Do[While[{a,b}={b,a+b};Length@Divisors@b>2],{#}];b)&
(a=b=1;Do[While[{a,b}={b,a+b};b~Mod~Range@b~Count~0>2],{#}];b)&
```

These are unnamed functions which take `n` as their input and return the correct Fibonacci prime. The shorter version uses `Divisors`. I'm not entirely sure whether this is allowed, but the other Mathematica answer even uses `FactorInteger`.

The second one doesn't use any factorisation related functions at all, but instead counts the number of integers smaller than `n` which produce `0` in a modulo operation. Even this version beats all valid submissions, but I'm sure just posting this answer will cause some people to provide competitive answers in GolfScript, APL or J. ;)

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, <s>94 68</s> 67

```
n=->j{a=b=1
while j>0
a,b=b,a+b
(2...b).all?{|m|b%m>0}&&j-=1
end
b}
```

## Clojure, 112

Ungolfed:

```
(defn nk [n]
  (nth 
    (filter
      (fn[x] (every? #(> (rem x %) 0) (range 2 x)))    ; checks if number is prime
      ((fn z[a b] (lazy-seq (cons a (z b (+ a b))))) 1 2)) ; Fib seq starting from [1, 2]
    n)) ; get nth number
```

Golf: `(defn q[n](nth(filter(fn[x](every? #(>(rem x %)0)(range 2 x)))((fn z[a b](lazy-seq(cons a(z b(+ a b)))))2 3))n))`

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica <strike>147 143</strike> 141 chars

```
f@0 = 0; f@1 = 1; f@n_ := f[n - 1] + f[n - 2]
q@1 = False; q@n_ := FactorInteger@n~MatchQ~{{_, 1}}
p = {}; k = 1; While[Length@p < n, If[q@f@k, p~AppendTo~f[k]]; k++];p[[-1]]
```

`f` is the recursive definition of Fibonacci number.

`q` detects primes.

`k` is a Fibonacci prime iff `q@f@k` is True.

For `n`=10, output is `433494437`.

Comment: oh god, induction...:shudders:

Comment: @acolyte It's fun to look at a trace of a function that calls itself.

Comment: Person: That was one of the courses that confirmed i needed to get the frak out of CompSci.

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell 108

```
p=2 : s [3,5..]  where
    s (p:xs) = p : s [x|x<-xs,rem x p /= 0]
f=0:1:(zipWith (+) f$tail f)
fp=intersect p f
```

To get `n`th number call it `fp !! n`.

EDIT:
Sic. Wrong answer, I fix it.

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 15 bytes

```
!fȯ=2LḊ¡oΣ↑_2ḋ3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASAA3/9odXNr//8hZsivPTJM4biKwqFvzqPihpFfMuG4izP//w)

Answer (score 0):

### Groovy: 105 (134 with whitespaces)

`b` is the fibonacci function.

the closure inside the if is the prime check function. **Update: a small fix on it**

`r` is the prime fibonacci number.

```
r={ n->
  c=k=0
  while(1) {
    b={a->a<2?a:b(a-1)+b(a-2)}
    f=b k++
    if({z->z<3?:(2..<z).every{z%it}}(f)&&c++==n)return f
  }
}
```

Test cases:

```
assert r(0) == 0
assert r(1) == 1
assert r(2) == 1
assert r(3) == 2
assert r(4) == 3
assert r(5) == 5
assert r(6) == 13
assert r(7) == 89
assert r(8) == 233
assert r(9) == 1597
```

A readable version:

```
def fib(n) { 
  n < 2 ? n : fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
}
def prime(n) {
  n < 2 ?: (2..<n).every { n % it }
}
def primeFib(n) { 
  primes = inc = 0
  while( 1 ) {
    f = fib inc++
    if (prime( f ) && primes++ == n) return f
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## C, 105 (with spaces)

#### fibonacci implementation using dynamic programming:

```c
long f(int n){int i;long b2=0,b1=1,n;if(n)return 0;for(i=2;i<n;i++){n=b1+b2;b2=b1;b1=n;}return b1+b2;}
```

Readable code:

```c
long f(int n)
{
  int i;
  long back2 = 0, back1 = 1;
  long next;
  
  if ( n == 0 ) return 0;

  for ( i=2; i<n; i++ )
  {
    next  = back1 + back2;
    back2 = back1;
    back1 = next;
  }
  
  return back1 + back2;
}
```

Comment: How can this have 1 vote? Does not answer the question (no primality check) and the short version does not even compile

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](http://pyth.herokuapp.com) - 29 bytes

Loops Fibonacci until array is length n but only adds to array if prime.

```
J2K1W<lYQAJK,+KJJI!tPK~Y]K;eY
```

Kind of slow, but reached n=10 in ~15 seconds. Can probably be golfed more.

```
J2              J=2
K1              K=1
W        <lYQ   While length of array<input
 AJK,+KJJ       J,K=K+J,J
 I!tPK          If K prime(not builtin prime function, uses prime factorization)
  ~Y]K          append K to Y
;               End loop so next is printed
eY              last element of Y
```

Disclaimer: Pyth is newer than this challenge, so not competing.

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 15 bytes

```
0+⁸¡1
ÇÆḍ=1µ#ṪÇ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASUA2v9qZWxsef//MCvigbjCoTEKw4fDhuG4jT0xwrUj4bmqw4f//zEw)

The version that uses builtins is [8 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9w28Md8x7umnRoq/LDnavAvP//DQ0A). This is a direct translation of that answer, but with the builtins replaced. This takes input

### How it works

```
0+⁸¡1 - Helper link. Takes k on the left
0     - Set 0 as the left argument
    1 - Set 1 as the right argument
  ⁸¡  - Repeat k times, updating the left and right arguments each time:
 +    -   Add
        This yields the kth Fibonacci number

ÇÆḍ=1µ#ṪÇ - Main link. Takes no input
     µ#Ṫ  - Read an integer n from STDIN and find the nth integer, k, in
            i = 0, 1, 2, ... for which the following is True:
Ç         -   The ith Fibonacci number
 Æḍ       -   Proper divisor count
   =1     -   Equals 1?
        Ç - Yield the kth Fibonacci number
```

Answer (score 0):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 31 bytes

```
1_qi{{_@+_:T,{)T\%!}%:+2>}g}*\;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/3zC@MLO6Ot5BO94qRKdaMyRGVbFW1UrbyK42vVYrxvr/f0sA)

This is slow.

There is a builtin for primality checking. With that included, it runs much faster, and the size drops to [19 bytes](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/3zC@MLO6Ot5BOz63QLE2vVYrxhooaAQA) (with the restriction that the supported maximum is 12, because CJam refuses to do a primality check on a BigInt).