# Hack Sequence : Simplify Hi = 2014*Hi-1 + 69*Hi-2

Tags: code-golf

Can someone help me with simplifying this sequence. I write code to loop through entire n, I am getting timeout.

Hack sequence of IndiaHacks-2014 if given as below
 H<sub>*i*</sub> = 2014*H<sub>*i*-1</sub> + 69*H<sub>*i*-2</sub> for (*i* > 2); H<sub>*i*</sub> = 1 for (*i* <= 2)

Given `n`, you need to find `n`th term of Hack sequence modulo (10<sup>9</sup> + 7), i.e H<sub>`n`</sub> % (10<sup>9</sup> + 7).

This is a Code golf problem. You need to write code with minimum number of characters.

Input: First line contain `T`, the number of test cases. Each of next `T` lines contain an integer `n`.

Output: For each test case output a single integer which is H<sub>`n`</sub> modulo (10<sup>9</sup> + 7).

Constraints : 1 ≤ `T` ≤ 103, 1 ≤ `n` ≤ 1015

Comment: I'm sure that this would make sense on the IndiaHacks website if I could be bothered to create an account in order to see it, but in copying it across you've lost whatever formatting it had and it no longer makes sense.

Comment: Although if I'm correctly guessing what the formatting should be, it's essentially a duplicate of [Fibonacci sequence](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/85/194).

Comment: Can you please tell me how to format questions here

Comment: Click on the help button next to the editor. It explains it in lots of detail.

Comment: For fibonacci, we loop n completely. We can solve this problem without looping completely.

Comment: Improved your formatting, but are you sure about the `% (109 + 7)` part? Or should it be `% 109 + 7`? BTW to see how I formatted your question, you can go to the review history (by clicking the "edited x minutes ago") and choose "side-by-side markdown"

Comment: sorry.. it should be 10^9 + 7

Comment: If you're getting a timeout, it's probably not code golf.

Comment: Which other values are missing superscripts? I'm now suspicious of the bounds on the input, and half-suspicious of the number `2014`.

Comment: Hi = 2014*Hi-1 + 69*Hi-2 for (i > 2);                  Hi = 1 for (i <= 2)  (H1 =1 & H2 = 1)

Comment: As for "looping completely", this problem is the same as the Fibonacci problem but with different parameters. Exactly the same approaches (direct recurrence, dynamic programming, matrix exponentiation, Binet's formula) apply.

Comment: Think this can be done by matrix exponentiation