# Fibonacci Sequenze without using loops!

Tags: popularity-contest

Here is one more "Challenge"! Today i had a meeting with a friend, and mostly we are a little bit crazy.. He bets, that it is not possible to create a Fibonacci Sequence without using loops.

No static output like:

```
return "1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, ..";
```

**GOAL / Requirements**

- Use only 1 int var
- Return the first 5 (or more) numbers
- Name your function "fibonacci"
- Call no other functions except "fibonacci"
- No loops are allowed
- Have fun ;)

**Scoring**

Popularity contest (Most upvotes minus downvotes)

**End Date**

June 17. 2014

**No special language required**

Comment: Two days for the contest?

Comment: ^ What do you think is okay?

Comment: Typically, 1 week is what is used.

Comment: ^ thx. Let's raise the end date

Comment: When you say "Call no other functions", how do you define "function"? Is addition a function?

Comment: Like what? Only recursive calls are allowed - that must be enough.

Comment: @Tyralcori It's not. Recursion without any other functions can't do anything.

Comment: @Ypnypn sorry, but i think, you are pretty wrong.. Look at MT0's answer ;)

Comment: @Tyralcori That answer uses two functions: addition and subtraction.

Comment: @Ypnypn okay, this "function" / addition is allowed and important.

Comment: @Ypnypn: At least in JavaScript, `+` is an operator, not a function.

Comment: @Dennis my words, but i wanna point this out for Ypnypn

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fibonacci function or sequence](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/85/fibonacci-function-or-sequence)

Comment: Recursion is a loop. What does "*use only 1 int var*" mean a) for use of non-int variables? b) for stack-based languages? c) for languages whose only primitives are combinators?

Answer (score 3):

## [Kona](https://github.com/kevinlawler/kona)

```
fibonacci:{((x-1)(|+\)\1 1)[;1]}
```

Execute in shell as `fibonacci 12` to get the first 12 Fibonacci numbers.

**Explanation**:

- `1 1` is a vector
- `(|+\)\` generates a vector of vectors by summing the elements of the vector
- `(x-1)` reduces 12 to 11 (due to 0 indexing) which is applied to the summation to repeat `x-1` times
- `[;1]` returns/prints the second element of each vector in the larger vectors.

If I neglected the `[;1]` portion, you can see what happens to the vector:

```
> fib 1
,1 1
> fib 2
(1 1
 2 1)
> fib 3
(1 1
 2 1
 3 2)
```

And so on.

Comment: Explanation for those unfamiliar with this language? :)

Comment: @Jwosty: updated

Answer (score 3):

## Python

```
def fibonacci(n):
    if n > 1:
        return fibonacci(n-1) + [(1.618033988749895**n/2.23606797749979 + 0.2) // 1]
    else:
        return [1]
```

Call `fibonacci(n)` to generate a list up to the nth element of the Fibonacci series. Sample output of `fibonacci(20)`:

```
>>> fibonacci(20)
[1, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 5.0, 8.0, 13.0, 21.0, 34.0, 55.0, 89.0, 144.0, 233.0, 377.0, 610.0, 987.0, 1597.0, 2584.0, 4181.0, 6765.0]
```

The correctness is limited by the precision of the double precision floating point.

Answer (score 3):

**EXCEL / NUMBERS / $spreadsheetapp**

I think I saw this somewhere here, but I can't remember. Nevertheless, credits go to unknown author. Just Fill in the first 2 fields, do a simple addition and then it's time to drag, baby!

[image]

Comment: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1844/9498

Comment: Oh great, you found it :) Thank you, obviously I didn't look deep enough

Comment: I knew it. That's why it was easy for me.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ECMAScript 6)

```
fibonacci=n=>n<2?[0,1]:[...fibonacci(n-1),fibonacci(n-1)[n-1]+fibonacci(n-2)[n-2]]
```

or more efficiently

```
fibonacci=n=>n<2?[0,1]:(i=fibonacci(n-1),[...i,i[n-1]+i[n-2]])
```

or even more efficently (but with a loop instead of recursion)

```
fibonacci=n=>[i[m]=m<2?+m:i[m-1]+i[m-2]for(m in i=[...Array(n)])]
```

Comment: The point is to return the first n Fibonacci numbers, though, not just the nth number.

Comment: I wonder if array comprehension should count as a loop?

Comment: @nderscore That's why I put in the ones without array comprehension