# Negate The String

Tags: code-golf, string

*Disclaimer: This isn't my challenge but [ThisGuy](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11802/67719) said I was OK to post.*

---

Occasionally I want to make a word into it's opposite, like `happiness` goes to `unhappiness`. Unfortunately when this happens, my brain will sometimes go blank. Then one day, after yet another this happening, I thought to my self "This is what programs are for!"

As the English language has many exceptions, I have created a list which contains the prefix for the starting letter

```
q or h          -> dis- (honest -> dishonest)
l                -> il-  (legal -> illegal)
m or p           -> im-  (mature -> immature)
r                -> ir-  (responsible -> irresponsible)
everything else  -> un-  (worthy -> unworthy)
```

## Task

Given an input as a string, make the string into its negative and output the result. You can assume that all the inputs given will fit the above rules. Submissions may be programs or functions, not snippets.

## Input

A single string, taken either as a parameter or from STDIN

## Output

The negated form of that string, conforming to the above rules

## How to Win

This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so shortest code wins

Comment: Can we assume we'll never get a word that starts with a `q` without a `u`?

Comment: @BasicSunset There's [_Qi_](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/qi). Arguably a proper noun, though

Comment: [Related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/92827/42963).

Comment: @BasicSunset Can you list 5 words beginning with a `q` and without a `u` in English?

Comment: Off the top of my head, `qadi`, `qat`, the aforementioned `qi`, `qirsh`, and `qwerty`. (I play a lot of Scrabble)

Comment: @wsbltc Well, there's [a fair few](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:English_words_containing_Q_not_followed_by_U), but they're pretty much all borrowed words from other languages so questionable whether they really count as English. So can we assume that a `q` is always followed by a `u` in the string or not?

Comment: Yes you can assume it always has a `u`

Comment: This challenge could make a pedant quite dishappy...

Comment: @Spratty You're not irright about that

Answer (score 10):

## Python, 55 bytes

```python
lambda n:'ddiiiiuiimmlrnss'[5-'rlmphq'.find(n[0])::7]+n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#JY1BCoMwEEX3nmLoJkpVWkopBOxFrItIkjqQTDSJlCKe3Rr7N/99eMzo5rUZYXspgDiTEvfMiNYaTyGw9l4xb@w4TKzWSDKn9tIVnD@6M21RhRiggZYNjnZmJTCj3sIksCLOXiXyKoyOAvbmmB/n4/BNNM3CoEYl0xhd@Ctdpp2HdBuQjg48g5TRI0U4Lfx6W6F6wrKe6t3dP@VJK0EfXRTbDw)

---

We need to handle 7 different starting letters:
`g` -> `dis`, `h` -> `dis`, `p` -> `im`, `m` -> `im`, `l` -> `il`, `r` -> `ir` and *everything else* -> `un`

We can store all these negations in a single string and extract the right one through slicing:

```python
 d      i      s
  d      i      s
   i      m
    i      m
     i      l
      i      r
       u      n

'ddiiiiuiimmlrnss'[i::7]
```

Now we need to calculate the start index `i`. `'rlmphq'.find` returns 0 for `'r'`, 5 for `q` and -1 for everything not contained in the string.
To get the needed value from 0 to 6 we still need to subtract the return value from 5, resulting in this code:

```python
'ddiiiiuiimmlrnss'[5-'rlmphq'.find(n[0])::7]
```

Comment: That's really cute!

Comment: Can someone explain how the hell is this works? I understand what's going on with the slice notation, but what are the magic strings `ddiiiiuiimmlrnss` and `rlmphq` and the number `5` for, why is the slice skip 7?

Comment: @Keatinge added an explanation. I hope it helps you

Answer (score 6):

## [GNU sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), 50 bytes

Includes +1 for `-r`

```
s/^q|^h/dis&/
s/^l|^r|^m/i&&/
s/^p/imp/
t
s/^/un/
```

Nothing fancy. Uses `&` in the replacement to combine a few substitutions, and `t` to skip the last one if one of the first substitutions happens.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/sed#JYpBCsMwDMDufkhvw4/pPdAx0xiS2LUdyiBvX9atNwlpOqZjpIwv9gXhsjKSjVSRl9sVuSpC/Bh7wzmzNPKAQvtWoG7RjcDIVZrzsxCcYpHfcPRVKkXmtoOK/9tHNPj65sO@)

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 30 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
1ị“qmlrrhp”iị“3bµWI⁼ṡ÷ʠ$»œs5¤;
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@2/4cHf3o4Y5hbk5RUUZBY8a5mZCBIyTDm0N93zUuOfhzoWHt59aoHJo99HJxaaHllj///8/Iz8vtbgEAA)**

#### How?

```
1ị“qmlrrhp”iị“3bµWI⁼ṡ÷ʠ$»œs5¤; - Main link: string
1ị                             - 1 index into the string (first character of the string)
           i                   - 1-based index of 1st occurrence of that in (else zero):
  “qmlrrhp”                    -     char list "qmlrrhp"
            ị                  - index into (1-based and modulo):
                            ¤  -     nilad followed by link(s) as a nilad:
             “3bµWI⁼ṡ÷ʠ$»      -         compressed string "dis"+"imili"+"run"="disimilirun"
                         œs5   -         split "equally" into 5: ["dis","im","il","ir","un"]
                             ; - concatenate with the string
```

Note that the repeated `r` in `“qmlrrhp”` is in the 5th index, which, if referenced, would result in prepending `un`, so it could equally well be anything other than `h` or `p`.

Answer (score 4):

## [///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////), <s>59</s> 56 bytes

```
/^/\/\/#//#qu/disqu^h/dish^l/ill^m/imm^p/ipp^r/irr^/un/#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/slashes#FcVBCoAwDATAx/Qs@yFZkFZIIK1ppE/3HJU5TILYPwUoc6HpPRflX2hQM3Zo73SoOwMaQayBkvmMa6tHlfMF)

Input goes after the very last `#`.

**How it works:**

I made an optimization that reduced the size to 56 bytes, but since that complicates things I will explain the original version, then explain the golf.

```
/#qu/disqu//#h/dish//#l/ill//#m/imm//#p/ipp//#r/irr//#/un/# |everything after the ` |` is not code.
/#qu/disqu/                                                 |replace `qu` with `disqu`
           /#h/dish/                                        |replace `h` with `dish`.
                    /#l/ill/                                |replace `l` with `ill`.
                            /#m/imm/                        |replace `m` with `imm`.
                                    /#p/ipp/                |replace `p` with `ipp`.
                                            /#r/irr/        |replace `r` with `irr`.
                                                    /#/un/  |replace everything else with `un`.
                                                          # |safety control
```

**Intuition:** The challenge is simple enough, just add the negative depending on the beginning of the word. However, in ///, you cannot just `concatenate if [...]`, you can only replace something following a specific pattern. So in this program, the positive word beginnings are replaced with the negative word beginnings. The `#` was added to make sure that once a new beginning was added, no more new beginnings would be added. The `#` also made it possible to do 'everything else: un'.

The golf incorporates a new substitution at he beginning: `/^/\/\/#/`. This replaces all `^` with `//#`, which was a common pattern in the original version.

Answer (score 4):

## TI-Basic, 104 bytes

```
Prompt Str0
sub(Str0,1,1→Str2
Str0
If Str2="Q" or Str2="H
"DIS"+Ans
If Str2="L
"IL"+Ans
If Str2="M" or Str2="P
"IM"+Ans
If Str2="R
"IR"+Ans
If Ans=Str0
"UN"+Ans
Ans
```

Requires all capital letters.

Explanation:

```
Prompt Str0             # 4 bytes, input user string to Str0
sub(Str0,1,1→Str2       # 12 bytes, store first character in Str2
Str0                    # 3 bytes, store Str0 in Ans
If Str2="Q" or Str2="H  # 14 bytes, if the first letter was Q or H
"DIS"+Ans               # 8 bytes, store DIS+Ans in Ans
If Str2="L              # 7 bytes, If the first letter was L
"IL"+Ans                # 7 bytes, store IL+Ans in Ans
If Str2="Q" or Str2="H  # 14 bytes, if the first letter was Q or H
"IM"+Ans                # 7 bytes, store DIS+Ans in Ans
If Str2="R              # 7 bytes, if the first letter was R
"IR"+Ans                # 7 bytes, store IR+Ans in Ans
If Ans=Str0             # 6 bytes, if Ans has not been changed (first letter was none of the above)
"UN"+Ans                # 7 bytes, store UN+Ans in Ans
Ans                     # 1 byte, implicitly return Ans
```

Comment: [81 bytes](https://pastebin.com/1s2tYETw)

Answer (score 3):

### Batch, 114 bytes

```
@set/pw=
@set p=un
@for %%p in (dis.q dis.h il.l im.m im.p ir.r)do @if .%w:~,1%==%%~xp set p=%%~np
@echo %p%%w%
```

Checks the first character of the word against the list of custom prefixes and if so changes the prefix from the default of `un`. Special-casing `qu` is possible at a cost of 21 bytes.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (<s>71</s> <s>64</s> 61 bytes)

`w=>({q:a='dis',h:a,l:'il',m:b='im',p:b,r:'ir'}[w[0]]||'un')+w`

Edits:

- Saved 7 bytes thanks to @ErtySeidohl (`charAt(0)` -> `[0]`)
- Saved 3 bytes thanks to @edc65 (assigning shared prefixes to variables)

```js
var f = w=>({q:a='dis',h:a,l:'il',m:b='im',p:b,r:'ir'}[w[0]]||'un')+w;

function onChange() {
   var word = event.target.value;
   var output = f(word);
   document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = output;
}
```

```html
Input Word: <input type='text' oninput='onChange()'/><br/>
Output Word: <span id="output">
```

Comment: If you don't care about backward compatibility with IE7, couldn't you use `w[0]` instead of `w.charAt(0)`?

Comment: @ErtySeidohl Thanks! Just learned something new ;-)

Comment: I'm new here, but is it legitimate to provide an answer starting with just `w=>...`? The actual function definition would include `let f=w=>...` ? (Probably covered in an FAQ somewhere...)

Comment: @SteveBennett yes it's legitimate. Naming the function is not relevant

Comment: `w=>({q:a='dis',h:a,l:'il',m:b='im',p:b,r:'ir'}[w[0]]||'un')+w` 3 bytes less

Answer (score 3):

## Javascript, <del>72</del> <del>71</del> <del>66</del> <del>61</del> <del>60</del> 59 bytes

<s>`w=>('dis....il.im...im.dis.ir'.split('.')[w.charCodeAt(0)-104]||'un')+w`</s>

<s>`w=>'un.dis.dis.il.im.im.ir'.split('.')['qhlmpr'.indexOf(w[0])+1]+w`</s>

<del>Yeah, it's *still* longer than an existing solution. :)</del>

```
w=>['un','dis','im','il','ir']['qmlrhp'.search(w[0])%4+1]+w
```

In case this needs any explanation, I'm taking advantage of the q/h and m/p pairs by combining their index in the search string with a mod 4, then using that as the lookup into the prefix array.

Comment: Great answer. Save 1 byte using `search` instead of `indexOf`. And some more, I think, using `&` instead of `%`

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know about `search`. Can't see how to make the & trick work - would be perfect if my array was only 4 elements.

Answer (score 2):

### Haskell, 71 bytes

```
f l=maybe"un"id(lookup(l!!0)$zip"qhlmpr"$words"dis dis il im im ir")++l
```

Usage example: `f "legal"`-> `"illegal"`. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#HY07DsIwEESvslmlsBWEuEBuABUlSuHIDl6x/uCPULi8cZBm9OZV0zbg2al9NVg9khYcwqtGwcNwkeOXIr4tu5hw/ISkM2rKcJQYyP2TUE4TN6fIwwxOxRuIWMu9pKuHM2wSHmiDN7ngCdk8FXc6VWoyfSSTY/CZVj6sfxS749J@)

Build a lookup table of prefix/replacement pairs for looking up the first char of the input string with a default value of `"un"` if not found.

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 54 bytes

```
^[^hqlmpr]
un$+
^[hq]
dis$+
^l
il$+
^[mp]
im$+
^r
ir$+
```

Explanation:

```
             {implicit replace stage}
^[^hqlmpr]   Append un to words starting with none of: hqlmpr
un$+         
^[hq]        Append dis to words starting with h or q
dis$+        
 ^l          Append il to words starting with l
il$+          
^[mp]        Append il to words starting with m or p
im$+    
^r           Append ir to words starting with r
ir$+
```

First time I've used Retina. It's a pretty neat language.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#@x8XHZdRmJNbUBTLVZqnos0VF51RGMuVklkMYudwZeaAxXILYrkyc0HMIq7MIhXt///L84tKMioB)

Comment: Very nice first try at a language! +1

Comment: And with that you have 2500 rep! Congratulations!

Comment: And your user index is 26600!

Comment: So much perfect base-10 !

Answer (score 1):

## C, <s>109</s> 107 bytes

```
f(char*s){printf("%s%s",*s-109&&*s-112?*s-108?*s-114?*s-104&&*s-113|s[1]-117?"un":"dis":"ir":"il":"im",s);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/c-gcc#bY1LCoMwEIb3nkICSiIKTSv04cKDlC5SG5tATCQTKcV67K5tYtuds/gf88HM3OJGMJsBGXsrtWsxSiABlGdQ0M0xTYPTbb3Uw2K0/LbyB3cvONOLD/saDRqd0E2CV2mDqCAdyoFU0@zvxx2TGpNojGI//pswmoNDpOoHBxj58CeK35laAx1zg@VrxHLojQZ5Vav4YawTz7CY5rc2RcMawT8)

Answer (score 1):

### Mathematica, 107 bytes

```
StringReplace[StartOfString~~x:#:>#2<>x&@@@{{"q"|"h","dis"},{"l","il"},{"m"|"p","im"},{"r","ir"},{_,"un"}}]
```

### Explanation:

`StartOfString~~x:#:>#2<>x&` is a pure function where the first argument is a [string pattern](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/StringPatterns.html) to match at the beginning of the string and the second argument is a string to prepend to the match. It returns a delayed rule suitable for use within `StringReplace`. This is then applied to each of the pairs `{{"q"|"h","dis"},{"l","il"},{"m"|"p","im"},{"r","ir"},{_,"un"}}` resulting in the list of rules

```
{
  StartOfString~~x:"q"|"h":>"dis"<>x,
  StartOfString~~x:"l":>"il"<>x,
  StartOfString~~x:"m"|"p":>"im"<>x,
  StartOfString~~x:"r":>"ir"<>x,
  StartOfString~~x_:>"un"<>x
}
```

Finally this list is passed into `StringReplace` which gives an operator on strings.

Comment: Does Mathmatica have a builtin for everything?

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 101 Bytes

```
echo preg_match("#^(qu|[hlmpr])#",$argn,$t)?[qu=>dis,h=>dis,l=>il,m=>im,p=>im,r=>ir][$t[1]]:un,$argn;
```

[Online Version](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4fb8d1549687fcda1a38eac52bc49f4400a987a9)

Answer (score 1):

## Excel 78 bytes

```
=TRIM(MID("  disdisil im im ir un",IFERROR(FIND(LEFT(A1),"qhlmpr"),7)*3,3))&A1
```

I found some close contenders using different methods that scored 81 bytes:

```
=IFERROR(CHOOSE(FIND(LEFT(A1),"qhlmpr"),"dis","dis","il","im","im","ir"),"un")&A1
```

And 84 bytes:

```
=IFERROR(TRIM(MID("im disi"&LEFT(A1),MOD(FIND(LEFT(F1),"qlmhrp"),3)*3+1,3)),"un")&A1
```

Answer (score 0):

### REXX, 78 bytes

```
arg a
s.=un
s.q=dis
s.h=s.q
s.l=il
s.m=im
s.p=im
s.r=ir
p=left(a,1)
say s.p||a
```

Saves a few bytes by replying in UPPERCASE, e.g. potent -> IMPOTENT.

Answer (score 0):

## Perl, 49 + 1 (`-p` flag) = 50 bytes

```
s|^[hq]|dis$&|||s|^[lmr]|i$&$&|||s|p|imp|||s||un|
```

Using:

```
perl -pe 's|^[hq]|dis$&|||s|^[lmr]|i$&$&|||s|p|imp|||s||un|' <<< responsible
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/perl5#LYlLCoQwDIb3PUdx54nEAcVgA20Tm4oI/9mnMz5236MZPkPYRixsvgNweUxlBPvuDQpOehP2jNaCZLLqIq1TdGmqeyFXyFSy8RzJqdgDh5Qazq9o5f9rvf4A).

Answer (score 0):

### Clojure, 65 bytes

```
#(str(get{\q"dis"\h"dis"\l"il"\m"im"\p"im"\r"ir"}(first %)"un")%)
```

Well this is boring... but I couldn't make it any shorter. At least there is very little whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

### OCaml, 85

```
(fun s->(match s.[0]with|'q'|'h'->"dis"|'l'->"il"|'m'|'p'->"im"|'r'->"ir"|_->"un")^s)
```

Anonymous function, uses pattern matching on its first char.

Answer (score 0):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 38 bytes

```
«÷c4w«?hḟ:u=[`un`|4%«⟑Ẇf:«2ẇ`Ġ⟨`p$i]?+
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%C2%AB%C3%B7c4w%C2%AB%3Fh%E1%B8%9F%3Au%3D%5B%60un%60%7C4%25%C2%AB%E2%9F%91%E1%BA%86f%3A%C2%AB2%E1%BA%87%60%C4%A0%E2%9F%A8%60p%24i%5D%3F%2B&inputs=honest&header=&footer=)

Messy.

Answer (score 0):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>66</s> 62 bytes

`%4+1` inspired by @[Steve Bennett](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115467/80745)

```powershell
param($s)(echo un dis im il ir)[('qmlrhp'|% I*f $s[0])%4+1]+$s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZAxT8MwEIV3/4obHBLTIIHEilSJiQWQOjBEEUrTKzGy49Rnq6A2vz3YTlQQN52/9@6d7cEc0VKHSk18Dw9wmobGNrrgJApsOwO@h50kkBqkAmlFVeQHrWw35OcMnq73wKm6rUV2v7qrV5ymkbF1wcoi70yP5PIS8jC/HEQUFH40KnKp5jZR3ThvMWG99IlbpMH0JLdqFu1fkBxHY133HUXfL71gAs6QwYlBKB7orgSOXwO2DnfPYavD8Fj@Push0isXwFX4g@ROvHrdPHpyRr9sP8NgvZ7jYm182yJRzFiGb/Dwf8PF/RYSo/WSHOv3FnNCEkY2Tj8)