# Fibtraction - Fibonacci but with subtraction

Tags: code-golf, number, sequence, fibonacci

The Fibtraction sequence (as I call it) is similar to the Fibonacci sequence except, instead of adding numbers, you subtract them.

**The first few numbers of this challenge are:**

```
1, 2, -1, 3, -4, 7, -11, 18, -29, 47, -76, 123, -199, 322, -521, 843, -1364...
```

The sequence **starts with 1 and 2**. Every next number can be calculated by subtracting the previous number from the number before it.

```
1
2
-1 = 1 - 2
3  = 2 - (-1) = 2 + 1
-4 = -1 - 3
7  = 3 - (-4) = 3 + 4
...
```

In other words:

```
f(1) = 1
f(2) = 2
f(n) = f(n - 2) - f(n - 1)
```

This is [OEIS sequence A061084](https://oeis.org/A061084).

### Challenge

Write a **program/function** that takes a positive integer **n** as input and prints the **nth number of the Fibtraction sequence**.

#### Specifications

- [Standard I/O rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods) apply.
- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are **forbidden**.
- Your solution **can either be 0-indexed or 1-indexed** but please specify which.
- This challenge is not about finding the shortest approach in all languages, rather, it is about finding the **shortest approach in each language**.
- Your code will be **scored in bytes**, usually in the encoding UTF-8, unless specified otherwise.
- Built-in functions that compute this sequence are **allowed** but including a solution that doesn't rely on a built-in is encouraged.
- Explanations, even for "practical" languages, are **encouraged**.

### Test cases

These are 0-indexed.

```
Input      Output

1          2
2          -1
11         123
14         -521
21         15127
24         -64079
31         1860498
```

<sup>That pattern was totally not intentional. :P</sup>

[This challenge was sandboxed.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13219)

> Before you go pressing any buttons that do scary things, hear me out. This might be considered a dupe of the [regular Fibonacci challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/85/fibonacci-function-or-sequence) and I agree, to some extent, that it should be easy enough to port solutions from there. However, the challenge is old and outdated; is severely under-specified; allows for two types of solutions; has answers that don't have easy ways to try online; and in general, is lacking of answers. Essentially, in my opinion, it doesn't serve as a good "catalogue" of solutions.

plz send teh codez

Comment: Note that after the first two terms it devolves into the Lucas sequence with alternating signs.

Comment: i could close this as a dupe of other Lucas number challenges but not having enough online executable answers is not reason to not be dupe. We could have a discussion about making that challenge clearer but it is still dupe regardless

Comment: Even if the old Fibonacci challenge has some shortcomings and doesn't serve it's purpose as a catalogue very well, the best solution would be to make a good, canonical Fibonacci challenge, not an almost-Fibonacci challenge, because no one will look for that as a repository of Fibonacci solutions. Before you do though, this should probably be brought up on meta. We've discussed retiring the old Fibonacci challenge a couple of times, and I think Chris said he'd be fine with it, but I'm not sure what to do with all the answers that do work there.

Comment: Okay, should I write a meta post? I strongly believe we should have a good "repository" of solutions for one of our most basic challenges.

Comment: Is this exactly similar to the regular Fibonacci sequence? If we say the first term of the Fibonacci sequence is 1, then second is also 1(0th term = 0 + 1). By that logic, this sequence should be `1, -1, 2, -3, 5, -8, 13, ....`.

Comment: Yeah, the Fibonacci sequence either starts with 1 and then adds/subtracts (leading to cst1992's solution) or starts with 1,1 (so then goes 0, 1, -1, 2, -3... and is thus also the Fibonacci sequence, albeit delayed by three places). Defining this as starting with 1, 2 seems... dubious.

Comment: I voted to close this challenge. If we want to make a proper catalog for the Fibonacci sequence that has a well-defined specification, then I think it should be for the vanilla Fibonacci sequence and not a manipulation of it. The challenge this is a dupe of is a better candidate in my opinion.

Comment: I marked this as a duplicate to "lock" the question and answers while the Meta question is sorted out. Thanks.

Answer (score 26):

## [Oasis](https://github.com/Adriandmen/Oasis), 4 bytes

```
c-21
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08sziz@/z9Z18jw////xoYA)

0-indexed.

I saw this language used for a similar challenge once, and immediately I knew I should try it here. Can't say I'm disappointed.

#### Explanation

```
   1    a(0) = 1
  2     a(1) = 2
c       a(n) = a(n - 2)
 -                      - a(n - 1)
```

Comment: I saw this challenge with only 1 answer and figured I could get an Oasis answer in. 2 seconds later you did it. Nice :P

Comment: Oh, wow, I'm a dumbass; I thought the chat was "05AB1E Oasis" as in a cool place to lounge. Little did I know it was a language.

Answer (score 12):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <strike>35</strike> 34 bytes

<sup>-1 byte thanks to [ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64121/ovs)!</sup>

```python
f=lambda n:n*(n<3)or f(n-2)-f(n-1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P802JzE3KSVRIc8qT0sjz8ZYM79IIU0jT9dIUxdEGWr@LyjKzCvRyE0s0EjTUShKzEtP1TDUUTAy1dTU/A8A)

Answers are 1-indexed. Takes advantage of `f(2)` and `f(1)` being equal to their respective inputs.

Answer (score 10):

### Javascript, 24 bytes

```js
f=n=>n<3?n:f(n-2)-f(n-1)
```

```js
f=n=>n<3?n:f(n-2)-f(n-1)

for (let i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
  console.log(f(i))
}
```

Answer (score 9):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 27 bytes

0-indexed.

```matlab
@(n)([1,2]*[0,1;1,-1]^n)(1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z@mYKugp6f330EjT1Mj2lDHKFYr2kDH0NpQR9cwNg4oZqj5P7GoKLEyrTRPI00HpELH0FDH0ETHCMg00TE2jNX8DwA)

Comment: Very nice approach!

Comment: How does this work?

Answer (score 8):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>29</s> 26 bytes

Inspired by alephalpha's answer I thought, I'd derive an explicit formula. It's been a while since I did an Eigenvalue decomposition, turns out the explicit formula (even after golfing it down) is longer and fails because of floating point issues.

0-indexed:

```hs
(g!!)
g=1:scanl(flip(-))2g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyflfraus4OPo5x7q6O6q4BwQoKCsW8uVZhvzXyNdUVGTK93W0Ko4OTEvRyMtJ7NAQ1dT0yj9f25iZp6CrUJBUWZeiYKKQm5igUKaQrSBnp6hgUHsfwA)

Saved 3 bytes thanks to @Laikoni

### Decomposition solution, 48 bytes

There are a couple eigenvector decompositions; the simplest is actually -1-indexed rather than 0-indexed or 1-indexed:

```hs
Prelude> map (\n -> ((-1 + sqrt 5)/2)**n + ((-1 - sqrt 5)/2)**n) [0..10]
[2.0,-1.0,3.0,-4.0,7.0,-11.0,18.0,-29.000000000000004,47.0,-76.0,123.0]
```

Since the `(-1 + sqrt 5)/2` term is less than 1, we can absorb that into the needed `round` at the cost of adding some leading terms,

```hs
Prelude> [round$((-1 - sqrt 5)/2)^n|n<-[0..10]]
[1,-2,3,-4,7,-11,18,-29,47,-76,123]
```

So e.g. one can get to a function by, but this is not much-more golfable and it's 48 bytes:

```hs
((1:2: -1:[round$(-(1+sqrt 5)/2)^n|n<-[2..]])!!)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyflfraus4OPo5x7q6O6q4BwQoKCsW8uVZhvzX0PD0MrISkHX0Cq6KL80L0VFQ1fDULu4sKhEwVRT30gzLq8mz0Y32khPLzZWU1FR839uYmaegq1CQVFmXomCikJuYoFCmkK0gZ6eoYFB7H8A)

Comment: You can drop the space in `2 g`. Also anonymous functions are allowed, so you do not need the `f=`.

Comment: Whoops, thanks! I thought about the anonymous function too, but then I have a naked expression in the code. Is this ok?

Comment: That's fine, see the [Guide to golfing rules in Haskell](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11924/new-users-guides-to-golfing-rules-in-specific-languages/11935#11935). For TIO you can either keep the `f=` or use [this tip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/129555/56433).

Comment: I think the most I can golf the explicit formula is the 48-byte `((1:2: -1:[round$(-(1+sqrt 5)/2)^n|n<-[2..]])!!)`, or subtract 6 bytes if the list is ok as output.

Comment: @CRDrost Yeah it's pretty much ungolfable (at least wrt. to the other solution). Feel free to create your own answer or edit it in, if you like.

Answer (score 8):

## x86 Machine Code, 12 bytes

**Iterative solution; 0-indexed**

```
31 C0
40
8D 50 01
29 D0
92
E2 FB
C3
```

The above function takes a single input, *n* (passed in the `ECX` register, following Microsoft's [fastcall calling convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#Microsoft_fastcall)), and returns the *n*<sup>th</sup> number of the Fibtraction sequence in the `EAX` register.

The implementation is based on the well-known trick for calculating a Fibonacci number using two variables, which [Snowman's answer in Java](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/131680/58518) reminded me of.

Not only is this solution *much smaller* in size than [my first attempt](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/131685/58518) (it even competes with [Mathematica using a built-in](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/131573/58518)), it will also be *much faster* because it is iterative, rather than recursive. Theoretical comp-sci's love for recursion is foiled once more!

**Ungolfed assembly mnemonics:**

```
Fibtraction:
   xor  eax, eax
   inc  eax                ; EAX = 1  (XOR+INC are 3 bytes; same as PUSH+POP)
   lea  edx, [eax + 1]     ; EDX = 2  (LEA is 3 bytes; same as PUSH+POP)
Iterate:
   sub  eax, edx           ; EAX = EAX - EDX
   xchg eax, edx           ; swap EAX and EDX
   loop Iterate            ; decrement ECX and keep looping as long as ECX != 0
   ret                     ; return, with result in EAX
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hc3daoMwGIDhY3MVH45CMuqqUVvFrQdr15tYhmTR2oCNQyMExm59LrC26ZkHIb9vHhE0QkyT6NSgQZx4DyZb77qqfv@AF/CZiSNmdiEziR3ZnpnUzqE9ozkze7vOKTNvdhxe7bvYL9CguZYCRjXIRtUVlCXXupefo67LEuMjH7TgbUsI4EdrHYwi@PqYWPPiF9ODVKIdqxqeB13J7um0RUgqDWcuFSboG3lfvd0fsf//DV5UhOlgy/SiYspfQrSEy01ESOF5qxXQ2YjeInqNgmieurNuWETj@TBxYXIDUzpPUkdSR6YR3cynDqUOXSfhJp9tY8fGjs3WYZJnyOtrPfYKwgL9TL/i2PJmmIJzTP8A)**

A couple of things worth pointing out here…

- We start by loading the constants 1 and 2 into registers. These are our starting values. The standard way, of course, to load constants into registers is `mov reg, imm`. That's fast, but it takes a whopping *5 bytes* to encode. So, for code-golfing purposes, we make use of various other tricks to load values into registers. A 2-byte `PUSH` that pushes the immediate value onto the stack, followed by a 1-byte `POP` that pops the value off the top of the stack and into a register, is the workhorse trick—very common and very useful. But, if you are just setting the register to 1, you can do `XOR`+`INC`, which is the same 3 bytes. And, if you already have the value you want in a register, then you can build off of it using the magic `LEA` instruction, which is also only 3 bytes. Both of those tricks are showcased here, since they are more interesting and somewhat faster than the good old `PUSH`+`POP`.
- Inside of the body of the loop, we do a pretty neat optimization. The fundamental operation we're doing here is:

  ```
  edx = (eax - edx)
  eax -= edx
  ```

  which would naively be translated to (indeed, this is what most C compilers do):

  ```
  sub  eax, edx                              ; 2 bytes
  mov  ebx, edx                              ; 2 bytes
  mov  edx, eax                              ; 2 bytes
  mov  eax, ebx                              ; 2 bytes
  ```

  or, somewhat better—rewrite the subtraction as addition of a negative so that the operand order can be reversed, allowing the result to end up in the desired register without having to clobber a temporary register (ICC is able to apply this optimization):

  ```
  neg  edx                                   ; 2 bytes
  add  edx, eax     ; edx = (eax - edx)      ; 2 bytes
  sub  eax, edx     ; eax -= edx             ; 2 bytes
  ```

  but I have written it as:

  ```
  sub  eax, edx                              ; 2 bytes
  xchg eax, edx                              ; 1 byte
  ```

  which is conceptually similar to the naive version (only one subtraction is done, then some moves), but much more compact because of the `XCHG` instruction. This avoids clobbering a register, and decreases the size of the code. (I guess you could have equally well used an `XOR` to avoid clobbering a register—the famous move-without-a-temporary trick—but `XCHG` is 1 fewer byte for golfing purposes.)

  Now, to be fair, the `MOV`s are probably much faster in real-world code, especially on modern processors that can elide moves in the front end via register renaming. Exchanges can't be elided, and aren't known for being particularly fast. If it weren't for register renaming, ICC's code (the add-a-negative approach) would probably be the fastest in the real-world, since it's compact and arithmetic operations are extremely efficient.
- The `LOOP` instruction. This is an old CISC-style instruction that is equivalent to:

  ```
  dec  ecx
  jnz  Label
  ```

  but is avoided in modern code (and by all compilers) because it's actually *slower* than the above sequence. It's also less versatile, because it has the `ECX` register hard-coded as the counter. However, for code-golf purposes, it's great! And since we used a calling convention that passes the parameter in `ECX`, we don't even have to do anything!

  (If you wanted to use a different calling convention, you'd just have to do a `MOV` or `XCHG` at the very top of the function to copy the parameter into `ECX`; or, you could swap out the `LOOP` instruction for the expanded form shown above. Either of these would only cost a couple of bytes, maximum, so this optimization isn't really saving us much, but I think it does earn a couple of *style* points! :-)

Similarly, if you wanted to write this for x86-64, like my original answer, which uses a different calling convention, it would be easy to adapt. Either of these will do it, and both are only 14 bytes:

```
Fibtraction_64_A          |      Fibtraction_64_B:
   push 1                 |         mov  ecx, edi
   pop  rax               |         push 1
   lea  edx, [rax+1]      |         pop  rax
Iterate:                  |         lea  edx, [rax+1]
   sub  eax, edx          |      Iterate:
   xchg eax, edx          |         sub  eax, edx
   dec  edi               |         xchg eax, edx
   jg   Iterate           |         loop Iterate
   ret                    |         ret
```

Comment: +1 for the very detailed explanation. Is there a way to run this code on TIO?

Comment: @cows As it turns out, yes. I just didn't know how to do it at the time I wrote this answer. I've added in a link. The trick uses a C wrapper to call the assembly code. There is an assembler on TIO, but screen output is platform-specific (and often requires a lot of code in asm), so doing it that way is a much bigger pain, which is why I used to avoid it.

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 7 bytes

```
3XIFDŠ-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/fOMLTzeXoAt3//y0A)

**Explanation**

```
3         # push 3
 X        # push 1
  IF      # input times do:
    D     # duplicate top of stack
     Š    # move the copy down 2 spaces on the stack
      -   # subtract top 2 numbers
```

Comment: Fails for [0](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f8/ItLT3eXoAt3//w0A) :(

Comment: @Datboi: Thanks for notifying! Fortunately it was easily fixed without costing any bytes :)

Comment: Oh wow. I was looking for a fix myself and the best I could come up with was 11 bytes but you just did it without using any more bytes :D gratz

Answer (score 6):

## [cQuents](https://github.com/stestoltz/cQuents), 8 bytes

```
=1,2:y-z
```

1-indexed. Since cQuents isn't stack based it isn't as terse as Oasis. Prints the whole sequence if no input is given.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy4sTc0rKf7/39ZQx8iqUrfq/38A)

#### Explanation

```
=1,2      Sequence start equals 1,2
    :     Mode: sequence. Prints the 1-indexed nth term for input n.
     y-z  Each item in the sequence equals the second to last item minus the last item
```

Comment: Note current version uses `Y` and `Z` instead of `y` and `z`

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
1_@¡3
```

0-indexed.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/98w3uHQQuP///8bGwIA)

Answer (score 6):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), 19 bytes

```perl6
{(1,2,*-*...*)[$_]}
```

[test it](https://tio.run/##LY5Bi8IwEIXv@RXvsNqmTINNa6sUPenV0552FREbpaCtmCqK6F/vTsKeZt73voG5mOsp72/W4J6rfSnOTwz3bWUw619hQpqiOFJKRfL3a7t5e/Hb2K4Uy9UCVduYuONYN8dSiEN7xYhd/CAhaELMI@WREQqXOCYTXvSUkDlS5Ey0U5Ips1S7o7Fmb5J5muaZiOcI13VTmQet77vTzUi8BFBbuEdD30iCrwg@qsO5C4NBajGbB/Ljq39W2ECKd/8H)

### Expanded:

```perl6
{  # bare block lambda with implicit parameter ｢$_｣
  (

    1, 2,  # seed the sequence

    * - *  # WhateverCode lambda used to generate the rest of the values

    ...    # keep generating until:

    *      # never stop

  )[ $_ ]  # index into the sequence
}
```

Comment: If it was `f(n) = f(n - 1) - f(n - 2)` it would be `{(1,2,*R-*...*)[$_]}` instead

Answer (score 6):

### Mathematica (using a built-in), <s>18</s> 12 bytes

*Several bytes saved by user202729 !*

```
LucasL[2-#]&
```

Or the same idea without a built-in, for <s>32</s> <s>31</s> <s>30</s> 29 bytes:

```
Tr[{p=(1+5^.5)/2,1-p}^(2-#)]&
```

Uses 1-indexing. [Try them at the Wolfram sandbox](https://sandbox.open.wolframcloud.com/) (they don't work in Mathics, unfortunately).

This uses the observation by ETHproductions and user202729 that the sequence is nearly the Lucas numbers (only with alternating sign, or reading backwards). The 29-byte function is the [closed formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_number#Relationship_to_Fibonacci_numbers) for the Lucas numbers.

Comment: I think that is `LucasL[1-#]&` or something. I didn't test...

Answer (score 5):

## [Mathics](http://mathics.github.io/), 31 bytes

```
f@1=1
f@2=2
f@x_:=f[x-2]-f[x-1]
```

-2 thanks to @MartinEnder!

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00sychMLv7/P83B0NaQK83ByNYISFbEW9mmRVfoGsXqgijD2P8BRZl5JdFp@g5BiXnpqQ6GprH/AQ)

Comment: The first two definitions can use `=` instead of `:=` and it's shorter to define an operator `±` instead of a function `f`, because you save the `@`s in the definitions. (I'm not sure the latter works in Mathics, but it would in Mathematica.)

Comment: @MartinEnder thanks! I tried it with just = earlier but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: The overall shortest approach is to use an unnamed function though: `If[#<3,#,#0[#-2]-#0[#-1]]&`

Comment: @MartinEnder it uh... Doesn't work in mathics due to garbage Unicode support. Welp.

Comment: You can post that answer, if you want.

Answer (score 5):

## Brainfuck, <s>51</s> 44 bytes

```
+++++>+>++<<[>[>>+<<-]>[<+>>-<-]>[<+>-]<<<-]
```

0-indexed, the input is on cell 0 and the output on cell 1.

Output is in two complement format.

<sub>Per [this meta consensus](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods), [input for Turing machines may be written to the tape pre-execution](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7031/65326), and [the contents of the tape post-execution may be used as a Turing machine's output](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7032/65326).</sub>

**How?**

```
# The tape: I O A B . . .
# I = input, O = output

>+     # O = 1
>++    # A = 2
<<[    
    >[>>+<<-]     # B = O              [ I   0   A   O  ]
    >[<+>>-<-]    # B = B - A, O = A   [ I   A   0  O-A ]
    >[<+>-]<<<    # A = B = O - A      [ I   A  O-A  0  ]
-]     # Repeat I times
```

Comment: Brainfuck is Brainfuck, not a Turing Machine.

Comment: Can we have a TIO link?

Comment: @Phoenix What's with that comment? It is anyway similar to a Turing machine, but lack random IP move. So it can be a subset of Turing machine (yet still Turing complete)

Answer (score 4):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 45 bytes

0-indexed

```php
for($x=1,$y=2;$argn--;)$x=$x-$y=$x-$y;echo$x;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jX5BRwKWSWJSeZ6tkbKhk/T8tv0hDpcLWUEel0tbIGiyjq2utCRRSqdAFioFJ69TkjHyVCuv//wE)

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 46 bytes

1-indexed recursive function

```php
function f($i){return$i<3?$i:f($i-2)-f($i-1);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAk00rzkksy8/MU0jRUMjWri1JLSovyVDJtjO1VMq1AYrpGmrpg2lDTuvZ/anJGPlCpsZGm9X8A)

Answer (score 4):

## Java, <s>65</s> 61 bytes

Golfed:

```java
n->{int a=1,b=2;for(;n-->0;a-=b)b=a-b;System.out.println(a);}
```

This uses the standard trick of calculating Fibonacci using only two variables to hold the state, but modified to work with subtraction. I am aware that theoretically, `System.out.print()` *should* work here but in practice it is inconsistent with flushing output and sometimes (often enough to be an issue) will literally print *nothing* using the Oracle JVM.

This function is zero-indexed.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVDBToNAEL3zFe8ICRCpnqztQRMTzz14MB4WusWpMEuW2RrT8O04EMG4yebN7Hsvs/PO5mIy11k@Hz/HqjF9j2cqxZtKyLGWjk1V0WOQV5KPQ1gpXKMI6ELZUIVejChcHB3RGuL4IJ64fnuH8XWfqBZ6Ts4jJhYQ7sH2C1qr5IoixSZFoVDcaTm1ircFhsWq5nhkZPu1x@SGwW5ylwqb7crMg7bgLMMeN1tVZTuUycpjNugryj/T4bsX2@YuSN7p56Xh2CQLPYxIQb/tEE132t7TxYj9t/4pPmukeRBq8lPgOav8yXEfWusfXlhsbf0eC5XOa/Aa0eLQ0G0nMc8jh2iIxh8)

Ungolfed:

```java
public class FibtractionFibonacciButWithSubtraction {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i : new int[] { 1, 2, 11, 14, 21, 24, 31 }) {
      f(n -> {
        int a = 1, b = 2;
        for (; n-- > 0; a -= b)
          b = a - b;
        System.out.println(a);
      } , i);
    }
  }

  private static void f(java.util.function.Consumer<Integer> function, int n) {
    function.accept(n);
  }
}
```

Comment: You can use `for(;n-->0;a-=b)b=a-b;` instead of `for(;n>0;--n){b=a-b;a-=b;}` to save 4 bytes.

Answer (score 3):

## C, 30 bytes

[**Try Online**](https://tio.run/##FcsxCoAwDEDRq4ggJLSFqpuxehapVDIYpXETz151@m/50W0xlqKUQPDWIFM3f3Qduj8tDkJPYdoXFsA7HRk4tMRj74mNsRo8JmC0Z2a5EtTNaqvaKn7XCw) 1-indexed

```c
s;f(n){s=n>2?f(n-2)-f(n-1):n;}
```

Comment: Is it acceptable to return the value through an external variable? I'm not very sure.

Comment: @KeyuGan the value is returned, one way or another, but consider this, this function does return the value of s with some compilers, try **tcc** on TIO

Comment: @Khaled.K Astonishing! I used to think `f(a){a=1;}` in GCC return 1 is weird enough. But tcc proves to be more interesting.

Answer (score 2):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 26 bytes

```
n->([1,2]*[0,1;1,-1]^n)[1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FctBCoAgEEbhqwyuNEboN3dRFxEDN4YQwxBtOr3l7nuLp@Vu/tReaevid5vAIU9pZqxgj3yIS8i9qF6vFfI76d3k@WlGGKpWnGMaHwOMyOFn5AXZ9Q8)

Answer (score 2):

## Common Lisp, 46 bytes

```
(defun f(n)(if(< n 3)n(-(f(- n 2))(f(1- n)))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FckxCoBADETRq6ScKbZwbb2NGgjIsKx6/hh/9eDvV9wjE8fpr8whIhybyVYKDY5W7mRpKfIvMWboMbj1WvkB)

1-indexed, plain recursive solution.

Answer (score 2):

### R, 38 bytes

```
f=function(n)`if`(n<3,n,f(n-2)-f(n-1))
```

1-indexed solution

**Explanation :**

The `'if'` function has the same syntax as `ifelse` : `ifelse(test, TRUE, FALSE)`.

In this solution, we create a function `f` that begins to test if the input `n` is strictly inferior to `3` (i.e. equals to 1 or 2 ; `test` part of the `'if'`). If its the case, the output is simply the input (`TRUE` part).

The function otherwise recursively calls itself and outputs the final result (`FALSE` part)

Comment: Can we have a TIO link?

Answer (score 2):

## Mini-Flak, 72 bytes

(1-indexed)

```
({}(()()())(())[()()()()]){({}(([{}]({})))[({}([{}]{})[({})])][()])}{}{}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVHBboMwDD0nX2GxC0gFjXWnTjvsA6btsBvqIWncgkoTBKGdhPh25iSla9cFkLD9/PxeLFtR6XRbi/00Re@Vrvx/BnlaaYXfqCLO42FkdB6gabHD9oig4VRWNa44i@PEPYmr9l0JS59K2BznnBUBEidrSna9tK3YWHjmSSDtrNjsQZvTCr4@Pok6hyVkdPgQAC02KCxoYvZCrnXwAKHuM08gkSCoEruvGMa17zENyAUIrUDjTlh0rUTolFvTLACPou4pT5HvTtjFhIAUZPY7JQwRqbwDutSObvQFbFl1IGtDmm6YU0kt9Bac3fshIQfT2TPKG2CzgWuWNCJE5KqOIZhzUlhyo9mj4BU8WeHMeqaUxtzppsQ67MOQdrpvW@I/@sPkDN6UcqEDCWmOM5RSO7TwyJ3DPxvPYduag9tZmIy0iotz385HPozznZClFlWvldBE6BcnwClBMDrsgU9T/vQD)

The TIO links have more comments, so it is easier to understand.

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <strike>34</strike> 33 bytes

```
Ａ¹αＡ²βＦ…²θ¿﹪ι²Ａ⁻βαβＡ⁻αβα⎇﹪Ｉθ²ＩαＩβ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5///9noWHdp7bCKI2ndv0fs@yRw3LgKwdh/a/37nq3M5DQKGFjxp3n9t0buM5GHsjiPeorx2o4v2elUC1m0DURhCx6f9/YyMA)

1-indexed. I insist on writing answers in a language with a totally different purpose... Link to the [verbose version](https://tio.run/##VcyxCoNAEATQ3q/YchfWIpfSKqQWQvAH9oyaA7nDOw3k6zeboEW6mYF5/VNyn2RWvZQSpognFmqqvTj2VsaUAe8Sp8GGhagCCCNgmx7bnDCwI4L90Ia4FfRmMNj1fxbTGL78LYe4YjfkKPl9QFcpKy5kHMMvyxE8ETWqZ6f1S@syfwA).

Comment: Save 1 byte by casting the result of the ternary instead of the two variables.

Answer (score 2):

## x86-64 Machine Code, 29 bytes

**Simple recursive solution; 1-indexed**

The following is a function written according to the [System V AMD64 calling convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#System_V_AMD64_ABI) that computes and returns the *n*<sup>th</sup> number of the Fibtraction sequence. The sole parameter, *n*, is passed in the `EDI` register. The function returns its result in the `EAX` register.

```
53
51
89 F9
83 EF 02
7E 10
E8 00 00 00 00
8D 79 FF
91
E8 00 00 00 00
29 C1
91
59
5B
C3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##3Vbfa9swEH73X3FvSSAJcbqNkq6Mrj@2whh72ENhjCHbl1jBljJJzo/@89lJsmW7y0Zhg8H8oLrSfXfffXdnhWmNZVIcJoLp8rgqZMIK@KYNUyaKNKaGSwFTg3tzvOOJUcztLCIA2FQ6B/uoZA/tcwEbhRrVFkEqvuKCHG5ZUSFwAbdvH/rQ9PnQawct5dYbY7ofA2b819CBGHSAukpqYMbHMG9j3t7cwyUImMDc2q0L9CfTOy64zjGr7fiSjF5fwnwMOxwohEwKhGHCNEJql6VUoDCtlCaJRtZXyorCoTvaOV@pLDeVIciQoo/IYc7THLimDUfEoQtkHcZfSKtJ/LXPOLZ2@zRfeTtmJWkkvQDNSA6SpSoMyKX1PZmPaklg6GPuLHkBQu7IfInFAVJqggTVHyUQj/qSu1qxQIzcplXBHN7nS0tABuEX8OS5gKUlZHIlq1U@nU5/mz61Skh/qWTp0ubCSLi98m0oN3CyDQlkpPqpCy3y@gkyeTbSt75CAyceizSVEqQkN3nD2pbq6uH4SRHrj7j7wAW2oxefhXlwmceh7AdtsPS1i1sb20TBZsmpzXMmMvoTw1CbTFZm1DHuOhRVSQ1hWyg5GNQ2G7Km@gd7avkxLRtvz7KMEtAWoA1xX/URxM9yCzoqtq@ViSKX6r0wLs09DRSo82xsl5ZbYrnNosjFutcNPYErZvgW39gDomnqhvDe10LTSL9Dc0OFMbpGv/cKNNDGVUJTIMUWlanJb6Tm1mAMBPDQ7xVWaI@rDTA7q5n9J3jSfCVs/UyOdequWekcGkquinXy/7yMjsxgMvirJQ3vUat8W1nHjha7kXFfWftOserDF@etTt6OixSabjhR48d@jaeunTpxHaTbUevH7pfeMcE2wv8wXF63dUnvXTmizmc2TF/kb/5FGzp@SVq5PKPpZxLvmi46vejnbY3CZdG5KMJeM9T9jfqDFrVlbfxYrj7yWRyu5Da8Y@O0wD03/Tq9mp2o06tZp@d4@NXQfHNp1jOEWUe94w8) <sub><sup>(Hey, I finally figured out how to make TIO work for assembly language! Ignore the ugly boilerplate to print numbers… :-p)</sup></sub>

**Ungolfed assembly mnemonics:**

```
Fibtraction:
   push     rbx           ; preserve original value in EBX
   push     rcx           ; preserve original value in ECX
   mov      ecx, edi      ; preserve original 'n' in ECX
   sub      edi, 2        ; EDI = n - 2
   jle      .Finished     ; if n <= 2, we're done (base case for recursion)
   call     Fibtraction   ; compute f(EDI), which is f(n - 2)
   lea      edi, [rcx-1]  ; EDI = n - 1
   xchg     eax, ecx      ; save result of f(n-2) in ECX (which we can now safely clobber)
   call     Fibtraction   ; compute f(EDI), which is f(n - 1)
   sub      ecx, eax      ; calculate f(n - 2) - f(n - 1)
.Finished:                ; fall through...
   xchg     eax, ecx      ; move result from ECX into EAX
   pop      rcx           ; restore original value to ECX
   pop      rbx           ; restore original value to EBX
   ret                    ; return, with result in EAX
```

Okay, it's assembly language, so there are no fancy built-ins to help us. But just look at all of those 1-byte opcodes! `PUSH`, `POP`, and `XCHG` are all very handy here.
These `XCHG` instructions are really just substitutions for register-to-register `MOV`es. We don't actually need to exchange the values; we just care about a one-way movement. But, although normally `MOV reg, reg` and `XCHG reg, reg` are both 2 bytes, there is a special 1-byte encoding for `XCHG` when one of the operands is the accumulator (`EAX`). Thus, this substitution saves us a few bytes (at the possible expense of speed).

The only long, ugly instructions are the `CALL`s, used to invoke the function recursively. (Technically, all of those 0s in the opcodes get replaced by the linker with the function's actual 32-bit relative displacement when the code gets linked, but the resulting binary will be the same size in bytes because this won't change the *length* of the instruction.) But there isn't really anything we can do to reduce the size. `CALL` can be emulated as `PUSH`+`JMP`, but just the `PUSH` instruction alone consumes more bytes than `CALL`!

The recursive nature of this algorithm made it a fun and interesting challenge—to me, at least. It's not very often in the real world that you get to write recursive code! It just isn't an efficient way to do things. (Double recursion leads to *exponential complexity*! Bleh!) Compilers also do a bad job, in general, optimizing it, so this hand-written assembly is head-and-shoulders above what a C compiler would generate for the naive solution:

```
int Fibtraction(int n)  { return n <= 2 ? n : f(n-2) - f(n-1); }
```

(although it has been optimized for *size*, rather than speed, obviously).

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, 26 bytes

Nothing fancy here, it's just a translation of Python or Javascript solutions :

```
f=->n{n<3?n:f[n-2]-f[n-1]}
```

The results are 1-indexed.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY7NCsIwEITvfYo9KiaF/NgfMYrPEXpQbDFQYkkapLY@e9xYPM3Ox8zuunCbYuwUPdnZHsXZHjptKW9oEtZ8on88Q38HBZoR4AQoikCRBMrk0LIKB14TkImUBRKeIqxGJngq7TnmKvmjopBN5lof@hHXXpy7TrltX5v1Uu7Nu93Oi1mg02aHL2QDrOlsCKOHf1PBWohf)

Answer (score 2):

## SWI Prolog, 88bytes

Did I hear recursion? Prolog is here!

```
g(1,1).
g(2,2).
g(X,Y):-A is X-2,g(A,B),C is X-1,g(C,D),Y is B-D.
f(X):-g(X,Y),print(Y).
```

Try it:
[SWISH](https://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/Fibtraction%20-%20Fibonacci%20but%20with%20subtraction.pl)

Comment: Can we have a TIO link?

Comment: Here you are: https://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/Fibtraction%20-%20Fibonacci%20but%20with%20subtraction.pl

Answer (score 2):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 17+3 = 20 bytes

```
43\n;
?!\:@-{1-:}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/38Q4Js@ay14xxspBt9pQ16r2/39zi/@6ZQqGhgA)

Input is expected on the stack at the start of the program, so +3 bytes for the `-v` flag.

Answer (score 2):

## Fortress 0.1 Alpha, 39 bytes.

```
f(n)=if n<3then n else f(n-2)-f(n-1)end
```

The interpreter is archived [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20070715233437/http://fortress.sunsource.net/files/documents/81/140/fortress_168.zip) (direct download).

This language is old and dead, very dead. (1-indexed: f(1)=1, f(2)=2).

Can be placed into a program like this:

```
export Executable
f(n)=if n<3then n else f(n-2)-f(n-1)end
run(args) = do
    println(f(3))
end
```

Does this **really** need explaining? This is just the definition.

Comment: Is there absolutely no way of trying it online?

Comment: Nope. If there was, I would've found it by now. Follow the link, it's *archived*.

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia](https://julialang.org/), 24 bytes

```
f(n)=n>2?f(n-2)-f(n-1):n
```

1-indexed

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0/f8/TSNP0zbPzsgeyNA10tQFUYaaVnn//WyNTLjS8osU8mwNrfy4ODPTFPJsgDRnQVFmXomGkooGSKumjoKSJhdnak5xKkwqJw8uqaenB5bNS@EC4v8A)

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 37 bytes

```
LinearRecurrence[{-1,1},{1,2},{#+1}]&
```

Comment: Does it work on Mathics? If so, can we have a TIO link?

Comment: [Once again, the obvious answer is shorter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/131526/60042)

Comment: Although MartinEnder came up with an even shorter, *more* obvious solution.

Answer (score 1):

## [Go](https://golang.org/), 50 bytes

```go
func f(n int)int{if n>2{n=f(n-2)-f(n-1)};return n}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYwxCsMwDEX3nEJksoYUrNCptGfoFUyIgkmsBONMxmd3bbpK8BE83v/bWS@37G5bITgvgw/XGROMHNJY@ZYF2Ah4SdiSPYN8KMu7wYlw6s9iecU13VFAyr/SlwxCHqBdW3p8Y2sfYtgQokJnlVpdtk8Vk26Tbs/dLvUH)

Answer (score 1):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), 32 bytes

```
?3sb1sc[lblcdsb-sc1-d0<d]dsdxlbp
```

1-indexed.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0n@/9/euDjJsDg5OicpJzmlOEm3ONlQN8XAJiU2pTilIiep4P9/QwA)

### Explanation

```
?     # Take input and push it onto the main stack.
3sb   # Push 3 into register "b".
1sc   # Push 1 into register "c".
[     # Begin macro definition.
 lblc # Load the values in registers "b" and "c" onto the main stack.
 dsb  # Duplicate the top-of-stack value and push it into register "b".
 -sc  # Push the difference of the top two values into register "c".
 1-d  # Subtract 1 from the top-of-stack value and duplicate the result.
 0<d  # If the result is greater than 0, execute the macro in register "d".
]     # End macro definition.
dsdx  # Duplicate the macro, push a copy into register "d", and execute the 
      # remaining copy.
lbp   # Output the value stored in register "b".
```

Answer (score 1):

## VBA, 62 Bytes

Recursive function that takes input, `n`, as integer and outputs the 1-indexed  element of A061084

```vba
Function f(n):If n<3Then f=n Else f=f(n-2)-f(n-1):End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Braingolf](https://github.com/gunnerwolf/braingolf), 22 bytes

```
[vl1-?!-|l1e2|l0e1|R]v
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLz89J@/8/uizHUNdeUbcmxzDVqCbHINWwJii27P///4YA)

Why is it so long D:

Answer (score 1):

## [Positron](https://github.com/alexander-liao/positron), 63 bytes

```
a=function{k=$1;if(k>2)then{k=((a@(k-2))-(a@(k-1)))};return k;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcgxCsAgDADAr3TokAwOuorFr0hRGoQoaZyKb7eUbsf1dpNK47VSKINPpcZPDbv1VKAeDvXKXwCkCNU4RPPLIuL0knUIb9XP1YVYY4rWrRc)

Comment: *\*aggressive parenthesizing\**

Comment: @totallyhuman It's to get around the 5000000000 bugs lol

Answer (score 0):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 52 bytes

```
fun f(n:Int):Int{return if(n<3)n else f(n-2)-f(n-1)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZYsxDsIwDEV3TuExHjokUZeqQmJk5gQZkioiGOS6A6p69pAw1h7@1396fr6lZKo1bQTJ0HQnwR47R9mYIDc4eySIZY3dGBwOvSwe/6dXyGQCL@sEN@bwnR/CmZYrwn6Bdp@2pJBJxiGeiFfEasmOCjltOW35bh31Bw)

Answer (score 0):

## [Groovy](http://groovy-lang.org/), <s>27</s> 26 bytes

```
f={n->n<3?n:f(n-2)-f(n-1)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy/Kzy@r/P8/zbY6T9cuz8bYPs8qTSNP10hTF0QZatb@LyjKzCvJyVNI0zDS5EJwjJE5hihShqbIPCMUOSMUOWMjzf8A)

Okay, so I feel like I stumbled upon a great language for golfing. This code is basically what most other answers are doing, if `n` is lesser than 3, then return `n` or else return `f(n - 2) - f(n - 1)`. But there are a few cool things about this.

For a language that compiles to the JVM, Groovy is surprisingly terse. Variable declarations need no type definition. Functions (called closures in Groovy) are denoted with the `{}` syntax. <s>`it` can be used to refer to the sole argument to the function, which means you don't need to specify the argument name and type.</s> Turns out naming the argument was shorter. Combined with the ternary operator, this code ended up quite golfy for a "practical" language.

Comment: Tip: Using `it` is better if there are 3 or fewer references to `it`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 15 bytes

First time doing Pyth. ^^

```
L?<b3b-y-b2y-b1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/38feJsk4SbdSN8kIiA3/V/pGGykYKxgaKRiaKhgZKRiZKhgb/QcA)

### Explanation

```
L?<b3b-y-b2y-b1

L                define a function y that takes an argument b
 ?<b3            if b < 3...
     b           ...return b
      -y-b2y-b1  else return y(b - 2) - y(b - 1)
```

Comment: [12 bytes](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%40u%2BG-F%3E2GQS2&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1%0A2%0A11%0A14%0A21%0A24%0A31&debug=0)