# Length of a Sumac sequence

Tags: code-golf, sequence, arithmetic

A Sumac sequence starts with two integers: t<sub>1</sub> and t<sub>2</sub>.

The next term, t<sub>3</sub>, = t<sub>1</sub> - t<sub>2</sub>

**More generally, t<sub>n</sub> = t<sub>n-2</sub> - t<sub>n-1</sub>**

The sequence ends when t<sub>n</sub> < 0.

Your challenge: Write a program or function that prints the length of a Sumac sequence, starting with t<sub>1</sub> and t<sub>2</sub>.

- t<sub>1</sub> and t<sub>2</sub> are integers within your language's range.
- Standard loopholes apply.

**Test cases**

```
t1  t2       sumac_len(t1,t2)

120  71      5
101  42      3
500  499     4
387  1       3
```

Bonus street cred:

```
3    -128    1
-314 73      2
```

This is code-golf, so shortest answer in bytes wins.

Comment: [Closely related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/131513/fibtraction-fibonacci-but-with-subtraction), if not a duplicate

Comment: This seems to be a good challenge, but is a little unclear. Are we supposed to take `t1` and `t2` as input? And what is `i` in the test cases?

Comment: Is it guaranteed that t1 and t2 are >= 0?

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing The "Your challenge" statement clearly states: *starting with t1 and t2.* - Also see the test cases

Comment: Updated test cases to be a little more clear what's input and what's output.

Comment: Not a dupe; we're printing the length, and we're starting with two arbitrary numbers instead of 1 & 2. Editing to clarify that they're integers.

Comment: Can we have a test case where **t_1** is negative? That is, if it can be...

Comment: Sure, why not. @totallyhuman.

Comment: Putting the ones with negatives under "bonus street cred" to avoid the problem.

Comment: @Blacksilver Huh? What's that bonus exactly? Bonus are generally [discouraged](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8106/36398) anyway

Comment: Do we have to handle `t_1 = t_2 = 0`? Does "bonus street cred" mean we don't have to handle `t_1 < 0` or `t_2 < 0`?

Answer (score 9):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 8 bytes

```
→V<¡oG-↔
```

Takes input as a 2-element list.
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6vkKtR/KipsUjz0Lb/j9omhdkcWpjvrvuobcr///@jDY0MdMwNY7miDQ0MdUyMgAxTAwMdE0tLIMvYwlzHMBYA)

### Explanation

```
→V<¡oG-↔  Implicit input, say p=[101,42]
   ¡      Iterate on p:
       ↔    Reverse: [42,101]
    oG-     Cumulative reduce by subtraction: [42,59]
          Result is infinite list [[101,42],[42,59],[59,-17],[-17,76],[76,-93]...
 V<       Find the first index where adjacent pairs are lexicographically increasing.
          In our example [42,59] < [59,-17], so this gives 2.
→         Increment: 3
```

Answer (score 8):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 22 bytes

```hs
a#b|b<0=1|c<-a-b=1+b#c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Vc6xCsMgFIXh3ae4kA5KEbxqSVLi0jfRNFCJ1RJTuuTdrRk948c/nJfN6xJCKbZzh5uEwWOeuOXO4NV1c3lbH8HAMxGo@2w@7nABlAI66LFFgRW1bPAmzlKPY6Nq6KsiIZwDPFL85iUDzbsPAX5pWzO7t32tKUc5sIYpV6jZ@USVPw)

I really wish there was a way to pattern match for a negative number...

### Explanation

```hs
a#b|b<0=1|c<-a-b=1+b#c

a#b                     -- define a function (#) that takes two arguments a and b
   |b<0                 -- if b is negative...
       =1               -- return 1
         |              -- otherwise...
          c<-a-b        -- assign a-b to c...
                =  b#c  -- and return the result of (#) applied to b and c...
                 1+     -- incremented by 1
```

Comment: I think the explanation is less clear than the code itself for once. :P

Comment: @WheatWizard That's most probably because I suck at explanations. :P

Answer (score 3):

### [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>12</s> 11 bytes

```
V<0t¡ȯF-↑2↔
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/P8zGoOTQwhPr3XQftU00etQ25f///9GGRgY65oaxAA)

Takes the bonus street cred for whatever that's worth.

#### Explanation

```
    ¡ȯ       Repeatedly apply the function to the right to the list of all
             previous values and collect the results in an infinite list.
          ↔  Reverse the list of previous results.
        ↑2   Take the first two values (last two results).
      F-     Compute their difference (using a fold).
   t         Discard the first element.
V<0          Find the first index of a negative value.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 13 bytes

```
`yy-y0<~]N2-&
```

This handles negative inputs (last two test cases).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/P6GyUrfSwKYu1s9IV@3/f0MjAy5zQwA) Or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##y00syfmf8D@hslK30sCmLtbPSFftf4SLn0pFyH9DIwMuc0MuQwNDLhMjLlMDAy4TS0suYwtzLkMuYy5dQyMLLl1jQxMuc2MA).

#### Explanation

```
`        % Do...while
  yy     %   Duplicate top two elements. Implicit inputs first time
  -      %   Subtract
  y      %   Duplicate from below: push previous term
  0<~    %   Is it 0 or greater? This is the loop condition
]        % End. Proceed with next iteration if top of the stack is true
N        % Push number of elements in stack
2-       % Subtract 2
&        % Specify that the next function, namely implicit display, should
         % only display the top of the stack
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 29 bytes

```ruby
->a,b{(1..a).find{a<b=a-a=b}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y5RJ6law1BPL1FTLy0zL6U60SbJNlE30TaptvZ/QWlJsUJatKGRgY65YSwXlGuso2toZBH7HwA)

Comment: `a<b=a-a=b` ...How does Ruby parse that..?

Answer (score 2):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), <s>142</s> 90 bytes

```
((()){{}<(({}({}))[({}[{}])({})])([(({})<(())>)](<>)){({}())<>}{}{((<{}>))<>{}}{}<>{}>}<>)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYoxCoBADAS/YpktBM/GJuQjxxVaCKJY2C55e0wgTBh2jm@/3vl89jtCRADSVYSeB/Rkpw@UJXst0OoMQ9SyrxZQczpFlG5l9PR6lkTE1qa2Lj8)

Not very short. Takes input backwards.

## Explanation

```
(
 (())   #Push 1
 {      #Until 0
  {}    #Pop (+1 to counter)
  <(({}({}))[({}[{}])({})])  #tn = tn-1 - tn-2
  ([(({})<(())>)](<>)){({}())<>}{}{((<{}>))<>{}}{}<>{}>  #Greater than 0?
 }      #End loop
 <>     #Get rid of everything
)       #Push result
```

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 11 bytes

```
[DŠ-D0‹#]NÌ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f8/2uXoAl0Xg0cNO5Vj/Q73/P9vbshlaGQAAA)

**Explanation**

Takes input as `t2, t1`

```
[             # start a loop
 DŠ           # duplicate top of stack and move it down 2 positions
   -          # subtract the top 2 values
    D0‹#      # if a copy of the top value is negative, break loop
        ]     # end loop
         NÌ   # push iteration index+2
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>32</s> <s>27</s> 26 bytes

*-5 bytes thanks to totallyhuman's abuse of gcc (seems to work on tcc too)*
*-1 byte thanks to PrincePolka*

```c
f(a,b){a=b<0?:1+f(b,a-b);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bc3fCoIwHIbhc6/ihxFstMWmhpp/upFONtdqUDPKOhGvfRkWNOn05eH7GnpsGrcwtjk/1AHKe6dMuz7VTiNBJO5FJUu22/KVRpIIKnExOGM7uAhj0bM1CkMfAFxvY9Qo5BEjkHKoaliqvQ0JaPRpGBe/kHECSeTDqc3gn8UNG1uS576Ms5SAD6c0YwQojzLfTc2HNObJeB178hvfdAico@oF)

Comment: [26 bytes](https://tio.run/##bc3fCoIwHIbhc6/ihxFstMWmhpp/upFONtdqUDPKOhGvfRkWNOn05eH7GnpsGrcwtjk/1AHKe6dMuz7VTiNBJO5FJUu22/KVRpIIKnExOGM7uAhj0bM1CkMfAFxvY9Qo5BEjkHKoaliqvQ0JaPRpGBe/kHECSeTDqc3gn8UNG1uS576Ms5SAD6c0YwQojzLfTc2HNObJeB178hvfdAico@oF) since, b<0 evaluates to 1, change ?1:1 to ?:1

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 55 bytes

```
(t=1;While[Last@LinearRecurrence[{-1,1},#,t++]>0];t-2)&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7X6PE1tA6PCMzJzXaJ7G4xMEnMy81sSgoNbm0qCg1Lzk1ulrXUMewVkdZp0RbO9bOINa6RNdIU@1/QFFmXolDWnS1oZGBjrlhbSwXQsTAUMfECFnE1MBAx8TSElnI2MIcaGzsfwA)

and now the regular boring approach by @totallyhuman

## Mathematica, 25 bytes

```
If[#2<0,1,1+#0[#2,#-#2]]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n6Zg@98zLVrZyMZAx1DHUFvZAMjWUdZVNoqNVfsfUJSZV6LgoJAWbWhkoKNgbhjLhSRkYKijYGKELGRqAFRlYmmJLGZsYa6jYBj7HwA)

Comment: FYI, the regular boring approach is [less than half as long](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n6Zg@98zLVrZyMZAx1DHUFvZAMjWUdZVNoqNVfsfUJSZV6LgoJAWbWhkoKNgbhjLhSRkYKijYGKELGRqAFRlYmmJLGZsYa6jYBj7HwA "Wolfram Language (Mathematica) – Try It Online").

Comment: @totallyhuman boring indeed... you can save a byte `#1` to `#`

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 22 bytes

```
[:#({:,-/)^:(0<{:)^:a:
```

How it works:

```
                  ^:a: - Repeat until the result stops changing, store the results in a list
          ^:(0<{:)     - repeat if the second term is positive
   ({:,-/)             - makes a tuple (second, first minus second)
[:#                    - number of elements in the list ([: caps the fork)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYpBCoMwFET3OcVgFypo@n@SEv3UkxQUKQ3ixkWW0rPHbOJshvdm9hTipEEQUPrIozml65/tLA29T8m9SmpVpVGHSdfo8BeEqNTvux0IYEOA5xuJAWcKviivbhwL28ED99kiZ2EzFLFYdvAW6QI)

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (ES6), 24 bytes

Returns [true instead of 1](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9067/58563).

```js
f=(a,b)=>b<0||1+f(b,a-b)
```

#### Test cases

```js
f=(a,b)=>b<0||1+f(b,a-b)

console.log(f(120,  71  )) //    5
console.log(f(101,  42  )) //    3
console.log(f(500,  499 )) //    4
console.log(f(387,  1   )) //    3

console.log('Bonus street cred:')
console.log(f(3,    -128)) //    1
console.log(f(-314, 73 ))  //    2
```

Comment: @totallyhuman Then you would need `f(b)(a-b)` so no saving.

Comment: What if `a<0`? (1 more to go)

Comment: Update: you are no longer required to support negative input, but it's cool if you do.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 29 bytes

```python
f=lambda a,b:b<0 or-~f(b,a-b)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Tcw7CoAwEEXR3lVMmYEJZJKIH3QxGSQo@ENsbNx6TCVpD/e987nnY7cpxXENm0wBAkkvg4Hj0m9UQkELpvNa9ltFxdYQNIxY/WKYwNtCapMb33UFubYhKFeOQLNtC9GOfb52iOkD)

Returns [True instead of 1](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9067/58563).

Answer (score 0):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 23 bytes

```apl
2∘{0>-/⍵:⍺⋄(⍺+1)∇-⍨\⌽⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R2wSjRx0zqg3sdPUf9W61etS761F3iwaQ0jbUfNTRrvuod0XMo569QLlaoHIFQyMDBXNDLiDDwFDBxAjIMDUwUDCxtASyjC3MFQwB)

**How?**

`2∘` - with an initial accumulator of 2,

`-/⍵` - if the next term

`0>` - is below 0,

`⍺` - return the accumulator. otherwise,

`(⍺+1)` - increase the accumulator

`∇` - and recurse with

`-⍨\⌽⍵` - the last two items reversed and differenced.

```apl
      {⍵} 8 2
8 2
      {⌽⍵} 8 2
2 8
      {-⍨\⌽⍵} 8 2
2 6
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 11 bytes

This is a recursive function that takes two arguments, `G` and `H`. The link is slightly modified in order to actually call the function on the given input.

```
M|<H0hgH-GH
```

**[Test suite.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=M%7C%3CH0hgH-GHgF&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=120%2C+71%0A101%2C+42%0A500%2C+499%0A387%2C+1&debug=0)**

Answer (score 0):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), <s>85</s> 75 bytes

```java
(b,c)->{int d,k=1;for(;;){if(c<0)break;else{d=c;c=b-c;b=d;k++;}}return k;};
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZDBboMwEETP8BV7tBWDMKRKoi39g@aSY9WDbUzlQAwyJlKF@HZqq72Wy65G@zQz2rt4imwYtb033aZ6MU3wLoxd0sRYr10rlIZrUFGCJnFKBnEpimmypsnkhTcKrmCh3ohkimZvSwQa1tUc28ERRLqYlqjXgkqnRYe6n/TS1ApVLTOFsm6wOxxwXZ32s7PQ4YpbMs6yD85/Ac/BNPAI3cjNO2O/Pj5B0Njs9j15/ciH2edjOPjeEptrwsuCwYnTWPNfpuAMjuUu81IEn@PlsgtV5xOD/ayKQcbL8y6TVfwYSlf097fr9gM)

ungolfed:

```java
(b,c)->{
    int d,k=1;
    for(;;){
        if(c<0)
            break;
        else{
            d=c;
            c=b-c;
            b=d;
            k++;
        }
    }
    return k;
};
```

Comment: I believe this would be shorter as a lambda.

Comment: @Potato44 indeed, but I did not have time yesterday to do it, but I did it now and saved 10 bytes.

Comment: [59 bytes](https://tio.run/##fZDBboMwDIbP8BQ@JmqCCDC1VZS@wXrpcdohCemUQgMKodKEeHaWaLuOiy3Ln35/8kO@JB1G4x5tt@leThO8S@uWPLMuGH@X2sA1TmkEg1JVBFLTmOfZmmdTkMFquIIDsSFFNKaXJQEt6QTj98Ejri@i5N3hgJdWaK6Fopor0fLVmzB7Bx1f@ZaNs@pj0l/ga7AtPKMLugVv3dfHJ0icTG7fUzDPYphDMcZF6B1yhUGsKgkcGU5a/zIlI9BUu8xbGXOa83kXqk9HAvu3agKUVaddhtasidI1/v3luv0A "Java (OpenJDK 8) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), <del>24</del> 19 bytes

*-5 bytes thanks to Brad Gilbert b2gills.*

```perl6
{+(|@_,*-*...^0>*)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/WlujxiFeR0tXS09PL87ATkuz9r81V3FipUKahqGRgY65oaa1goKygilMzMBQx8QIImYMFTM1MNAxsbQECiormEDFjC3MdQzBIsb/AQ)

**Explanation**: The whole thing in the parentheses is exactly the sequence in question (`|@_` are the first 2 terms (= the two parameters), `*-*` is a function that takes two arguments and returns their difference, and `* <0` is the stopping condition (term less than 0). We omit the last term with `^` after the `...`). We then force the numerical context by the `+` operator, which yields the length of the sequence.

Comment: `{+(|@_,*-*...^0>*)}`

Comment: @BradGilbertb2gills: Thank you. I had a large break with golfing, so I'm a bit rusty. What I don't get, though, is why you must put the space in `* <0*, but why you don't need it in `0>*`...

Comment: The space is needed so it doesn't get confused with `%h<a>`

Answer (score 0):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), 44 bytes

```java
int f(int a,int b){return b<0?1:1+f(b,a-b);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVDLasMwELz3K4aAwaJSsGyHJE1Iv6CnHEsPkh9BaSIbax0owd/uyg@Ke5mFYWd2Zq/qoURVF/aaf/d1q28mQ3ZTzuFDGYvnC@BIkcl6YwllOKDiA2r2bApqGwt9jN7lm3wtQ82V0OzQ9V42m01qPCqT4@4twzM1xl4@v6Cai2PjBYAKR6GMI46tZIcFFUmONF5Sm8hvpfv9kkt2W45/woRDyHi3pEQiU@@fjFz3V2yKNm5M5TC1m5OdfxwV93XV0rr2wakMV0Gac3iAOCHIA7vig0pz/55hsvlA1/8C)

#### Shortest iterative I found (50 bytes)

```java
(a,b)->{int c=1;for(;b>=0;c++)b=a-(a=b);return c;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZBBa8MwDIXv@xWiUHCoE5Imoy0mge22w9ihx7GD7CTFXeoEWymU0t@eOWk3sossPp70nnXEM4ZtV5lj@T10vWy0AtWgc/CO2sD1CcARkla@OXpt1JNuoro3inRrojdDr9qgvXx0lUVqLdT5wJDLICyu2hCoPBF1a5mQRR4LtVoFMseQYS4DYSvqrQElboPw6x/udzs4t7qEk8/A9mS1OXx@AdqDC6ZIAFQ5Ysk65rBJAjFDccIhW8/Rc@xV2W43Z@l2w@HfYMohTNbbOQrTJPP704nd/i5xjzYpxh8ih/GRv8n2F0fVKWp7ijofnGq2WGYlB18gLGBZLs2Cj1OSQx1h1zWXF@fvyEYUPLxuww8)

Answer (score 0):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), 24 bytes

```
?[dsb-1rlbrd0<a]dsaxz1-p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0n@b2hkoGBu@N8@OqU4SdewKCepKMXAJjE2pTixospQt@D/fwA)

#### Explanation

```
?                         # read input                | 71 120
 [dsb-1rlbrd0<a]          # push string               | [string] 71 120
                dsa       # copy top to register a    | [string] 71 120
                   x      # execute the string        | -5 27 1 1 1 1
                    z     # push length of stack      | 6 -5 27 1 1 1 1
                     1-   # decrement top by 1        | 5 -5 27 1 1 1 1
                       p  # print top

 # string in register a:

  dsb                     # copy top to register b    | 71 120
     -                    # subtract                  | 49
      1                   # push 1                    | 1 49
       r                  # swap top two elements     | 49 1
        lb                # load register b           | 71 49 1
          r               # swap top two elements     | 49 71 1
           d0<a           # if top < 0 execute register a
```

Answer (score 0):

## Z80 Assembly, 10 bytes

This version attempts to do the "street cred" version of the task. However, for  the suggested test case where t1=-314, t2=73 this program produces answer "0", which, frankly, makes a little bit more sense than "2".

```
SumacLen:
        xor a           ; HL = t[1], DE = t[2], A is the counter
Loop:   bit 7,h
        ret nz          ; stop if HL is negative
        inc a
        sbc hl,de       ; HL = t[3], DE = t[2]
        ex de,hl        ; HL = t[2], DE = t[3]
        jr Loop
```

The test program for ZX Spectrum 48K written using Sjasmplus assembler can be downloaded [here](http://introspec.retroscene.org/codegolf/sumaclen.asm). A compiled snapshot [is also available](http://introspec.retroscene.org/codegolf/sumaclen.sna).

Comment: Presumably the non-bonus version uses `Loop: ret c` instead?

Comment: Yes, checking the sign bit of H would no longer be needed. "bit 7,h" can be removed and "ret nz" replaced by "ret c", with "inc a" moving just in front of it. 8 bytes altogether.

Comment: Yeah; the `2` result is really just a thing with my program.

Comment: Do you mean that `0` is an acceptable answer for that test case? Or do you mean that it would be better to modify my program to output `2`?

Answer (score 0):

## Common Lisp, <s>59</s> 42 bytes

```
(defun f(a b)(if(< b 0)1(1+(f b(- a b)))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY3RCsIwFEN/JQzEFBn0tpV14M9s1kJhrsPN1/16XdU8hMAJnPuU1qUUhkd8z4gcMCqmyBtGaCWUCyNGtqigpnDKecGw4vtFmnEmxWh0okDRAmeOcdUaru@PZX2HiixaMV6xteLQWaUQMhjz6zls2NDsLgC/8mE/NVV58L@5fAA)