# Sum of combinations with repetition

Tags: code-golf, combinatorics, integer-partitions

Write the shortest code you can solving the following problem:

**Input:**

An integer X with  `2 <= X` and `X <= 100`

**Output:**

Total combinations of 2, 3, and 5 (repetition is allowed, order matters) whose sum is equal to X.

**Examples:**

Input: `8`

Output: `6`, because the valid combinations are:

```
3+5
5+3
2+2+2+2
2+3+3
3+2+3
3+3+2
```

Input: `11`

Output: `16`, because the valid combinations are

```
5+3+3
5+2+2+2
3+5+3
3+3+5
3+3+3+2
3+3+2+3
3+2+3+3
3+2+2+2+2
2+5+2+2
2+3+3+3
2+3+2+2+2
2+2+5+2
2+2+3+2+2
2+2+2+5
2+2+2+3+2
2+2+2+2+3
```

Input: `100`

Output: `1127972743581281`, because the valid combinations are ... many

Input and output can be of any reasonable form.
The lowest byte count in each language wins.
Standard [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Unfortunately, here we don't answer general programming questions. However, you may be able to get help on [so]. Just be sure to check their [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) out before asking. :)

Comment: Can someone reword this into a challenge? Because this would be a fun one.

Comment: I was thinking the same, @MagicOctopusUrn, but then I got to wondering if it's not a dupe.

Comment: @Shaggy Ugghhh... filtering through the challenges with the word `sum` in them was not a good idea to try to solve that inquiry...

Comment: I rewrote your question a bit to make it better fit on codegolf. I also changed the result for input `11` from `12` to `16`. Of course feel free to fix this if I misunderstood your intention

Comment: @TonHospel voted for your edit.

Comment: I feel like we've had a challenge like this before, to express a number as a sum from a fixed set, maybe of coins. Don't know how I'd search for a potential dupe here. Anyone remember what I might be thinking of?

Comment: This is https://oeis.org/A079973

Comment: Borderline dupe of https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/85/194

Answer (score 10):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>46</s> 45 bytes

thanks to [xnor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/20260/xnor) for -1 byte

```python
f=lambda n:n>0and f(n-2)+f(n-3)+f(n-5)or n==0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P802JzE3KSVRIc8qz84gMS9FIU0jT9dIUxtEGUMoU838IoU8W1uD/2lARqZCZp6ChY6CoaEVl4JCQVFmXglQT6bmfwA)

Comment: Looks like `and/or` works and saves a byte: `f=lambda n:n>0and f(n-2)+f(n-3)+f(n-5)or n==0`.

Comment: @xnor thanks a lot. I just tried it [the other way round](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P802JzE3KSVRIc8qz8YwMS9FIc/W1kAhv0ghTSNP10hTG0QZQyhTzf9pQIlMhcw8BQsdBUNDKy4FhYKizLwSoOJMzf8A)

Answer (score 7):

## [Oasis](https://github.com/Adriandmen/Oasis), 9 bytes

```
cd5e++VT1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08sziz@/z85xTRVWzssxPD///@GBgYA)

**Explanation**

```
        1    # a(0) = 1
       T     # a(1) = 0, a(2) = 1
      V      # a(3) = 1, a(4) = 1

             # a(n) = 
c    +       # a(n-2) +
 d  +        # a(n-3) +
  5e         # a(n-5)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Pyth](https://pyth.readthedocs.io), 9 bytes

```
/sM{y*P30
```

**[Try it here!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2FsM%7By%2aP30&input=5&debug=0)**

## [Pyth](https://pyth.readthedocs.io), 16 bytes

```
l{s.pMfqT@P30T./
```

**[Try it here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=l%7Bs.pMfqT%40P30T.%2F&input=11&debug=0)**

#### How?

1. Generates the prime factors of **30**, namely **[2, 3, 5]**, gets the powerset of it repeated **N** times, removes duplicate elements, sums each list and counts the occurrences of **N** in that.
2. For each integer parition **p**, it checks whether **p** equals **p ∩ primefac(30)**. It only keeps those that satisfy this condition, and for each remaining partition **k**, it gets the list of **k**'s permutations, flattens the resulting list by 1 level, deduplicates it and retrieves the length.

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 11 bytes

```
5ÆRẋHŒPQḅ1ċ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/0cFvQw13dHkcnBQQ@3NFqeKT7P1AQAA)

### How it works

```
5ÆRẋHŒPQḅ1ċ -> Full program. Argument: N, an integer.
5ÆR         -> Pushes all the primes between 2 and 5, inclusively.
   ẋH       -> Repeat this list N / 2 times.
     ŒP     -> Generate the powerset.
       Q    -> Remove duplicate entries.
        ḅ1  -> Convert each from unary (i.e. sum each list)
          ċ -> Count the occurrences of N into this list.
```

Comment: Speed it up by replacing `³` with `H` (then it will time out at 12 rather than 6)

Comment: @JonathanAllan Done, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

## Perl, 38 bytes

Includes `+1` for `p`

```
perl -pE '$_=1x$_;/^(...?|.{5})+$(?{$\++})\1/}{' <<< 11; echo
```

Interesting enough I have to use `\1` to force backtracking. Usually I use `^` but the regex optimizer seems too smart for that and gives too low results. I'll probably have to start giving perl version numbers when using this trick since the optimizer can change at every version. This was tested on `perl 5.26.1`

This `49` is efficient and can actually handle `X=100` (but overflows on `X=1991`)

```
perl -pe '$\=$F[@F]=$F[-2]+$F[-3]+$F[-5]for($F[5]=1)..$_}{' <<< 100;echo
```

Comment: I only just now learned that you did this 3 years before my [Fibonacci answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/223243/17216). I wonder why you didn't apply this to Fibonacci? Anyway, I've been now extending the idea much further, answering various challenges with regex ``-output (output by number of possible matches), and added it as a built-in to RegexMathEngine.

Comment: Also, you can do this in [3 fewer bytes](https://tio.run/##BcFBCoAgEADAr3QQMiTFQ5c6@JEoJKSEXEWFArOnt80EE88BwTeXjmBhT01r7mCidQayPscxOR2z03k72gnlTdb3FQvlnKuHl6F2jFClCpkZq52oBVHKz4dsPSTsww8 "Perl 5 – Try It Online"), [as done](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/223243/revisions) in my Fibonacci answer but without `-p`. And obligatory note: With the ``$\`` and `}{` trick you're doing, the program will still try to loop, but it won't reset the value of ``$\``, so it only works properly when given one number followed by EOF.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 32 bytes

Same algorithm as in [ovs' Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/155938/sum-of-combinations-with-repetition/155950#155950).

```js
f=n=>n>0?f(n-2)+f(n-3)+f(n-5):!n
```

#### Test cases

```js
f=n=>n>0?f(n-2)+f(n-3)+f(n-5):!n

console.log(f(8))
console.log(f(11))
console.log(f(13))
```

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 10 bytes

```
30fIиæÙOI¢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/f2CDN88KOw8sOz/T3PLTo/39TAA)

Answer (score 2):

## C, 41 bytes

```
G(x){return x>0?G(x-2)+G(x-3)+G(x-5):!x;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/99do0Kzuii1pLQoT6HCzsAeyNc10tQGUcYQylTTSrHCuvZ/Zl6JQm5iZp6GJlc1lwIQFBQBhdI0lFRTYvJUU5R0FNw1LDRBpKGhpqY1V@1/AA)

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>56</s> <s>49</s> 47 bytes

Recursive approach from [ovs's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/155938/sum-of-combinations-with-repetition/155950#155950). [Giuseppe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/67312/giuseppe) shaved off those final two bytes to make it 47.

```
f=pryr::f(+`if`(x<5,x!=1,f(x-2)+f(x-3)+f(x-5)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P822oKiyyMoqTUM7ITMtQaPCxlSnQtHWUCdNo0LXSFMbRBlDKFNNTc3/aRoWmlxpGoZGYBJEGGn@BwA)

Comment: [48 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/r/P822oKiyyMoqTcNAOyEzLUGjwsZUp0LR1lAnTaNC10hTG0QZQyhTTU3N/2kaFppcaRqGRmASRBhp/gcA "R – Try It Online")

Comment: @Giuseppe Very nice improvement!

Comment: ah, you don't need the `0` (I didn't consider that before), as unary `+` will coerce to `numeric` as well.

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 43 bytes

```
Tr[Multinomial@@@{2,3,5}~FrobeniusSolve~#]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7P6Qo2rc0pyQzLz83MzHHwcGh2kjHWMe0ts6tKD8pNS@ztDg4P6cstU45Vu1/QFFmXkl0mr5DtYWOoaGOoYFBbex/AA)

Explanation: `FrobeniusSolve` computes all solutions of the unordered sum `2a + 3b + 5c = n`, then `Multinomial` figures out how many ways we can order those sums.

Or we could just copy everyone else's solution for the same byte count:

```
f@1=0;f[0|2|3|4]=1;f@n_:=Tr[f/@(n-{2,3,5})]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 15 bytes

```
:"5Zq@Z^!XsG=vs
```

Very inefficient: required memory is exponential.

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/30rJNKrQISpOMaLY3bas@P9/Q0MA)

#### How it works

```
:"       % For each k in [1 2 ... n], where n is implicit input
  5Zq    %   Push primes up to 5, that is, [2 3 5]
  @      %   Push k
  Z^     %   Cartesian power. Gives a matrix where each row is a Cartesian k-tuple
  !Xs    %   Sum of each row
  G=     %   Compare with input, element-wise
  vs     %   Concatenate all stack contents vertically and sum
         % Implicit end. Implicit display
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 32 bytes

```
n->1/(1-x^2-x^3-x^5)%x^(n+1)\x^n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsytRNL/ifpmD7P0/XzlBfw1C3Is4IiI2B2FRTtSJOI0/bUDOmIi7vf1p@kUaegq2CoY6CsYGOQkFRZl4JUEBJQdcOSKRp5GlqanJBRA0NDBDiQA6yBKoMUOo/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 41 bytes

```ruby
f=->n{n<5?n==1?0:1:[n-5,n-2,n-3].sum(&f)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/P81W1y6vOs/G1D7P1tbQ3sDK0Co6T9dUJ0/XCIiNY/WKS3M11NI0a/8XKKTpaZiYav4HAA)

This is a recursive solution, the recurcive call being: `[n-5,n-2,n-3].sum(&f)`.

Answer (score 1):

## Regex  (ECMAScript<sup><sup>[RME](https://github.com/Davidebyzero/RegexMathEngine/)</sup></sup> / Perl / PCRE / Raku<sup><sup>`:P5`</sup></sup>), 14 bytes

```
^(xxx?|x{5})*$
```

Takes its input in unary, as a string of `x` characters whose length represents the number. Returns its output as the number of ways the regex can match. (The rabbit emoji indicates this output method.)

[Try it on replit.com](https://replit.com/@Davidebyzero/regex-Ordered-partitions-with-2-3-5) (RegexMathEngine)
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RU/LTsMwELz3KyxrVXnJowmilzpOUqlcOXGjxSpRK1mYNsRBCjjmyAfwifxI6gQkLqvd2dmdmfrQ6OXw8k6g4cTqc7XXBBbcjyLbrO/XuZsdzw0DIxKe5RwtUUc/oa0bdWoJ3Z4od6TUwtRatYxGNDRvT6b1JzKM0jDFw@tIKv7RxOO4Aol8/GW84r4pdXaNttQP6U74muy4mxEyKas/AFQmJoLvggAtVN4SYbSjHSgUnwtW9KxYQYOssEEAlcPtcyblR94DK6YmRhyjmfl8cj@Z98lSTn7TgIop@fn6JjSGyhN7v3JOytu7jZTDI@u6rug7u3R4BcOQRDfJBQ) - Perl
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVTbbtNAEH3PV0wNbdaxU8UEEIrjRqUU8RBaFKUSKA2Wu1k7qzpra22T9JJXPoBP5EMIs944dSlgJfZ6dubMmTOzpmnajijdPOOCxsWMQT@lkh3Ojxp0Hkjw08kUPBgZb5fL66tu8eXm5vN4/no5J5uvZLVaDe5Xd6/WZuv5xvzTw7ChlXp@ajlu4wE9y2c8UfB1k@QiemzjCVpZsHjqd9TgIocUl7nPpEwkoYnIcijpthYsy4KImXeYp9ej6AD9PmytalnamZjFLkiWF1KA464bhch4JNgM4kRE@haIbMmkW2Zb3Pg0iOOkyIlSp3rxr@KEXkOLmnCn3S1rB9tB2DI24IKgQwPwSidYRMwESc22M/U6LmhCujRIqWeQQc9wcWV5qX4YJhmc4H/PRHuBkN0Xfg6JClb4ES5K7DoQF2mRq3DJoCWZC3WNUJQ0lzpasqyIc71WaoZhxnIbsDhkGeVzvZN8YzRP5KQ71akQ1QOtRLJIecxQlkPqY3Ji2vDpZHTqvzsfHw@HcK/fLsbv39hwoDPrRZWqY2pMHgLZk8ys9AvLFocEy0JvGwwFVHKUECClMhz2Zz3Yzy4FDlsNU@fZAtc7hrQfeqm3Q8QjqshbpWgpYsTymAtG9AxxYWs9TRd9nKqVJWcMEx0EDfKEk9KpkgF1EI4NaZLhtt4JuZiRZru55aUu4Sgh0WfPq/ev1xPKOPgLLlilvwVIpIfJH7B0c1U6wZb6bSIcy5m6OP8L1IVkNjRXTUUMS8lwc@rV4ndCcE@o2ep7wnHBsni94qpTtyYgKZWENC9FU0uzlY8qofGocXUz4Of3H4CTqw8Isqul1LOkJrCaJ7ZilEhmw9nFcGgDMuY4IuVvO4Q2dE33CR@N0u/AwUGFiJKWs3c6Gp2P/LPzj8fjkw/mo8jdsakoG6dqvozH@CzO2P/DtrVVn5cwLrL5P6qsVb9u6Hs50z09jJIxrMXcfUW257Ox3nTaLzu/aBgHUbZpx0qs3w) - PCRE1
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVXrTttIFP6fpzi4uzCTON2EbisUx0Q0RAKpDVUatN1S1jL2OBnVGVv2uAS6/O0D9BH3QZY9c0liSKS1wJnLOd@5fec4yvP2LIoeX8Qs4YLBh@FkdBgML05HweX4fBr8cX46PYOjxgsuorSKGfTzqGCHL@fHjWgeFhDkV9fgw8R5e3v79eZV9efd3afp/M3tnDz@RZbL5eDv5ffXD7T5yyN9LuG40Mz9IG91vRp8KQsuZgp/c8YzPGXh4nhL7rjBhYQclzJgRZEVJMpEKUH71lywsgxnjML3Usa9XoQS0O@DPVZLfc5EnHpQMFkVArrewxam2kdZzFy4ybIUMj8J01LBajMW7urw9ZtrrwH48ASITlMwYxYjsFLE4BCT58vh2cnkqEntpQslv2dZQtaO/7Y6qclTSrUV9ZAMBiaIKKsk9GAdKFXhOVoNtAc9cJ4Fr5UdB7WcL8Kh63wkaVXOTSTrpDQeGpUo@UywGNJMzMwrFOUtKzydsMVdEIVpim7Y2O0uuEmz6Cs0Ixe@ZTyGZhzKEHOnkqSW4PtA1E2T7m8wqMVutdaV6djKLEIuCAJoB/MrJELKBMlpu3vtdzwTgmEH5JHvkEHP8XDV8nPz41AyGOL/HsXzChFfHQYSi4q6Cn6GCw1dB@Iir6RS14FhCaFZsNV@EcpoHuhYmpu1QStYWaXSNSXwbHt9PP880idJUjK8xHgxhJmcPxFoZt9YJFHLVgLbbGV/kfOUEUuKjx@mE5pHL6MAnSXUtRifR5OLYDqavD8fn0xHp6vj0afpaHyq9vvaJ/trPenQDYP3CiSgzX29G/TbytVC97eyEeA@lCxIimwR5KGUrBCkQJaPL9@9swB1HWxdyZYSk7ha@bvuLSzZQsEI1hRcQbg1Xrq7ePYcwJhK@YLXQdpd6tWEYpbL/xUqWFQVJc/ETkFtNskK0NPlfs1cnBgpDmJiGpkL13CPeivG6/KgiuhgekKZcaIFVuXH@ouuC3lW4rW5wcEek4P2gTWqHtFVuUWZPb/O815PqMPBDlxoafkWdCkODNHZYJlZq8wJdmt2V6Lb6l57OGwWmAlSunCwPFCOYYJKvLz2a/rrJHBfqB7s@6LrQavF6xGvSHlPAZ1SRsjBF4EhYepQWvMzIc6vMfzz4yfgp4XjlRkh6FjNmukl1ZRP2aWJWe8odJpjQ@i/DadxbctIvS3nDG6/A/v71saeb7tuMrmYBOOL9yfT4Rl9oqjpV2uv1cSQRcWe2WD41dnS3Ux/nN824h2TXD0Pjc17V2MlBWNkE992QxuB9Z7WJ6K5xJmxHtgmEvx0PHbav3f@jZI0nJWP7VTrtI/@Aw) - PCRE2
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7X1qcquDr7@ftGmmt4Brm6KMQGF2cWKmgraGhXqFeoRKvWVeXa5VaYRVgqh@rUKegYpuWmZdZnAFkBkbrayqk5RcpxBkbWsdac0Fl/sdpVFRU2NdUVJvWamqp/P8PAA) - Raku

Same method as used for [Fibonacci function or sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/85/fibonacci-function-or-sequence/250137#250137), directly enumerating the ordered partitions.

```
^          # tail = input number
(
    xxx?   # tail-=2 or tail-=3
|          # or
    x{5}   # tail-=5
)*         # Loop the above as many times as possible, minimum zero
$          # Assert tail == 0
```

## Regex  (Raku), 14 bytes

```
^(xxx?|x**5)*$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoFKkYKugb6Nim5aZl1mcYadvrVCcWKmgraFeoV6hEq@pl5tYkpyhoVKkY5VaoamQll@kEGdsYM0FVf8/TqOiosK@pkJLy1RTS@X/fwA)

Raku's plain regex alternation operator is `||`, and `|` does something special – it chooses the alternative making the longest match. But it'll still try every alternative when backtracking, so this makes no difference in the number of matches.

## [Perl](https://www.perl.org/), 38 bytes <sub><sup>(full program)</sup></sub>

```
1x<>~~/^(...?|.{5})*$(??{++$i})/;say$i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9n5evUJ5YlJeZl16soJ5aUZBalJmbmleSmGNlVZybWFSSm1iSnKFu/d@wwsaurk4/TkNPT8@@Rq/atFZTS0XD3r5aW1sls1ZT37o4sVIl8/9/Q8N/@QUlmfl5xf91fU31DAwNAA)

Interestingly, I noticed after making this post that [Ton Hospel already used](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155955/17216) the same basic method (and it predates my [Perl Fibonacci answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/223243/17216) by 3 years), but did it with Perl `-p` in 37 bytes (which can be reduced to 34 bytes), by exploiting Perl actually using literal `{` `}` to create the `-p` loop. I previously assumed Perl emulated a loop when launched with `-p`, not that it literally string-concatenated the program into a loop.

Using the `$\` trick (setting the `print` record separator), there's an alternative 38 byte flagless full program:

```
1x<>~~/^(...?|.{5})*$(??{++$\})/;print
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9n5evUJ5YlJeZl16soJ5aUZBalJmbmleSmGNlVZybWFSSm1iSnKFu/d@wwsaurk4/TkNPT8@@Rq/atFZTS0XD3r5aW1slplZT37qgKDOv5P9/Q0MA)

Sadly it's only literally a `print` record separator and doesn't apply to `say`.

## [Raku](https://raku.org/), 27 bytes<sup><sup>[SBCS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252)</sup></sup> <sub><sup>(anonymous function)</sup></sub>

```
{+m:ex/^(...?|.**5)*$/}o¹x*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/WjvXKrVCP05DT0/PvkZPS8tUU0tFvzb/0M4Krf/WxYmVCnpAdWn5RQpxxgb/AQ)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 9 bytes

```
⁺¤fẋfṗUṠO
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJQIiwiwr3ijIoiLCLigbrCpGbhuotm4bmXVeG5oE8iLCIiLCI4Il0=)

The header in the link halves the input to make things faster. It will return the same result if you remove it, but it may time out.

`⁺¤f` could alternatively be `30ǐ` (prime factors of 30) or `5~æ` (prime numbers up to 5).

```
⁺¤fẋfṗUṠO
⁺¤f       # Push the digits of 235: [2, 3, 5]
   ẋf     # Repeat the list the input times
     ṗ    # Powerset
      U   # Uniquify
       Ṡ  # Sum each
        O # Count the number of times the input appears in this array
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), 101 bytes

```
l=mod(floor(nk/n^{[1,2,3]}),n)
f(n)=∑_{k=1}^{n^3}0^{(n-total([2,3,5]l))^2}l.total!/∏_{a=1}^3l![a]
```

Ugh, no recursion sucks. I literally see all these answers going `f(n-2)+f(n-3)+f(n-5)`, like super golfy, but nope, can't do that in Desmos.

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/dnqm2xi5df)

[Try It On Desmos! - Prettified](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/s3jdt2lnig)

Answer (score 1):

## [Prolog (SWI)](http://www.swi-prolog.org), 50 bytes

```
N+O:-N>0,N-2+A,N-3+B,N-5+C,O is A+B+C;N<0,O=0;O=1.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcTBCoQgEADQX@mozEzoxkLUJlR35ypEhw4RgpVk0Oe7vcOL1xnOjdLjc7bADVmj0NIH@vcKhvcvjMiFT0UPA4yt/SnkTrXc6TI3tC8x@HSLyc3GCAeMz@XvNRzCkWEpcapRa9TVLMv8Bw)

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 21 bytes

```
Œṗe€2,3,5$Ạ$ÐfŒ!Q$€ẎL
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opIc7p6c@alpjpGOsY6rycNcClcMT0o5OUgxUAQo@3NXn8///f0NDAA)

Surely can be golfed

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth, 12 bytes

```
l{fqQsTy*P30
```

This is horrendously inefficient and hits the memory limit for inputs above 5.

[Try it online](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=l%7BfqQsTy%2aP30&input=5&debug=0)

#### Explanation

```
l{fqQsTy*P30
         P30   Get the prime factors of 30 [2, 3, 5].
        *   Q  Repeat them (implicit) input times.
       y       Take the power set...
  fqQsT        ... and filter the ones whose sum is the input.
l{             Count unique lists.
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Proton](https://github.com/alexander-liao/proton), 32 bytes

```
f=n=>n>0?f(n-2)+f(n-3)+f(n-5):!n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyjKL8nP@/8/zTbP1i7PzsA@TSNP10hTG0QZQyhTTSvFvP8FRZl5JRppGqaamv8B)

Same approach as [ovs' answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/155938/sum-of-combinations-with-repetition/155950#155950).

Comment: [JS polyglot](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155947/58563) :-)

Answer (score 0):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 40 bytes

```hs
f 0=1
f n|n<0=0|1>0=f(n-2)+f(n-3)+f(n-5)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P03BwNaQK00hrybPxsDWoMbQzsA2TSNP10hTG0QZQyhTzf@5iZl5CrYKBaUlwSVFCioKxRn55UAqTcHQ8D8A)

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
1λèƵ†S₆O
```

Port of [*@ovs*' Python 2 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155950/52210).

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f8NzuwyuObX3UsCD4UVObP1DAEAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##ATEAzv9vc2FiaWX/dnk/IiDihpIgIj95/zHOu8OoxrXigKBT4oKGT/99LP9bOCwxMSwxMDBd).

Outputting the infinite sequence would be 6 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage) instead:

```
λƵ†S₆O
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3O5jWx81LAh@1NTm//8/AA)

**Explanation:**

```python
 λ        # Start a recursive environment
  è       # to output the (implicit) input'th value
          # (which is output implicitly in the end)
1         # Starting with a(0)=1, and a(-1)=a(-2)=a(-3)=a(-4)=0
          # And where every next a(n) is calculated as:
   Ƶ†     #  Push compressed integer 235
     S    #  Convert it to a list of digits: [2,3,5]
      ₆   #  Calculate a(n-v) for each value v in this list: [a(n-2),a(n-3),a(n-5)]
       O  #  Sum this list together: a(n-2)+a(n-3)+a(n-5)

λ         # Start a recursive environment
          # to output the infinite sequence
          # (which is output implicitly in the end)
          # (implicitly starting with a(0)=1, and a(-1)=a(-2)=a(-3)=a(-4)=0)
          # And where every next a(n) is calculated as:
 Ƶ†S₆O    #  Same as above
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (section *How to compress large integers?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `Ƶ†` is `235`.