# Patience, young "Padovan"

Tags: code-golf, number, sequence

Everyone knows the Fibonacci sequence:
You take a square, attach an equal square to it, then repeatedly attach a square whose side length is equal to the largest side length of the resulting rectangle.
The result is a beautiful spiral of squares whose sequence of numbers is the *Fibonacci sequence*:

[image]

But, what if we didn't want to use squares?

If we use equilateral triangles—instead of squares—in a similar fashion, we get an equally beautiful spiral of triangles and a new sequence:  the *Padovan sequence*, aka [A000931](https://oeis.org/A000931):

[image]

**Task:**

Given a positive integer, \$N\$, output \$a_N\$, the \$N\$th term in the Padovan sequence OR the first \$N\$ terms.

Assume that the first three terms of the sequence are all \$1\$.  Thus, the sequence will start as follows:
$$
1,1,1,2,2,3,...
$$

**Input:**

- Any positive integer \$N\ge0\$
- Invalid input does not have to be taken into account

**Output:**

- The \$N\$th term in the Padovan sequence **OR** the first \$N\$ terms of the Padovan sequence.
- If the first \$N\$ terms are printed out, the output can be whatever is convenient (list/array, multi-line string, etc.)
- Can be either \$0\$-indexed or \$1\$-indexed

**Test Cases:**
(0-indexed, \$N\$th term)

```
Input | Output
--------------
0     | 1
1     | 1
2     | 1
4     | 2
6     | 4
14    | 37
20    | 200
33    | 7739
```

(1-indexed, first \$N\$ terms)

```
Input | Output
--------------
1     | 1
3     | 1,1,1
4     | 1,1,1,2
7     | 1,1,1,2,2,3,4
10    | 1,1,1,2,2,3,4,5,7,9
12    | 1,1,1,2,2,3,4,5,7,9,12,16
```

**Rules:**

- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf): the fewer bytes, the better!
- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.

Comment: `14` (0-indexed) is shown as outputting `28` while I believe it should yield `37`

Comment: @JonathanAllan yes, you are correct.  I fixed the last two test cases for \$N\$th term but not that one.  The post has been edited.

Comment: @LuisMendo I believe so.  I'll edit the post.

Comment: Not to detract from the question, but is this the actual definition of the Fibonacci sequence? I was taught it as a sequence of numbers, in which the first two numbers are 1, and the 3rd and subsequent numbers are the sum of the prior two numbers. Then again, I was taught this as an example of a problem to solve with recursion...

Comment: @sharur this definition for the Fibonacci sequence is the *visual* definition.  Each successive square added has a length of that term in the sequence.  The sequence you describe is the numerical reasoning behind it.  Both sequences work just as well as the other.

Comment: Note that the OEIS sequence you linked is slightly different, since it uses `a_0=1, a_1=0, a_2=0`. It ends up being shifted by a bit because then `a_5=a_6=a_7=1`

Comment: @Carmeister yes, that is correct.  The OEIS sequence is the *true* Padovan sequence, but I shifted it over to \$a_0=a_1=a_2=1\$ for convenience (plus most mentions I've seen of this sequence start it at the aforementioned shift).

Comment: Questions in Code Golf that result in answers under 10 bytes should automatically get a hat or something.  Yet again the compact answers were mind boggling and it is hard to think that this question was not considered when the languages were developed.

Comment: Can we define the sequence as \$1,0,1,1,1,2,2,3,...\$ if that's the [natural output from the algorithm used](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/223250/17216)?

Comment: Can we take no input and output forever?

Answer (score 71):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 10 bytes

```
9s3’Ẓæ*³FṀ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASAA3/9qZWxsef//OXMz4oCZ4bqSw6YqwrNG4bmA//8xMP8zNA)

1-indexed. Computes the largest element of: $$\begin{bmatrix}0&0&1 \\ 1&0&1 \\ 0&1&0\end{bmatrix}^n$$
where the binary matrix is conveniently computed as: $$\begin{bmatrix}\mathsf{isprime}(0)&\mathsf{isprime}(1)&\mathsf{isprime}(2) \\ \mathsf{isprime}(3)&\mathsf{isprime}(4)&\mathsf{isprime}(5) \\ \mathsf{isprime}(6)&\mathsf{isprime}(7)&\mathsf{isprime}(8)\end{bmatrix}$$

(this is a total coincidence.)

```
9s3         [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]    9 split 3
   ’        [[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8]]    decrease
    Ẓ       [[0,0,1],[1,0,1],[0,1,0]]    isprime
     æ*³    [[0,0,1],[1,0,1],[0,1,0]]^n  matrix power by input
        FṀ                               flatten, maximum
```

Comment: this is clearly some kind of voodoo

Comment: This should be published.

Comment: @YSC It has already been published in [A000931](https://oeis.org/A000931). I'd never have guess the primes trick:)

Comment: @flawr ho... I missed it

Comment: Funnily enough I saw this method on the OEIS page and thought there was no way it would be less than my 10 byte binomial sum method (turns out that guess was right, unless someone can golf a byte off this one!)

Comment: ...make that "unless someone can golf two bytes off this one" :) (now that I have a [9 byter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/182805/53748))

Comment: I'm so used to seeing absurdly small answers here, that I thought the comma after 'Jelly' was in fact the code for this problem

Comment: @Pureferret The fact that the entries coincide with "isprime" is a coincidence, but using matrix powers to compute linear recurrence relations is a classical [way to solve them](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving_via_linear_algebra).

Answer (score 34):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>10 9</s>  8 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ŻṚm2Jc$S
```

A monadic Link accepting `n` (0-indexed) which yields `P(n)`.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///o7oc7Z@UaeSWrBP///9/YGAA)**

#### How?

Implements \$P(n) = \sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor\frac{n}2\rfloor}\binom{i+1}{n-2i}\$

```
ŻṚm2Jc$S - Link: integer, n       e.g. 20
Ż        - zero range                  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ..., 19, 20]
 Ṛ       - reverse                     [20, 19, ..., 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
  m2     - modulo-slice with 2         [20, 18, 16, 14, 12, 10,  8,  6,  4,  2,  0]  <- n-2i
      $  - last two links as a monad:
    J    -   range of length           [ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11]  <- i+1
     c   -   left-choose-right         [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 28,126, 45,  1]
       S - sum                         200
```

---

And [here](https://tio.run/##AR4A4f9qZWxsef//M@G4iuG5l1Lhuo7Cp8SL4oCY////MTU) is a "twofer"
...a totally different method also for **8 bytes** (this one is 1-indexed, but much slower):

```
3ḊṗRẎ§ċ‘ - Link: n
3Ḋ       - 3 dequeued = [2,3]
   R     - range = [1,2,3,...,n]
  ṗ      -   Cartesian power         [[[2],[3]],[[2,2],[2,3],[3,2],[3,3]],[[2,2,2],...],...]
    Ẏ    - tighten                   [[2],[3],[2,2],[2,3],[3,2],[3,3],[2,2,2],...]
     §   - sums                      [ 2,  3,   4,    5,    5,    6,     6,...]
       ‘ - increment                 n+1
      ċ  - count occurrences         P(n)
```

Answer (score 29):

## [Oasis](https://github.com/Adriandmen/Oasis), 5 bytes

**nth** term 0-indexed

```
cd+1V
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08sziz@/z85Rdsw7P///4aWAA)

**Explanation**

```
   1V   # a(0) = 1
        # a(1) = 1
        # a(2) = 1
        # a(n) =
c       #        a(n-2)
  +     #              +
 d      #               a(n-3)
```

Answer (score 19):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 26 bytes

```hs
(l!!)
l=1:1:1:2:scanl(+)2l
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyfmfZhvzXyNHUVGTK8fW0AoEjayKkxPzcjS0NY1y/ucmZuYp2CoUFGXmlSioKOQmFiikKUQb6OkZmsb@/5eclpOYXvxfN7mgAAA) Outputs the n'th term zero-indexed.

I thought that the "obvious" recursive solution below would be unbeatable, but then I found this. It's similar to the classic golfy expression `l=1:scanl(+)1l` for the infinite Fibonacci list, but here the difference between adjacent elements is the term 4 positions back. We can more directly write `l=1:1:zipWith(+)l(0:l)`, but that's longer.

If this challenge allowed infinite list output, we could cut the first line and have 20 bytes.

**27 bytes**

```hs
f n|n<3=1|1>0=f(n-2)+f(n-3)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P00hrybPxtjWsMbQzsA2TSNP10hTG0QZa/7PTczMU7BVKCjKzCtRUFHITSxQSFOINtDTMzSN/f8vOS0nMb34v25yQQEA)

Answer (score 12):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 30 bytes

```python
f=lambda n:n<3or f(n-2)+f(n-3)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P802JzE3KSVRIc8qz8Y4v0ghTSNP10hTG0QZa/5PA4rkKWTmKRQl5qWnahiaalpxKRQUZeaVKOTpANVo/gcA)

Returns the n'th term zero indexed. Outputs `True` for 1.

Answer (score 8):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 33 bytes

```
a@0=a@1=a@2=1;a@n_:=a[n-2]+a[n-3]
```

1-indexed, returns the nth term

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78/z/RwcA20cEQiI1sDa0THfLirWwTo/N0jWK1QZRx7P@Aosy8EgWHxGhDo9j//wE)

Answer (score 7):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/) / MATLAB, <s>35</s> 33 bytes

```matlab
@(n)[1 filter(1,'cbaa'-98,2:n<5)]
```

Outputs the first *n* terms.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mq6en999BI08z2lAhLTOnJLVIw1BHPTkpMVFd19JCx8gqz8ZUM/Z/moahkeZ/AA)

#### How it works

Anonymous function that implements a [recursive filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_filter).

`'cbaa'-98` is a shorter form to produce `[1 0 -1 -1]`.

`2:n<5` is a shorter form to produce `[1 1 1 0 0 ··· 0]` (*n*−1 terms).

`filter(1,[1 0 -1 -1],[1 1 1 0 0 ··· 0])` passes the input `[1 1 1 0 0 ··· 0]` through a discrete-time filter defined by a transfer function with numerator coefficient `1` and denominator coefficients `[1 0 -1 -1]`.

Answer (score 6):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 22 bytes

*-2 bytes thanks to ngn and Galen*

### closed form, 26 bytes

```
0.5<.@+1.04535%~1.32472^<:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/DfRMbfQctA31DExMjU1V6wz1jI1MzI3ibKz@a3Jx@TnpKRjoZualpFakpnClJmfkK6QpZOoZGfwHAA)

### iterative, 22 bytes

```
(],1#._2 _3{ ::1])^:[#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/NWJ1DJX14o0U4o2rFaysDGM146yilf9rcnH5OekpGOhm5qWkVqSmcKUmZ@Qr6Ogp2DikKRkoZOoZGfwHAA)

Comment: Another 24-byte solution (boring) : (1#.2 3$:@-~])`1:@.(3&>) [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/NQyV9YwUjFWsHHTrYjUTDK0c9DSM1ew0/2tycfk56SkY6GbmpaRWpKZwpSZn5CukKajZKWTqGRn8BwA "J – Try It Online")

Comment: 23 bytes thanks to ngn `1:` -> `#` : [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/NQyV9YwUjFWsHHTrYjUTlB30NIzV7DT/a3Jx@TnpKRjoZualpFakpnClJmfkK6QpqNkpZOoZGfwHAA "J – Try It Online")

Comment: @GalenIvanov tyvm, that's a great trick.

Comment: `1:` -> `1`. "adverse" works with a noun on the right, apparently

Comment: @ngn TIL... ty again!

Answer (score 5):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), <s>47</s> 42 bytes

```
K`0¶1¶0
"$+"+`.+¶(.+)¶.+$
$&¶$.(*_$1*
6,G`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/3zvB4NA2w0PbDLiUVLSVtBP0tA9t09DT1jy0TU9bhUtF7dA2FT0NrXgVQy0uMx33hP//zQE) Outputs the first `n` terms on separate lines. Explanation:

```
K`0¶1¶0
```

Replace the input with the terms for `-2`, `-1` and `0`.

```
"$+"+`.+¶(.+)¶.+$
$&¶$.(*_$1*
```

Generate the next `n` terms using the recurrence relation. `*_` here is short for `$&*_` which converts the (first) number in the match to unary, while `$1*` is short for `$1*_` which converts the middle number to unary. The `$.(` returns the decimal sum of its unary arguments, i.e. the sum of the first and middle numbers.

```
6,G`
```

Discard the first six characters, i.e. the first three lines.

Answer (score 5):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 24 bytes

```
{(1,1,1,*+*+!*...*)[$_]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/WsNQBwS1tLW0FbX09PS0NKNV4mNr/xcnVipoxBkZatrZ6aml/QcA)

A pretty standard generated sequence, with each new element generated by the expression `* + * + !*`.  That adds the third-previous element, the second-previous element, and the logical negation of the previous element, which is always `False`, which is numerically zero.

Comment: Why is this community wiki?

Comment: @JoKing Beats me.  If I did it somehow, it wasn't on purpose.

Comment: Note that using `…` in place of `...` doesn't change the UTF-8 length in bytes, but with a Perl 6 specific [SBCS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_Byte_Character_Set) it would be 22 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/WsNQBwS1tLW0FbUeNSzT0oxWiY@t/V9QlJlXoqARZ2SoaWenp5b2HwA "Perl 6 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 5):

## [Cubix](https://github.com/ETHproductions/cubix), 20 bytes

This is 0 indexed and outputs the *N*th term

```
;@UOI010+p?/sqq;W.\(
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy5Nyqz4/9/aIdTf08DQQLvAXr@4sNA6XC9G4/9/QxMA)

Wraps onto a cube with side length 2

```
    ; @
    U O
I 0 1 0 + p ? /
s q q ; W . \ (
    . .
    . .
```

[Watch it run](https://ethproductions.github.io/cubix/?code=ICAgIDsgQAogICAgVSBPCkkgMCAxIDAgKyBwID8gLwpzIHEgcSA7IFcgLiBcICgKICAgIC4gLgogICAgLiAuCg==&input=MTQ=&speed=20)

- `I010` - Initiates the stack
- `+p?` - Adds the top of stack, pulls the counter from the bottom of stack and tests
- `/;UO@` - If counter is 0, reflect onto top face, remove TOS, u-turn, output and halt
- `\(sqq;W` - If counter is positive, reflect, decrement counter, swap TOS, push top to bottom twice, remove TOS and shift lane back into the main loop.

Answer (score 5):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>20</s> <s>18</s> 17 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

This code is 1-indexed. It's the same number of bytes to get `n` items of the Padovan sequence, as you have to drop the last few extra members. It's also the same number of bytes to get 0-indexing.

**Edit:** -2 bytes thanks to ngn. -1 byte thanks to ngn

```
4⌷2(⊢,⍨2⌷+/)⍣⎕×⍳3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKNdIe2/yaOe7UYaj7oW6TzqXWEE5Gjraz7qXfyob@rh6Y96NxuDlHGlPWqb8Ki3z/BRz1712mp1HXWgNAgXqT/q3aoO1AzSCOQnF6mnqSs86p2rUFKUmJKWp1CSrwCk/lcDlSkYPurdAmLopAGJ2kMrgKaDGMYGAA)

**Explanation**

```
4⌷2(⊢,⍨2⌷+/)⍣⎕×⍳3

  ⍺(. . . .)⍣⎕⍵   This format simply takes the input ⎕ and applies the function
                   inside the brackets (...) to its operands (here marked ⍵ and ⍺).
  2(. . .+/)⍣⎕×⍳3  In this case, our ⍵, the left argument, is the array 1 1 1,
                   where we save our results as the function is repeatedly applied
                   and our ⍺, 2, is our right argument and is immediately applied to +/,
                   so that we have 2+/ which will return the pairwise sums of our array.
       2⌷          We take the second pairwise sum, f(n-2) + f(n-3)
    ⊢,⍨            And add it to the head of our array.
4⌷                 When we've finished adding Padovan numbers to the end of our list,
                   the n-th Padovan number (1-indexed) is the 4th member of that list,
                   and so, we implicitly return that.
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>56</s> 48 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,a=1,b=1,c=1:n>2and f(n-1,b,c,a+b)or c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcgxDoAgDADA3Vd0hIgDjCb4EeNQwGoTLYSw@HpkuOXK1@4srnfyD74hIYhBb00YorerbA4lASlZRppocA46V4i9VJYGOynWQGMYWKCiXKeyTh9T/wE)

Returns nth value, 0-indexed.

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 7 bytes

Thanks to [Kevin](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen) for -1 byte!

```
Ì1λè₂₃+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//cI/hud2HVzxqanrU1Kz9/7@xMQA)

#### Previous version: [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 8 bytes

```
1Ð)λ£₂₃+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f8PAEzXO7Dy1@1NT0qKlZ@/9/I1MA)

Bear with me, I haven't golfed in a while. I wonder if there's a shorter substitute for `1Ð)` which works in this case (I've tried `1D)`, `3Å1` etc. but none of them save bytes). Outputs the first \$n\$ terms of the sequence. Or, without the `£`, it would output an infinite stream of the terms of the sequence.

```
1Ð)λ£₂₃+ | Full program.
1Ð)      | Initialize the stack with [1, 1, 1].
   λ     | Begin the recursive generation of a list: Starting from some base case,
         | this command generates an infinite list with the pattern function given.
    £    | Flag for λ. Instead of outputting an infinite stream, only print the first n.
     ₂₃+ | Add a(n-2) and a(n-3).
```

Comment: I don't think `1Ð)` can be 2 bytes tbh. I can think of [six different 3-bytes alternatives](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f8PAETR0u48OthjpcEcYXduhwHdvqGAwU8TnSoMP1qKk1GEj//w8A), but no 2-byters.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen That's 5 alternatives btw (the first is still `1Ð)`). Also: `7bS`, `7Yв`, `X3и`

Comment: `₁SĀ` works too

Comment: [7 bytes](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//cI/hud2HVzxqanrU1Kz9/7@xMQA) by outputting the 0-based \$n^{th}\$ value instead of first \$n\$.

Answer (score 4):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://gitlab.com/n9n/k), <s>24</s> 20 bytes

-4 bytes thanks to ngn!

```
{$[x<3;1;+/o'x-2 3]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNS8/7/z/NqlolusLG2NrQWls/X71C10jBOLb2f5q6gqKh0X8A)

0-indexed, first N terms

Comment: `f[x-2]+f[x-3]` -> `+/o'x-2 3` (`o` is "recur")

Comment: @ngn Thanks! I tried it (without success) in J; it's elegant here.

Comment: @ngn In fact here's one possibillity how it looks in J: (1#.2 3$:@-~])`1:@.(3&>)

Comment: ah, right, base-1 decode is a train-friendly way to sum :)

Comment: `1:` -> `#` in the j solution

Comment: @ngn `#` is a nice golf! Now it's 23 bytes and beats Jonah's J solution :)

Comment: Boo! :)  @ngn thanks for that # trick

Answer (score 4):

## x86 32-bit machine code, 17 bytes

```
53 33 db f7 e3 43 83 c1 04 03 d8 93 92 e2 fa 5b c3
```

Disassembly:

```
00CE1250 53                   push        ebx  
00CE1251 33 DB                xor         ebx,ebx  
00CE1253 F7 E3                mul         eax,ebx  
00CE1255 43                   inc         ebx  
00CE1256 83 C1 04             add         ecx,4  
00CE1259 03 D8                add         ebx,eax  
00CE125B 93                   xchg        eax,ebx  
00CE125C 92                   xchg        eax,edx  
00CE125D E2 FA                loop        myloop (0CE1259h)  
00CE125F 5B                   pop         ebx  
00CE1260 C3                   ret
```

It is 0-indexed. The initialization is conveniently achieved by calculating eax * 0. The 128-bit result is 0, and it goes in edx:eax.

At the beginning of each iteration, the order of the registers is ebx, eax, edx. I had to choose the right order to take advantage of the encoding for the `xchg eax` instruction - 1 byte.

I had to add 4 to the loop counter in order to let the output reach `eax`, which holds the function's return value in the `fastcall` convention.

I could use some other calling convention, which doesn't require saving and restoring `ebx`, but `fastcall` is fun anyway :)

Comment: I love to see machine code answers on PP&CG!  +1

Comment: [15 bytes, 1 indexed](https://tio.run/##ZZFNboMwEIXXnlOM1EpZBCJQf1TRRVftqjeIoshgk7gyGNkmJa16djoGR0laJJD9@c17M4Y7J5tSH9Oau2asjW24x9f3N5SDrHrPSy3xDmDrPLe@ACs7j/kjqiLHb2CNOaCshgQVsIprjfUFa9wOVuZGFWwwFqUgRB9gQh1QfBorcE2SDT6jlb2TdCCrUAmMC4FCJ7jIFrPfmvAmIQbMS@dR8mDGSfrRfmEIiblizl3mwFxfxtBgOZ2Gqvu4LmlNKtV6vH3KAH8Apj6nE3pn2VwTdZgNpKQ@y3AFou/wBSisYNRuno11wYB1vdtjfMgFMbqeURJx02v8o1RtdUZhuitAY6zyYrqcKzs@p1T73UXtKeUfFhPWxnQnvKLxuvP21IyVfqy3shU0n3Kd5kectmmd5g/L8GvGXw)

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 11 bytes

```
5B+Ɲ2ị;Ʋ⁸¡Ḣ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASAA3/9qZWxsef//NUIrxp0y4buLO8ay4oG4wqHhuKL///8zMw)

0-indexed.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 23 bytes

Implements the recursive definition of [A000931](https://oeis.org/A000931), but with \$a(0)=a(1)=a(2)=1\$, as specified in the challenge.

Returns the \$N\$<sup>th</sup> term, 0-indexed.

```javascript
f=n=>n<3||f(n-2)+f(n-3)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/zTbP1i7PxrimJk0jT9dIUxtEGWv@T87PK87PSdXLyU/XSNMw0NTkQhUxxBAxwhAxwRAxwzQHU5ERpm3Gxpqa/wE)

Comment: I don't think it's reasonable to say that returning `true` is the same as returning `1` if the rest of the output is numbers.

Comment: @Nit [Relevant meta post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9067/58563).

Comment: I think you are missing some requirements:
Have a look at my modification (version in Java) [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/182895/86478).

Comment: @Shaq The challenge clearly specifies that _the first three terms of the sequence are all 1_. So, it's _not_ the sequence defined in A000931 (but the formula is the same).

Comment: @Arnauld yep I can see it now. Sorry!

Comment: With 24 votes against 16 + 4 votes, looks like the community has accepted `true` as valid here. But if you don't like that, you can make the first three terms explicitly `1` by adding an extra byte: `f=x=>x<3?1:f(x-2)+f(x-3)`

Answer (score 3):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org) 5.3, <del>49</del> 48 bytes

```lua
function f(n)return n<4 and 1or f(n-2)+f(n-3)end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYzBCgIxDETv/YrcbHAVd/WoH1PbFAIl0W57Wvz2mkWHgQzDy5QexshdYmMVyF6wUutVQO43CJJg1rrXpwWP@7kiSRpFYyiw0hsesH1cNoYtzhMsF0jqwNTCs9CZZaXavKGTzTCis3/nXpWl@R8SVWL4Iwcz4vgC)

Vanilla Lua doesn't have coercion of booleans to strings (even `tonumber(true)` returns `nil`), so you have to use a pseudo-ternary operator. This version is 1-indexed, like all of Lua. The `1or` part has to be changed to `1 or` in Lua 5.1, which has a different way of lexing numbers.

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 26 bytes

```ruby
f=->n{n<3?1:f[n-2]+f[n-3]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/P81W1y6vOs/G2N7QKi06T9coVhtEGcfW/tcw0NMzNtbUy00sqK6pqClQiK7QSYuuiAVKAQA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-N`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 12 bytes

```
<3ªßUµ2 +ß´U
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LU4&code=PDOq31W1MiAr37RV&input=MTA)

Comment: Looks like 12 is the best we can do :\

Comment: I stand corrected!

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>12</s> 9 bytes

Returns the `n`th term, 1-indexed.

```
@1gZÔä+}g
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=QDFnWtTkK31n&input=MzQ)

```
@1gZÔä+}g     :Implicit input of integer U
        g     :Starting with the array [0,1] do the following U times, pushing the result to the array each time
@             :  Pass the array through the following function as Z
 1g           :    Get the element at 0-based index 1, with wrapping, from the following
   ZÔ         :    Reverse Z
     ä+       :    Get the sums of each consecutive pair of elements
       }      :  End function
              :Implicit output of the last element in the array
```

Answer (score 2):

## TI-BASIC (TI-84), 34 bytes

```
[[0,1,0][0,0,1][1,1,0]]^(Ans+5:Ans(1,1
```

0-indexed \$N\$th term of the sequence.

Input is in `Ans`.
Output is in `Ans` and is automatically printed out.

<s>I figured that enough time had passed, plus multiple answers had been posted, of which there were many which out-golfed this answer.</s>

**Example:**

```
0
               0
prgmCDGFD
               1
9
               9
prgmCDGFD
               9
16
              16
prgmCDGFD
              65
```

**Explanation:**

```
[[0,1,0][0,0,1][1,1,0]]^(Ans+5:Ans(1,1      ;full program (example input: 6)

[[0,1,0][0,0,1][1,1,0]]                     ;generate the following matrix:
                                            ; [0 1 0]
                                            ; [0 0 1]
                                            ; [1 1 0]
                       ^(Ans+5              ;then raise it to the power of: input + 5
                                            ; [4  7 5]
                                            ; [5  9 7]
                                            ; [7 12 9]
                               Ans(1,1      ;get the top-left index and leave it in "Ans"
                                            ;implicitly print Ans
```

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, 16 bytes

```
L?<b3!b+y-b2y-b3
```

This defines the function `y`. [Try it here!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=L%3F%3Cb3%21b%2By-b2y-b3&input=25&debug=0)

Here's a more fun solution, though it's 9 bytes longer; bytes could be shaved though.

```
+l{sa.pMf.Am&>d2%d2T./QY!
```

This uses the definition given by David Callan on the OEIS page: "a(n) = number of compositions of n into parts that are odd and >= 3." [Try it here!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2Bl%7Bsa.pMf.Am%26%3Ed2%25d2T.%2FQY%21&input=25&debug=0) It takes input directly instead of defining a function.

Comment: `y-b2y-b3` could maybe be refactored with either bifurcate or `L`? Though declaring an array of 2 elements is costly. `yL-Lb2,3` is longer :(

Comment: @Ven I was able to replace `+y-b2y-b3` with `smy-bdhB2` which is the same amount of bytes; `hB2` results in the array `[2, 3]`

Comment: Well done on `hB2`. Too bad it's the same byte count.

Comment: Yeah, though I wonder if there's some way to get rid of the `d` in the map.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 34 bytes

```perl
sub f{"@_"<3||f("@_"-2)+f("@_"-3)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/7@4NEkhrVrJIV7JxrimJk0DxNI10tSGsow1a/@rxNumaajEa/434DLkMuIy4TLjMjThMjLgMjb@l19QkpmfV/xftyAHAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [R + pryr](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>38</s> 36 bytes

Zero-indexed recursive function.

```r
f=pryr::f(`if`(n<3,1,f(n-2)+f(n-3)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P822oKiyyMoqTSMhMy1BI8/GWMdQJ00jT9dIUxtEGWtqav5P0zDQ5ErTMAQRRiDCBESYgcXATCOwvLGx5n8A)

Thanks to [@Giuseppe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/67312/giuseppe) for pointing out two obviously needless bytes.

Comment: If you're going to be using `pryr`, the language should be `R + pryr` and this can be [36 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/r/P822oKiyyMoqTSMhMy1BI8/GWMdQJ00jT9dIUxtEGWtqav5P0zDQ5ErTMAQRRiDCBESYgcXATCOwvLGx5n8A)

Comment: @Giuseppe thanks! Updated now.

Answer (score 2):

## Java, 41 bytes

Can't use a lambda (runtime error). Port of [this Javascript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/182807/84303)

```java
int f(int n){return n<3?1:f(n-2)+f(n-3);}
```

[TIO](https://tio.run/##LYyxCoMwFEV3vyJjHkWhzVYL/YJOjqXDqxqJjU9JXoQS8u1phC73DIdzZ9yxnodP7i16Lx5oKFaekU0vsiEWWh5LEN3IwZGgm7qfr1pSfYHTAQVtylt421L8w301g1jKlezYGZqeL3STh1h1X8/j0qyBm60ItiS1VABtlVL@AQ)

Comment: I think you are missing some requirements:
Have a look at my modification [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/182895/86478).

Comment: Please disregard Shaq's comment: your answer is correct and is the shortest Java answer possible (as of Java 12).

Comment: Ok then. I'm not sure what I "missed" but ok.

Edit: nvm I read the JS answer.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 8 bytes

This implementation of the binomial formula: `a(n) = Sum_{k=0..floor(n/2)} binomial(k+1, n-2k)` is interestingly the same length as the [recursive solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/182828/47066).

```
;Ý·-āscO
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9TVmmvpKBrp6BkX1n53/rw3EPbdY80Fif7/9f5b8BlyGXEZcJlxmVowmVkwGVsDAA)

**Explanation**

```
;Ý        # push [0 ... floor(input/2)]
  ·       # double each
   -      # subtract each from input
    ā     # push range [1 ... len(list)]
     s    # swap
      c   # choose
       O  # sum
```

Answer (score 2):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), <s>41</s> 33 bytes

```c
a(i){return i<3?1:a(i-2)+a(i-3);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jdDNCoJAEADgcz7FYgQOrbE/opRSpw6degEv4lot2Ca2QmA@u41GdNTTzM5@DDOT@3mZmWvfZ56Gti5sUxuiE3ngO6z4AtZDkBB3/VKbvGxUQZKnVfqxue0dbSy5Z9p40DqLqsbnxXNPpmosSe2bnBv7S4@vqshtoVLjQvy3KzX@juGbIKCMZh4DyqclR8lnSYFSzJIBygComJYhyhBoMGPOoSnHrjKaMeqwv8ADCMamtZSopQQaRXKLvOs/)

Comment: Welcome to PPCG :)

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <sup><s>9</s></sup> 8 bytes

```
↑ƒ(+ḋ7Ẋ+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//1HbxGOTNLQf7ug2f7irS/v///@GRgA)

There <del>*might* be</del> is a shorter version using `fix`. -1 from Leo!

Comment: There _is_ https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//1HbxGOTNLQf7ug2f7irS/v///@GRgA

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), <s>38</s> 36 bytes <sub><sup>(full program)</sup></sub>

*-2 bytes [thanks](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/85/fibonacci-function-or-sequence?page=1&tab=modifieddesc#comment546580_223243) to dingledooper*

By the challenge's specification, this is \$1\$-indexed:

```
1x<>.1~~/^(...?)*$(?{++$i})\1/;say$i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9X1qcqpBaUZBalJmbmleSmKOgXpybWFSSm1iSnKFu/d@wwsZOz7CuTj9OQ09Pz15TS0XDvlpbWyWzVjPGUN@6OLFSJfP/f0PLf/kFJZn5ecX/dX1N9QwMDQA)

This uses the same trick as [Fibonacci function or sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/85/fibonacci-function-or-sequence/223243#223243), with the 1 byte modification of inserting an extra `.` in the regex, so that the [number of ordered partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padovan_sequence#Combinatorial_interpretations) as a sum of the numbers \$2\$ and \$3\$ is counted. For example, \$11\$ can be represented \$9\$ ways:

```
2+2+2+2+3
2+2+2+3+2
2+2+3+2+2
2+3+2+2+2
3+2+2+2+2
2+3+3+3
3+2+3+3
3+3+2+3
3+3+3+2
```

This tells us that the term at index \$11-1\$ (in the \$1\$-indexing requested by the challenge) is \$9\$.

In the form of a full program, [Xcali's recursive answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/182864/17216) is longer at **43 bytes**:

```
sub f{"@_"<3||f("@_"-2)+f("@_"-3)}say f(<>)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/7@4NEkhrVrJIV7JxrimJk0DxNI10tSGsow1a4sTKxXSNGzsNP//N7T4l19QkpmfV/xf19dUz8DQAAA)

But the most mathematically consistent indexing for the Padovan sequence would have it start with \$0,1,0,1,1,1,2,2,3...\$ at index \$0\$, based on the Fibonacci indexing in which \$0,1,1,2,3,5,8...\$ starts at index \$0\$. By this challenge's specification that would be “\$3\$-indexing”. The regex backtracking method golfs best with “\$2\$-indexing”, and the recursive method golfs best with “\$0\$-indexing”.

With “\$2\$-indexing” and higher, **<s>1</s> 0** bytes must be taken to coerce the return value into an integer, because the term at index \$1\$ is \$0\$, and `++$i` would never get executed – which would leave it with a non-value if it were not initialized. This can be golfed by adding the boolean falsey return value of the regex match operator (which gets coerced to the integer `0`) to `$i`, though Perl gives the runtime warning `Use of uninitialized value $i in addition (+)` if this happens with `use warnings` enabled.

Something similar happens with the “\$2\$-indexing” recursive version, requiring the use of a `^1` XOR which gives the warning `Possible precedence problem on bitwise ^ operator` with `use warnings` enabled.

“\$0\$-indexing”: `1x<>.11~~/^(...?)*$(?{++$i})\1/;say$i` **37 bytes** - [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9X1qcqpBaUZBalJmbmleSmKOgXpybWFSSm1iSnKFu/d@wwsZOz9Cwrk4/TkNPT89eU0tFw75aW1sls1YzxlDfujixUiXz/39Di3/5BSWZ@XnF/3V9TfUMDA0A)
“\$1\$-indexing”: `1x<>.1~~/^(...?)*$(?{++$i})\1/;say$i` **36 bytes** - [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9X1qcqpBaUZBalJmbmleSmKOgXpybWFSSm1iSnKFu/d@wwsZOz7CuTj9OQ09Pz15TS0XDvlpbWyWzVjPGUN@6OLFSJfP/f0PLf/kFJZn5ecX/dX1N9QwMDQA)
“\$2\$-indexing”: `$_=1x<>;say/^(...?)*$(?{++$i})\1/+$i` **36 bytes** - [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3tawwsbOujixUj9OQ09Pz15TS0XDvlpbWyWzVjPGUB9I//9vZPAvv6AkMz@v@L@ur6megaEBAA)
“\$3\$-indexing”: `$_=1x<>;say/^.(...?)*$(?{++$i})\1/+$i` **37 bytes** - [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3tawwsbOujixUj9OT0NPT89eU0tFw75aW1sls1YzxlAfSP//b2T4L7@gJDM/r/i/rq@pnoGhAQA)

“\$0\$-indexing”: `sub f{"@_"<3||f("@_"-2)+f("@_"-3)}say f(<>)` **43 bytes** - [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/7@4NEkhrVrJIV7JxrimJk0DxNI10tSGsow1a4sTKxXSNGzsNP//N7T4l19QkpmfV/xf19dUz8DQAAA)
“\$1\$-indexing”: `sub f{"@_"<3?pop>0:f("@_"-2)+f("@_"-3)}say f(<>)` **48 bytes** - [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/7@4NEkhrVrJIV7Jxti@IL/AzsAqTQPE1TXS1IayjDVrixMrFdI0bOw0//83tPyXX1CSmZ9X/F/X11TPwNAAAA)
“\$2\$-indexing”: `sub f{"@_"<3?pop==1^1:f("@_"-2)+f("@_"-3)}say f(<>)` **51 bytes** - [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/7@4NEkhrVrJIV7Jxti@IL/A1tYwztAqTQMkomukqQ1lGWvWFidWKqRp2Nhp/v9vZPAvv6AkMz@v@L@ur6megaEBAA)
“\$3\$-indexing”: `sub f{"@_"<3?1&pop:f("@_"-2)+f("@_"-3)}say f(<>)` **48 bytes** - [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/7@4NEkhrVrJIV7JxtjeUK0gv8AqTQPE1TXS1IayjDVrixMrFdI0bOw0//83MvyXX1CSmZ9X/F/X11TPwNAAAA)

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-n`, <s>43</s> <s>42</s> 40 bytes <sub><sup>(full program with implied loop)</sup></sub>

It is longer when required to be executed in a loop, due to the need to initialize `$i` each time, but this can be golfed to cost only 4 bytes:

```
1x$_.1~~/^(...?)*$(?{++$i})\1/;$i=!say$i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcHRCoIwFADQ9/sVBgM1cXrV0YOEX9AfRDFi0AU3xzZBifz0bud4E2bFazSZ2bwJZI1Les7yaHVIVqfXOx8ZN/GUeBzNo5BSTuVZFNOnqgR9yzs2o6DrKepdEDNCBz0ouAAq6BD64bf4RIuLXN@UbLHl2v0B)

Alternative **40 bytes** (doesn't work for “\$2\$-indexing” and higher):

```
1x$_.1~~/^(...?)*$(?{++$i})\1/;$i%=say$i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcHRCoIwFADQ9/sVPkzUxOlVRw8SfkF/EMWICw3cHNsEI/LTu53jKSyKt0gZ7Z6CseSSXrIiWh2S1en5KibGXTwkHkd7L6WUc3US5fypa2G@1Q3bSZj8EvVbGGaEHgZQcAZU0CMM42/1yawucnNVssOOG/cH)

“\$0\$-indexing”: `1x$_.11~~/^(...?)*$(?{++$i})\1/;$i=!say$i` **41 bytes** - [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcHdCoIwFADg@/MUBgM18bjjTzcSPoFvIMWIQQM3x7bAiHz0Tt/ndVgHfkWd6d3rYKx2Sa1ZHq0Kyar0eOYj0y7uSHQcza1AxKk8i2L6VJUw33KhZhTmeorqLQyzBIIWergA9dBK6Lrf5pPZXOR6HlCS5Nr9AQ)
“\$1\$-indexing”: `1x$_.1~~/^(...?)*$(?{++$i})\1/;$i=!say$i` **40 bytes** - [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcHRCoIwFADQ9/sVBgM1cXrV0YOEX9AfRDFi0AU3xzZBifz0bud4E2bFazSZ2bwJZI1Les7yaHVIVqfXOx8ZN/GUeBzNo5BSTuVZFNOnqgR9yzs2o6DrKepdEDNCBz0ouAAq6BD64bf4RIuLXN@UbLHl2v0B)
“\$2\$-indexing”: `$i=0;1x$_~~/^(...?)*$(?{++$i})\1/;say$i` **39 bytes** - [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcfRCoIwFADQ9/sVPgzUxLlZk2CEX9AfRDHiQgM3xzZBifz0bp23EzBOipaEBa4Bo3Xos5mKMjkTszP5@So1MXsRWq7sse/dveKcj/WBVeO7aZj91DfZ6WQ2ZokESOjhCCcY4AxygP4/9Z1DtrNP1F4VF1JQ638)
“\$3\$-indexing”: `$i=0;1x$_~~/^.(...?)*$(?{++$i})\1/;say$i` **40 bytes** - [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcHRCoMgFADQ9/sVPQjVItPMRcjoC/YHY0OGMCFN1EEx1qfv7pxg4iLxnUxhtmCidcZnvRRlcjpmp/PzVSok9sIU38jjOLo7rSilc30i1fxpGmK/9Y13KumdWEQGHHoQMICEESbgI/QCxPm3hmxXn7C9Sso4w9b/AQ)

“\$0\$-indexing”: `sub f{"@_"<3||f("@_"-2)+f("@_"-3)}say f($_)` **43 bytes** - [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/7@4NEkhrVrJIV7JxrimJk0DxNI10tSGsow1a4sTKxXSNFTiNf//N@Ay5DLiMuEy4zI04TIy4DI2/pdfUJKZn1f8X9fXVM/A0OC/bh4A)
“\$1\$-indexing”: `sub f{"@_"<3?pop>0:f("@_"-2)+f("@_"-3)}say f($_)` **48 bytes** - [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/7@4NEkhrVrJIV7Jxti@IL/AzsAqTQPE1TXS1IayjDVrixMrFdI0VOI1//835DLiMuYy5TLnMjTlMjLkMjb5l19QkpmfV/xf19dUz8DQ4L9uHgA)
“\$2\$-indexing”: `sub f{"@_"<3?pop==1^1:f("@_"-2)+f("@_"-3)}say f($_)` **51 bytes** - [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9X1qcqlCeWJSXmZdebP2/uDRJIa1aySFeycbYviC/wNbWMM7QKk0DJKJrpKkNZRlr1hYnViqkaajEa/7/b8BlyGXEZcxlwmXGZcFlaMZlBOSZ/ssvKMnMzyv@r@trqmdgaPBfNw8A)
“\$3\$-indexing”: `sub f{"@_"<3?1&pop:f("@_"-2)+f("@_"-3)}say f($_)` **48 bytes** - [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/7@4NEkhrVrJIV7JxtjeUK0gv8AqTQPE1TXS1IayjDVrixMrFdI0VOI1//834DLkMuIy5jLhMuUy57LkMjTnMjLmMjb7l19QkpmfV/xf19dUz8DQ4L9uHgA)

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-pl`, <s>43</s> <s>42</s> 40 bytes <sub><sup>(full program with implied loop)</sup></sub>

The initialization can be golfed in this form as well (but this doesn't work for “\$2\$-indexing” and higher):

```
1x$_.1~~/^(...?)*$(?{++$i})\1/;$i%=$_=$i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFBCoMwEADA@77Cwxa10shqQw8ifkSUUAJdSDQkKQilPr3bmWCj0/JOtrBHsJG93bJxRZm8idmb/HyVg9CBq6LzbJdKKTXVV6ymT9Mgf@uZ2gH5MuI6IosQdNCDhgeQho6gv//2kHnfktyC@wM)

“\$0\$-indexing”: `1x$_.11~~/^(...?)*$(?{++$i})\1/;$i%=$_=$i` **41 bytes** - [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFBCoMwEADA@77Cwxa10uiq7UXEj5RKKAsNJBqSFIRSn@464znYu3wjZ7x5DsbxkrTN8uh0SE6n9ycfhDacFdG@169CKTWVVyymX1Wh@ZdPqgc0lxHnEY1IAwQt9PAA6qFtoOuO1SezLlFu3p4)
“\$1\$-indexing”: `1x$_.1~~/^(...?)*$(?{++$i})\1/;$i%=$_=$i` **40 bytes** - [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFBCoMwEADA@77Cwxa10shqQw8ifkSUUAJdSDQkKQilPr3bmWCj0/JOtrBHsJG93bJxRZm8idmb/HyVg9CBq6LzbJdKKTXVV6ymT9Mgf@uZ2gH5MuI6IosQdNCDhgeQho6gv//2kHnfktyC@wM)
“\$2\$-indexing”: `$i=0;1x$_~~/^(...?)*$(?{++$i})\1/;$_=$i` **39 bytes** - [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9X1qcqpBaUZBalJmbmleSmKOgXpybWFSSm1iSnKFu/V8l09bA2rBCJb6uTj9OQ09Pz15TS0XDvlpbWyWzVjPGUN9aJd5WJfP/fwMuQy4jLmMuEy4zLgsuQzMuIyDP9F9@QUlmfl7xf92CHAA)
“\$3\$-indexing”: `$i=0;1x$_~~/^.(...?)*$(?{++$i})\1/;$_=$i` **40 bytes** - [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcHRCoIwFADQ9/sVPlxQk6ZzmcQQfySSEYMubDq2BULkp3c7J9joBn4nW9g92Ejertm4okzexOxNfr5KzUhTp@WOy3G0D1EJIeb6hNX8aRqkb32XrcZlQmLuQEIPCi4wwAg3kCP0CtT1t4VM25r4HNwf)

“\$0\$-indexing”: `sub f{"@_"<3||f("@_"-2)+f("@_"-3)}$_=f($_)` **42 bytes** - [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/7@4NEkhrVrJIV7JxrimJk0DxNI10tSGsow1a1XibdM0VOI1//834DLkMuIy4TLjMjThMjLgMjb@l19QkpmfV/xftyAHAA)
“\$1\$-indexing”: `sub f{"@_"<3?pop>0:f("@_"-2)+f("@_"-3)}$_=f($_)` **47 bytes** - [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/7@4NEkhrVrJIV7Jxti@IL/AzsAqTQPE1TXS1IayjDVrVeJt0zRU4jX//zfkMuIy5jLlMucyNOUyMuQyNvmXX1CSmZ9X/F@3IAcA)
“\$2\$-indexing”: `sub f{"@_"<3?pop==1^1:f("@_"-2)+f("@_"-3)}$_=f($_)` **50 bytes** - [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/7@4NEkhrVrJIV7Jxti@IL/A1tYwztAqTQMkomukqQ1lGWvWqsTbpmmoxGv@/2/AZchlxGXMZcJlxmXBZWjGZQTkmf7LLyjJzM8r/q9bkAMA)
“\$3\$-indexing”: `sub f{"@_"<3?1&pop:f("@_"-2)+f("@_"-3)}$_=f($_)` **47 bytes** - [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/7@4NEkhrVrJIV7JxtjeUK0gv8AqTQPE1TXS1IayjDVrVeJt0zRU4jX//zfgMuQy4jLmMuEy5TLnsuQyNOcyMuYyNvuXX1CSmZ9X/F@3IAcA)

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), <s>47</s> 45 bytes <sub><sup>(anonymous function with no side effects)</sup></sub>

```
sub{my$i;1x"@_".1~~/^(...?)*$(?{++$i})\1/;$i}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY5RisIwGISv8lMCSbZrJLDrg9nqHkSUqKn@0KQlSV211EcP4BG9SI37IPj0zTAzMI3x1ffQBgMhetxEBU/9p71DtwsKXP0yQM2xMR6tcVFX02mw2ker42ZPP@mhxm1Cm5oYUVd4NluqwJ6AlMUQ2nVnTwSVPGa/q0zIy2W8ZEKIOf8gbN7lOcGeL@RYJQ7q7UJZe/bcFjKFP8XXJCHPeQdYMoIzybvGo4vZwmU9/EsgKCjcrzeggpFyNEs9zqEfHg) - displays terms \$1\$ through \$46\$ with “\$1\$-indexing”

As a function already, [Xcali's **34 byte** answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/182864/17216) is shorter, although significantly slower:

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9X1qcqlBcUpSZXGKtAGKXJxblZealF1v/Ly5NUkirVnKIV7IxrqlJ0wCxdI00taEsY83a/9Zp@UUauZUqmbYG1iqZNrYmpkBKW1uzWiEzTUMlU7O6oCgzr0QpJk@pVgHMVFDJ1FNXeNQ2SUFdTwOsRFOh9j8A) - displays terms \$0\$ through \$45\$ with “\$0\$-indexing”

“\$0\$-indexing”: `sub{my$i;1x(2+pop)~~/^(...?)*$(?{++$i})\1/;$i}` **46 bytes** - [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY5fisIwGMSv8iGBJJs16rK@GLteRISoqX7QpCFJ/bOlPnoAj@hFuuk@CD79ZpgZGG9CNe@baCCmgLukYNBnHRy6Q1Tg6pcBai7eBLTGJV0tFtHqkKxOuyP9pKca9xlNbmJCXeGv2VMF9gqkLPrYbFt7JahmF/YlfO357TbZMCnlin8QtmqFINjx9WyiMnv19qGsAxvGxTSHy@J7niEEbwFLRpC3PqBLo7UbdfAvgaCk8Lw/gEpGyvHP0OLQ9X8)
“\$1\$-indexing”: `sub{my$i;1x"@_".1~~/^(...?)*$(?{++$i})\1/;$i}` **45 bytes** - [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY5RisIwGISv8lMCSbZrJLDrg9nqHkSUqKn@0KQlSV211EcP4BG9SI37IPj0zTAzMI3x1ffQBgMhetxEBU/9p71DtwsKXP0yQM2xMR6tcVFX02mw2ker42ZPP@mhxm1Cm5oYUVd4NluqwJ6AlMUQ2nVnTwSVPGa/q0zIy2W8ZEKIOf8gbN7lOcGeL@RYJQ7q7UJZe/bcFjKFP8XXJCHPeQdYMoIzybvGo4vZwmU9/EsgKCjcrzeggpFyNEs9zqEfHg)
“\$2\$-indexing”: `sub{my$i;(1x pop)=~/^(...?)*$(?{++$i})\1/+$i}` **45 bytes** - [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcpBCsIwEEDRqwxloInB1ILiIsZepAgqjQzYNCQtKqEuPYBH9CLRuPpv8V3nr5s0hQ7C6Ok8Ksi@Hb0lewkK@geg0SlMp9g/kBSr7@AGx/WzOjApZcMXyJooBNLM27rKTcoMnuVdrxTSTq@3vwjBI5BhSDw6T3YsWlvM8CcgyRI@rzeUkqFZ7vPFYU5f)
“\$3\$-indexing”: `sub{my$i;(1x pop)=~/^.(...?)*$(?{++$i})\1/+$i}` **46 bytes** - [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcpBCsIwEEDRqwxloInB1IKCEGMvUgSVRgZsGpIWlVCXHsAjepFoXP23@K7z102aQgdh9HQeFWTfjt6SvQQF/QPQ6BSmU@wfSIrVd3CD4/pZHSSTUjZ8gayJQiDNvK2r3KTM4Fn@9Uoh7fR6@4sQPAIZhsSj82THorXFDH8Ckizh83pDKRma5T5fHOb0BQ)

“\$0\$-indexing”: `sub f{"@_"<3||f("@_"-2)+f("@_"-3)}` **34 bytes** - [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9X1qcqlBcUpSZXGKtAGKXJxblZealF1v/Ly5NUkirVnKIV7IxrqlJ0wCxdI00taEsY83a/9Zp@UUauZUqmbYG1iqZNrYmpkBKW1uzWiEzTUMlU7O6oCgzr0QpJk@pVgHMVFDJ1FNXeNQ2SUFdTwOsRFOh9j8A)
“\$1\$-indexing”: `sub f{"@_"<3?pop>0:f("@_"-2)+f("@_"-3)}` **39 bytes** - [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9X1qcqlBcUpSZXGKtAGKXJxblZealF1v/Ly5NUkirVnKIV7Ixti/IL7AzsErTAHF1jTS1oSxjzdr/1mn5RRq5lSqZtobWKpk2tiZmQEpbW7NaITNNQyXTzlCzuqAoM69EKSZPqVYBzFRQydRTV3jUNklBXU8DpEhTU6H2PwA)
“\$2\$-indexing”: `sub f{"@_"<3?pop==1^1:f("@_"-2)+f("@_"-3)}` **42 bytes** - [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9X1qcqlBcUpSZXGKtAGKXJxblZealF1v/Ly5NUkirVnKIV7Ixti/IL7C1NYwztErTAInoGmlqQ1nGmrX/rdPyizRyK1UybQ2sVTJtbE3MgZS2tma1QmaahkqmZnVBUWZeiVJMnlKtApipoJKpp67wqG2SgrqeBliJpkLtfwA)
“\$3\$-indexing”: `sub f{"@_"<3?1&pop:f("@_"-2)+f("@_"-3)}` **39 bytes** - [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9X1qcqlBcUpSZXGKtAGKXJxblZealF1v/Ly5NUkirVnKIV7IxtjdUK8gvsErTAHF1jTS1oSxjzdr/1mn5RRq5lSqZtgbWKpk2tiYWQEpbW7NaITNNQyVTs7qgKDOvRCkmT6lWAcxUUMnUU1d41DZJQV1PA6xEU6H2PwA)

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), <s>27</s> <s>26</s> <s>25</s> 24 bytes<sup><sup>[SBCS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252)</sup></sup> <sub><sup>(anonymous function)</sup></sub>

```
{+m:ex/^(...?)*$/}o¹x*+2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/WjvXKrVCP05DT0/PXlNLRb82/9DOCi1to//WxYmVCnpARWn5RQpxxgb/AQ)

[Thanks to Jo King](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/85/fibonacci-function-or-sequence/223243#comment518590_223243) for extending the idea to this language.

“\$0\$-indexing”: `{+m:ex/^(...?)*$/}o¹x*+2` **24 bytes** - [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/WjvXKrVCP05DT0/PXlNLRb82/9DOCi1to//WxYmVCnpARWn5RQpxxgb/AQ)
“\$1\$-indexing”: `{+m:ex/^(...?)*$/}o¹x*+1` **24 bytes** - [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/WjvXKrVCP05DT0/PXlNLRb82/9DOCi1tw//WxYmVCnpARWn5RQqGenrGBv8B)
“\$2\$-indexing”: `{+m:ex/^(...?)*$/}o¹x*` **22 bytes** - [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/WjvXKrVCP05DT0/PXlNLRb82/9DOCq3/1sWJlQp6QCVp@UUKccZG/wE)
“\$3\$-indexing”: `{+m:ex/^.(...?)*$/}o¹x*` **23 bytes** - [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/WjvXKrVCP05PQ09Pz15TS0W/Nv/Qzgqt/9bFiZUKekA1aflFCnHGxv8B)

[Sean's non-regex answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/182820/17216) (shown below adapted to different indexings) is still shorter, but only by 2 bytes (though it's longer at “\$3\$-indexing” and ties at “\$2\$-indexing”). Fibonacci [is not even close](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/41728/17216).

“\$0\$-indexing”: `{(1,1,1,*+*+!*…*)[$_]}` **22 bytes** - [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/WsNQBwS1tLW0FbUeNSzT0oxWiY@t/V@cWKmgB1SSll@kEGds8B8A)
“\$1\$-indexing”: `{(0,1,1,*+*+!*…*)[$_]}` **22 bytes** - [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/WsNAxxAItbS1tBW1HjUs09KMVomPrf1fnFipoAdUkpZfpGCop2ds8B8A)
“\$2\$-indexing”: `{(1,0,1,*+*+!*…*)[$_]}` **22 bytes** - [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/WsNQx0DHUEdLW0tbUetRwzItzWiV@Nja/8WJlQp6QCVp@UUKccZG/wE)
“\$3\$-indexing”: `{(0,1,~0,*+*+!*…*)[$_]}` **23 bytes** - [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/WsNAx1CnzkBHS1tLW1HrUcMyLc1olfjY2v/FiZUKekA1aflFCnHGxv8B)
“\$3\$-indexing”: `{(0,1,0,*+*+*%1…*)[$_]}` **23 bytes** - [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/WsNAx1DHQEdLGwhVDR81LNPSjFaJj639X5xYqaAHVJOWX6QQZ2z8HwA)
“\$3\$-indexing”: `{(0,1,0,*+*+*×0…*)[$_]}` **23 bytes** - [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/WsNAx1DHQEdLGwgPTzd41LBMSzNaJT629n9xYqWCHlBRWn6RQpyx8X8A)

Note that the same regex method used in the Perl 5 versions can also be directly ported to Perl 6:

“\$0\$-indexing”: `{my$i;¹x$_+2~~/^(...?)*${++$i}./;$i}` **36 bytes** - [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/OrdSJdP60M4KlXhto7o6/TgNPT09e00tlWptbZXMWj19ayD5vzixUkEPqD4tv0ghztjgPwA)
“\$1\$-indexing”: `{my$i;¹x$_+1~~/^(...?)*${++$i}./;$i}` **36 bytes** - [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/OrdSJdP60M4KlXhtw7o6/TgNPT09e00tlWptbZXMWj19ayD5vzixUkEPqD4tv0jBUE/P2OA/AA)
“\$2\$-indexing”: `{my$i;¹x$_~~/^(...?)*${++$i}./;+$i}` **35 bytes** - [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/OrdSJdP60M4Klfi6Ov04DT09PXtNLZVqbW2VzFo9fWsQ9b84sVJBD6g8Lb9IIc7Y6D8A)
“\$3\$-indexing”: `{my$i;¹x$_~~/^.(...?)*${++$i}./;+$i}` **36 bytes** - [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/OrdSJdP60M4Klfi6Ov04PQ09PT17TS2Vam1tlcxaPX1rEPW/OLFSQQ@oPi2/SCHO2Pg/AA)

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 14 bytes

```
(>:%1-*:*>:)t.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qfpmBrpWCgAMT/NeysVA11tay07Kw0S/T@a3Ip6Smog@XVFXQUaq0U0rhSkzPyFdIUMvUUjAz@AwA)

Asks for the (input)-th Taylor coefficient of the generating function $$x \mapsto \frac{x+1}{1-x^2\cdot(x+1)}.$$

(The parenthesized train `>:` `%` `1` `-` `*:` `*` `>:` is read as: “increment over one minus square times increment.”)

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 34 bytes

```cs
int f(int g)=>g<3?1:f(g-2)+f(g-3);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/P8/M69EIU0DRKZr2tql2xjbG1qlaaTrGmlqgyhjTev/aflFYAWZtgbWmTZGQEJbW5MrvCizJNUnMy9VA6hdE6gMAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [C++ (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>81</s> <s>75</s> 74 bytes

-6 bytes to small golfing

-1 byte thanks to @ceilingcat

```cpp
int a(int n){int a=1,b=1,c=1,d,i=2;for(;i++<n;c=d)d=a+b,a=b,b=c;return c;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZDPboQgEMbP@hST7UUjTfzTrO0ivWx66DM0e2CBNiSKRjFpYn12OyDddA8ww8dvJvONGIbHLyG2TRsLPHG3SRf/YAW54hF4JNGspJ/9mFCdZY2hgslUMp5dCWdXxAQdlZ1HA4Ku24M2op2lgkb3kx0V715j17Hj2iQpLHE0WXk6iX620DRweDcDZj9w5q2YW26VhH7epbfvQYldsKgcHO@LlZEtjSM/79yd@aQmYPAcJO06Th8XlJacQEGgJPBE4Ig5hhK1qloDvLcOdOHpW0FVOxrxuq5eXAHuAPyWNNI5xdDcBqCQZdr7uzcYptEX7xZdeRtu2UFP7z7@5tn5/27XOAprzmm8br8)

Simple function to compute the values iteratively. No loop occurs for `n<3`, so the first cases default to the initial 1.

Answer (score 1):

## [Gaia](https://github.com/splcurran/Gaia), <s>16</s> <s>14</s> 12 bytes

```
7b@⟨ṇ;(++⟩ₓ(
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0/MTPz/3zzJ4dH8FQ93tltraGs/mr/yUdNkjf//jY0B)

0-based index. Only holds the last 3 values.

```
7b		| push [1 1 1]
  @		| push input
   ⟨     ⟩ₓ	| do the following that many times (0 times if 0 or less)
    ṇ		| pop the first element and leave the rest below
     ;		| copy from below
      (		| take the first element
       +	| add the two together
	+	| and concatenate to the list. End loop.
	   (	| finally, take the first element
```

## [Gaia](https://github.com/splcurran/Gaia), 14 bytes

```
ø@⟨18b+ₔ…Σ¦⟩ₓ<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASUA2v9nYWlh///DuEDin6gxOGIr4oKU4oCmzqPCpuKfqeKCkzz//zEw)

Returns the first `n` elements, 1-based index. `<` could also be `E` to get just the `n`th element.

Uses the identity from the OEIS page \$a(n+5)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n a(i)\$.

This is quite inefficient, as it repeatedly copies the first few lists.

```
ø		| push empty list
 @⟨	   ⟩ₓ	| do (input) number of times:
   18b		| push [1 0 0 1 0] by converting 18 to bits
      +ₔ	| append cumulative list (initially empty) to end of bits
	…Σ¦	| and calculate the cumulative sums, replacing old cumulative list
	     <	| finally, take the first (input) elements of cumulative sums
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 26 bytes

```
If[#<3,1,#0[#-2]+#0[#-3]]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b73zMtWtnGWMdQR9kgWlnXKFYbTBvHxqr9DyjKzCtx0ErTdwhKzEtPdTAy@A8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 28 bytes

0-indexed.

```
f(n)=if(n<3,1,f(n-2)+f(n-3))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYsxCoAwEAS/sqTy8AImESv1I2KRRglIOIKNrz8vzc7swkpuxd@ieg2VtmK5Jg5s9JHGjkSkWeT5hgq/Q1qpr6nrxaHfiHFMjMCIjJmxmBuibSmdpD8)

---

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 35 bytes

1-indexed.

```
n->Vec((1+x+O(x^n))/(1-x^2-x^3))[n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYrBCoNADER/ZfCUYJayuxVP@gu99SIKUmoRJATxsP36bXoY5s1jbD338LG6YUDVMD7fL6LYlvZBZVHmG8VQluTJzJPOdTU7vqQII@zc9XJs/qPBRv4XTFGQBFnQCXpB9Eru8n3m@gM)

The generating function of the sequence is \$\frac{1+x}{1-x^2-x^3}\$.

Answer (score 1):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), <s>50</s> 48 bytes

```
 2+sx3si1d:a[liddddd3-;ar2-;a+r:a1+silx>M]dsMx;ap
```

It's 1-indexed! [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ddA7CsMwDADQvacwdDSFys7Xob1BoEO3kMHEGQweSuSCb@/GSulSpEEInhCS3JLVNSuJSaMHZ@wUvCuhL4Pd1J7kZixI9CHdx9nhmAb7yue4YhT49nE9Tc9SpxsYMT8EiDJMLPu4QL0/V@SKdU2uWa/IK9Zr8pr1hrxhvSVvWe/IO9Z78p51OA4E/kI4VgR@R/V94t8X8wc) [Previous version!](https://tio.run/##ddDNCsMgDADg@55C2LEMFu2vZXuDwg67lR6k9iB4GI0D397ZdAwGqYcg@UJIYuckrwmjQgdWagPajN7Z7alLb1aZQ7HmfIHOx/swWRxib17pHBYMAt8uLKfxuf3jDbSYHgIwijn381T4Q0koeVSEiseSsOSxIqx4rAlrHhvChseWsOWxI@x4hH0XOFgG9pngYCj5PdP/ndIH)

Golfed off two bytes by only populating the first element in the array.

Probably can be golfed a bit more, but it's tricky because you have to a: seed the initial values, and b: use arrays since `dc` doesn't let you pick from arbitrary stack positions.

`2+sx3si` adds two to the user input at top of stack into register `x`, and starts an increment counter register `i` at 3. We have to add two because the array is now populated in such a way that it's 3-indexed.

`1d:a` populates element 1 of array `a` with a 1. The 50 byte version populated elements 1 and 2 with `1d2:a1:a`. The mechanism works with just the single element populated, however, it just takes a little while to get enough 1s in place such as to start the sequence. Even though going from `1d2:a1:a` to `1d:a` saves 4 bytes, we now have to `2+` our input. Still two bytes saved. Initially, I thought I had to seed the first three elements with `1dd3:a2:a1:a` (+4 bytes), but... `dc` returns a zero for any unassigned array element, and if we start macro `M` (below) by creating the third element, adding 0 to 1... we're good to go.

Macro `M`:

`liddddd` loads register `i` and makes a bunch of copies of it. We subtract 3 from one of these, get the corresponding element from `a` and then swap top of stack. Subtract 2, get the corresponding element from `a`, add the two elements to get our new value, then swap the top of stack. At this point, `:a` puts our new value into `a` at position `i`. `1+si` to increment `i`, and `lx>M` to keep running `M` until we hit our target (stored in `x`). `dsMx` runs `M`, and once `M` has finished running, the stack should be full of leftover `i` values, the topmost of which is the last one we made. Load the value from `a` with `;a` and print it with `p`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 96 bytes

```
(()()()){({}[()]<{({}[()])<>(())(<>)}{}>)}{}{({}[()]<<>({}<(({}(({}))<>)<>[{}])>)<>({}<>)<>>)}<>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYsxCoBQDEOv0wwOOpde5POH7yCI4uBaevaaCkrbNPCS9R77NW3nODJFUAMXjybo@hmokUHUEB6v/BkiDxVKHRjlNo@OMsXqs6OWOS8P)

Answer (score 1):

## [Clojure](https://clojure.org/), 46 bytes

```clj
(defn f[n](if(< n 3)1(+(f(- n 2))(f(- n 3)))))
```

Just for completeness sake :)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dc@xCsIwEAbg3ac4Ml0QIcmVFqGrg5MPYJ3aBCoSQ0nBwXePLXgpGXrTD/fxc9e/3s95sinhYJ0Hd/cPHB224IGkxiM6PC3ZSPlPJNdJGKbRRxBXH@YIXfzCbY4cL59g@2iHzgt5YKmWjQB0oCSILq5OF0Az0DvAMDA7oGJQZWAKUDOoM6jKG3KF3jqoKc/In5jtFaNUgYgYEWXUNHReVfoB)

Comment: Welcome to PPCG :)

Answer (score 1):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 16 bytes

```
qi7Yb{((_j\(j+}j
```

0-indexed, returns nth item
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/vzDTPDKpWkMjPitGI0u7Nuv/f2NjAA)

Explanation: It uses a recursive function to add a(n-2) to a(n-3) to find a(n).

```
qi7Yb{((_j\(j+}j
qi               - reads input as integer
  7Yb            - push an array of [1, 1, 1]. It does this by pushing 7, then 
                   turning it into binary.
     {        }j - define a recursive function to calculate a(n), where the 
                   predefined values for n = 0,1,2 are 1,1,1
      ((         - subtract 2 from n | Stack: n-2
        _        - duplicate | Stack: n-2, n-2
         j       - find a(n-2) | Stack: n-2, a(n-2)
          \      - swap the top two items in the stack | Stack: a(n-2), n-2
           (     - decrement | Stack: a(n-2), n-3
            j    - find a(n-3) | Stack: a(n-2), a(n-3)
             +   - add, finding a(n)
                 - implicit output
```

In pseudocode:

```
read input as integer
define padovan_sequence(n):
    return padovan_sequence(n-2) + padovan_sequence(n-3)
print(padovan_sequence(n))
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
ÉKΦΘÄO¢
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=904be8e98e4f9b&i=0%0A1%0A2%0A4%0A6%0A14%0A20%0A33&a=1&m=2)

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 17 bytes

```
$[2&(],_2{+/\)3##
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/VaKN1DRideKNqrX1YzSNlZX/a3KlJmfkK6QpGMEY5jCGofl/AA)

```
                #   length of input, 1
              3#    1,1,1
 [                     N times:
  2       +/\          sums of length 2 windows
       _2{             pick second to last
     ],                append
$                   take N 
{                   (or pick Nth term for same score)
```

Answer (score 1):

## x86, 19 bytes

```
f:	xor eax, eax
.a:	push edi
.a2:	sub edi, 3
	jc  .l
	call .a
	inc edi
	jmp .a2
.l:	inc eax
	pop edi
	ret
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVAxbsMwDJylV3AokCG2YCdF0apDp3bqD4IgoC0pdSFZhiSnST/vUrazdBGo4/HuSIxRu8beSoPRTcYHhwnePz9AX3U7Jmyshj3np5gwJMmZ8xfQqiug4qKWrEVrwaxwey3AxTMXXrKrD8QjgB7OVHcB9eODggMRjvAKQY9RU0O3eY4zVAqULWBTbRa1A8HHgjDOko4JNGYxJOp3/wvC36Msntuaszg2q2UWnLt55nGtG6qJ1fUJHp6rXLR5E9JzA4iaA6VpoH4CNQ7wxklUMgpVV5NZ17knECjZMMaveVzgTq7WdJU9ybUAglLPpxH43wh3XFi5gHmbwQ9LN@g0mZPuFdl2cbB4g/lbmrJ@2ea7TH8)

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia](http://julialang.org/), 21 bytes

```
!n=n<3||!(n-2)+!(n-3)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Nc3NCsMgEATg@zyF3pT@oG6oVJonEQ@h8ZASJBADKeTdLVWyl/kYGPazzdOg91J46tOLjoOLdDPy8g@SJcc1r6xnHorV09AnzImuweDR0EG3iixM2xmlQFRpLT0RME7rMg9f4eESc3Ff4jvHkTnBk0R7e@eiwrurDhJBlh8)

Comment: Is there any shorter way to get the first three terms to be `1` instead of `true` than `!n=+(n<3||!(n-2)+!(n-3))` [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Nc1BCsMgEAXQ/ZxCdw5pizqhUklOIi5C4yIlSEALKeTuhiqZzX98@Mznuy6T2kvhcexEHOg4uIh3jd0/CLHkkHJiI3MgWT0F6oK@0DdoeDb0oFpFBnTbaSmBqNIYeoGHeUnbOv2EAxuZDfsW3jnMzAoeEdrbBxcVzt6UR/BYTg "Julia 1.0 – Try It Online") (**24 bytes**)?

Comment: @Deadcode `true == 1`, i think I can leave it like that. Otherwise  with Julia 0.7 [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Nc3NCsMgEATg@zyF3pT@oG6oVBr6IOIhNB5SggQ00D69pUr2Mh8Dw773dZlsrTyN6UFP7bhIFyNP/yBZS8wls5F5KNZOQx8wB4YOg1vHAN0rsjB9Z5QCUaO1dEfAvORtnb7CwyXm4meLrxJn5gRPEv3tlYsG7846SARZfw "Julia 0.7 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [Arn](https://github.com/ZippyMagician/Arn) `-al`, [9 bytes](https://github.com/ZippyMagician/Arn/wiki/Carn)

I'm not particularly sure why this works...

```
w®¦€•3=⁺■
```

[Try it!](https://zippymagician.github.io/Arn?code=MSAxIDF7Iyt9LT4=&input=MQozCjQKNwoxMAoxMgoxOQozMw==&flags=YWw=) 1-indexed, outputs the nth term

## Explained

Unpacked: `1 1 1{#+}->`
Exploits Arn's weird precedence bugs to save a byte. A more "normal" version would have `{_ _+}` as the block or something like `{#_+}` (as `#` is a suffix)

```
[ ... ]      Implied by `-a` flag
  1          First entry = 1
  1          Second entry = 1
  1          Third entry = 1
    {        Other entries determined by
        _      a[n - 1], throwaway implied
      #        This implies the `_` before it while allowing + to not have it b/c bugs
        _    a[n - 2], implied
      +      Plus
        _    a[n - 3]
    }        Return this last value
  ->         Sequence has length of
    _        STDIN; implied
         Then, get last item
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 8 bytes

```
‡_+T⁺
ḞẎ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLigKFfK1TigbpcbuG4nuG6jiIsIiIsIjIwIl0=)
Woo, we beat Jelly!

```
‡  T      # A triadic lambda function taking three arguments...
 _+       # Pop the first and add the next two
    ⁺NL   # With the initial vector [1, 1, 1]...
       Ḟ  # Create an infinite generator that calls the function with the last <arity> (3 in this case) arguments and appends that to the list.
        Ẏ # Get the first n items.
```

NL in the explanation represents a literal newline. In Vyxal, `⁺` takes the index of the next character in the Vyxal codepage and adds 101 to it. As Vyxal's codepage is aligned with ASCII, a newline is #10, so the number 111 can be represented by `⁺` and a newline.

Comment: [8 bytes](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLigKFfK1TigbpcbuG4nuG6jiIsIiIsIjIwIl0=)

Comment: @lyxal Nice, forgot about that!

Answer (score 1):

## [tinylisp](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/tinylisp), 63 bytes

```
(d f(q((x y z u)(i u(f y z(a x y)(s u 1))x
(d g(q((x)(f 1 1 1 x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYpRCoAgFAT/PcV@7vvLjO4ThCJEFCZolzd7sjCwwzzxrEdMV2vc4XmTBRUvsjAi0/@HG7oUJmRYkWJ6GjSVHlhdaQyYxHRa5axclOvw48yjck5M@wA)

-10 from dlosc

Comment: lol my bad.....

Comment: What do you think of `(d g(q((x)(i(l x 3)1(a(g(s x 2))(g(s x 3`

Comment: I did *not* think about naive recursion, lol. You should post it separately

Answer (score 0):

## [Groovy](http://groovy-lang.org/), 22 bytes

```
a->a<3?1:f(a-2)+f(a-1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy/Kzy@r/J@mYKtQ/T9R1y7Rxtje0CpNI1HXSFMbRBlq/q/lSssv0si0NbDOtDEEEtramtVcCgVFmXklOXkKaRqZmly1Clz/AQ)

Comment: This is Fibonacci with an extra \$1\$ term, not Padovan. The correct form for the latter would be `a->a<3?1:f(a-3)+f(a-2)` [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy/Kzy@r/J@mYKtQ/T9R1y7Rxtje0CpNI1HXWFMbRBlp/q/lSssv0si0NbDOtLE1ApLa2prVXAoFRZl5JTl5CmkamZpctQpc/wE "Groovy – Try It Online") at the same byte length.

Answer (score 0):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 144 bytes, 0-indexed.

```cs
using C=System.Console;class A{static void Main(){int i=int.Parse(C.ReadLine());C.Write(p(i));}static int p(int i){return i<3?1:p(i-2)+p(i-3);}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYvBCsIwEER/ZY8J0oD2Zi0iuSqIHjyHdJGFupFsKkjot8cEvMwwj3leOh8ilrII8RPseP9KwpexgSXMOPjZicApS3KJPHwCTXBxxEpn4gQ01jRXFwWVNTd005kYldaDNY9ICdVbUV3r329OJc3UOWJaIgMd@uN2X2m305tWff2vpfwA)

Quite frankly, this is not my best work ever.  But here it is.

Answer (score 0):

## Excel, <s>79 77</s> 65 bytes

*-2 bytes, sequence didn't need to be horizontal*

*-12 bytes, change lower bound to 1 and handle errors from COMBIN*

```
=LET(k,A1+2,m,SEQUENCE(INT(k/2)),SUM(IFERROR(COMBIN(m,k-2*m),0)))
```

It uses the equation \$P(k-2)=\sum_{m=\lceil k/3\rceil}^{\lfloor k/2\rfloor}{m \choose k-2m}.\$

```
=LET(
k=A1+2                        'k = N + 2
m=SEQUENCE(INT(k/2))          'm = 1 .. floor k/2
SUM(IFERROR(COMBIN(m,k-2*m))) 'Sum of combinations (m, k-2m)
```

Answer (score 0):

## MMIX, 40 bytes (10 instrs)

(jxd)

```
00000000: e3010000 e3020001 e3030001 22ff0102  ẉ¢¡¡ẉ£¡¢ẉ¤¡¢"”¢£
00000010: c1010200 c1020300 c103ff00 27000001  Ḋ¢£¡Ḋ£¤¡Ḋ¤”¡'¡¡¢
00000020: 5b00fffb f8020000                    [¡”»ẏ£¡¡
```

(disassembly and explanation)

```
pado    SETL $1,0       // a(4) - pad(0) except that doesn't work properly
        SETL $2,1       // a(5) - pad(1)
        SETL $3,1       // a(6) - pad(2)
0H      ADDU $255,$1,$2 // a(n + 3) = a(n) + a(n + 1)
        SET  $1,$2      // shift down
        SET  $2,$3
        SET  $3,$255
        SUBU $0,$0,1    // one cycle done
        PBNZ $0,0B      // return if done
        POP  2,0
```