# Advanced Binary Number System

Tags: code-golf, number, number-theory, binary

Your task is to write a program that calculates the amount of different ways to display any given whole positive number using the following rules:

Meet the 'advanced binary system':

Any whole positive number can be displayed in binary form, but each bit can have every number from 0 to 9. This means, a valid number might look like this: **480** and would be calculated to 4 * 2^2 + 8 * 2^1 + 0 * 2^0 = 32. You see, every 'bit' is multiplied with 2 to the power of the significance of the bit, just like in binary but with 10 (0 to 9) different possible bits instead of 2 (0 and 1).

It is given a whole positive decimal number in any kind of form. This can be text input, a variable value, an array element, etc. Then your program calculates in how many ways (using the number format explained above. Leading zeroes obviously do not count) the inputted decimal number can be displayed. The result should then be returned, printed or drawn in any readable way as a decimal number.

Examples:

Input: 3 -> Output: 2 >
Reason: the decimal number 3 can be displayed as 11 (1 * 2^1 + 1 * 2^0) and as 3 (3 * 2^0), thus 2 different possibilities

Input: 1 -> Output: 1 >
Reason: the only possibility is 1 (1 * 2^0)

Input: 2 -> Output: 2 >
Reason: possibilities are 10 and 2

And so on.

This is code golf: program with least amount of bytes wins!

**Test cases**

The first 30 values are:

```
1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 6, 6, 10, 10, 13, 13, 18, 18, 22, 22, 30, 30, 36, 36, 45, 45, 52, 52, 64, 64, 72, 72, 84, 84, 93
```

Comment: Could you provide some larger test cases?

Comment: Note that this sequence `1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 6, 6, 10, 10, ...`  initially matches [https://oeis.org/A018819](https://oeis.org/A018819) which counts number of partitions of `n` into powers of `2`, but limiting the digits to 9 causes it to continue `13, 13, 18, 18, ...` rather than `14, 14, 20, 20, ...`.

Comment: For completion's sake (and for the interlinking) A018819 was asked about in [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/249404/number-of-binary-partitions) challenge.

Comment: I think this isn't actually a dupe of the challenge to enumerate these base representations, because just counting them allows shortcuts as seen in mine and especially dingledooper's Python answers.

Comment: Is there a word for a number with digits larger than its base?  Like "denormalized"?  I googled some but didn't find anything.  (You might not even call it a "base" anymore, just a set of place-values.)  I guess you could also look at the digits as coefficients for a polynomial which you're evaluating at x=2.  Fun fact: a bigint can be thought of as a number in base 2^64, with each chunk as a digit.  Or depending on the implementation, 2^30, allowing room for digits to exceed the base w/o overflow, deferring normalization to [allow efficient SIMD](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8866973/224132)

Comment: @PeterCordes: perhaps you're looking for the term "[non-standard positional numeral system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-standard_positional_numeral_systems)", many of which use a set of D digits that is greater than its base B. The non-standard positional numeral system I encounter most frequently is signed-digit binary, which uses 3 digits N0P representing -1, 0, and +1, used in in [Booth's multiplication algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Booth%27s_multiplication_algorithm). It defers normalization to canonical [non-adjacent form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/non-adjacent_form).

Comment: Most of the answers are just functions, not actual programs.  Are we just trying to write the function with the fewest characters? Seems like these "byte" sizes are assuming 1 byte per character. I guess we're not measuring the size of the standalone program + all its dependencies? (You can't run a python program without installing python but we get all the dep.s for free?)

Comment: @CommaToast Check out our [welcome guide](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20861/78410), especially Answering section. To address individual concerns: 1) [Full programs and functions](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2419/78410) following [standard I/O methods](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447/78410) are allowed. 2) Byte sizes are measured in UTF-8 by default, but some langs (05AB1E/Jelly/Vyxal/...) use custom encodings to score each char as 1 byte; as a tradeoff they can *only* use 256 specific chars supported by the language.

Comment: @CommaToast 3) Your guess is correct; we only care about the piece of source code you write. Dependencies (e.g. the `python` binary to run Python code) are free, and you can even use 3rd party libraries as long as you specify that in the answer. Btw, golfing in standalone machine code is also a thing.

Comment: Cool OK. I gave an answer in Swift, not the shortest here but best I could come up with :D

Answer (score 8):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 45 bytes

Based on the conjectured formula presented in [OEIS A309616](https://oeis.org/A309616).

```python
f=lambda n:n<2or-f(n/2-5)*(n>9)+f(n-2)+f(n/2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Lc7BDoIwDAbgO0/R46YQoAwE4nwEX4BwmBGUBDsyufj0c1lJ/i9Ne@m//fa3JfR@1qv5PJ4GqKcrWpfNgnLMankSdOvkOawZxpGj9Ia@oGG4W5pSKFPAGBXTxJTFoTq0DJFVxaFhqmY1skaxC7JWsa4ak9k6IFgInKHXJML/dSIROknZJ7C5hXYIRSVoDeE60Oj/)

Comment: Nice find! The conjecture is true and isn't hard to show, by the way. Let \$n>9\$ be even, and write \$n=2k\$. Then, using your \$f\$, we have \$f(n)=f(k-4)+f(k-3)+f(k-2)+f(k-1)+f(k)\$. Likewise, \$f(n-2)=f(k-5)+f(k-4)+f(k-3)+f(k-2)+f(k-1)\$, and subtracting these gives \$f(n)-f(n-2) = f(k)-f(k-5) = f(n/2)-f(n/2-5)\$ as desired. For odd \$n\$, just replace \$n\$ with \$n-1\$, which doesn't change \$f(n)\$ or \$f(n-2)\$ or \$n/2\$ if we floor-divide.

Comment: Maybe a bit more directly: For \$n>9\$, list out the advanced binary forms of \$n-1\$ and \$n\$ respectively. There are "easy" pairs where we just increment the last digit of one for \$n-1\$ to get one for \$n\$. For \$n\$ odd, they all pair off this way, so \$f(n-1)=f(n)\$. But, for \$n\$ even, there are unmatched extras: where a form for \$n\$ ends in 0 or one for \$n-1\$ ends in 9. There's \$f(n/2)\$ of the former and \$f((n-10)/2)\$ of the latter. So, the difference in sizes gives \$f(n)-f(n-1)= f(n/2)-f((n-10)/2)\$. Adjusting with \$f(n-1)=f(n-2)\$ gives \$f(n)=f(n-1)+f(n/2)-f(n/2-5)\$.

Comment: @xnor Wow! Super nice! Thanks for posting all that!

Answer (score 7):

## [Python](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 53 bytes

```python
f=lambda n:sum(f(k)for k in range(n)if~9<2*k-n<1)or 1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RcqxDkAwEADQX7mxJwzVBakvEUOFoymnqRosfr2YzO/5Ky47q8qHlKhdzTaMBrg5zk2QcEh7AAeWIRieJ8Fo6a51mbmCtcQXZfLBchQdvQhf57/LHJTEHtMD)

The `if` condition is golfed from `0<=n-2*k<=9`.

---

## [Python](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 46 bytes

```python
f=lambda n:sum(map(f,range(n//2+1)[-5:n]),n<1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcpBDkAwEAXQq8xyJipNiUSEk4hFhSLR36ZYOH0tvPWL770H1G1MObvhtH5eLKG7Hs/eRnYqWWwrQ@uqMDKWTYdJFHojOaYDN4@OIeRCItAB@rtRVBuZJH8)

*-2 by dingledooper*

Comment: You can drop the `0,` argument in `range`. Integer division in Python 2 could also save a byte. I was not aware that ranges could be sliced!

Comment: @dingledooper Nice catch. Yeah, `range`s in Python 3 aren't always awful, mostly just with concatenation!

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
BḌRDḄċ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AS0A0v9qZWxsef//QuG4jFJE4biExIv/LMOHxZLhuZgkauKAnCAtPiDigJ0pWf//MzA)

### How it works

For the input \$x\$, we generate the range \$[1, n]\$, where \$n\$ is the binary representation of \$x\$, treated as decimal. For example: \$x = 3\$ yields \$n = 11\$ and \$x = 6\$ yields \$n = 110\$. We then convert each number in this range to its decimal digits, convert them back to binary, and count the occurrences of \$x\$.

We use the fact that Jelly's base converter doesn't care about the digit values, and simply sums up \$a \times b^n\$ for digit \$a\$, base \$b\$ and position \$n\$.

```
BḌRDḄċ - Main link. Takes x on the left
B      - Convert x to binary
 Ḍ     - Treat this binary representation as a base 10 number, n
  R    - Range from 1 to n
   D   - Convert each to digits
    Ḅ  - Convert the digits to binary
     ċ - Count occurrences of x
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 5 bytes

```
↵2vβO
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLihrUyds6yTyIsIiIsIjUiXQ==)

Times out after default time online for anything over 4, times out for all inputs over 5 after maximum time.

Kind of similar to caird's jelly answer but much slower.

### Explained

```
↵2vβO
↵      # 10 to the power of the input - this will always be longer than the binary representation of the input
 2vβ   # convert each item in the range [1, that] to base 2 - the base converter just happens to be nice with digits greater than the base. 
    O  # Count how many items in that list are equal to the input
```

Comment: `↵vBO` should work, but bugs, bugs, bugs, bugs.

Comment: `elif t_item is float or is_sympy(item): 
         return int(item)` it's a feature @Steffan

Comment: it's also useless

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), 35 bytes

Based on the [OEIS formula](https://oeis.org/A309616) found by [dingledooper](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/251969/58563).

```javascript
f=n=>n<2?n>=0:f(n-2)+f(n/=2)-f(n-5)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYzBCoMwEAV/ZQ8esoSoDXhRV3/FYE1pkbeipRfx29N4GgaG@YRfOOb9vX0d9LmkFAUyoPcjBqnbaOA824xKPLtbG05RdwMSenQE6qmpM61lmhWHrku56stMwRQnLs5Zcd4DviZOfw)

Answer (score 4):

## [Swift](https://swift.org/):

## - 187 bytes (standalone program)

## - 66 bytes (function f)

(The question asks for a "program" so providing it as a program.)

```swift
import Darwin.C.stdlib
guard let x=CommandLine.arguments.dropFirst().first,let n=Int(x) else {exit(1)}
func f(_ n:Int)->Int{n<1 ?n==0 ?1:0: n%2==0 ?f(n-1):f(n/2)+f(n-1)}
print("\(f(n))")
```

[Try it online!](https://jdoodle.com/a/5a0y)

To get multiple output for a range:

```swift
print("\((0...100).map(f))")
```

Notes:

- not that it matters for the sake of this contest, but the compiled & optimized standalone Swift program for arm64 macOS 11+ is 134,440 bytes, and can be downloaded [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ypVZgHUTBPkbW3qvlzT5IEqykpUCIrTs/view?usp=sharing) for inspection; this might seem large but not when you consider that it requires no dependency to be installed also, such as a Python, Java, or Javascript runtime (Swift compiles in a manner similar to C or C++)
- if you have Swift installed (for linux/windows/Mac) you can just use the function (and not the full program) directly in the Swift REPL as you would use a function in the Python REPL etc.

The algorithm used is [Michael Somos](https://oeis.org/wiki/User:Michael_Somos)' Haskell answer above for [the OEIS sequence](https://oeis.org/A018819).

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice answer!

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 14 bytes

```
ＮθＩ№Ｅ⊕⍘θ²⍘Ｉι²θ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/98zr6C0xK80Nym1SKNQ05oroCgzr0TDObEYSOSXApm@iQUannnJRam5qXklqSkaTonFqcElQFXpGoU6CkaamjoKSEJgjZmaUIlCTU1N6///jQ3@65blAAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: Port of @caird's Jelly answer.

```
Ｎθ              Input `n` as a number
       θ        Input `n`
      ⍘ ²       Convert to a string in base `2`
     ⊕          Increment in base `10`
    Ｅ           Map over implicit range
           ι    Current value
          Ｉ     Cast to string
         ⍘  ²   Interpret as base `2`
   №            Count occurrences of
             θ  Input `n`
  Ｉ             Cast to string
                Implicitly print
```

I tried to solve this myself but I ended up with a 21 byte port of @xnor's Python answer but using dynamic programming instead of recursion:

```
⊞υ¹ＦＮ⊞υΣΦυ¬÷⁻⊕ι⊗λχＩ⊟υ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYo7CsMwEER7n0LlChywSekyJpAiRuATyLKCF/Qx0q6vr2yKTDXvzbjDFpdtaM1wPYB7Neqp@@Si4JVOpoXj5gtorf77yhGeGEis0JJJjjTjhbuHNyauwq746BP5HVD3as68BelBC4yDlkydKZgIHrYSmHwC/2Rr96HdrvAF) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
⊞υ¹
```

Start with `1` way to produce `0`.

```
ＦＮ
```

Repeat `n` times.

```
⊞υΣΦυ¬÷⁻⊕ι⊗λχ
```

Get the counts at `n/2`, `n/2-2` ... `n/2-8` and take their sum to produce the next count.

```
Ｉ⊟υ
```

Output the final count.

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <sup><s>42</s> <s>39</s></sup> 37 bytes

```c
f(n){n=n<1?!n:f(n-2)+f(n/=2)-f(n-5);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZBtT4MwEMff71OcJEvogAzKg5sMfWH8FMILUtpJ1LLQJhIJX10sbYeuuV/b@/fu0jsSnAmZZ@ZyNPKCn6KnO/6gvAAjTx37AqNgcVOUT3PLJXzWLXcRjBtQaxHocKFE0ua1ggLGyAesLdGWaYtCS2w5GDA2xKElMySpIcWGLDHcY8MhMRzjKdf/IB0XEshb3e/UTsk77c13nHJ4weVwfFakjg///dix2azrwV1aaXlDB5UW5vZ6AtF@04651ybR3gq7VcnB83Q00sXMYK7DkaqaKeVBlN88CfXEXIluVarUdaI6s/oLuPQqhLnOtoHgEdS@FSVXXUkfhL82LoqCVrbstJnmH8I@6rOYg69f)

*Port of [Arnauld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58563/arnauld)'s [JavaScript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/251976/9481) based on [dingledooper](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/88546/dingledooper)'s [Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/251969/9481)!!!*
*Saved 3 bytes thanks to [jdt](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/41374/jdt)!!!*
*Saved 2 bytes thanks to [alephalpha](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/9288/alephalpha)!!!*

Comment: [39 bytes](https://tio.run/##VZDJboMwEIbveYoRUiQcQAGzNCmFHqo@ReGAjJ2itibCloqKePVSx3ZIY83n5Z9FniHBiZBlYS5HEy94GT2ra4CRp459gVFweabokZdBlM9LxyV8NR13EUwbUOsi0PFMiaTtWw0FTJEPWFuiLdMWhZbYcjBgbIhDS2ZIUkOKDVlieMCGQ2I4xnOu/0F6LiSQ92bYqZ2SDzqY7zjV@Iqr8fiiSB0f/r9jx2azfgD30krHWzqqtDC31ycQ3Q/tmXttEu2tsFuVHDxPRyNdzAzmOhypqplSHkT5nUsoF3MlulepUteJ6sz6FnAeVAhznW0LQQlq34qKq66kD8JfGxdFQWtbdt7Myy9hn81JLMH3Hw) port of Arnauld’s port of dingledooper’s formula :-)

Comment: @jdt Nice one - thanks! :D

Comment: `f(n){n=n<1?!n:f(n-2)+f(n/=2)-f(n-5);}`.

Comment: @alephalpha Wow, amazing - thanks! :D

Comment: Don't you need more than just this snippet for this to be able to compile into a program?

Answer (score 3):

## [Fig](https://github.com/Seggan/Fig), \$10\log_{256}(96)\approx\$ 8.231 bytes

```
IxeBefa_Ob
```

[Try it online!](https://fig.fly.dev/#WyJJeGVCZWZhX09iIiwiMzAiXQ==)

Port of caird's Jelly answer.

Answer (score 3):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), 75 bytes

```
f(n)=∑_{k=0}^{10^N}0^{(n-∑_{j=0}^Nmod(floor(k/10^j),10)2^j)^2}
N=log_2n
```

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/hs4krz2bxb)

[Try It On Desmos! - Prettified](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/rsnx9kdx6b)

We can golf some bytes, but it'll be super slow (it can't calculate values any higher than around \$n=6\$ in a reasonable amount of time.):

#### 66 bytes

```
f(n)=∑_{k=0}^{10^n}0^{(n-∑_{j=0}^nmod(floor(k/10^j),10)2^j)^2}
```

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/qtmuorhscj)

Comment: You can use `n^4` instead of `10^n`. See my PARI/GP answer.

Comment: @alephalpha that’s very interesting, will fix when I get the chance

Answer (score 2):

## [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr), 35 bytes

```
f(n)=if(n<1,!n,sum(i=0,4,f(n\2-i)))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728ILEoMz69YMHiNAXbpaUlaboWN5XTNPI0bTOBpI2hjmKeTnFprkamrYGOiQ5QKMZIN1NTUxOqVCUtv0gjT8FWwVBHwchAR6GgKDOvBCigpKBrByRABsHULlgAoQE)

A port of [@xnor's Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/251967/9288).

---

## [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr), 42 bytes

```
n->sum(i=1,n^4,fromdigits(digits(i),2)==n)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728ILEoMz69YMHiNAXbpaUlaboWN7XydO2KS3M1Mm0NdfLiTHTSivJzUzLTM0uKNaBUpqaOkaatbZ4mVIdKWn6RRp6CrYKhjoKRgY5CQVFmXglQQElB1w5IpGnkaWpC1S5YAKEB)

A port of [@lyxal's Vyxal answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/251970/9288), but uses the upper bound \$n^4\$.

In fact, when \$n>2\$, `fromdigits(digits(n,2),10)` \$\le 10/9\times10^{\log_2 n}=10/9\times(10^{1/\log2})^{\log n}<(10/9\times10^{1/\log2})^{\log n}<(e^4)^{\log n}=n^4\$. It's easy to see that this is also true when \$n=1,2\$.

---

## [HOPS](https://akc.is/hops/), 28 bytes

```
A=1-x^9+x*A+(x-x^11)*A@(x^2)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70kI7-geG20kq5uQVFqsq2ZgVLsgqWlJWm6FnscbQ11K-IstSu0HLU1KoBMQ0NNLUcHjYo4I02IEqjKBVAaAA)

This is not a [sequence](/questions/tagged/sequence) challenge. I cannot use the IO convention for [sequence](/questions/tagged/sequence). But it is still fun to find the generating function. So I won't post this in another answer.

The generating function of this sequence satisfies \$B(x)=(1-x^{10})B(x^2)/(1-x)\$. But we cannot determine the constant term of \$B(x)\$ from this equation.

We know that this constant term is \$1\$. Let \$B(x)=1+x A(x)\$, then we have \$1+x A(x)=(1-x^{10})(1+x^2A(x^2))/(1-x)\$, whence \$A(x)=1-x^9+x A(x)+(x-x^{11})A(x^2)\$.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
bLCI¢
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/ycfZ89Ci//@NDQA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W9s4Opnr6TwqG2SgpK93/8kH2e/Q4v@6/wHAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
b      # Convert the (implicit) input-integer to binary
 L     # Pop and push a list in the range [1,binary(input)]
  C    # Interpret each integer as binary, and convert it to a base-10 integer
   I¢  # Count how many times the input occurs in this list
       # (which is output implicitly as result)
```

Comment: This is crazy haha nice answer

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>40</s> 37 bytes

```ruby
f=->n{n<1?1:(0..n/2).last(5).sum(&f)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/P81W1y6vOs/G0N7QSsNATy9P30hTLyexuETDVFOvuDRXQy1Ns/Z/gYKGoZ6esYGmXm5iAUjoPwA)

Based on xnor's answer.

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 6 bytes

```
Đɓř2Ĩɔ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f//yISTk4/ONDqy4uSU//@NTAE)

Port of [caird coinheringaahing's Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/251966/116013)

```
Đ           implicit input; Đuplicate
 ɓ          convert to ɓinary (automatically casted to decimal number)
  ř         řangify
   2Ĩ       interpret each element of the array as a base-2 Ĩnteger
     ɔ      ɔount occurrences of input in array; implicit print
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-x`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 10 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
ôÂ¢@¶Xì ì2
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LXg&code=9MKiQLZY7CDsMg&input=NQ)