# Find the nth Fibonacci number, where n is the mth Fibonacci number

Tags: code-golf, sequence, integer, fibonacci

## Introduction

If \$\newcommand{\fib}{\operatorname{fib}}\fib(x)\$ calculates the \$x\$th Fibonacci number, write a program that calculates \$\fib(\fib(m))\$ for any integer value of \$m \ge 0\$. (Of course, there will be practical limits based on the language, so lesser limits are acceptable. Also, it's okay to stop at \$m = 20\$, even if the language could in theory go higher.) Any means of calculation is acceptable.

## Challenge

Write a program or function, in as few bytes of code as possible, that for any given positive integer input, will return the same output as function `fibfib` in the following Python code:

```
fibs = [0, 1]

def fib(n):
    global fibs

    while len(fibs) <= n:
        fibs.append(fibs[-2]+fibs[-1])

    return fibs[n]

def fibfib(m):
    return fib(fib(m))
```

You do not have to use the same or a similar algorithm; the output just has to be the same.

## Example Input and Output

```
 0 -> 0
 1 -> 1
 2 -> 1
 3 -> 1
 4 -> 2
 5 -> 5
 6 -> 21
 7 -> 233
 8 -> 10946
 9 -> 5702887
10 -> 139583862445
15 -> 13582369791278266616906284494806735565776939502107183075612628409034209452901850178519363189834336113240870247715060398192490855
20 -> 2830748520089123910580483858371416635589039799264931055963184212634445020086079018041637872120622252063982557328706301303459005111074859708668835997235057986597464525071725304602188798550944801990636013252519592180544890697621702379736904364145383451567271794092434265575963952516814495552014866287925066146604111746132286427763366099070823701231960999082778900856942652714739992501100624268073848195130408142624493359360017288779100735632304697378993693601576392424237031046648841616256886280121701706041023472245110441454188767462151965881127445811201967515874877064214870561018342898886680723603512804423957958661604532164717074727811144463005730472495671982841383477589971334265380252551609901742339991267411205654591146919041221288459213564361584328551168311392854559188581406483969133373117149966787609216717601649280479945969390094007181209247350716203986286873969768059929898595956248809100121519588414840640974326745249183644870057788434433435314212588079846111647264757978488638496210002264248634494476470705896925955356647479826248519714590277208989687591332543300366441720682100553882572881423068040871240744529364994753285394698197549150941495409903556240249341963248712546706577092214891027691024216800435621574526763843189067614401328524418593207300356448205458231691845937301841732387286035331483808072488070914824903717258177064241497963997917653711488021270540044947468023613343312104170163349890
```

Comment: This is [A007570](https://oeis.org/A007570) in the OEIS.

Comment: This isn't a duplicate; the linked question is just `fib(x)`; this is `fib(fib(x))`.

Comment: This *is* a duplicate, because every answer to the linked fibonacci challenge can be trivially modified to give an answer to this challenge (just apply the function twice), and every answer to this challenge can be trivially modified in reverse (just remove the code which applies the function twice). They are not interestingly distinct enough challenges.

Comment: @pxeger I'm not 100% convinced of that. For example, the OEIS page links a paper which gives a direct recurrence for fib(fib(n)). An implementation of that may be competitive because it avoids the overhead of having to set up two separate functions which is significant in some languages.

Comment: I don't agree that it's a duplicate, and don't agree with @pxeger's reasoning.  Answers that output the infinite sequence in the other question can't be easily modified.  And just because an answer can be easily modified, it doesn't follow that it can be easily modified *competitively*.  As @loopy walt points out, declaring a new ```fib(fib(x))``` function can be longer than building a new function, and the likely chance to re-use of some code elements could provide some new golfing opportunities.

Comment: (I've just realised that by "voting" to re-open, I've actually singlehandedly re-opened it, when I really just wanted to vote...)

Answer (score 9):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage), <s>4</s> 3 bytes

```
ÆḞ⁺
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700KzUnp3LBgqWlJWm6FisOtz3cMe9R464lxUnJxVDBJdGGBrFQNgA)

```
ÆḞ⁺
  ⁺ # Twice:
ÆḞ  # Nth fibonacci
```

*-1 byte thanks to Unrelated String*

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 4 bytes

```
ÅfÅf
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//cGsaEP3/b2gAAA)

```
ÅfÅf
Åf   # Nth fibonacci
  Åf # Nth fibonacci
```

## [flax](https://github.com/PyGamer0/flax), 4 bytes

```
;f;f
```

```
;f;f
  ;f # Nth fibonacci
;f   # Nth fibonacci
```

[Try it online!](https://staging.ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70kLSexYsGCpaUlaboWS6zTrNOWFCclF8MEog0NYqFsAA)

## [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 2 bytes

```
FF
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0wuKU3Myan8/9/N7f9/QwMA)

```
FF
F  # Nth fibonacci
 F # Nth fibonacci
```

Comment: The Jelly can be 3: `ÆḞ⁺`

Answer (score 6):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `benchmark.fib3`, 37 bytes

```factor
[ [ 0 ] [ 1 - fib 1 - fib ] if-zero ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYsxDoMwEAR7XrEfAIHoyAOiNGkiKuTisM7CQsbO@VKEzxtXNDPNjCOrUcr8eb2fE1Y@7BZI9s75dUQg3ZCEVf9J/KHI/P3VhDMeTTP08FGpLFjQw1QOaFHH2wbetSdLhCmBErKS3btyAQ)

### Huh?

Factor comes with a suite of benchmarks. One of these is to implement the fibonacci function in seven different ways. *Naturally*, `fib` is the shortest one of these; it has an off-by-one error, it doesn't handle 0 correctly, and it's very slow because it uses the naive recursive algorithm.

Regardless of these problems, fixing them is still shorter than rolling our own. If we were to do so, however, it would only cost 3 more bytes:

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `combinators.extras`, 40 bytes

```factor
[ [ 0 1 rot [ tuck + ] times . ] twice ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY6xbsIwFEX3fMXtjOQkDBToB1RduiAmxPAwz4kVxy@1X5Tw9anb7QxHOseRVUnb9fL1/XnGSNpjSqz6mpKPitzPzgWGlfHhIxU1G141UcbAKXJA5p@Zo@WMj6pqm@2GGxq0SKKFdLYDdrhD/VgU80eLt4z7ZikEmKp6w4UZveqUz3Vt5cmdBGeykh14tT3Fjk3p11Tv983xeKhP76f2ACcJFMHrFKiceYkQh6V/IetTZoXPZV8WHztkGRn/3@goPajj7Rc)

Answer (score 5):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 20 bytes

```
Nest[Fibonacci,#,2]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b73y@1uCTaLTMpPy8xOTlTR1nHKFbtf0BRZl5JdJq@Q1BiXnpqtIGOkUFs7H8A)

Slightly shorter than the naive `Fibonacci@Fibonacci@#&`.

Answer (score 5):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 50 bytes

```r
function(n,s=5^.5,`?`=round)?((r=s/2+.5)^?r^n/s)/s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qflpkERLb/00rzkksy8/M08nSKbU3j9Ex1EuwTbIvyS/NSNO01NIpsi/WNtPVMNePsi@Ly9Is19Yv/FycWFORUahhYGRroQIzR/A8A)

Adapted from [J.Doe's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/177730/95126) to the [Fibonacci function or sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/85/95126).
Based on the closed-form formula for the fibonacci sequence, applied to itself.
The chance to assign the function (`round`) and variable (`s/2+.5`) that will be re-used means that we can re-perform the closed-form calculation on itself for less bytes than a 'trivial' adaption of simply appending a 'do it twice' function `;g=function(n)f(f(n))` (even in [R](https://www.r-project.org/) ≥4.1 where defining a new function can be much golfier using `\` instead of `function` *).

---

Note that a shorter [R](https://www.r-project.org/) solution to the older challenge is [user5957401's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/89653/95126), which can be further golfed-down to <s>25</s> [23 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/r/vyi1IDWxRKE4I79cw81GN0RbI8TWTVPz/38A)**: `repeat show(F<-T+(T=F))`.  However, as a full program, this is less easy to 'do it twice'.
If we re-arrange it into function form (`function(n){while(n<-n-1)T=F+(F=T);T}`), we can exploit the fact that the answer is already assigned to a variable to conditionally return this, or run the function again on this, for <s>60</s> [58 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/qflpkERLb/02zTSvOSSzLz8zTydHJtQzSryzMyc1I18mx083QNNUNs3bQ13IDC1gmZaQkauTppGiE6Bpo6IZq1/4sTCwpyKjUMrSx1IKZp/gcA):
`` f=function(n,m=T){while(n<-n-1)T=F+(F=T);`if`(m,f(T,0),T)} ``.
This is again shorter than simply appending a 'do it twice' function, but longer than the closed-form approach above (although appending a 'do it twice' function wins in [R](https://www.r-project.org/) ≥4.1 *).

Finally, [plannapus's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/66657/95126) (golfed-down by [Robert S.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/81727/robert-s)) used the classic recursive approach.  When adapted to run twice this is only one byte longer than the modified shortest fibonacci answer, with [59 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/qflpkERLb/02zTSvOSSzLz8zTyNBMy0xI08myMdQx10jTydA01tUGUkaamdTqysjQNoLCm5v/ixIKCnEoNAytLnXTN/wA):
`` f=function(n)`if`(n<3,1,f(n-1)+f(n-2));g=function(n)f(f(n)) ``.
Boringly, though, this one *is* just the 'trivial' adaptation of appending `;g=function(n)f(f(n))`.

**Thanks to pajonk for pointing out the golfing differences when using [R](https://www.r-project.org/) ≥4.1*
***23-byte fibonacci function inspired by [Giuseppe's answer here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/247838/95126)*

Comment: Good job analyzing all the approaches! Worth noting, that some of the conclusions may be different in R>=4.1, where defining a function is less costly.

Comment: @pajonk - Ah, that's a very good point.  Indeed, that does change the ranking a bit, although the closed-form-on-itself still wins.  This kind of subtlety is exactly what makes golfing interesting.  Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 5):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <s>49</s> 45 bytes* <sub><sub>*(you can actually score like 14 but that's *boring*)</sub></sub>

*-4 bytes thanks to [ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64121/ovs)!* (also thanks for [this for 33 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70wa8FOJT31NAVbKwV1BR0FAwUrINbVU3AO8nFbWlqSpmtxU7G62rBap1JDW19BT0tfx6paL85K00gBCFWUrcxNK2prYQo1uVKTM_IdNJSsdNQVdO0U1HWUrBzSNBVSE5MzFDL1jAwhChcsgNAA), which uses newer J features!)

```
1{,@f=:{&(2 2 2$#:151x)`(-&2+/ .*&f<:)@.(>&1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcNBCoMwEAXQvaf4xJJk2mR0At0MKoFCV131BAVRWzfdCh4@yuOtxbBb0CscAlroOTIe79ezyB7y3OtufcLpUqvcZaOPjzbdGvDVzp1SZj9YoULVNH7/2RsNDnGAC0bzQqbFj5Ns5QA)  Uses the matrix method mentioned on the OEIS page.

### Explanation

*This applies to the less golfed version, but fundamentally remains the same. I will continue to explain the less golfed version as it is more intuitive what is going on.*

```
f=:{&(2 2 2$#:151x)`(-&2(+/ .*)&f<:)@.(>&1)
1{,@f
```

First, we define a helping verb `f` which recursively computes the matrix. `f` consists of two part: seed generation and recursion calculation. If the input is greater than 1 (`>&1`), then (`@.`) we calculate recursion; otherwise, we call the seed function. As I think it looks nicer by replacing the current `f` with the recursive verb `$:`, I shall explain that version, though they remain functionally equivalent.

```
f=:{&(2 2 2$#:151x)`(-&2(+/ .*)&$:<:)@.(>&1)
   <-----seed-----> <---recursion--->
   <-----seed----->                     if not(input > 1):
   {&(            )                       index the input into the following array
            #:151x                          get the bits of 151 (1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1)
      2 2 2$                                and create a 2x2x2 array
                                          the result is 1 0,:0 1 for 0, and 0 1,:1 1 for 1
                    <---recursion--->   if input > 1:
                    (-&2          <:)     compute input-2 and input-1
                        (     )&$:        call this verb on each, then
                         +/ .*            perform matrix multiplication
```

Since, however, `f` computes a matrix, and we are only interested in one member of that matrix, our actual verb is the last line `1{,@f`, which simply takes the top-right element of the matrix.

## * [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 14 bytes

```
(+/@:!&i.-)^:2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvEW2loKSnoJ6uYGulrqajaa0Xb6jg46ago1BrpWCgAMT/NbT1HawU1TL1dDXjrIz@a3KlJmfkO2goWemoK@jaKajrKFk5pGsqGShk6hkZVvwHAA)

Of course, the first highlighted method is *much* longer than taking the trivial approach of modifying [the existing shortest Fibonacci in J](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/87107/31957) thanks to [@miles](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/6710/miles) and applying it twice. While this approach is about ~30x slower than the first, it's the length which matters. Nonetheless, I consider it trivial, which is why it is not the most-featured solution in my answer.

Comment: You don't need the parentheses around the matrix multiplication and you can actually inline the definition of `f`

Comment: Nice to see someone use the matrix method--now to wait until there's a language where it might maybe be the shortest

Comment: [33](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70wa8FOJT31NAVbKwV1BR0FAwUrINbVU3AO8nFbWlqSpmtxU7G62rBap1JDW19BT0tfx6paL85K00gBCFWUrcxNK2prYQo1uVKTM_IdNJSsdNQVdO0U1HWUrBzSNBVSE5MzFDL1jAwhChcsgNAA) with `^:` instead of recursion, requires newer J than on TIO for the direct definition. Maybe a tacit version would be shorter.

Comment: @ovs ah, right, the matrix multiplication is parsed with higher preference. good note about the inlining! i don't think i knew it was parsed like that. and... that new version of J looks like wizardry lol, i don't understand what's even going on in that one

Answer (score 4):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 24 bytes

The single-Fibonacci part was borrowed from [R. Martinho Fernandes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/85/fibonacci-function-or-sequence#comment110_89).

```hs
map(f!!)f
f=0:scanl(+)1f
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyfmfrmCrEPM/N7FAI01RUTONK83WwKo4OTEvR0Nb0zANKJGZB1RRUJSZV6KgolCSmJ2qYGigkP7/X3JaTmJ68X/dCOeAAAA)

Answer (score 4):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 115 bytes

```
f=n=>n<4?n+3n>>2n:(f(--n)**2n-(u=-1n)**(F=y=>y<2?y:F(--y)+F(--y))(n-=2n)*f(--n)*f(n+=3n)-u**F(--n)*f(--n)**2n)/f(n)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=TU-7DoJAEOz5igvVLZfzcVgYYKGSL7C0E84QcC8RKC7GL7Gh0I_ybzwFEqqZ7OzM7D5fZIpyGN59p-X-02okTCnZZSRCSlNFEddcSoIgUCR5j3L74zxHi6lNVGaj3OkWxAjASaJyK5NLcxIYEsg-CPJ5NOfB2skwVddnQ61pylVXXUvun-hoTO1D7GlzY7wpO1YxZBuKHSbI1J8JAezuMTZ7G3Nx91bgbA9vGXigYpE5Vs5ffwE) (includes benchmark)

Way longer than Radvylf's, but is way, way, faster. [ATO for Radvylf's with benchmark, which times out](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70kLz8ldcGidNulpSVpuhY3lSts7TTSbCtt7SptjOwrrdI0KnUNNbVBlJGmpkaaRoWmJlRpZnJ-XnF-TqpeSWZuqoZSTF5Ifn62kqY1V1p-kYJGTmqJQqaCrYKBNZCysVUwAjG0tTUVqrkUFGA6c_LTNdI1MjWBmmq5kI1zzUtBMhFi4YIFEBoA).

Formula found at [this paper](https://codehappy.net/fibo.pdf).

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 131 bytes

```
f=lambda n:n>3and(f(n-1)**2-(-1)**F(n-3)*f(n-4)*f(n-1)-(-1)**F(n-2)*f(n-3)**2)//f(n-3)or n+3>>2
F=lambda y:y>1and F(y-1)+F(y-2)or y
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3m9NscxJzk1ISFfKs8uyME_NSNNI08nQNNbW0jHQ1wLQbkG-sqQUSNoFQhppIUkYQMWOQDk19fQg7v0ghT9vYzs6Iyw1mfqVVpZ0h0HwFN41KoGZtEGUEUlgJdYpCdEFRZl4JyH5NTYU0kBEKmXkKRYl56akaRoaasRB1MKcDAA)

Same concept.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python](https://www.python.org) NumPy, 66 bytes

```
lambda n:ptp(x**ptp(x**n))
from numpy import*
x=mat("1 1;1 0","O")
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY3nXISc5NSEhXyrApKCjQqtLSgVJ6mJldaUX6uQl5pbkGlQmZuQX5RiRZXhW1uYomGkqGCobWhgoGSjpK_kibUJMW0_CKFPIXMPIWixLz0VA1DHSNDTauCosy8Eo00DaB5ChCFCxZAaAA)

While this isn't really competitive (the `numpy import` is just too expensive, as is setting up the auxiliary matrix) I thought this is interesting. Perhaps it can be ported to one of the other matrix languages.

How?

The standard recurrence `a,b <---| a+b,a` can be conveniently expressed by the matrix \$ M = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \$. Doing n iterations then is as easy as taking the n-th power: $$ M^n = \begin{pmatrix} F_{n+1} & F_n \\ F_n & F_{n-1} \end{pmatrix} $$

Thus we could simply do `(x**(x**n)[0,1])[0,1]`. We save a few bytes using `ptp` instead which in turn uses that `F_n = F_n+1 - F_n-1`. (Note that this incorrectly returns 1 for input `0` because `F_-1` breaks the pattern `F_n <= F_n+1`, so ptp does not pick the right elements in that case.).

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 5 bytes

```
2(‹∆f
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCIyKOKAueKIhmYiLCIiLCIyMCJd)

### How?

```
2(‹∆f
2(    # Execute twice:
  ‹   # Decrement to make this 0-indexed
   ∆f # Nth fibonacci number
```

Comment: Oh interesting, Vyxal's `∆f` is `1, 1, 2, 3, 5, ...`?

Comment: @RadvylfPrograms Yep. Idk why.

Answer (score 3):

## [SageMath](https://www.sagemath.org/), 28 bytes

```python
lambda n,f=fibonacci:f(f(n))
```

[Try it online!](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxFld1uG0cMhe8N-B32zjKwBcjh8GcCuC_S9CJRpNRo6xi2ChQ1_O79qDSobcja-SEPzznkfn34eHvzx6c_P3_5tD3t54fz4-dvT5-Ox8cP58P58HR_f3tze3M5vV5et4ftIPum-zb2zfZt7pvvW-xb7lvt22Krt1kbwq3T38-n4-X05f9r-uNyH-lvZn1nTWJ4yqgiktrysooxp_eT17BYuXRkjYjQWBKj5lyzJNLcwzNjcU2GSmqZpIeOPiRLbA4y-Fii5aJZrsvCtFbZNAtVG1OK9DNTXUJsla4xl5Q30I43y4dIAcKWipdMIAIzdWoEGIpEgFwj5jJO-OoUcwDDJpVIXw_JRiHcsaxkk0rGIHSQc7inDYCEiRq4fYm4ql7Tr-R-VJmvlcNcPFcFyzMozqk7h5vMgAR4XGCnbCjSBV8WhCQRtfvigDhbrK-MoZRuuRKWZVpMnW5Q4-qRg7ALFseExgBg17U6TpQigTvgdYIM4AsY6DMjqFAVZOQcFXOgD0yHAIUyyCYQqasXYJltsMB2rE5CzpnGDuEoHopYLUmriS4ONcilrOGQZfBBceja7sElwkEPG00FNRGZ_T6iDggK4Zf8aATOWYUWGsNhlhKABRv8dQWwMnMMiOBsszKb2KCsofAYXqWYEnH7PzxHwlkhVhIA6fkiGBHFIQ-7VQsoiIfFXMk2gbLQ0attLfA-NCaUozjUExaOJ3ZAbOpJPIkmilWA3RplYryVald1rKQlRpsmGv7pL2jEgjkbIY2Cp4gZS5FaBwaEgDYElCE96CcOJALyGo2xeJh4mcIpclJV2eK2mSX7CLVWBFYmI9BBDs90QNdGMxC6-1IwonRjggEB0IeHGN1ncB6VHTOhBmuPBVGOSR15q6QF1Svf3lrNahCC662rchiB3ZhNNSQlZ2g36DA37e7jFk1XWFGbWtozITyxUgWGWmgpIoN10nWr0jPJIXwKtYEH8TjssERF1abrAULldCfGHQwFzhWNASvDyS2C1TEMe1EdngBFd7dDwWSstoNTGTvtnoE74RFgzb0xDXv-pFNatzAc-2xBe9JxhZJtYjamVsfwGbiN0qG2LQdhg2nIJ-WTiZb2NmyTFdk19-hjcNKos4cCkw2wcG6D1gG8N524ZfbkZdpqWwS98TFF0VlMrmoLGxQzBqU93VoBgYUenHadRqXfG6FLyJ4bPcUTnyYe5DzywDLWaNZpK1bwYItnSI5BaUXmxoTgfp8cfzsdfz-99Ovk7uNfNN7xbt-u39Tu2D9_e9ku-2l7fNr-eXw-XF9Z-_bjLXT_4fZm46ffYl8Pl_vvT88vj0-Xw_nu7fK-_fTz9vb6vr39l-eX08PD66_vd_f_AgOOgoU=&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==)

Answer (score 3):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 4 bytes

```
‼!İf
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//1HDHsUjG9L@//9vDgA)

```
‼     # twice = apply function twice:
 !    #   index = value at index (of input) of
  İ   #   infinite sequence of
   f  #   fiboncci numbers
```

Answer (score 3):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf), 2 bytes

```
ff
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/z8NiA0NAA)

```
ff
f  # Nth fibonacci
 f # Nth fibonacci
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 15 bytes

```
#@*#&@Fibonacci
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7X9lBS1nNwS0zKT8vMTk5839AUWZeSbSyrl2ag3KsWl1wcmJeXVBiXnpqtIGOkUHsfwA)

```
      Fibonacci     fib
#@*#&@                fib ∘ fib (composition)
```

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (Node.js), 35 bytes

```
x=>(f=y=>y<2?y:f(--y)+f(--y))(f(x))
```

Simple recursive solution (now intended for use with bigints, thanks to Steffan for pointing out that's necessary).

Comment: You probably need to use BigInts, because JS can't reliably handle numbers over 2**53-1. It actually times out for n >= 10, though. My solution, which doesn't time out, needed BigInts to not show `NaN` and `Infinity`.

Comment: it doesn't even cost bytes to change to bigint, just change `y-1` and `y-2` both to `--y`

Comment: @Steffan Done, thanks!

Comment: And all without a single bigint literal. *claps*. Even though you shouldn't need them, because you'd hit the recursion limit *waayyy* before hitting problems with int precision.

Comment: @emanresuA = ```fib(20)``` is 6765, so you need a recursive depth of 6765 to calculate ```fib(fib(20))``` (which I assume is comfortably beyond int precision).  Surely JavaScript has (or can be set to have) a recursion depth limit higher than that?

Comment: @DominicvanEssen It's browser dependent, and varies a lot, but on Chrome it's around 14k it seems (at least, for me. It could very well change based on the memory of the device, the OS, some sort of flag, etc.).

Comment: [TIO Node.js recursion limit is about 14k as well](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/09aAK822wtZOI1NbWydNo0JTk4urpKhSoZpLQSFNw1iTq1YhObEkOUNBI14TLJicn1ecn5Oql5OfrpEJlP7/HwA "JavaScript (Node.js) – Try It Online"), and V8 is very close to that. [And in V8, you can set the `--stack-size` parameter.](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/j/P9PWgCvNtsLWTiNTW1snTaNCU5OLq6SoUqGaS0EhTcNYk6tWITmxJDlDQSNeEyyYnJ9XnJ@TqpeTn66RCZT@//@/rm5xSWJytm5xZlWqrYmBpRkA "JavaScript (V8) – Try It Online") (but it segfaults if you set it too high)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 47 bytes

```
from sympy import*
lambda n,g=fibonacci:g(g(n))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3DdOK8nMViitzCyoVMnML8otKtLjSbHMSc5NSEhXydNJt0zKT8vMSk5MzrdI10jXyNDUhGlcXFGXmlWikaVjCRGBGAgA)

Without builtin:

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 52 bytes

```
lambda n:g(g(n))
g=lambda y:y>1and g(y-1)+g(y-2)or y
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY3TXISc5NSEhXyrNI10jXyNDW50m2hQpVWlXaGiXkpCukalbqGmtogykgzv0ihEqJ3dUFRZl6JRpqGpaYmRGTBAggNAA)

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 39 bytes

```
->n{(g=->y{y>1?g[y-1]+g[y-2]:y})[g[n]]}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsHiNNuYpaUlaboWN9V17fKqNdJtde0qqyvtDO3Toyt1DWO1QZRRrFVlrWZ0enRebGwtRPmyAoW0aMtYCGfBAggNAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/) with `-lgmp` and `-m32`, <s>266</s> <s>265</s> <s>259</s> 241 bytes

- -1 thanks to ceilingcat
- -6 thanks to MackTuesday

As no native type supports `f(f(20))`, I used GMP for the math. Uses iteration to compute the Fibonacci sequence.

```c
#import<gmp.h>
#define q mpz_set
f(i,r){mpz_t k,l,s,t;for(mpz_inits(k,l,s,t,0);mpz_cmp(k,i)<1;mpz_add_ui(k,k,1))mpz_cmp_ui(k,1)>0?mpz_add(l,s,t),q(s,t),q(t,l):q(mpz_get_ui(k)?t:s,k);q(r,t);}g(i,r){mpz_t a;mpz_init_set_ui(a,i);f(a,r);f(r,r);}
```

Unfortunately, TIO doesn't have the 32-bit version of GMP installed so it's 259 bytes in 64-bit mode:

```c
#import<gmp.h>
#define q mpz_set
f(i,r)mpz_t i,r;{mpz_t k,l,s,t;for(mpz_inits(k,l,s,t,0);mpz_cmp(k,i)<1;mpz_add_ui(k,k,1))mpz_cmp_ui(k,1)>0?mpz_add(l,s,t),q(s,t),q(t,l):q(mpz_get_ui(k)?t:s,k);q(r,t);}g(i,r)mpz_t r;{mpz_t a;mpz_init_set_ui(a,i);f(a,r);f(r,r);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZDdasMwDIXv8xSipWBTZyS7rNP0PcaghCT2RP5tt4OVvPoyOfFGd2PJH0dHxy5jXZbLssduHIzLdDe@fOTRvqoV9jVM0I1fV1u7SDEUhvubA@rkY2sb0QornFSDYZ5gj86yQEXCpYdlNxJCnqXrtaiq6w2JNCLlPAg2kvI8uQQNWz24mFgoTrT8NK1rdO3WAX5xJysaLidmSCRn/RTzL2Qhf6P5p/jBgtJIRcX4YnyZF@wddAX27D5gxeERAXiEkprgWNtb62QUgHdkG@Ne5D8Bz4kEzF5TOo/HzQXAx4InJRF68mjIX7GdZgfad87h8Fa99zsB/8VzNC/fpWoLbZe4pcEl/vwB)

Ungolfed (without GMP, assuming `int` is big enough):

```c
int f(int i) {
  int j[2]={0}, k=0, l;

  for(; k<i+1; k++)
    if(k<2) j[k]=k;
    else {
      l=j[0]+j[1];
      j[0]=j[1];
      j[1]=l;
    }

  return j[1];
}

int g(int i) { return f(f(i)); }
```

Comment: You can shave off a few more bytes with "#define q mpz_set" and the appropriate substitutions.

Answer (score 2):

### Batch, 123 bytes

```
@set/af=h=0,g=i=1
@for /l %%a in (1,1,%1)do @set/aj=h+i,h=i,i=j
@for /l %%a in (1,1,%h%)do @set/ah=f+g,f=g,g=h
@echo %f%
```

Explanation: Regular Batch variable expansion with `%` happens before the line is parsed, so the `%h%` has to be on a separate line to the code that sets `h`, but `set/a` is a special case and can access the current value of variables so works fine inside a loop.

Answer (score 2):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), <s>49</s> 45 bytes

```
pp-p~1
f(n)=(p^n-(1-p)^n)/5^{.5}
g(n)=f(f(n))
```

Just applies [Binet's Formula](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Binet%27s_Formula) twice. Did not include the last two test cases as the output is too large for Desmos to handle.

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/h1huhh1zkb)

[Try It On Desmos! - Prettified](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/56vslsycqe)

Answer (score 2):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 32 bytes

```matlab
@(n,m=[1 1;1 0])(m^(m^n)(2))(2);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mq6en999BI08n1zbaUMHQ2lDBIFZTIzcOiPI0NYw0Qdj6f1p@kUKWgq2CgZWhIZdCQVFmXkmahpJqioKSTppGlqYmV2peClDNfwA)

Port of my Python answer.

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 42 bytes

```
.+
$*
+`11(1*)
1$1,$1
,

+`11(1*)
1$1,$1
1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P9fT5tLRYtLO8HQUMNQS5PLUMVQR8WQS4cLQ8jw/39zAA) Note: Very slow, so will probably time out on TIO for inputs more than `8`. Explanation: Based on my Retina 0.8.2 answer to [Fibonacci function or sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/85).

```
.+
$*
```

Convert to unary.

```
+`11(1*)
1$1,$1
```

Recursively replace `n` with `n-1` and `n-2`, until each unary integer has been replaced down to `1` and `0`.

```
,
```

Sum the `1`s in unary, resulting in the Fibonacci of the input.

```
+`11(1*)
1$1,$1
```

Calculate the Fibonacci of the Fibonacci.

```
1
```

Sum and convert to decimal.

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 41 bytes

```
2{K`0,1
"$-1"+`\d+,(\d+)
$1,$.(*_$1*
,.+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPyvquGe8N@o2jvBQMeQS0lF11BJOyEmRVtHA0hocqkY6qjoaWjFqxhqcenoaXP9/2/AZchlxGXMZcJlymXGZc5lwWXJZQgUNOUyMgAA) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
2{
```

Repeat the whole program twice.

```
K`0,1
```

Replace the input with the two integers `0` and `1`.

```
"$-1"+`
```

Repeat the number of times given by the stage before the previous stage. On the first iteration this is the input, while on the second it is the result of the first loop.

```
\d+,(\d+)
$1,$.(*_$1*
```

Replace the first integer with the second and the second with their sum.

```
,.+
```

Delete the second integer.

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 27 bytes

```
ＮθＦ²«≔Ｅ²κυＦθ≔⟦⌈υΣυ⟧υ≔⌊υθ»Ｉθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/98zr6C0xK80Nym1SKNQ05orLb9IQcNIU6Gai9OxuDgzPU/DN7FAw0hHIVtTR6EUqIATrKJQUwEqHe2bWJGZW5qrUQpUEAymY6EqYQZk5sEVgKyo5Qooyswr0XBOLC4BGqT5/7/5f92yHAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explantion:

```
Ｎθ
```

Input `n`.

```
Ｆ²«
```

Repeat twice.

```
≔Ｅ²κυ
```

Start with the two integers `0` and `1`.

```
Ｆθ
```

Repeat `n` times.

```
≔⟦⌈υΣυ⟧υ
```

Replace the first integer with the second and the second with their sum.

```
≔⌊υθ
```

Save the first integer for the next pass or the result.

```
»Ｉθ
```

Output the result.

Although the above code calculates the result quickly enough for inputs of `n` up to about `20`, here is a 42-byte version which is fast even for large values of `n`:

```
≔⮌Ｅ²Ｅ³¬⁼ιλυＦＮ⊞υＥ³ΣＥ²ΠＥ…⮌υ²§ξ⁺ν⊘⁺λπＩ§§υ±²¦¹
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PU7LCoMwELz7FTluID3U0pMnkUI9VKT9glS3KsQkTbJivz5VQQeWYWDn0fTSNUaqGHPvh07DEyd0HuEhLaSCrXQRrDIBbl@SysMgmOIrBCOeJR/jGJTaUqhofKMDzllNvgc6zC8a97jamZaasMni1ygsemOPTloy0@XyUOoWZ5gXgyIPWrC7VBO2sEklmOUHsqR2gw5QSB9gd@68jKiwkwEhXQef1/8Y02s8TeoP) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
≔⮌Ｅ²Ｅ³¬⁼ιλυ
```

Start with \$ ((F_{F_0-1}, F_{F_0}, F_{F_0+1}), (F_{F_1-1}, F_{F_1}, F_{F_1+1})) \$ which is `[[1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1]]`.

```
ＦＮ
```

Repeat `n` times.

```
⊞υＥ³ΣＥ²ΠＥ…⮌υ²§ξ⁺ν⊘⁺λπ
```

Calculate \$ (F_{F_{i+2}-1}, F_{F_{i+2}}, F_{F_{i+2}+1}) \$ from the previous terms. There are a number of ways of doing this e.g. \$ F_{F_{i+2}-1} = F_{F_i-1}F_{F_{i+1}-1} + F_{F_i}F_{F_{i+1}} \$.

```
Ｉ§§υ±²¦¹
```

Output the middle term of the penultimate result which is \$ F_{F_n} \$ as desired.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 5 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
MgMgU
```

[Try it here](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=TWdNZ1U&input=OA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Raku](http://raku.org/), 27 bytes

```
[o] {(0,1,*+*...*)[$_]}xx 2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFBCoAgEAXQq3xEQk2GMahN1EUipEWuisI2SXX26b1zzVsne0GVMMh0zHgM@@Bd7YjI2UnH@btvNNLjWgqUjhhGPAk6fgrpyHgNEwW2HqH1aFh@)

- `0, 1, *+* ... *` is the lazy, infinite Fibonacci sequence.
- `[$_]` looks up a number in the sequence by its index.
- `{ ... }` wraps the lookup in an anonymous function.
- `xx 2` replicates that function twice, producing a list of two elements.
- `[o]` reduces that list with function composition.

Answer (score 0):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 38 bytes

```
2>01@@:}@{?vrn;
:v? (1}-1:{<+@
-\{~~$1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/38jOwNDBwarWodq@rCjPmsuqzF5Bw7BW19Cq2kbbgUs3prquTsXw////umXmAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [J-uby](https://github.com/cyoce/J-uby), 13 bytes

```ruby
(:++[0,1])**2
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700K740qXLBIjfbpaUlaboWazWstLWjDXQMYzW1tIwgYssKFNyiLWIhnAULIDQA)

### Explanation

This is the standard J-uby Fibonacci function, `:+ + [0,1]` (start an array with `[0,1]` and apply `:+` (sum) to its last two items \$n\$ times), iterated on twice, i.e. `F**2`.

Answer (score 0):

## Excel, 66 bytes

```
=LET(q,SQRT(5),f,ROUND((.5+q/2)^ROW(A:A)/q,),INDEX(f,INDEX(f,A1)))
```

<sup>Note: Excel will add a leading zero to `.5` to make it `0.5` when the formula is entered.</sup>

The main portion of this is generating the Fibonacci sequence (or at least the first 1,474 terms (after that Excel can't handle numbers that large (which also limits to input to values ≤ 16))). That's what this part does:

```
q,SQRT(5),f,ROUND((0.5+q/2)^ROW(A:A)/q,)
```

After that, we use `INDEX(f,INDEX(f,n))` as the equivalent  to `fib(fib(n))`.

[image: Screenshot]