# Previous Fibonacci number

Tags: code-golf, number, fibonacci

The sequence of Fibonacci numbers is defined as follows:

\$
F_0 = 0 \\
F_1 = 1 \\
F_n = F_{n-1} + F_{n-2}
\$

Given a Fibonacci number, return the previous Fibonacci number in the sequence. You do not need to handle the inputs \$ 0 \$ or \$ 1 \$, nor any non-Fibonacci numbers.

Errors as a result of floating point inaccuracies are permitted.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins.

Answer (score 19):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 4 bytes

```
kg/ṙ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJrZy/huZkiLCIiLCIyIl0=)

Port of Unmitigated's JavaScript answer

```
  /  # Divide by...
kg   # Phi
   ṙ # Round
```

Answer (score 15):

## JavaScript, <s>21</s> 17 bytes

```js
n=>n*5**.5-n+1>>1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/ifZvs/z9YuT8tUS0vPVDdP29DOzvB/QVFmXolGmoaRpiYXjG2MxDZFYlsgsQ2RFRkZIus2QdaOot8S2QAToLr/AA)

-4 bytes thanks to [att](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/81203).

Comment: [17 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/ifZvs/z9YuT8tUS0vPVDdP29DOzvB/QVFmXolGmoaRpiYXjG2MxDZFYlsgsQ2RFRkZIus2QdaOot8S2QAToLr/AA)

Answer (score 13):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), <s>23</s> <s>22</s> 20 bytes

*Edit: -1 byte thanks to pajonk, then -2 bytes thanks to att*

```
\(x)(x*5^.5-x+1)%/%2
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMHqgqLUsvi0zCQFG92lpSVpuhZbYjQqNDUqtEzj9Ex1K7QNNVX1VY0gUjc1YKo1kjWMdIx1THUsdAyNdYwMdYxNdEyBPEsdQxMTTU0uiPoFCyA0AA)

The ratio between consecutive fibonacci numbers famously converges towards [the golden ratio phi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio), equal to `(1+5^.5)/2`.
This is sufficiently accurate that rounding produces the correct value for all fibonacci numbers, including even the second `1` at the start which we don't need to handle here.

(Edit after reading some other answers: this was independently-derived, but is also the approach taken by [Luis Mendo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/247844/95126) and [unmitigated](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/247840/95126))

Comment: Shouldn't this possibly work for [-1 byte](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMHqgqLUsvi0zCQFG92lpSVpuhbbYjQqNDUqtDRM4_RMdQ01tQ01VfVVjSCSNzVg6jWSNYx0jHVMdSx0DI11jAx1jE10TIE8Sx1DExNNTS6I-gULIDQA)?

Comment: @pajonk - Thanks - yes!  Somehow whenever I'd tried something like that, it always came out longer (probably because I was adding ```.5``` instead of your clever way to add ```1```)...

Comment: [20](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMHqgqLUsvi0zCQFG92lpSVpuhZbYjQqNDUqtEzj9Ex1K7QNNVX1VY0gUjc1YKo1kjWMdIx1THUsdAyNdYwMdYxNdEyBPEsdQxMTTU0uiPoFCyA0AA)

Comment: @att - lovely, thanks!  Whenever I look at something like this I think 'Doh!  Why didn't I think of that...?'

Answer (score 11):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), 27 bytes

```r
\(x){while(x>T)T=F+(F=T);F}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMHqgqLUsvi0zCQFG92lpSVpuha7YzQqNKvLMzJzUjUq7EI0Q2zdtDXcbEM0rd1qISrWwvRoGBprckHEFiyA0AA)

Similar to [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/247836/67312), iterates through the Fibonacci sequence until `T==x` and returns `F`.

Comment: Realised that this is the shortest R fibonacci function (with ```F```>```T```) and have cited it [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/89653/95126) and [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/247637/95126)...

Comment: @DominicvanEssen odd, I really thought I had seen this approach somewhere before but can't seem to track it down.

Comment: You might want to post it directly into the [fibonacci challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/85/fibonacci-function-or-sequence) (as [suggested](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/85/fibonacci-function-or-sequence/89653?noredirect=1#comment554792_89653) by the author of the otherwise-shortest-but-actually-rather-longer answer...)

Comment: @DominicvanEssen [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/248102/67312)!

Answer (score 11):

## x86-64 assembly, <s>13</s> 12 bytes

```
6a 01 58 99 92 01 c2 39 fa 75 f9 c3
```

In assembly:

```
previous:
    push 1
    pop rax
    cdq     # zeroes rdx
previous_loop:
    xchg eax,edx
    add edx,eax
    cmp edx,edi
    jne previous_loop
    ret
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVHRbtswDHw2v4JoMOwlMeqkW9sA3cuA/cQ2GIxFO@pkyZPkxP76jLaStClmwDZF3h1PJIXA7c6Mq6aqTgtKJw543FPkA3vUAbXF704xBq6idhbJKnR97PqIw6Cwdr6lCAvlONjPEY/O/0FdYzVxhG7INyIU92Sx0x3jrq9r9rDYiYAICmGinRUFFrHtq720GY80Qq5tZFOG0UYa0LrOc60HyBVFghDJx/Jse9yepHjQrg9bQHm6PuyxSKHr0NMwx5X6CxdgaZzrEnqo9g0yDUtWCUdKocRLvvDaLp2Vns@vlvFGZ856jie26s0UXKLSsH15X1rd2gcIFdm6DNFr22why1OEd5/6X/ZOPMso/l/Gl2@YQNLjioCatOk9ly2HQA1v4Ur5IRVW@cT4AJpdYo4r/FAAyCMPUX6NcTsy2JK2MH3ES@h36EO3fJoT56lmrTtIVi@lAplhQq/08uf7W/6GrCJjcM5BFjnEtAOZefZqGGVeSYcnqghdGJfJQ3azuIQNV@y168303kSmpHSS1V6Ng/QU89P605WyaacFrGFdwOYBigd5nzZfN0XxfL9BWD8/Fuviy/3j5h8)

Uses the usual calling convention of taking the first argument in `rdi` and returning in `rax`. It's also valid x86-32, just with `edi` and `eax` instead.

It's pretty simple- it just explicitly computes Fibonacci numbers and returns if the new number is equal to the input. At the end of a loop, `rdx` contains the next Fibonacci number and `rax` contains the previous. If `rdx` is equal to the input `rdi`, then the loop terminates (and thus `rax`, the previous number, is returned). Otherwise the two are swapped, and the loop begins again.

This uses 32-bit registers to save a few bytes, so it only works up to the 47th Fibonacci number, `2971215073`. It can be expanded to work with 64-bit numbers by changing all the registers to 64-bit, at the cost of 2 bytes:

```
6a 01 58 99 48 0f c1 c2 48 39 fa 75 f7 c3
```

The added bytes are the REX.W (`0x48`) prefix that swaps the operand size to 64-bit. `xchg rax,rdx; add rdx,rax` is also replaced with `xadd rdx,rax`, which is shorter because it uses one fewer REX.W prefix.

-1 byte thanks to [@PeterCordes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/30206/peter-cordes).

Comment: If we start with EAX=1 we can `cdq` for EDX=0 in 1 byte.  That should enable savings even without changing the calling convention, e.g. xchg after add?  If necessary, [`xadd`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/xadd) can exchange-and-add between any two registers in one more byte than `add`.  But with EAX involved it's the same size as `xchg eax, reg` / `add`.  It's faster; only 3 uops on Intel or 2 on AMD, same as xchg, one less than xchg+add.  And lower latency.  (https://uops.info/).

Comment: @PeterCordes Good call. Swapping the two just adds one extra loop, since the first loop becomes effectively a no-op of `add edx,0`. It changes the output for an input of `1` to `0` instead of `1`, but those are both equally valid.

Answer (score 9):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `math.unicode`, <s>21</s> <s>19</s> <s>18</s> 14 bytes

```factor
[ φ / round ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0tMLskv@h8a7OnnbqWQm1iSoVBQlFpSUllQlJlXopCdWpSXmgMW10vOzysuScwrKYZwS/Myk/NTUiGctNK85JJMoAIFay4uE0MLQ67/0Qrn2xT0FYryS/NSFGL/Jyfm5Cjo/QcA)

-4 thanks to @DominicvanEssen!

Divide the input by the golden ratio and round the result.

Comment: Interesting fact: 1-phi (the golden ratio) is equal to 1/phi.  So you can just [divide by the golden ratio](https://tio.run/##JcgxDkAwFAbgvaf4T0AkBuEAYrGISQxNVTTqtXmewelLGL9v1UYCp3Ho@rbGoWVDZCtyR3Yk2C2T9d9nJtApmuT8uV5kxL2HRqmyqAqVJsTNIQeHixbMyWjvkaUH) instead of multiplying by phi-1...

Comment: Does Factor need the whitespace? If not you could save a few bytes

Answer (score 9):

## [C(gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/c99status.html), <s>57,55,53,50,45</s>, 36 bytes

```c
x;y;f(a){for(x=y=1;y-a-x;y+=x=y-x);}
```

Naive approach based on calculating all previous Fibonacci numbers, breaking when we reach the input.

[Try it here](https://tio.run/##dczBCgIhGATgu08hG4GyGbkRBH/2JF1E1xJKw3VDWfbZzUu3nNvMB6PYXalSEmQwRNLF@ECSyIJDZpLVuRe1skRhLRvr1HPW42WK2vr944qsi/glrSMfbzVdEK55h7oa0m31zXU7QwZK4S8cW3BqwbkFvPk18J@EMc7B4QOgtXwB)

Edit:  Thanks for Neil, golfing <s>2</s> 5 bytes.

Edit2: Thanks Dominic van Essen for golfing an other 5 bytes.

Edit3: Thanks att for golfing 9 bytes.

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice answer!

Comment: You already have the previous number, so you can just use `y-a` as the condition and return `x`, saving 2 bytes, but you can also use globals and `for` to save a few more bytes: `x;y;c;f(a){for(x=y=1;y-a;c=y,y=x+y,x=c);return x;}`.

Comment: [45 bytes](https://tio.run/##dczRCsIgGIbh812FLAIlF7kIgj@7kk7kd5bQNMyFMnbttpPO8jt8H/iwuyOWkiADgqGKzcYHmmSWAnKnAGXmWaZd5kkigyQTLGVjHT4nPVzeUVu/f1wb6yIZlXX0461mc0PWvcJaDW23@uZabmjPGPyFYw1ONTjXQFS/evGTMMQpOHKAZilf) with a rather hacky return trick...

Comment: [36 bytes](https://tio.run/##dczBCgIhGATgu08hG4GyGbkRBH/2JF1E1xJKw3VDWfbZzUu3nNvMB6PYXalSEmQwRNLF@ECSyIJDZpLVuRe1skRhLRvr1HPW42WK2vr944qsi/glrSMfbzVdEK55h7oa0m31zXU7QwZK4S8cW3BqwbkFvPk18J@EMc7B4QOgtXwB)

Answer (score 8):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 41 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,a=0,b=1:n-b and f(n,b,a+b)or a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##xVBBboQwDLzzCt8A1SvhBBKyUvqRtocAQYvaZhGkUlvE26mD2jc0h2Q89owdz1/xdg/yOEb75t67wUFAZyvsLF3DpQMXBhiLgB26h668L@CO6Ne4goVCIEiEBqFFIEaCmKiZSZRhruZASM5IrREUVQimZUSN4Vs0LedralmmtGIRVaZW/GhNzIlWNVxWK6m4gW4qkUoEScOOZBQr2Zl0S1Rm/nP2ffRDmitp/320Mutvvn/1S5oof/4Quu5zhBORzMts5GVG9DAF@J7m4twqwt8/ymsGfNKexyKWZzAvU4jFmG9xh8sjbOsO22@TJ2/t@rKz7fED)

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>29</s> <s>28</s> <s>27</s> 24 bytes

*The footer uses [@Noodle9's checker code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/247843/36398)*.

*1 byte saved thanks to [@Chris](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58834/chris)!*

*3 more bytes off thanks to [Albert.Lang](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/101374/albert-lang)!*

Function that returns an integer-valued `float`. It fails for large inputs due to floating-point inaccuracies.

```python
lambda n:~n*(1-5**.5)//2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY1BDoIwEEXXcorZ0WJRWzQmJPUiyAJhEKLWhtYEJXh1rFVXzupN5s9/@m6bq0qmWu6nc3E5VAWo9KkiwuNNFC02dLkUk0VjjcwES/IAe42lxUpmnIk8qK8d9NAq6Ap1RCIYX61oGsx@sUWhNaqK@Ios5jkNZp7/DvMvCRcpGyxP2IEEEu5vYrsuQwaeeBJSL7UM39pHqz8VDH5Kpwc3xn3XxFK/6K5VltThYEeIdzCYEYavJEMpTT662ukF)

Comment: 27 bytes, [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY1BDoIwEEXXcorZ0UJVWiQmJvUiyAJhEKLWhtZEJZwda8WVs3qT@fOfftr2ptKpkYfpUl6PdQlqR0SkYk7Xa8LjLIpWGZ0sGmtkLlhaBPjQWFmsZc6ZKILm1sMDOgV9qU5IBONJQnfB4hdblVqjqomvyJe8oMHC898hnkm4SNVidcYeJJDwcBfbTRUy8MTTkHqpZfjRvjr9rWDwUzo9uDHuuyGW@kX3nbKkCQc7wnIPgxlhmCU5SmmK0dVObw "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: `~n*(1-5**.5)//2` seems to work just as well.

Comment: `lambda n:round(n/1.618)`

Comment: @py3programmer Although the challenge allows floating point inaccuracies, that is usually interpreted as inaccuracies inherent to floating-point computations. Defining the golden ratio with only three decimals is not covered by that allowance

Answer (score 5):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 17 bytes

```
Round[2#/++√5]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7Pyi/NC8l2khZX1v7Uccs01i1/4GlmaklDgFFmXkl0cq6dmkOyrFqDlpumUn5eYnJyZl1wcmJeXVBiXnpqdHGOkYGsf8B)

Comment: haha `++√5` love it!

Answer (score 5):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 31 bytes

```powershell
[int]("$args"/1.61803398874989)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/PzozryRWQ0klsSi9WEnfUM/M0MLA2NjSwsLcxNLCUvP///9GxsYA)

The ratio of two adjacent numbers in the Fibonacci series rapidly approaches ((1 + sqrt(5)) / 2). So if N is divided by ((1 + sqrt(5)) / 2) and then rounded, the resultant number will be the previous Fibonacci number...

at least according to [this article.](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-the-previous-fibonacci-number/#:%7E:text=Approach%3A%20The%20ratio%20of%20two,be%20the%20previous%20Fibonacci%20number.)

-16 thanks [mazzy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80745/mazzy)

Comment: 1. The constant `1.61803398874989` is shorter then the expression `(1+[math]::sqrt(5))/2)` :) 2. $x is redundant. 3. `-replace'\..*'` is shorter then `[math]::round()` :) Welcome to the CodeGolf

Comment: @mazzy thanks! i tried to still your `$args` trick from last time but could not get it accept input.

Comment: `$args` is an array. use `"$args"` to get a value.

Comment: see also [Tips for golfing in PowerShell](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/191/tips-for-golfing-in-powershell)

Comment: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/PzozryRWQ0klsSi9WEnfUM/M0MLA2NjSwsLcxNLCUvP///9GxsYA "PowerShell – Try It Online") or try `&{[int]("$args"/1.61803398874989)} 233` in your PS console

Comment: `1.618033989` is shorter and is sufficient for all 47 possible inputs, [here's a test](https://tio.run/##bY/NSgNBEITveYoh5JCFVftv@udZxIPIShZCIlHwID77WuPBk3uY7emq6v7m7fq53N5Py/m8ba/X2/L8cjoe1rZe2pHnJnPTufW55dwYlaCnhs5oFXqGiygUjZibM82tEhX3wik9oRsnYh6OEFOZ4xfBY3x6h81cHQuikwyLsBYmcjmSmMyRw9zZRLAzVcho8JiL14CKVEKhXawHIj1IcmCUSNjvXisl6HAbw8MQtSiTxwRXBCsHGOE1cIyI957ENjg9CtsLBoNcZop8QKSM8XoGTBFIB1eqKzOuCFbgOZ1Cp2n3tWv4HtfLx9Nxf1j3D3zvnKRaYLXKmtrd/3JNu@9t2/4wfgA).

Answer (score 5):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>38</s> 37 bytes

This works for an aribrary size of inputs. We iterate through the Fibonacci sequence until we find some number `x`, that is larger than half the input `n`. This is works because the previous fibonacci number is roughly `0.618*n`.
The Fibonacci list `f` was borrowed from [R. Martinho Fernandes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/85/fibonacci-function-or-sequence#comment110_89).

```hs
g n=[x|x<-f,2*x>=n]!!0
f=0:scanl(+)1f
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P10hzza6oqbCRjdNx0irws42L1ZR0YArzdbAqjg5MS9HQ1vTMO1/bmJmnoKtQkFRZl6JgopCbmKBQrpCtJGOsY6pjoWOoXHsfwA)

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript, Node.js, 32 bytes

*-1 thanks to Arnauld*

```
n=>(y=1,f=x=>y-n?f(y,y+=x):x)(0)
```

**Explanation:**

This is  a recursive solution, based off one of the two most common recursive fibonacci algorithms, which involves a function `f(x, y) = f(y, x + y)` that stops at some point. With this function, `x` is always a fibonacci number, and `y` is always the fibonacci number after it, so once `y` is the fibonacci number we were given as input, we know `x` is the one before it.

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ÅF¨θ
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//cKvboRXndvz/b2gAAA) or [verify some more test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/R/ic7jncGtaWaW9ksKjtkkKSvaV/w@3uh1acW7Hf53/AA).

`¨θ` could be a lot of different alternatives, like `Á¤` or `` `\ ``.

**Explanation:**

```python
ÅF    # Push a list of Fibonacci numbers lower than or equal to the (implicit) input
  ¨   # Remove the last one (the input)
   θ  # Keep the next last one
      # (after which it is output implicitly as result)
```

Comment: Oof, sorry about accidentally answering it the same way. Guess I hadn't refreshed the page since then. Nice to know my solution was at least somewhat good, haha :)

Answer (score 4):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), <s>6</s> 4 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
)φ/i
```

-2 bytes porting [*@emanresuA*'s Vyxal answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/247842/52210), which is in turn a port of [*@Unmitigated*'s JavaScript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/247840/52210).

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/1/zfJt@5v//RlzGXKZcFlyGxlxGhlzGJlymQJ4ll6GJCQA)

**Original 6 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py) answer:**

```
╒fg<┤Þ
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7///R1Elp6TaPpiw5PO//fyMuYy5TLgsuQ2MuI0MuYxMuUyDPksvQxAQA)

`g<` could alternatively also be `á>`: [try it online](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7///R1ElphxfaPZqy5PC8//@NuIy5TLksuAyNuYwMuYxNuEyBPEsuQxMTAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
)      # Increase the (implicit) input-integer by 1
 φ/    # Divide it by the golden ratio 1.618033988749895
   i   # Truncate it to an integer
       # (the +1 and truncate act as a round builtin here, which MathGolf lacks)
       # (after which the entire stack is output implicitly as result)
```

```python
╒      # Push a list in the range [1, (implicit) input-integer]
 f     # Get the 0-based n'th Fibonacci number for each value in this list
  g    # Filter it by:
   <   #  Where it's smaller than the (implicit) input-integer
    ┤  # Extract the trailing value
     Þ # Discard the list from the stack, keeping just that value
       # (after which the entire stack is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 4):

#### [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>50 bytes</s> 48 bytes

```python
def f(n,a=0,b=1):
 while b<n:a,b=b,a+b
 return a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY1NbsMgEEb3nGJ2xgqJDLZUKSq9iOsFtofaakUQECWN5bMTTNNsMqtv/t6zv2E6mTrGETVoapiSFeslL48ELtP8g9C/m6NKo56pXU/AYTg7AyoG9MHLVrC6I3i1OAQcZcuZ6Ig@ObjCbMAp84VUMF5VG/D/7KCsRTPSjGj3vCsJ5Pyy2D2SSCfDhMM3OpBAi8@zeGuGgkFOvC7KLA0MN@1ttn8I9lRu@lQ@fWsaytxYN5tAdbGEFfYfsPgVloekRSl9tyZs5E0T7w)

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice first answer!

Comment: Welcome to CGCC! You can save 2 bytes: by changing `b!=n` to `b<n`, and by removing the second line and using `def f(n,a=0,b=1):` instead. Enjoy your stay! Oh, and if you haven't seen it yet [Tips for golfing in Python](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54/tips-for-golfing-in-python) and [Tips for golfing in 'all languages'](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5285/tips-for-golfing-in-all-languages) might be interesting to read through. :)

Comment: You can also save some bytes by reducing your indentation to only one space per line, because that's all that is required in Python.

Comment: @pxeger The code had tabs for indent, so it wouldn't matter

Answer (score 4):

## [Prolog (SWI)](http://www.swi-prolog.org), 35 bytes

```
1+0.
N+M:-nth1(M,_,_),X is N-M,M+X.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyjKz8lP1y0uz/z/31DbQI/LT9vXSjevJMNQw1cnXideUydCIbNYwU/XV8dXO0Lvv5WugrGJtq@OQkFRZl6Jhq@m3n8A)

-9 bytes thanks to Jo King

Of course, it's shorter to just use floating point:

## [Prolog (SWI)](http://www.swi-prolog.org), 31 bytes

```
N/M:-M is round(2*N/(1+5^0.5)).
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyjKz8lP1y0uz/z/30/f10rXVyGzWKEovzQvRcNIy09fw1DbNM5Az1RTU@@/la6CsYm@r45CQVFmXomGL1AIAA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 26 bytes

```
.+
$*
(\2?(\1)|1)+1
$1$2
1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@q4Z7wX0@bS0WLSyPGyF4jxlCzxlBT25BLxVDFiMvw/38LLmMTLkMTEwA) Link includes test cases. Explanation: Loosely based on @MartinEnder's Retina answer to [Am I a Fibonacci Number?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/126373).

```
.+
$*
```

Convert to unary.

```
(\2?(\1)|1)+1
```

Match as many Fibonacci numbers as possible. The first iteration only matches the leading `1` while subsequent iterations match iteration of the loop matches the penultimate Fibonacci number (if any), then the previous Fibonacci number, while saving it as the next penultimate Fibonacci number. The match actually sums the Fibonacci sequence, resulting in a sequence one less than the Fibonacci sequence, so a final `1` needs to be matched.

```
$1$2
```

Because the match is summing the sequence, the final capture of the sequence `$1` is actually the Fibonacci number before the one we want, so we need to add on the penultimate matched Fibonacci number `$2`.

```
1
```

Convert to decimal.

Answer (score 3):

## [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr), 16 bytes

```
n->n*2\/(1+5^.5)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728ILEoMz69YMHiNAXbpaUlaboWG_J07fK0jGL0NQy1TeP0TDUhwjfN0_KLNDIVbBWMdBQMDQx0FPKA7LTMpPy8xOTkTI1MTWuFgqLMvBKNPAUlBV07IJGmkaepCdW-YAGEBgA)

Port of [Unmitigated's JavaScript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/247840/9288). `a\/b` is a short way to write `round(a/b)`.

PARI/GP's floating point number is 128-bit by default. This gives the correct result until the 184th Fibonacci number (`127127879743834334146972278486287885163`).

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 bytes

```
‘:Øp
```

Add 1 to the input and integer-divide by the golden ratio.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9RwwyrwzMK/v//b2wCAA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 5 bytes

```
→←xİf
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//1HbpEdtEyqObEj7//@/kSEA)

Makes use of the built-in list of Fibonacci numbers.

#### Explanation

```
→←xİf
   İf  Take the list of Fibonacci numbers
  x    Split it on occurrences of the input
 ←     Get the first sub-list
→      Get the last element of that
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 10 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
Çâ'Ç,¼)í"─
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=808327802cac29a122c4&i=2%0A3%0A5%0A8%0A19134702400093278081449423917&a=1&m=2)

#### Approach

- Start with an infinite Fibonacci generator
- Keep values while they are less than the input, resulting in array e.g. `[1, 1, 2, 3, 5]`.
- Extract last element.

Comment: [9 bytes with |5](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=8257db960850f2dbae&i=2%0A3%0A5%0A8%0A19134702400093278081449423917&a=1&m=2)

Answer (score 3):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), <s>12</s> 11 bytes

```
--2!(1-%5)*
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k/#eJxNjU1OwzAYRPc+xYegUgK4xn+xYx+DZVXR1Nht1NYucYJSoXJ2LLHJavRGTzPBYMweKopXsn5GaDQ/T5vb72ACAMx2l0622oWuP9vZ3uxQb+8o9Pt3/zX56LxhwEGCBsqBUeACZKEWqBDAOAeuFDT0DVqtgMpWAZNagKCaQqMaWe42izVLXzH9WBRbhF6qpRBgQTVCBB3H8ZoNIS59+kM6h3UeO3fyszt28eDXLl1IsfPYp5gJE0pzSa6D/+7TlHEZS7Fzrsdxuuz9UAQtVPP4H+gPmTxTfA==)

Applies @Albert.Lang's approach from [this comment](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/247835/previous-fibonacci-number?answertab=scoredesc#comment554398_247844).

- `(1-%5)*` calculate 1 minus the square root of 5 (i.e. `-1.2360679774997898`) and multiply it by the (implicit) input
- `-2!` integer divide by 2 (rounding towards 0, e.g. `-8!-7` returns `-1`)
- `-` negate (and implicitly return)

Answer (score 3):

## [APL(Dyalog Unicode)](https://dyalog.com), 17 bytes <sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

```
{⌊.5+⍵÷.5×1+5*.5}
```

[Try it on APLgolf!](https://razetime.github.io/APLgolf/?h=AwA&c=q37U06Vnqv2od@vh7Xqmh6cbaptq6ZnWAgA&f=e9Q39VHbhDQFQwtjM2NDQ0sDY65HUCELSwA&i=AwA&r=tryapl&l=apl-dyalog&m=dfn&n=f)

5

Comment: 5឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵

Answer (score 3):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 10 bytes

```
Ua*DRT5//2
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ILNgebSSbkWBUuyCpaUlaboWq0ITtVyCQkz19Y0gAlDxm2rRStGGCkYKxgqmChYKhsYKRoYKxiYKpkCepYKhiYmCkbFxLNwYAA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Fig](https://github.com/Seggan/Fig), \$5\log_{256}(96)\approx\$ 4.116 bytes

```
_\mG}
```

[Try it online!](https://fig.fly.dev/#WyJfXFxtR30iLCI0MTgxIl0=)

No round builtins, so I use the old increment and floor trick.

```
_\mG}
    } # The input number incremented
 \    # Divided by
  mG  # The golden ratio
_     # Floor
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Go](https://go.dev), 59 bytes

```go
import."math"
func f(n float64)float64{return Round(n/Phi)}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NY9JDsIwDEX3OYXVVSOFoRNtQdwBsUUIhSEQ0ToopKuqR-AEbCokDsFRuA0ulI39_azv4f44mvZ1kbuzPB6glBqZLi_GuqGnSuc9K6cG2Xv2Z6V0J4-pCnegfARVGOkmMe9zbQ-usghLU-Hex9HipHnTj7h9Td0Cn9dM6e0VpnNYrf_WUEAkIBGQCQhIhQGBmEiHcmIxFWFEnShNBUyCsYA8IxUkOcUwyeKGKWNhI3A6txLpnW5LzRZWoyvQR9HdzDlrWH9U2_7yBw)

wow built-in constants

#### Calculated version, 72 bytes

```go
import."math"
func f(n float64)float64{return Round(2*n/(1+Pow(5,0.5)))}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NY9BTsMwEEX3PsUoKxuGUjtxm1TqnmXVLULIlLpENOPKOGIR5QicgE1UiUNwFG7DBNLNzJ830v8zn-dDGL5PbvfqDntoXE2ibk4hplnmm5R9tcnflD93F9a49JIJ39IOvCTwx-DSolBT7-I-tZFgG1p6luaKbqW-3oR3aXE-s0qpfvL7-HMY06TqhK-f3mC1hvuHi49ByBEsQomgWRnNoGAyoopZwYPJeZMvlwgLPUeoSlbaVlyNLYte-BDhEWm1jo74tzGlE5tYUzqSJBwfUEr0YjpqGP77Lw)

Answer (score 3):

## m68k assembly (GNU), 16 bytes

```
70 00 72 01 d0 81 c1 41 b2 af 00 04 66 f6 4e 75
```

Or in assembly:

```
begin:
    moveq.l #0, %d0;
    moveq.l #1, %d1;
loop:
    add.l %d1, %d0;
    exg.l %d0, %d1;
    cmp.l 4(%sp), %d1;
    bne loop;
    rts;
```

Works with both the Linux and the SysV calling conventions (parameters on stack, return in %d0, %d0-%d1 are scratch registers).

The c function definition is:

```c
unsigned long prev_fibonacci(unsigned long num);
```

All calculations are done in 32 bit mode. 16bit is the same size, only faster.

Code execution takes 22 cycles plus 46 cycles per loop iteration. (On a 68000 w/ a 16bit bus and no waitstates)

Answer (score 3):

## x86-64 machine code, 10 bytes

Expects input in `edx` and outputs to `eax`.

```
b8 dd bc 1b cf f7 f0 d1 e8 c3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVJhb5swEP3OrzgxIUHibLBVWtWUTdHGh0ptEtF23bROCAwkSNggIGmiLn999I6QEDIUXex3z@/d@cxHC87r@l0ieboKI7guqzCR1fvlF6WPZf9BaRKcY0UiF2fYtvwghC8JVVaofOlVUPgvXh7HXrCtovK3Zf4BG17NTXDJwNyEIcWAU7QCijymGH9uotlwLIpRw@efdmNFWWdJCAMURe28KlBw@nh7iwm0BIR1@pcGvCqAH22KqFr7KTII8EuhNwv6VJGtIQo3DDQLniWoXYb7aQraxzOU@BoWFvmbfuYKVLsQKuh7M@M00eDSYO3qWHqPhIoqMrCYvajR1ot6q0Iee9jt@xR@InW6iUOfp/eBU8h1uhQGFtY6d2cPnutMvsPf/frJvXlwDhvnp/ONwd1k7s3dmx@TJkG7yXQ2/XU3e7zHm8cflkM2IhI833YtsP6EyfBQOJW5TBZLLMhix07T7KUPVCJvD8RZAc3wEtscQ3J9cYFxODx02JLxNGqMzwTJqMMa26F9ot0dphdCeaOj5/iYq1hXKaWFxhVoIdACtPJZ4lCIzug4IzcGeuPZyBvwFVSV5jcYgOO6MBiorfKuNz8TR1fX/3ic@ouyHj3h66pHAh@jjd5R@gY)

### Explanation

Disassembly:

```
b8 dd bc 1b cf          mov    eax,0xcf1bbcdd
f7 f0                   div    eax
d1 e8                   shr    eax,1
c3                      ret
```

The function approximates \$\operatorname{round}(\frac{n}{\phi})=\lfloor\frac{n+\frac{\phi}{2}}{\phi}\rfloor=\lfloor\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{2^{32}n+2^{31}\phi}{2^{31}\phi}\rfloor\$, where \$\phi=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\$. \$2^{31}\phi\approx3474701533\$, which fits nicely into a 32-bit integer as `0xcf1bbcdd`. Since `div r32` works on `edx:eax`, `n` can be loaded into `edx` and `0xcf1bbcdd` can be loaded into `eax` to create the numerator of the fraction, while also having `eax` as the denominator of the fraction after `div eax`. Afterwards, all that is left is to divide by two, which is handled by `shr eax, 1`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 6 bytes

```
ÞFḟ‹∆f
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLDnkbhuJ/igLniiIZmIiwiIiwiMzQiXQ==)

Answer (score 2):

## [rSNBATWPL](https://github.com/Radvylf/rSNBATWPL), 32 bytes

```
x~for{t=1;x>t;f=b}{b=t;t=f+t}$-1
```

[Try It Online!](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJyYWlzaW4tYmF0d2FmZmxlIixudWxsLCJnPXh+Zm9ye3Q9MTt4PnQ7Zj1ifXtiPXQ7dD1mK3R9JC0xOyIsImckMTMiLCIiLCIiXQ==)

Port of R answer.

Answer (score 2):

## [rSNBATWPL](https://github.com/Radvylf/rSNBATWPL), 31 bytes

```
n~(y=1;x~cond{y!n}{{y=y+x}}$x)$
```

[Try It Online!](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJyYWlzaW4tYmF0d2FmZmxlIixudWxsLCJnPW5+KHk9MTt4fmNvbmR7eSFufXt7eT15K3h9fSR4KSQ7IiwiZyQxMyIsIiIsIiJd)

Port of my JS answer:

> This is a recursive solution, based off one of the two most common recursive fibonacci algorithms, which involves a function `f(x, y) = f(y, x + y)` that stops at some point. With this function, `x` is always a fibonacci number, and `y` is always the fibonacci number after it, so once `y` is the fibonacci number we were given as input, we know `x` is the one before it.

Comment: Wow, nice language name. I wonder who could have possibly made it

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 6 bytes

```
i*½←√5
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6f@6ip8X@m1qG9j9omPOqYZfr///9oQx0jHWMdUx0LHUNjHSNDHWMTHVMgz1LH0MREx8jYOBYA)

Same strategy as [my R answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/247850/95126) (and also those of [Luis Mendo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/247844/95126) and [unmitigated](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/247840/95126)).

([Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk) has a fibonacci sequence built-in, but using it here seems to come-out longer at [7 bytes](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/P1gx/1HbhEdNa45sSPv//7@RIQA): `S!o←€İf`).

Update: proven wrong by [Leo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/247923/95126)

Answer (score 2):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), <s>25</s> 22 bytes

*-3 bytes thanks to [@Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/steffan)*

```
pp-p~1
f(n)=round(n/p)
```

Port of some of the other answers.

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ghhxxfiubs)

Comment: @Steffan yep, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 27 bytes

```c
f(a){a=2*a/(1+sqrt(5))+.5;}
```

Port of [Unmitigated's JavaScript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/247840/112488).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TVDRbsMgDHyGr3A7TYKRdkulPlH2JVMlkpAOaSMdodWkLvv17CDTtAfss82dD9rNqW3nuRdW3qzZPdhHUavxIyaxl1Jt93qa73xo3y6dO4yp88P29ZlzHxJPbkwCgM7RXSvKKLjPJPmNs1xEN2rOEMlQL8oI9Tli1ov1fUeKEL4RXsK6Klza/IqBtXRAyRrpEkNu0sqUG5pPi4l364O4Dr77W2srasCFRqb2QyRh4aBGe0kBKeI8acAD1chKBUngs4aOhixsMptRo0vPZIkjNRKWbVZlkb4MlQ/I6/K7pn8@4W7@AQ)

Comment: [26 bytes](https://tio.run/##TVBdT8MwDHxOfoUZQkpoC3TSnrLwS9Ck9GtEgnSk2YQ0yl8v5xQhHmKf7dz5krY6tu2yDMrpq7PK3U8fMamdrlxR68etmZdbH9q3c9fvp9T58eH1WUofkkz9lBQAnWJ/KYlR6D@TllcpuIj9ZKRAJEuDyiPUp4jZoDZ3HRWE8I3wEjZl5lL1KwbW2gGFNdI5Bm7Sjc03jJxXE@/OB3UZffe31pXUgAsNpg5jJOXgoEZ7TQEp4jwZwD3VyEURNIEvGjpYcrApHKPG5J5liQM1GpYdq4pIX5byB/A6ftf8zyfcLT8)

Answer (score 2):

## [Rattle](https://github.com/DRH001/Rattle), 17 bytes

```
|r`=+s[$+~[\gq]]0
```

[Try it Online!](https://www.drh001.com/rattle/?flags=&code=%7Cr%60%3D%2Bs%5B%24%2B%7E%5B%5Cgq%5D%5D0&inputs=34)

## Explanation

```
|             take input
 r`           save input as special arg
   =          set top of stack to 0
    +         increment
     s        save value of 1 to storage
      [...]0  infinite loop

 $            swap top of stack with value in storage
  +~          increment top of stack by value in storage
    [\...]    if the top of the stack is equal to the special arg...
      g       get the value in storage (i.e. the previous Fibonacci value)
       q      quit and print implicitly
```

Answer (score 2):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), <s>21</s> 22 bytes

```
{_x%1.618033988749895}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.bitbucket.io/k#eJxLs6qOr1A11DMztDAwNra0sDA3sbSwNK3l4kpTMDG0MAQAhuYHhA==)

Increased 1 byte to round the number.

Comment: You need to round the number, because the output has to be an integer.

Answer (score 2):

## [BitCycle (-u)](https://esolangs.org/wiki/BitCycle), 93 bytes

[Try it online!](https://dloscutoff.github.io/Esolangs/BitCycle/?p=c4sc4jcwncztA2jsr1sczBcBcsCc3secnjcwrsczcqiB2isc2qoczcbr1DzcDcnc2tCcezrADAznc3tc2nc3Ba&i=MjE_&f=1)

```
    v    / <^ ~+AA/v
1v ~B B vC   v> ^/ <
v ~ ?\BB\v  ?= ~ !
1D~ D ^  +C >~
ADA~^   +  ^   B@
```

The program generates a Fibonacci number, doubles it, and compares it to the input. If it's greater than or equal to the input, it is halved and output, otherwise it's discarded and the next number is generated.

```
          the question mark [input] hits a splitter [\]. one bit is redirected while the rest of the bits move to top B  [input].
1v ~B     top D [2fib(n-1)], which starts with 2, is emptied to right A [2fib(n)] and left A [intermittent]. 
v ~ ?\B   bottom D [2fib(n-2)] empties to right A.
1D~       right A empties to top D and top B [2fib(n)].
ADA~      left A empties to bottom D [2fib(n-2)].
```

```
v    / <   *'top B' refers to BOTH B's; 'bottom B' refers to BOTH B's*
B B vC     if bottom B [input] isn't empty, it hits a splitter. one bit is redirected to D [intermittent] while the rest of the bits re-enter bottom B.
  BB\v     top B [2fib(n)] hits a splitter. one bit is redirected to top C [2fib(n)] while the rest re-enter top B.
D ^  +C    if bottom B is empty, top B hits another splitter. one bit is redirected to bottom C ["2fib(n) >= input"?].
^   +  ^   D will eventually empty to bottom B.
```

```
   ^ ~+AA/v   *'A' refers to BOTH A's
C   v> ^/ <   if bottom C ["2fib(n) >= input"?] isn't empty, it hits a switch. the bits are redirected to B [terminator]
   ?= ~ !     if bottom C is empty, top C [2fib(n)] hits a switch. the bits are redirected into the question mark, destroying them.
 C >~         if bottom C isn't empty, top C empties to A [fib(n)]
      B@      A hits 2 splitters. one bit is redirected away, and another is redirected into the exclamation mark [output]. the rest of the bits re-enter A.
              B empties into the at-sign, which terminates the program.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 29 bytes

```ruby
->n{a=b=1;0while n>a=b+b=a;b}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6vOtE2ydbQ2qA8IzMnVSHPDsjVTrJNtE6q/V@gkBZtaGIS@x8A)

Answer (score 2):

## Raku, 40 bytes

```
sub p(\n,\a=0,\b=1){n==b??a!!p(n,b,a+b)}
```

[Try it online!](https://glot.io/snippets/gfwihepb2g)

Answer (score 2):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 43 bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYw9D4JADIb3@xUdrxoxICRKwuDo4GScjMOJfBkoenQxhN9@HnGzdmjS5@37DLlpjetvjyJnOJqGYFQA96KEzh/a2GpIYW@teV9ObBuqrpjCmRqGDEY3/5Wa0gMxZlrTojNcB8PLsk5wRcsQ1xEG3PvcgR81r6fXcEu61BHiD9kIkgiyFSSUtSiU7ljK/9h3Uh9/m5OalPsA)

```scala
def f(n:Int)=((n*math.sqrt(5)-n+1)/2).toInt
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 24 bytes

```
ＮθＦ²⊞υιＷ‹⌈υθ⊞υΣ…⮌υ²Ｉ§υ±²
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Rcy9DoIwFIbh3avoeE6Cg4SNyXQiUULwCmo92iYthf4gXn0tLq5vnu@TSnjphMm5m@YU@2Tv5GHB9vB0nkGNbEhBQaqYLu2ttCEGFwoBrmLTNllIWLEF/@5WGv9IQ1y5GUZayQf6qRqxfAxeTxG4CBHOsZsetO2rnl4iEuwE25xPTZOPq/kC) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｎθ
```

Input the target.

```
Ｆ²⊞υι
```

Start with `[0, 1]`.

```
Ｗ‹⌈υθ
```

Repeat until the target is reached.

```
⊞υΣ…⮌υ²
```

Generate the next Fibonacci number.

```
Ｉ§υ±²
```

Output the highest one less than the input.

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, 57 bytes (or 14 bytes)

Complete solution which handles arbitrarily large input:

```
f n=(x!!).flip(-)1.length.fst.span(<n)$x
x=scanl(+)0(1:x)
```

Explanation:

1. Let `x` be a an infinite list of fibonacci numbers ( `x = scanl (+) 0 (1:x)` ).
2. Partition list into a tuple (`[Int], [Int]`), the leftmost portion being all numbers `<` than the input.
3. Take the first portion with `fst`.
4. Subtract 1 from the length of that list.
5. Extract (`!!`) the number with the resultant (`idx--`) index from the infinite list.

Simple solution:

```
round.(/0.618)
```

Comment: It's actually quite a bit shorter just to define `x` as a global function: https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708I7E4OzUnZ8GCpaUlaboWNy3TFPJsNSoUFTX10nIyCzR0NQ31clLz0ksy9NKKS_SKCxLzNGzyNFUquCpsi5MT83I0tDUNNAytKjQhBmzOTczMU7BVKCjKzCtRUFFIUzA0hsjArAAA

Comment: True, suppose I was aiming for the one-liner aesthetic

Comment: If the ```round.(/0.618)``` is indeed a valid program or funciton, would you mind to post a link so it can be run & tested?  I am quite sceptical that it will return the correct answer for large-ish inputs, for instance 17711...

Answer (score 1):

## [Brainfuck](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainfuck), 94 bytes

```
>>>>+<<<+[[-]<[->+>+<<]>>[-<<+>>]>>[->+>+<<]>>[-<<+>>]<<<[->>+<<]>[-<+>]>[-<+<<<->>>>]<<<<]>>
```

Input should be entered into the first address. Output is at the address pointed to when the program terminates.

Might add an explanation later.

Answer (score 1):

### Brev, <s>50</s> 45 bytes

```
(define((p x y)n)(if(= n y)x((p y(+ x y))n)))
```

Example:

```
(map (p 0 1) '(34 13 55 2))
=> (21 8 34 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

## TI-BASIC, 13 bytes

```
round(2Ans(1+√(5))⁻¹,0
```

**Hexdump:**
(Token hex-values found [here](http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/tokens).)

```
12 32 72 10 31 70 BC 35 11 11 0C 2B 30 | round(2Ans(1+√(5))⁻¹,0
```

Takes input in `Ans` and prints the requested output in the challenge.

**Explanation:**

```
round(2Ans(1+√(5))⁻¹,0           ; full program

           1+√(5)                ; phi * 2
          (      )⁻¹             ; 1 / (phi * 2)
       Ans                       ; Ans / (phi * 2)
      2                          ; Ans / phi
round(              ,0           ; round to nearest integer
```

---

**Note:** TI-BASIC is a tokenized language.  Character count does *not* equal byte count.

TI-BASIC only has decimal precision up to 14 decimals for calculations and 10 decimals for equivalence.

Byte count is determined via the following steps:

1. Find the program's size via `MEM`>`Mem Mgmt/Del…`>`Prgm…`
2. Subtract the length of the program name
3. Subtract the program header length, which is 9 bytes

Answer (score 1):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 17 bytes

```
01\~n;
=?\:@+:{:}
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/38Awpi7PmsvWPsbKQduq2qr2////umUWlgA)

**Explanation**

Starts at **0,1**.
Calculates the next Fibonacci number until we reach the input.
Prints the second newest.

Answer (score 1):

## [J](https://www.jsoftware.com), <s>12</s> 14 bytes

```
1.61803<.@%~>:
```

Pretty self-explanatory.

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=JYw9CsJAFAZ7TzEIGgSz5O3bvwQNgiAIVl5BsoiNjbZexCYWtvYexdsYSPExzBTf83Xpv1NTZNYNBUsqmmGlYXs87N73Wy7TR0yQVOnKbGaPthnjb7-YdKfzlTxvsSiehChWUIcfrEacw6qiMRKkok4R8XXE-uRwkoQQgx8P-37kHw)

```
1.61803<.@%~>:
            >:  NB. increment input
1.61803         NB. golden ratio
          %~    NB. flip arg order and divide
       <.@      NB. then floor the result
```

I saw `1.618` might be too inaccurate. `-:>:%:5` results in `1.61803`, so I added the extra digits.

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>26</s> 24 bytes

-4 thanks to c--.

This uses int and overflows at the 46th fib (first exceeding \$2^{31}\$) but

`p(n){n=round(n*2/(1+sqrt(5)));}` breaks at 43 and is longer.

```c
p(n){n=n*.618033989+.5;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY5PC8IwDMXv/RRBEbqtGxtTUesEQW8ePQpDNqMBrcU/J9lnn20dWszlkd9LXlLFx6pqW81V8FKFCpNxNknzfDqZRslINm2fVHV@1geY3x81XZPTgpF6wGVPigcvBqZsjyVAAan0QPkHwE5kP6DAW8HrjVtIRSppPhxLiqIu3tkuDUvpEbuNHnBxBkd2WrKv4Y5r42mOgcf1zTjIezQbhLUN@CjGXb9ab7bL2aCGneoJ@K79KhckjGSZQKepQC2652LUwee3hjWMtW8)

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
kG/V
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPWtHJTJGViZmb290ZXI9JmlucHV0PTEzJmZsYWdzPQ==)

##### Explanation

```python
      # Implicit input...
  /   # ...divided by...
kG    # ...phi...
   V  # ...then rounded
      # Implicit output
```